# How should I handle downvote complaints?

Tags: discussion, comments, voting, etiquette

When a question or answer gets downvoted, the person asking the question or answer seems to routinely comment, complaining about the down vote. How should I handle that?

This happens even when an explanation is given. Which means the social/economic behavior is basically: *I don’t like down votes! Don’t do that! I don’t care what your reason is!*

My way of handling issues like this is to just ignore the retort and possibly flag it, depending on the original question/answer poster’s response. Sometimes I enter the back-and-forth fray when my better judgement is lacking. But I am pretty much past that now.

Is there any other established way of handling cases like this?

Comment: "This happens even when an explanation is given." This is why we can't have nice things.

Comment: Much like you, unless I'm in a particularly foul mood and do it wrong, I simply flag the OP's comment and move on. When the post gets downvoted further and closed ... the OP has their answer.

Comment: I do know I've asked for an explanation a few times on downvotes, usually when I suspect a "personal dislike" downvote. I've had that happen a few times, when the person said they downvoted because they didn't personally like my choice of platform, language, project goal, whatever. So, there is that flip side that some people treat downvote like an "Unlike" button, using it to voice opinion instead of fact.

Comment: I rarely see explanations for down votes on my questions or answers, they just show up typically within a minute or so.  I decided some time ago that a down vote does not mean anything more than I have tripped over someone's personal bias.  And that the person probably read enough to have a gut reaction, clicked the down vote, and moved on.  What I don't get is the up votes on questions that a google search can answer with a lot more detail and background than a stack overflow answer.

Comment: Just thinking about the mere fact that there are complaints: is it always clear to the users why their question or answers is downvoted? Maybe it's partly just the lack of explanation. I wouldn't want to change the rules but there are cases where a minimal explanation could not hurt. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22883731/can-the-getencoding-method-load-a-tbl-file) for an example of a downvoted recent question without comment or answers. Why was this question downvoted?

Comment: From a downvoted answerer`s perspective, I think asking *why* a down vote is not a good response at my end. If ever I get downvoted, instead of asking *why* in a comment, I ask myself. I go over the question again, in detail, and re-evaluate my answer, and try to find if my answer (1) Was relevant to the asked question (2) Actually solves the OPs problem (3) Is clear (4) makes me happy(optional). If I find something wrong, or not helpful, I improve/delete my answer, depending my current level of knowledge on the issue. If everything seems fine, *I move on*.

Comment: People who down vote the question are sometimes not fair. They don't read the question, they don't try to understand, the question itself sometimes it is hard to explain. There are people here they down vote just because they don't know the answer or understand the question and if they don't know the answer, the question must be wrong because they are perfect. It is a competition for them. You cannot ask a question which has an answer but not known by this kind of people. I can see the logic behind voting answers. But I guess no benefit voting questions negatively.

Comment: Minor grammatical quibble: you wrote, "Which means the **social/economic** behavior is basically: I don’t like down votes! Don’t do that! I don’t care what your reason is!"...I`m pretty not liking downvotes has nothing to do with 'economic' behavior

Comment: Use the same rule as "How should I handle downvote". You could be wrong when posting question or answer; so as you could be wrong when downvoting.

Comment: "This happens even when an explanation is given." That's normal.. Do you expect to always undo your downvote when an explanation is provided from the person you are downvoting?

Comment: @RichardChambers - It's because upvoters are not rational beings.  By that I mean that it's clear when an answer should be downvoted - it's either not useful, or it's wrong, or whatever.  Basically, it's flawed in some way.  But upvoting is less black and white - it's really a matter of opinion.  So the upvote button is essentially a "like" button; whereas the downvote button is not a "dislike" button, even though there are some miscreants who treat it that way.

Comment: @n00bProgrammer Thank you for that comment. I felt that this is the way to go even before reading this page but it's always good to be confirmed

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The core problem here is that a lot of users, especially new ones, don't understand downvotes:

A vote is:

- Not for factual correctness.
- Not for liking or disliking OP.
- Not for being first.

Voting measures one thing, usefulness of the situation in the scenario.

I usually leave comments like:

> Sorry, I didn't leave a comment (I usually do!). I downvoted it. Remember, down votes don't indicate factual correctness or lack of, they indicate usefulness in context or lack of.

Followed by a short sentence like:

> I don't find your answer useful given X's which already explains this only in more detail.

Or

> This solution uses a library and is not useful for OP since their question was about how to accomplish it without the library.

Or anything else that explains shortly the disagreement.

It's very important to remember the vast majority of people want to help. Being given bad criticism for your work is never easy.

Comment: "Not for factual correctness." - Huh?

Comment: @YourCommonSense: "Usefulness" is a function of "Factual Correctness".

Comment: @YourCommonSense yes. I down-vote factually correct answers all the time. For example, when they repeat the same information another answer on the question added some time ago (for example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21862907/1348195 ) since they are not useful in the context of the question. On the other hand, I upvote answers that are helpful but are not factually accurate all the time too (examples: mixing JSON and JS objects, mixing promise terminology, calling a library a framework, non working but conceptually correct code). The judge should be promoting the most useful information.

Comment: (Of course, usefulness is not completely objective, but I trust the judgement of experienced users in this particular regard)

Comment: Ah. I see. Yes, I downvote factually correct answers a lot myself. Took it upside down at first.

Comment: 'Factual correctness' not to be confused with 'personally preferred methods,' of course, which is something I've seen more than I care to. Thankfully, those kinds are becoming more the exception than the rule.

Comment: Re: "factual correctness" - as Benjamin_Gruenbaum (in particular) points out, DV'ing factually correct answers is normal. The **problem** in the Answer that readers are picking up is that, as worded ("A vote is: • Not for factual correctness."), it implies that a vote *is* for  "factual INcorrectness" - and thus Your_Common_Sense's "Huh?", which I shared.

Comment: The way I read this answer is that "incorrect" is a degree on a scale called "correctness". A small-to-zero degree. Being fundamentally incorrect is on most questions a sufficient condition but not a necessary condition for a downvote, hence many downvotes are not for (the place the answer falls on the scale of) correctness.

Comment: This answers a lot of questions for me regarding voting and I have been on the site for 3 years.

Comment: @JakeGould That sounds remarkably sexist. Yes, StackOverflow does have competitive elements, but that trait is neither inherently male nor inherently female. Furthermore, it's a non sequitur to go from "male dominated and competitive" to "people aren't trying to be helpful." This also flies in the face of my experience here. People commenting and answering are freely giving me their time to explain something to me or help me solve a problem; how does that not qualify as "trying to be helpful"? Not to mention the majority of them are polite and respectful to me, even when I look like an idiot.

Comment: @JakeGould I didn't say or imply it wasn't male dominated, and I didn't say or imply it wasn't competitive. I said that competitiveness is not inherently "male" and that your conclusion that these two qualities lead to people being unhelpful is a non sequitur. I then cited my experience here at StackOverflow as a counter-example, where people are overall very helpful. In other words, I reject your conclusions, not all of your premises.

Comment: But there is counter effect - downvoting reduces reputation of OP. If they delete the question, it is restored and they even may gain new badge. The problem for me is that I answer the question, I can get some reputation but OP will delete it in future. My work is gone, my reputation gain as well. I found that I tend to ignore questions with negative score as waste of time.

Comment: -1 This answer is factually incorrect on the legitimacy of factual correctness as a voting critera

Comment: @Chris how about you read the tooltip text on the up/down vote button?

Comment: I do not understand the distinction between factual correctness and usefulness. I do not call it factuall correct it does not address the concern and if it does, it is useful. This seems to be only name game to me...

Comment: @FinalContest let's say someone posts an answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11227809/why-is-processing-a-sorted-array-faster-than-an-unsorted-array) today containing the text "This happens because of branch prediction, your CPU is choosing better branches in the sorted case" - it's 100% correct, and it addresses the concern - however it is not useful _in the context of the other answers_, in fact all it does is take attention from the other answers - which is why I'd downvote it for sure. It's about the value that is added to the reader, not about devine correctness.

Comment: I would not call that the "factually correct answer". It is more a like a "huh?!" answer for a newbie, or perhaps even for an advanced person. It does not even mention algorithm complexity and so on. I think the whole debate is just a name game, and we all think about the same thing behind. ;]

Comment: @FinalContest factual correctness is actually quite objective. My point in this answer was that even though saying "The JavaScript programming language has a `null` literal but not an `undefined` literal" is a factually correct statement - if it doesn't solve OP's problem better than the other answers - it's not useful. It's _usefulness_ to future visitors that we should care about, in fact - I believe it's really the _only_ thing to consider when down or up voting an answer. See my debate with "Your Common Sense" above :)

Comment: Yes, it is objective. Does it solve the OP's concern and hence problem? If the answer yes, upvote it, do not be so destructive to downvote such an answer! If it solves the OP's issue and hence addresses the question, it is just as good as any other answer doing so.

Comment: @FinalContest I believe we are in full agreement then :) If it solves OP's (and other users') concern and hence problem - upvote it. If it doesn't, downvote it - regardless of its "truth" value.

Comment: Can you share the sources of this information so I could read more on the subject of upvotes and downvotes to get a much better understanding please.

Comment: This answer is from 8 years ago and I am not sure what's the up to date source. I no longer really engage with the meta of StackOverflow as I've found it quite opaque and toxic so I stick to just answering stuff (at a much lower capacity) and being a "regular" user and spend most of my time elsewhere.

Answer (score 72):

First off, don't own up to the downvote. Don't deny the downvote, don't even *mention* the downvote. I know, this seems... Sneaky? Underhanded? Perhaps even dishonest?

But it's not. Voting is anonymous for a reason, and it's on you, the voter, to keep it that way. If you ignore this advice and some petty jackass decides to attack you verbally or via revenge-votes, we'll do the best we can to protect you from that... But it ain't gonna be fun for anyone involved.

Now, *if* you want to be helpful (and depending on the tone of the post or the comment, you may have a good reason *not* to be), then leave a comment that summarizes the problems with the post. Be polite but not apologetic, and stick to the facts. If you've already done this (perhaps even before voting), then congratulate yourself on a job well done...

**Then walk away.**

If someone replies with [**an honest request for more information**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37090/downvoter-sends-a-notification-to-all-downvoters-for-your-post/37123#37123), you can reply or suggest they ask a new question or ignore it - your time, your choice. If someone replies to correct you, and it turns out you *were* wrong then do the right thing and admit it. But if someone responds angrily or argumentatively, let them stew - you almost certainly have better things to do than to get into it with someone who can't admit when *they* were wrong.

Comment: Yeah, I think that recommendation is... really naive at best, and often counter-productive. If you want to help someone, tell them what's wrong with *their post* - don't get sidetracked talking about voting. If they care about the vote but don't care what they did wrong, then you're not going to help them anyway.

Comment: I don't quite see why you can't do both? You can leave a constructive critical comment, and downvote, without specifically saying that you downvoted. That way you are helping the poster with advice, help future readers by putting the better answers at the top, and still don't put yourself in a position to get personally attacked. Well, if your comment is the only one, and there's only one downvote, it's probably a reasonable guess that the downvote came from you. But there's still no conclusive information to track it to you.

Comment: That's... the entire point of this answer, @Reto. Comment on the content, vote on the post. Just don't comment on your vote.

Comment: When confronted with a bad question, I comment first. If my comment isn't well-received, I downvote. Sometimes I am "blamed" for downvotes made by other people even before I get a chance to cast my own downvote. So be it... Note that I have the policy to cast at least one up-vote for every two downvotes I give. Maybe SO could make this a rule ;-)

Comment: I often leave comments along the lines of "I didn't downvote this but it is clear the reason it was downvoted was..."  I've done this for answers and questions I did and didn't downvote.  It changes the feel of the comment to "Hey buddy here is some free advice..."

Comment: @Hogan I do that many times too. But it feels wrong to have to "defend" your comment, even if it's meant to help improve the answer. Just a minute ago I was (wrongly) accused of downvoting for commenting on an answer, *sigh*

Comment: @Shog9 Problem with your approach is that in some cases 2 similar if not exact same answers have different reaction : one get down-voted and second up-voted for no apparent reason until you look in a patterns where same users walk same line and, in times, it appears like they are working in coalescent group to raise each other reputation while down-voting anyone on their way.

Comment: That's... An entirely separate issue, @All. Note that some folks will down-vote *duplicate* answers purely because they add nothing useful; I'm not convinced commenting in these cases is really worthwhile, since the author need only open their eyes to see the problem.

Comment: I seen this in more than one occasion when 2 post made within same time, can not tell same second but same minutes for sure, it was not a duplication of the answer it was only answer which make sense to the question and no surprise that it was basically almost the same. But one was down-voted and second up-voted by exact same amount of votes! Even better first one was criticized for thing which is must to know and even in basics for C#  and SQL programming theory!

Comment: If you think something untoward is happening, flag it @All. Like I said though, some of us - myself included - will up-vote one answer and down-vote another just to avoid the scenario where two redundant answers clog the page. Some of us also delete our answers when they're clearly redundant.

Comment: And you think that this is wright? It will confuse OP because he sees that answers basically the same but one up and second down and he will just run away somewhere else for the help!

Comment: I've yet to see this become a problem, @All. I've seen cases where *both* answers don't work because they were too hastily-written, and the OP dismisses them both (and then we down-vote them both). But for the sorts of trivial questions where this is commonplace, it's less time to just test the fix than it is to spend hand-wringing over votes. Anyway, this conversation is extremely off-topic; [join me in chat](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/89/tavern-on-the-meta) if you care to continue it.

Comment: -1 For "First off, don't own up to the downvote". Except in the case of obvious trolls, [Assume Good Faith](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:AGF) the majority of contributors are attempting to add value to the community through give and take.  Using the assumption of good faith it follows, that someone has given their best attempt to contribute. By pointing out why you believe the submission is worthy of a down vote, you clarify to all involved the logical fallacy involved.  Heck it might even be that your assumption of incorrectness is incorrect and you may learn something in rebuttal

Comment: [This is what I saw in my inbox this morning](http://i.stack.imgur.com/kuLWH.png), @James. No criticisms, no good-faith arguments against what I wrote... Just "-1". Think about that. Is that *really* what you want folks to be focusing on when you take the time to comment on their work? I could not care less how you voted here, but I am interested in your opinion on the strategy I'm recommending, any mistakes I might've made when writing it or omissions that could be corrected. If you're gonna call attention to a post, you should make good use of both your time and the author's.

Comment: The first rule of the downvote club is, you don't talk about downvote club.

Comment: Have to say I disagree. I vote frequently and almost always state my reasons for downvoting (usually with the goal of getting the author to edit their post, maybe 5% of the time with the goal of getting it deleted because it's not savable/a duplicate). I'm often too blunt also (something which I do try to reign in) and in my time active on SO I don't think I've ever been "persecuted" for handing out tough love to authors of bad content. I think the key point is to focus on the content (always) and not the person. I.e. "in the answer x" not "you wrote x (derp!)".

Comment: Surely explaining your downvote is as vital as not explaining your upvote. There are a lot smarter people than me out there which I'm fine with, but I get downvoted often when asking a genuine question that I'm new to the area of (having reviewed for days the answer) and it really puts me off carrying on in this forum.

Comment: I've found that folks are much, much more receptive to constructive criticism @TheSenator: comments that suggest areas for improvement vs. those that simply express frustration. Failing that, even comments that focus on the *source* of the author's frustration at least give the author somewhere to start: "I can't seem to get this to work on Windows 8.1 - it crashes on line 6" vs. "-1: doesn't work".

Comment: @Shog9 thanks for that. It has made me feel better and I appreciate it. I think StackOverflow should make it impossible to downvote without at least an indicator - I've seen opposite arguments however but I don't agree. I understand there are genuinely 'stupid answers' like reviewing my own responses 5 years ago, but weren't we all once really stupid rather than just slightly stupid now?

Comment: I've used systems with that rule, @thesenator, as well as those without any form of negative feedback beyond comments; the results were frequently ugly. Some people struggle mightily to be constructive in their criticisms, and even the best of us have bad days. Making it optional allows for folks to quietly recuse themselves until they or someone else can provide something useful.

Comment: Why can't we have anonymous commenting? @Shog9

Comment: Just read the first paragraph. But It is very easy to do this while answering people, but when you ask a question, it is quite hard to ignore it. Because you stay there to see when it gets answered. And if it gets downvoted, you question to yourself, why.

Answer (score 21):

The outcry against downvotes is to be expected. No one likes to be criticized.

A few people will learn from the criticism and improve (in some cases, this will happen even if you don't provide a explanation). Others, however, will be convinced of their intrinsic "rightness" no matter how strong your argument to the contrary.

Don't spend valuable time worrying about any particular response. Do what is best for the site and for the future visitors to the site. If you think an explanation will improve the site and help future visitors, feel free to give it. If you think your time is better spent elsewhere, feel free to move on without comment.

Comment: I think a lot of people learn from downvote -- some times it leads to good things and sometimes to bad...

Comment: I disagree with not liking to be criticized, I actually like when someone points out a flow in my reasoning or teaches me something I did not know. Any chance to improve myself, my questions or my answers is good for me; I don't even care if the tone is borderline or challenging in general (though depending on the mood it might annoy me). A downvote is different, I don't care about reputation any longer (I stopped caring before I even reached 50k, it just accrued on its own since) but it does irk me to see a "lesser" answer getting promoted (and being first, upvoted) when mine rots because ...

Comment: ... of some "careless" downvote without any explanation as to what my answer lacks that the other could have. Especially when of late it seems that most downvotes on my answers happen to be mistake or bad assumptions on the part of the downvoter :x

Comment: Totall agree that being critiized is unpleasant. I have a rush to the face when I'm wrong and realise it. But it's much worse for someone to simply say you're wrong and not explain why. Even worse that someone thinks it's too obvious to explain.

Answer (score 4):

I would reference what Stack Overflow has written about the downvote privilege (https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down) and why you think the post you downvoted fit the description of what the site says is an acceptable post to downvote.

I would also be open to the idea that perhaps you cast a downvote that you shouldn't have and try to consider why the person on the other feels that it's unfair that they were downvoted. I know there's been some questions where I've probably spent close to an hour reading over a few paragraphs trying to catch every single flaw I've typed, only to still get downvoted by someone who thinks I put no effort into my question. In my opinion this is a scenario that should be avoided. An edit or comment, as opposed to a downvote, can help clear things up.

If you're completely behind your downvote and the other person won't agree with you, I'd recommend ignoring the complaints, flagging it if it's aggressive or detrimental to the community.

You're also never obligated to explain your downvote. I find it to be nice however, and it encourages more thought-out downvoting.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a Data Explorer query that finds downvote complaints in the past month:

https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/403267/find-posts-that-are-complaining-about-downvotes

```
select PostId [Post Link], Text
from Comments
where (Text like '%why the downvote%'
or Text like '%why so many downvote%'
or Text like '%fuck you downvoter%'
or Text like '%why am i downvote%'
or Text like '%downvote??%')
and CreationDate > DATEADD(MONTH, -1, GETDATE())
order by Score desc
```

You can look through them and either flag them as too chatty, or help OP to make their question/answer better. Whatever's more appropriate depending on the situation.

Comment: Downvoting should at a minimum  be accompanied  by constructive feedback. What appears to be a invalid question / answer to one person can be subjective, the OP needs an objective response. I have noted  what appear to be perfectly valid questions and answers that have been downloaded for no apparent  reason. This is purely counter productive for the OP.