# When is it justifiable to downvote a question?

Tags: discussion, downvotes, voting, downvote-reason

In light of [recent discussion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252506/question-quality-is-dropping-on-stack-overflow?cb=1), the quality of questions on Stack Overflow is dropping rapidly, and as such, I find myself being more of a critic than I used to be a year ago.

Questions which hardly show any effort on the part of the asker are becoming more and more prevalent, oftentimes just consisting of a couple of lines of code with the obligatory "*can anybody help me?*". These questions do not provide a specific description of the **problem** experienced, and more often than not lack a descriptive error message, or approaches already attempted by the person asking.

Therefore they ignore the first, and one of the most important principles outlined for a *good* question on the [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)-page, namely:

- **Pretend you're talking to a busy colleague** and have to sum up your
  entire question in one sentence: what details can you include that
  will help someone identify and solve your problem? Include any error
  messages, key APIs, or unusual circumstances that make your question
  different from similar questions already on the site.

These questions usually boil down to the person asking not wanting to put in the effort required to solve his problem, and asking others to do his work for him.

Though that may be what this website has always (*kind of*) been about, I find myself downvoting these questions and providing them with comments pointing out why I downvoted it and how the question could be improved, which is often along the lines of "*what have you tried already?*", "*what is the error you are getting?*, etc.

However, I often get a lot of flak for posting comments like that from people who are willing to do the OP's homework, and answered his question. This makes me question if I am doing the right thing, or maybe I'm too harsh on these people?

Should I keep downvoting these poorly written questions, or am I becoming [a grumpy old man](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251758/why-is-stack-overflow-so-negative-of-late?lq=1) who's trying to stick to traditions of a time long past? When is it "OK" to downvote a question, and when is it not?

Comment: The downvote button tooltip says: 'This question does not show any research effort, it is unclear, or not helpful'. I tend to read it as  'This question does not show *enough* research effort, it is unclear *(except to you)*, or not helpful *for anybody else*'....

Comment: I see no point in another discussion about being harsh or welcoming new users etc...You are not obligated to vote at all... it's not like a downvote is always required on poor questions. If you feel like *something* deserves a downvote in YOUR OWN OPINION, than vote and dont think of consequences.

Comment: you can never error on the side of too many down votes because there are thousands of people willing to come behind you and up vote crap for no reason at all. So down vote your daily maximum, it can only help the site!

Comment: Oh yeah, if it is worth of a downvote it probably needs a close vote and vice versa! *Nothing makes much less sense than a question that 5 people voted to close and not a single down vote on the question!*

Comment: @JarrodRoberson: A lot of new people post a question and throw a hissy fit if we "maek them lose all there rep".  I tend to only downvote if the OP has >100 rep, but use close votes liberally.

Comment: @KeithThompson the follow up, what others are going to do think etc. voting is anonymous, it doesnt require to leave a comment etc... you can never expect every single person to upvote good stuff or downvote bad stuff. I have seen ideal questions with 100s of upvotes and random 5 downvotes... how to make sense out of that then

Comment: @JarrodRoberson It makes a lot of sense to vote to close a question without down-voting if the question simply belongs somewhere else. A new user (or even a somewhat experienced one) can easily choose the wrong SE site for a question, in which case a vote to close makes perfect sense and a downvote does not.

Comment: When it is justifiable? From what I can see users do it always when they disagree, it's a newbie or they just don't like that person. Personal experience.

Comment: *wait, down votes are supposed to be justifiable? by whom?*

Comment: I have enough "reputation points" to UpVote, but not nearly the required 125 points to DownVote! If I continuously UpVote, what's the point?

Comment: In fact I have just recently been awarded the right to UpVote any comment, and cannot DownVote a comment as well..

Comment: @eoredson no one can downvote comments.

Comment: @c0der - every down vote comes with a complete explanation, just hover over the down vote button and you will get all the explanation you should expect or *deserve* for [a very good reason](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252826/is-asking-reasons-for-downvote-in-comments-non-constructive). *"This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful** so your assertion that the down votes *typically with no explanation* is not factually correct, since every down vote has one by default.

Comment: We need more like **"How to downVote"** actually.

Comment: [Any time this applies.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YaeH4.jpg)

Comment: One thing that bothers me about "what have you tried already?" is, that it often seems to be passive aggressive. I doubt that the commenter wants to know it, but think he wants to communicate "please try to solve it yourself first" without saying it. And as many people are using such phrases to stealthy criticize questions, it gets harder to actually ask for what the person tried as it may be perceived like this. So don't do this. You don't need to educate people how to ask good questions in the comments section. Ask concrete real questions like "Did you try the ``-s`` switch (see man page)?"

Comment: @RazvanR Freedom of speech doesn't apply to a privately owned website.  Freedom of speech prevents the government from restricting that right; not a private organization.

Comment: "I often get a lot of flak for posting comments like that from people who are willing to do the OP's homework[...]" People criticizing you is a problem that could likely be soothed by the *"Welcome to StackOverflow, please take a look at this FAQ"*, and then stating what you normally do. You are not wrong in my opinion, but I'm also kinda okay with people who answer poorly written questions (they did help the asker, I'd like to encourage that). Having both kind of posts also seem good: The asker gets what he needs and is informed to behave better in the future (good cop, bad cop style).

Comment: You are not a grumpy old man, you are just fundamentally flawed in your thinking and social behavior. It is absolutely *not* necessary to put in a lot of effort before you ask on stackoverflow. At least it shouldn't be. The reason you think otherwise is only to protect your own past efforts. It is but more humble to just give it away as long as the one asking did at least check the obvious solutions. Why do you want to make him go through the trouble of trying different approaches when you could just as easily tell him what to do? That is just arrogant (cf. "homework").

Comment: @rene, am a new user, just for my knowledge. when is it justifiable to upvote a question? this question is because: if the post was unclear it gets downvotes and will be closed. the OP will get answers only if the question was clear. all the answers to the question are getting upvotes, then why not the question is getting upvotes?

Answer (score 276):

Don't over-protect users. Judge the quality of the post dispassionately:

- Poorly written question? Downvote and move on.
- Fed up with OP's wall of hideous spaghetti code? Downvote and move on.
- Did the OP obviously forego googling? Downvote and move on.
- Did the OP obviously forego reading the documentation? Downvote and move on.
- Is the OP confusing Stack Overflow with a free version of [Mechanical Turk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amazon_Mechanical_Turk)? Downvote and move on.

The list goes on, and on, *ad nauseam*.

As things stand, perhaps 99% of the questions on certain tags merit a downvote or ten. Browse your favorite tags, open a dozen questions in new tabs, and don't even try to parse the question **if it's obviously low quality**: downvote and move on.

For the few that don't immediately qualify for a down vote, **actually scan through the question** to pick up an overall impression. If the post is too long, unclear, hard to understand, lazy, *downvote and move on*.

**By laziness here, I mean not demonstrating the minimum amount of effort you'd expect from a co-worker who shows up with a question.** If he obviously went through the documentation, googled his problem, perhaps tried a thing or two, and now needs a hand, some direction, or a second pair of eyes, that's absolutely fine and that's what colleagues (or Stack Overflow enthusiasts) are for. Anything short of that is broadcasting the message that you're expected to do his work.

On the right tags, you'll plough through your 40-vote limit per day in a matter of minutes.

Moreover, **a question ban will only kick in if an OP's questions are sufficiently downvoted.** So don't be afraid to downvote stuff that deserves it.

Comment: -1. Please, leave a comment if you downvote unless somebody else already specified the reason to downvote.

Comment: Is this your opinion, or is there a formal reason to downvote these scenarios?

Comment: At no point do you think that you should comment instead of move on to help OP become a good member of SO?

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: Do tell… Why should I be bothered to waste even a moment explaining a down vote if OP cannot be bothered to do his homework and research before asking?

Comment: @JuJoDi: seldom not. It would take an OP who radiates competence with an honest question for me to do so, and it's no coincidence that questions asked by them happen to be great.

Comment: @Denis Why should you waste a moment? Because if you don't, they'll just keeping posting the same badly mangled questions.  If you care enough to downvote, shouldn't you care enough to tell the new poster what they are doing wrong.  Doesn't have to be long, just one of "We can't help you unless you tell us what you've tried/clearly explain the problem/clearly explain what you're trying to achieve/explain why the docs (or basic google search) haven't helped you"...

Comment: @PaulyGlott: The formal criteria is right there on the tool tip when you hover your mouse on the down vote button. It reads: "This question does not show any research effort, it is unclear, or not useful."

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: Never. Only if it requires it. Otherwise, downvote and move on.

Comment: @AmeliaBR: Not necessarily. After a sufficient number of closed, down voted questions, an OP gets question banned.

Comment: @Denis because some people have a genuine interest in contributing to this site and some contributors have a genuine interest in helping the site and its users grow.  Your answer pushes newcomers away and is entirely negative.  Why should you have to be competent to want to learn to program?

Comment: @JuJoDi: Stack Overflow is **NOT** a site to learn to program. It is a site for * professional and enthusiast programmers*. If someone comes here asking for help to learn to code, that person is on the wrong site.

Comment: @JuJoDi People like that generally don't ask completely terribly awful questions, and in the event that they do get downvotes, they're the type of people who will look through the help center, faq, etc. to look for resources on how to ask appropriate questions.  There's *more* that enough information out there on how to ask good questions, people just need to have the willingness to go read it.

Comment: @Denis I interpret that as "professional programmers and enthusiastic programmers"

Comment: I'd add to this that a question should be downvoted immediately if the OP doesn't have a good command of English, to the point where the question is very difficult to parse. This is an English language site, and if you want to play here you should learn English first. There are other sites for speakers of other languages.

Comment: @Denis "Poorly written question" does not meet the criteria "This question does not show any research effort, it is unclear, or not useful." -1

Comment: @PaulyGlott: "unclear" and "poorly written" are very close concepts. I suppose you can write badly and still be clear, in theory. In practice, if it's badly written it's unclear.

Comment: @JuJoDi: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252302/2591612

Comment: @staticx that answer encourages a comment with your downvote, as I'm suggesting as well.

Comment: Downvote, and... don't move on yet! Cast a close vote if applicable. Then proceed on your merry way.

Comment: how to ask questions on stackoverflow is not innate it is an acquired knowledge. If you don't want to help; you don't have to.

Comment: I generally agree with your sentiment here but I emboldened a few sentences I felt needed emphasis.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian it is an acquired knowledge - but in my opinion this should be considered part of the research we expect from OP before asking a question. If this research doesn't at least include five minutes for checking if a question is on-topic and generally acceptable for SO, and finding out how to do basic formatting, then they're doing it wrong. That said, I do always leave comments explaining a downvote, or upvote existing comments that express my reasons to downvote.

Comment: This is all good advice, but I would hasten to add that if a question *doesn't* fall into these traps **please upvote it!** [Carrot + stick](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carrot_and_stick) works better than just stick; don't forget to reward the folks who get it right. When folks see the front page of the site or the hot lists, they should see examples they can follow - if we don't upvote them, this won't happen no matter how many downvotes we cast.

Comment: Taking into account your: "At the first hint of incompetence, down vote and move on." -1 for *ad nausea*. Please, *please*! Don't try to look cool using Latin if you don't actually *know* Latin. *ad* wants the accusative case not the nominative case! The correct form is: *ad nause-**am***.

Comment: @JuJoDi - this answer only pushes the leech users away, those that want to participate correctly will put in the effort to do so. Those that don't, **good riddance**. I agree, if they don't put in the effort why should they warrant any effort beyond the official reason for a down vote. **Should say, this question is wasting your time, but more importantly thousands of other peoples time.**

Comment: Oh, and don't waste your time commenting on trivial errors that you can fix in less time than it takes to talk about them. @Bakuriu.

Comment: @Shog9 I wanted to provide an extreme example of what Denis wrote. Even if he took his time writing this answer in a very clear way, it was still incompent in a detail which, according to himself, should deserve a downvote straightaway and no looking back (or further).

Comment: I agree with everything here to some degree except the "At the first hint of incompetence, down vote and move on.". That hint of incoetence might be the reason why they are asking. If the user presented code (but is wrong somehow, hence "incompetence"), read the docs, linked to post about the topic, then I don't see the reason for the downvote at all

Comment: @Lamak: In my view, a user who read the docs and used google *is competent*: he did the absolute minimum amount of research effort before asking. Were OP's colleague in that case, I'd answer; if not, I'd invite him to do a bit more research effort prior to asking me to do his work.

Comment: @Denis Then you are talking about a limited definition of "incompetence", maybe you should clarify that in your answer, given that many users seem to be misunderstanding that part

Comment: @Lamak: edited accordingly.

Comment: I don't think "incompetent" means what you think it means, @Bakuriu.

Comment: There needs to be a reason communicated for the down vote. Just because someone asks a question worthy of a down vote doesn't mean they don't have other questions that are good. Maybe there's just one aspect of question writing they don't get yet. It's fine not to comment if someone else has or if you vote to close with a reason, but lacking those, a reason should be given.

Comment: if a question or an answer is to be downvoted, the least it deserves is an explanation and the downvoter should be "man" enough to sign his/her name to a downvote.  just good old manners and common courtesy.  ;-)  DOWNVOTED -1   tg

Comment: The co-worker analogy doesn't work for me personally. I would go a long way to ensure a new SO question was well researched, whereas my colleagues and I are _very_ comfortable asking each other questions where we know expertise lies, including all kinds of questions big and small we would be ashamed to put into writing. We treat it pretty much the same way we treat borrowing a stapler; no one responds to a question with "You LEACH! _BAD_ question!".

Comment: (I did have a sysadmin who felt this way, though, even about the stapler: "I'm busy! ***ing keep out of my ***ing office!")

Comment: I feel like your attitude is 100% the reason this question got asked: http://goo.gl/9sbjHy. The problem is, a lot of what you said is right. The part that you were especially correct about was expecting the degree of effort your co-worker would put in. But PLEASE don't tell people not to even bother thoroughly reading questions or to click down vote at the first sign it looks like a bad question. If you expect them to take the time to write good questions, you should at least take the minimum time to make sure they are really bad questions before down voting.

Comment: @Lamak - you are confusing *incompetence* with *ignorance* there is a significant semantic difference!

Comment: @Denis Fair enough, a reasonable reply. Downvote reversed, +1

Comment: @AndrewC: I can't speak for others, but I can take almost any amount of trivial questions from colleagues. Especially when they come from a intern. What I cannot take however, is them asking me or others do their job for them without the slightest effort to show for it. And sadly, the vast majority of SO questions I run into fall into that latter category.

Comment: @Denis Can you give me an example of that happening in real life - I just can't imagine doing it - you've turned down a colleague for help because they've been lazy by asking you? The only time I try to turn away work is during meetings where jobs are being shared out and it's being shared per person when they forget that I'm in two teams, and this would result in me staying up late every night for a week while they can slot it easily into the weekdays, or when they're asking a favour and I'm in one of those weeks; the equivalent for me on SO is just not answering.

Comment: @AndrewC - I've had the situation a bunch of times when assigning simple tasks to try remote freelances before assigning them something more material. For instance "please cook up X to do Y" with them coming back to me hours or days later asking how they can possibly write such a thing. Not the best approach to do so; the level of ineptitude I've encountered in the wild was programmers coming back asking *how* because it was evident they didn't even *try* to google their way out of a problem.

Comment: I agree with @J.F.Sebastian; You should provide a reason, so when the person whom asked the question ask's another question he knows what he did wrong the first time and hopefully improves this and learns what he should or should not ask on stack overflow. Reason can be as short as: Downvoted, no research effort. Takes you 2 more seconds.

Comment: @rofavadeka We are not here to teach individual users how to use the site; that's what the help documentation is for. We are here to create good question/answer pairs. Downvoting and voting to close serves that goal. Taking time out to educate individual users (who may not care to learn the lesson) is a distraction from that goal.

Comment: @Denis Good example - the worst I've dealt with like that was part time staff who never got the ethos, but we got better at hiring and haven't had a duffer on the team for years (there is __no__ substitute for seeing someone in action at the intended job). I guess I never thought of askers in SO as professional in any way - some of them come across as like students (some of them _are_ students), and occasionally there's an interesting question, but I treat those like a peer asking, rather than someone I _expect_ stuff from. Very interesting, thanks - I understand your point much better now.

Comment: +1 for "*down vote away, wide and large, as viciously as you can, without fear or mercy.*".

Comment: @Denis There is such a thing as having a "bad google day", but struggling your ass off, or needing some direction from some peer experts. Sometimes what is unclear to one, is not clear to another - a simple request / comment for more info is most often complied with and does not require a down-vote.  It also alienates those who consider this site a excellent resource.  My wife, who is a graphic designer (lightweight web), knows and uses stack.

Comment: @AnthonyHorne: *"struggling your ass off"* —- Ding! Ding! Ding! Ding! Ding! Not "plz show me teh codez", but indeed "I struggled my ass off and tried/looked into this". That makes a world of difference in my view.

Comment: @Denis Agreed.  Either way, it is nice to know there are so MANY people on Stack who care about the quality and helpfulness of the site.  To find the balance is the trick.

Comment: instead of downvoting rubbish, vote to close...

Comment: @jwenting Why be selective? If it deserves to be closed, it almost certainly isn't useful. That's what the downvotes are all about. Downvoting will get the bad questions off of the homepage, even if the close process takes a while (and it usually does).

Comment: When I was a new user, I did not pay attention to reputation. A downvote would mean nothing to me, a comment however would be useful. Some suggestions are simple, like "Can you provide sample input and your desired output", and new user could learn right away.

Comment: This way of thinking is horrific, A dictator would think like this, what if I was an old lady 75 year old, I want to spice up my life and learn how to code! I know this is extreme, but dictating the hows and the harsh way of doing this is self destructing concept. I often feel I need a degree to ask a question, what if I don't know the rules yet, give people a chance and lax, otherwise you will create the negative emotional feeling increment and the bubble will burst one day. Same negative feeling when a traffic warden does not allow a 2 minute parking to buy some water, gum, cigarettes.

Comment: @Val I'm not convinced that the emotional hyperbole is a sufficient counterargument. If the hypothetical 75-year-old lady wants to learn to code, good for her! She should go and do so. That does not, however, obligate StackOverflow to become something it is not, namely, a place to teach beginners how to code. There are other websites, books, tutorial videos, and college courses for that. (cont'd)

Comment: (cont'd) StackOverflow isn't a tutorial service; the mission is clearly stated in the [documentation](http://stackoverflow.com/tour): "_Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers...we're working together to build a library of detailed answers to every question about programming._"

Comment: @GeorgeCummins spoken like a true robot :) not personal, but even law makers in real world do take emotions into consideration and other states of what makes us humans. Efficiency and Effectiveness doesn't mean perfect ;) I mean if it wasn't for in-perfections and accidental discoveries e.g: a certain monkey discovering fire, we would not be here to talk about it. I think just because it states its a q/a for "enthusiasts" it does not mean it can't be challenged and argue pro and against to allow room for error. If it's for the community, it should not outcast people.

Comment: Let's be honest, the reason Down voters don't leave comments on why they down voted is because they fear retaliatory down votes.  If their convictions about keeping the site clean and high quality were that strong, they WOULD leave a comments to teach new users what they are doing wrong.  Instead, the site gives them anonymity, so they can down vote for ridiculous reason and feel superior.  

I agree there are a lot of question from users with 1 rep point that show NO research, but this OP goes too far IMHO.

Comment: The goal should be to improve the site. Not just 'downvote and move on', an act which is next to useless to improving the site. If you don't want to be a 'care bear', then recuse yourself from moderation duties, because that's what moderation is: taking special care to try to improve the site in a positive manner.

Comment: @Denis This seems like an excessively negative answer to the question.  I have only a few questions on SO and only a couple of answers, and I have only received one downvote.  That one had a comment that allowed me to correct the issue and have it reversed.  Please try to be more constructive.  Decades of psych research has shown that constructive criticism is more effective than discipline.  (Though discipline is important, the comment is far more valuable).

Comment: Your prescription to judge based on the title increase the prejudgement a good question. Sometimes people can't find a suitable title, also two similar titles may ask somethings from different perspectives... it's not that easy... however I agree with most part of your answer.

Comment: I think you have been here too long and should have a vacation.

Comment: Taking 30 seconds to add a comments in respect to the author of the question and other reader is the only time required to improve the world. But it seems your self-esteem is too high and you worth too much in regards to other people.

Comment: @DenisdeBernardy: Its only because of care bears, the world is still a livable place for humans.

Comment: Downvoted this answer because of "Down vote and move on". Downvoters should be forced to provide an answer! How else can the OP learn where he is wrong? (And don't give me that Informed crap)

Comment: How about, ignore and move on. For a community designed to be helpful, it is a very hostile one. Goodbye.

Comment: I think downvoting without giving a helpful comment is worse than ignoring the question. You are just expressing your frustration this way.

Comment: It sounds fair to me when someone wastes my time that I am entitled to feel that they have wasted my time, and downvote without further time waste.

Comment: Why down vote duplicates? They should be closed and that's it. I see it the whole time and it makes no sense. AND: No. It doesn't show poor research.

Comment: @DenisdeBernardy There is no bad question! Only bad answer! So if you don't understand, just ignore and move on. If you think you are superior, maybe be your are able to share your knowledge. If no, just move on!

Comment: Remember that different people are at different points on the learning curve for the SO site. By taking this harshest possible approach, you are trying to say that everyone needs to be in the top 20% of a group in terms of being able to ask a question correctly. Every individuals level or research to solve a problem will be different and you will be assuming if you dismissed 1's research effort that you consider as deserving. Hence there is a lot of subjectivity and judgement in your approach and hence this answer is incorrect in its robotic, emotionless approach. (... contd.)

Comment: (contd.) We need to follow rules and guidelines and also must take on our moral duty to help colleagues learn the rules of this game called SO. If you are at a reputation level of 20-50K+ and you consider someone with 1 reputation level asking a novice and uninformed question, you are perhaps very much right. Help this novice understand and they will also reach at a 100+ level to understand the rules better than where they were when they started off.

Comment: I am borderline offended by the amount of apathy shown here. I'd wager 99,9999% of new users would never get the chance to learn the ropes here, (a lot of them just started to learn to program) and will be downvoted into oblivion without knowing why at all.

Comment: -1. Horrible suggestion. One should first try to find ways to upvote something unless it cannot be done. It is easy to find an error or flaw in a question or an answer of the subject of expertise of the downvoter. I will not expect a person asking a C language related question to go through the C99 or C11 standard document first.  There has to be a balance. Definitely downvote absolutely crap quesstions which one cannot give any benefit of doubt.

Comment: "You got a speeding ticket, because you were speeding." So, by leaving a comment is allowing the `OP` to correct their mistake.  Now, if there is `no change` from the `OP`, then `Downvote` away.  Cops can give you ticket after ticket, until you get towed.  Our responsibilities (I believe), are if OP drives the car, letting them know our rules helps.  As Not everyone knows every rule in every city.  Yes, it is the OP's responsibility to know the rules, but come on now... *arguments* are: _You don't speed from time to time?..._ That is what I have read here. Thank you all for caring/commenting.

Comment: I am horrified that this is considered the accepted answer to this question. The attitude shown by the answerer is imo actually offensive. Don't get me wrong - there are definitely many many questions that absolutely deserve a downvote. But time and time again I see questions downvoted, even to the extent of being automatically deleted, when someone who is probably very new to programming has asked a genuine question, and it only takes 30 seconds for someone to flag as a duplicate and help everybody out. (continued)

Comment: I guess I'm a "benefit of the doubt" kind of guy, yes even a "care bear" - but I take the view that people come here because they need help, and it should be incumbent on everyone who chooses to give time here to actually try to help such people rather than implicitly tell them "your question is dumb, you're too stupid to use this site".

Comment: StackOverflow is a big place. We may not have understood everything before posting a question. Anyways, a downvote for you, Sir, without any other explanation.

Comment: A note to future readers: counter-arguing this position with comments of the form "I'm downvoting and I'm not explaining why" is completely missing the point. Downvoting without providing feedback is not for the sake of not wanting to explain the issues behind the post, but a combination of the downvote tooltip being enough feedback, and the user not wishing to become a target of subsequent pointless arguments or abusive behaviour.

Comment: @JeanFrancoisFabre: I understand what you tried to achieve, but your edits (and the subsequent edits after yours) completely denatured and neutered what was in the original answer. It used to be a scream for a more exclusive community, as in no beginners unless there's some research to show for it thank you very much; it is now bordering on the opposite of that in just about every other way. The only thing you seem to have left out in your edit was a (very popular) call to explain downvotes -- which I wholeheartedly disagree with, irrespective of how many times I actually do so myself.

Comment: What I think is harmful about downvotes is their anonymity.  If you downvote something, your identity should be known and you should be prepared to justify your downvote.

Comment: @msdr: if they bring in mandatory commenting, I'll just write the word "tomato". They'll know what it means.

Comment: @msdr: here's the conclusions you can draw. At 88 rep, you're new to the community, and it's probably fair that you spend a little time learning the challenges of running a successful Q&A before immediately involving yourself in insulting behaviour. Please, take a step back a little, and understand that voters, curators, editors, answerers and other volunteers probably have very good reasons for their conduct. Every great idea you have about what we should do differently has already been discussed.

Comment: I don't know if it is fair to say we are "welcoming" or "not welcoming" - we are a disparate set of people and all here for different reasons. The people who are most involved in the success of this site - volunteers and employees - have been doing this for a decade. Stack Overflow now uses data scientists and UX experts and human behaviourologists and A/B testing - pretty involved stuff - to try to triangulate between subject matter experts and people who can barely write English.

Comment: It is fair to say that if the Stack Overflow company wants to make it easier to post rubbish - and some of it is really woeful, I assure you - there could be such a drop in site quality that SMEs would go elsewhere. Presently the curation tools - editing, anonymous downvoting, question closing, post deletion, moderator flagging etc - are working pretty well. There are surely lots of things we could do better, but figuring out what they are is a very tricky task. Do please get involved with Meta and site curation, and you'll find out what we're up against.

Answer (score 182):

Downvote if the question:

- **Doesn't show research effort**

  - Asking us to do ... anything, with no attempt to do so oneself.
  - The question can be answered with a copy-paste from the manual.
  - The question can be answered by copying directly from one of the results in the first page of a Google search of the title (or similar).
- **Is unclear**

  - It takes you more than ~10-20 seconds to get a basic idea of what the question is asking.
  - The language in the question is such a mess that you have absolutely no idea what's going on. It might not even be a programming question. Perhaps the guy's trying to make coffee. Perhaps he's trying to make contact with some aliens.

    I'm fairly lenient on the language aspect - not everyone is particularly good at English. If I can edit it to fix most language issues, I'd rather do that.
  - The question is underspecified to such an extent that you'll have to write a book if you were to consider all the possible assumptions you could make in trying to answer the question.

    One or two unclear things doesn't usually cause me to downvote, but I might vote to close it instead if those things makes it impossible to answer the question.

  I consider downvoting on the unclear aspect a more extreme version of voting to close as unclear (although the reverse may be true for some), but I often vote to close as well when downvoting for this reason.
- **Is not useful**

  - The question is so fundamentally wrong for this site that you have to wonder what OP was smoking.

    This is probably more of a repetition issue - just a single off topic question here and there might not be downvote-worthy (arguable...), but if one can't be bothered to post on the correct site or conform to the on-topic guidelines, one really should help oneself to a few downvotes.
  - You strongly feel that the question wouldn't provide any / much value to anyone else, for whatever reason (but there isn't a close reason that applies).

    Ideally we should be allowed to close these, but work with what you've got, I guess... (there is the unreproducible / typographical error reason, but that doesn't exactly cover everything)

    I personally feel "Is my answer right?"-type questions (e.g. complexity analysis of functions, binary search tree insertions by hand) are often not particularly useful, so I may downvote them.

And absolutely **DO NOT** comment **without** downvoting where a downvote would've been appropriate, hoping OP will fix their issues eventually, or that those one or two downvotes already on the question is enough. Questions with a few downvotes that get fixed can easily pick up enough upvotes again to reach a positive score. And while some may change due to a few "What have you tried?" comments on their question, the vast majority is unlikely to, where-as a handful of downvotes is way more likely to change them, or at least get them off the site quick enough if they don't.

Although, by all means, downvote **and** post a comment if you wish. But I personally feel that "This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful" is pretty self-explanatory in most cases, although this isn't really the issue up for discussion here.

Comment: that's a bit too long for a tool-tip on voting arrows ;) +1 though

Comment: A tip of the hat towards close votes here might be nice too. Well written though :)

Comment: Honourable mention to [Is it appropriate to downvote a question without closevoting it?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251735/is-it-appropriate-to-downvote-a-question-without-closevoting-it/251743#251743) Beyond mentioning that, I'm not sure how to incorporate mentioning close votes in more detail here. Roughly ... close the question if one of the close reasons apply, but also if it's not useful or not good for the site (which presumably includes off-topic-ness) - don't just close it **because** one of the reasons apply.

Comment: You'd think google searching the exact title of a question wouldn't work all that often, but it does. Surprisingly a good percentage of these questions are well-written and show a bit of effort, but simply demonstrate a failure at googling - makes you wonder what OP searched for. Even worse, often when a question can be answered in this way there is another relevant stackoverflow question in the top three results, which means both the automated duplicate checker and the SO search were not used (or useful) either. At least this mostly leads to a duplicate and the question can be closevoted...

Comment: Absolutely do not reply? How do newbies learn this way? If they're brand new to the site, for crying out loud, remind them of the obvious and link 'em to the FAQ. One doesn't need to beat up newbies just because they're newbies. Downvote, yeah, but comments more often than not DO help the person become a better SO member.

Comment: @JasonMc92 No, absolutely do not **just** comment.

Comment: Ah, thanks for clearing that up. I keep "hearing" (seeing) people say to never bother commenting.

Comment: I do not feel that an unclear question is always a reason to downvote. Yes, some questions show a lack of effort and should be downvoted. But for some people, English is not their first language or they just are not talented at expressing themselves clearly. Should they be excluded from SO? If you can tell this is a case, don't downvote, instead edit their question to make it clearer or leave a comment or move on.

Comment: This is the correct answer. Why is it below the "rip off their faces, spit down their gaping neck hole, and move on" answer?

Comment: @dallin I agree that one should edit it instead if possible, but if someone is **unable** to express themselves **somewhat understandably** in English, the sad fact of the matter is - having their illegible questions stick around and having them continue to ask such questions isn't helping anyone. While commenting to request clarification is good, it shouldn't take away from downvoting and/or closing these questions as they're unable to be answered **in their current state** (and we shouldn't wait forever before doing so - the system is made to reopen and upvote it if the problems get fixed).

Comment: @Dukeling I agree with everything you said completely. I just want to make sure people don't down vote without thought if they don't understand a question immediately.

Comment: A lot of people downvote because "it takes you [them] more than ~10-20 seconds to get a basic idea of what the question is asking.", where the problem is that the person downvoting doesn't understand the problem space.  That's a practice that needs to be stamped out.  People should only downvote if they can explicitly determine why the question is incomprehensible to them - say, it's very poor English or the code indentation is terrible.  If it's incomprehensible and they're not sure why, they should leave it alone, because it's likely their comprehension and not the question that's at fault.

Comment: @WarrenDew A well put together question allows anyone, even those with no domain knowledge, to quickly get a basic idea of what it is asking. It's about clearly stating the problem and laying the question out in such a way that you don't have to read the whole of a long question before you figure out whether the asker wants to know why the code gives some error, how the code works, how to do something, a better approach, or whatever.

Comment: @Dukeling I disagree.  Teaching the reader about what can be a substantial domain of programming knowledge is way beyond the scope of asking a question.

Comment: @WarrenDew Either we have **vastly** different opinions on what "a basic idea of what the question is asking" is, or the questions we've looked at are largely mutually exclusive. You don't have to understand anything said in the question to have a basic idea of what it's asking. The end of my last comment summarizes exactly what I mean - "the asker wants to know why the code gives some error, how the code works, how to do something, a better approach, or whatever.".

Comment: @Dukeling, if I question (valid one) does not belong to the containing community, but to a different one within StackExchange, should it be downvoted instead of moving it/closing it/leaving a comment and let the OP move it? Which is the right way to treat this kind of questions?

Comment: @SajibAcharya If a question doesn't belong on Stack Overflow, you should absolutely comment or vote to close. When deciding whether to downvote, you should probably take into account how clear and useful the question is and how far off topic it is, although you could also argue that downvoting might motivate the asker to move it themselves, but I haven't found that to work too well.

Comment: @CodeMouse92 I could not agree more.  I keep seeing new users flooded with down votes, typically with no explanation. 
 I think it is very discouraging. I think that down voting users with say reputation of 50 or less,  
 should be technically blocked. Positive feedback is much more helpful. 
 Give them a chance to find their way before kicking their b**t.

Comment: I rarely see questions that are fixed getting the votes back. Actually, I never did.

Comment: People can down vote for any reason period. Just because 1 person "feels like it" or "in their mind" believes the question isn't good for "them" they simply down vote it. I have witnessed many times that an experienced programmer will down vote a question, because "for them" it's a question that is so easy, it shouldn't even be asked. Obviously someone posts a question because they don't know the answer and they have tried to debug the issue, and find the answer. This happened to me. My question was carefully researched, and drafted, with code- but apparently not good enough for somebody.

Comment: @Paul just want to add situation upon yours. I once got downvote because one part of my code doesn't meet someone's industrial standard or best practice, which is completely irrelevant to the question. I appreciate the person at least comment it out but it never justify the downvote neither provide any helps for the original question. My true experience with downvote was usually associated to this kinds of users as an experienced SO users unfortunately. Some posts really overestimate the downvoter's behavior logic

Comment: @Paul People are indeed able to downvote for any reason, but that doesn't mean they're downvoting for a *valid* / justifiable reason. This is about when you *should* downvote, not about when people *do* downvote.

Comment: I totally agree. As a community-oriented website, quality management must be done by our hands.

Answer (score 38):

I think that you can be **objective** about this question and you should put aside any moral concerns. This reminds me of something *Joel Spolsky* has written in one of his [articles](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/GuerrillaInterviewing3.html):

> Don’t be afraid that you’re going to reject too many people and you
>   won’t be able to find anyone to hire. During the interview, it’s not
>   your problem. Of course, it’s important to seek out good candidates.
>   But once you’re actually interviewing someone, pretend that you’ve got
>   900 more people lined up outside the door.

***Same analogy.***

So when it comes to **objectively** evaluating a question you should **be ruthless** and free of any moral constraints. Use downvote **and** flag the question for closure. If you just downvote nothing will happen and we'll just see a bunch of downvoted questions. If you flag it there is a good chance that it will be closed and it will cease to pollute the list of questions with noise.

There is an important thing though: **you should comment** on the question. This should be a no-brainer but people often just *fire and forget*. If you don't tell them what the problem is they might just get angry and ask again or something like that. On the contrary if you comment and tell them what was the problem they get feedback and can improve *(if they want to of course)*.

In my case I often short-circuit if I see any of these *patterns* and downvote+flag+comment on the question accordingly. I think that it is OK if you have a file with the standard comments for every pattern.

- **Classic bozo question like:**

> How to pass arraylist of custom class in intent using Parcelable interface ? I have arraylist having objects of custom class now i want to pass this arraylist from one activity to another activity. Please help ! Thanks in advance.

No code, no Exception no nothing. You might often feel in these cases that the user is so hopelessly pointless that no amount of explaining will make him/her understand. Standard answer is :

*This question in its current form is not answerable, consider editing it or reading the FAQ.*

- ***"I failed to google my basic question"* question:**

> I'm newbie in coding and i do know that both programming language supports OBJECTS but can anyone explain what is the major difference in term of object in both languages.
>
> Thanks in advance

Standard answer: *I think this question can be googled rather quickly. If you don't understand what the problem is please read the FAQ.*

- ***"Solve my homework"* question:**

> This is a homework that I want your help in order to do it! Thanks all!!! Hope it is not difficult to give me instructions how to solve it or to give me some parts of code to start with!

Then he goes on and copy-pastes the homework and the instructions. Standard answer is:
*This is a question and answer site if you are confused please read the FAQ. If you want someone to solve your homework hire a consultant but we are not supposed to solve it for you. After all it is a homework assignment in the first place.*

- **"Suggest me a library" question:**

> Can anybody suggest me a Code Library Software that we can implement
>   in our development team. We are working on the following development
>   technologies:
>
> iPhone (on Mac) Android (on Windows & Mac) PHP/LAMP Model ( on Windows
>   & Mac) Flash/ActionScript (on Windows & Mac) Thank you.

Standard answer is: *On this site we are supposed to provide concrete answers to concrete questions. Suggestions are not part of its agenda. If something is not clear please read the FAQ.*

- **Classic duplicate question:**

> How does parameter passing work in java?

It has been answered like 1024 times. No reason to answer it again. You don't need to comment since after flagging it a comment will appear with something like "possible duplicate of..."

These are the most common ones I see. There are some general things to remember:

- Downvoting/flagging is not a personal attack. You evaluate a question and react to it. This is supposed to be objective only considering the question itself not the user.
- Sometimes you will feel the need to answer the question. **Don't do it.** It will just lead to a proliferation of new questions with zero worth and you will end up cleaning up the mess.
- If someone gets fed up and starts to attack you personally then stay objective and link to the FAQ or explain the problem again. Imagine yourself in their situation. Stay polite and use the flag function.
- Don't be afraid to comment. Voting anonymously is easier, I know but if you don't provide a pointer to what the problem is you leave the user without any guidance.

I hope this helps.

Comment: -1 I think you are wrong. There are many ON HOLD questions that are very useful to me and other people and are often left unanswered.

Comment: Just because there are a lot of ON HOLD questions it does not mean that any of them are in the categories I mentioned. I did not say that there are no useful questions ON HOLD.

Comment: Well, are you actually suggesting downvoters should harass curators taking care of review queues by both downvoting and flagging ? As I see it downvotes should be enough to go all the way up to questions deletion. And the actual thing we should ask ourself is only "Should this question be on SO ?", not asking to yet someone else to take actual decision.

Answer (score 17):

I will concentrate on two parts of the question:

> However, I often get a lot of flak for posting comments like that from people who are willing to do the OP's homework, and answered his question. This makes me question if I am doing the right thing, or maybe I'm too harsh on these people?

Probably for different users different things are the "right thing". People have different tolerances towards badly posed questions. Some will require less.

You have a right to downvote, but others have a right to answer questions even if they are downvoted.

I would even go further and say, as long as there are others willing to do the OP's homework, well, it's their business, isn't it? It doesn't affect you and how you see the question. I would still downvote the question (but not the answer).

> Should I keep downvoting these poorly-written questions, or am I becoming a grumpy old man who's trying to stick to traditions of a time long past? When is it "OK" to downvote a question, and when is it not?

It is okay, when it is according to the guidelines. Your way (the traditional way I assume) is not worse than other ways. Just continue, but stay open just in case a usage pattern emerges that might be better.

Lately I wonder if downvotes and close votes are not strongly correlated and therefore partly redundant. One could imagine that there would be no downvotes, but only upvotes or close votes. In this case the discussion would be more to the point: to close or not to close.

Comment: "*no downvotes but only upvotes or close votes*" - I very much like that.

Comment: @firda: Well, that would need a completely different system as lots of important parts depend on downvotes (among others, quality-bans, delete-voting, and the roomba would need to be replaced). Would it be better? That depends on how the lack of downvotes is compensated.

Comment: I would have given you +10, if I could! 4 years later, and especially after the reduction of the close votes required to close a question, I strongly believe that downvotes are able to kill even salvageable posts, because they don't give time even to willing askers to perform the simple edits. Those edits would sometime tranform a closeable question in an interesting one, but there's no chance ti recover a -2.

Comment: I strongly agree with your last paragraph, with a twist, close votes are usefull in once case: duplicates, because we do not want to remove them but close the question and point to the duplicate (also not all duplicates are exact duplicates than can be merged). Why not use downvotes to go up the logical end of bad questions: actual deletion, without transit by review queue.

Comment: I disagree with “ as long as there are others willing to do the OP's homework, well, it's their business, isn't it? It doesn't affect you” because answering bad questions leads to more bad questions, and avid users of the site have to waste their time looking at those bad questions instead of looking at good questions.

Comment: @EkadhSingh-ReinstateMonica I fully understand. The source of the disagreement is probably that I see homework questions not as bad questions per se while you seem to equal them. Homework is just a label to me and not a particularly specific one. I think there even might be good, useful homework questions. Please also note that my answer is from 2014, more than 8 years ago. I'm not even sure I would agree with myself would I carefully read and understand the matter again.

Answer (score 5):

Anytime you feel like it basically.

But a little more seriously: Last year, many close options for reviewers were [removed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184154/closing-changes-on-hold-unclear-too-broad-opinion-based-off-topic-reasons?rq=1). In their place, the use of the downvote was recommended in many of these cases. Therefore, anytime a question shows what you judge as lack of quality, downvote it. Really the question for the discerning user is when should a question be closed as well. That is the question which requires more explanation. If you feel a question needs a-downvoting, downvote it.

Comment: I don't think that should be the case.  Just because 1 person "feels like it" or "in their mind" believe the question isn't good for "them" they simply down vote it.  I have witnessed many times that an experienced programmer will down vote a question, because "for them" it's a question that is so easy, it shouldn't even be asked. Obviously someone posts a question because they don't know the answer and they have tried to debug the issue, and find the answer.   This happened to me.  My question was carefully researched, and drafted, with code-  but apparently not good enough for somebody.

Comment: Sorry for the very late comment. But this is false. Closing is just as recommended as it was before. Close vote is far more helpful than a downvote. Read the link you gave. The system was streamlined, but there is no suggestion to downvote instead.

Answer (score -7):

The casuistic of a "lazy" question could be a lot. Maybe they are lazy, stressed, have poor English skills (like me, sorry for that), or maybe they are very 
lost. Who knows.

I suppose a direct downvote is not the best option. Maybe the second option before trying with a comment saying that the question is not right. Anyway, if the user is willing to learn, he/she will make another better question, so it is not a big deal.

Answer (score -10):

The top-voted answers on this question adopt an "ahistorical" view of questions. That is, a question is what it is when asked; and you will downvote or not-downvote it and move on with your life.

In fact, questions change due to feedback - especially when they're poor or lacking in some respect, and thus don't get answers which satisfy the posting user. And this is more common with new/inexperienced users.

Therefore I would qualify what the top-voted answers suggest, by saying that users, especially new ones, should first receive comments on the failings of the question, without the downvote, and a downvote if those comments are not addressed. Of course, questions which are excessively flippant or bad and don't show the intent to ask a reasonable question are the exception to this rule, but **don't rush to "penalize" new users immediately just because they don't know how things work around here.**

See my discussion of a specific case, [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/390728/1593077).

Comment: *'don't dump on new users immediately because they don't know how things work around here.*' That's not what I do. But I DV questions that generally speaking show no effort. Sadly, such questions often are written by new users. Tough luck.

Comment: @Sockenpuppe: So, I'm saying you should give a new user the benefit of the doubt, that maybe they have made some effort but has not reported it, or even - will make more effort they have not already made and edit their question. And in the mean time, you would just make a comment saying the question doesn't show effort and will likely be downvoted if not edited.

Comment: Yes, that's possible. But the number of questions that would require this treatment is so hight for popular tags that doing this is a full time job. It's best to remove bad questions as fast as possible before they swamp the site.

Comment: @Sockenpuppe: Ok, so that's a valid counter-argument. It is indeed a trade-off between the kind of "niceness" I'm suggesting, and the speed of editorial work + speed of removal of bad questions. I'm arguing that we are too far to one end of that. But I don't discount your point of view, so +1.

Comment: I don't vote for the benefit (or "punishment") of the poster; I vote for the benefit of others who chance upon the post later, to signal to those people whether the post is worth their time.

Comment: @HereticMonkey: 1. I realize _you_ don't intend to punish the user; but the user doesn't know that (plus, your motivation is not shared by everyone). 2. If you at least explain why you downvoted and how the question could be improved, it's already better. 3. You could wait with the signaling to future users, make the comment, and let the new user, hopefully, improve the post. Again, the important distinction here is new vs veteran users.

Comment: Your answer, in bold, is accusing people of penalizing new users by downvoting immediately and moving on. And frankly these same arguments are made for requiring comments on downvotes, and that doesn't work out. Finally, we've just come out of an experiment where downvotes were not shown (sometimes after 0, sometimes after -1). Let's wait to see how that experiment pans out before we start jumping down people's throats for voting as they see fit...

Comment: @HereticMonkey: I am indeed a proponent of commenting on downvotes; a strict requirement is a bit harsh, but perhaps not when it comes to new users. It is indeed a good idea to consider the effects of such an experiment; however - what are the criteria for it having succeeded?

Comment: No idea. The experiment kind of just sprang up out of nowhere. [Shog probably has more insight as to the criteria](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/390179/215552).

Comment: Yes, that could go a long way towards reducing the friction with new users (one or more phases before actual voting).

Answer (score -14):

> I tend to read it as 'This question does not show enough research
>   effort

See this is a real problem, because just like with email, a very low percentage of readers will read a large article. Analogously, an email is scanned briefly by the majority of users and so is a message posted here on Stack Overflow.

There is little sense in writing reams of detail of events leading up to the question, in the initial question.

It is actually wrong for Stack Overflow to be instructing users to write long detailed initial posts of things you tried leading up to the original post.

The reason is the same reason you would not generally actually read a long email that you get from someone in its entirety.

What happens is that the skimmers of the post will not see what was written because the trees obscure the forest. This is how humans need to operate. We need to use brevity, for good reason. We need to be OK with that when other people use brevity, and not automatically start to make negative assumptions about the work ethic or whatever of the counterparty.

Comment: State the essence of what your question is about in the title, state the question briefly at the start of the body, then go into background and your research, and if it is neccessary for any reason (elaboration or long background/much research) re-state the question at the end. Thus everybody skimming it will get the essence immediately, but you won't be downvoted for lack of clarity and research.

Comment: It doesn't have to be linear. The [inverted pyramid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverted_pyramid_(journalism)) instead of the linear academic style from school *can* give you both brevity and sufficient detail when needed.