# Add downvote capability to close review queue

Tags: feature-request, review-queues, vote-to-close

Between downvoting and closing, there are four possible permutations that you can do to a question:

1. Downvote + Close : I think generally frowned upon
2. Downvote + Leave Open : Good in cases of quality not arising to predefined close cases
3. No Downvote + Close : Good in a number of predefined cases
4. No Downvote + No Close : Question is ok as it is.

When reviewing  the close queue, only 3 and 4 are possible.  Given that 2 is the preferred option in many cases of poor questions, why can't I downvote as a possible action and get credit for the review?  I can edit and get credit for reviewing a close queue question which seems weird because I am not answering the close/leave open question.

Let me downvote when a question is bad but should not be closed.

Comment: I don't think Downvote+Close is frowned upon. There are plenty of instances of it being advocated in highly-upvoted responses in this discussion: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252677/when-is-it-justifiable-to-downvote-a-question

Comment: @AndrewMedico Yes, actually I might agree with you now that I think about it.  A closed question can always be reopened and we still need some way to say this is not a good example of an SO question.

Comment: I do agree that this would be a very useful feature. I frequently open questions in a new tab to downvote very low-quality questions in the review queue.

Comment: I downvote most of the crap questions that I closevote. It's really quite simple: if the question fits the description of the downvote arrow (no research, unclear, not useful), downvote it. If it is off-topic or fits one of the other close reasons, closevote. These two actions are by no means mutually exclusive.

Comment: @AndrewMedico The issue is that blindly downvoting every question you vote to close is wrong. Some questions should be closed, some should be downvoted but don't fit any close reasons, and some should receive both. It's for the latter that adding the downvote option would be useful. I'd actually suggest adding both as some questions are incorrectly flagged as off-topic and I'd still have to open a new tab to open them. **But since this got basically no views, should this be migrated/requested on the main meta instead?**

Answer (score 8):

I second this motion, but with a difference: add the downvote arrow near the question's vote count:

[image: Screenshot of a question review page with the space below the vote count circled in red]

This would be consistent with the already implemented upvote/downvote system and would not clutter the action with (possibly) unwanted noise.

Comment: This works as long as the down-vote arrow does the same thing it does on every other page.  The reviewer would, after clicking the down arrow, still need to click one of the buttons in the action bar.