# Close and Triage queues need a downvote option. No, really

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, review-queues, downvotes, vote-to-close

I've been spending a lot of time in [the close vote queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close). I feel that there is a problem with the tools available to me there or in the triage queue. As a syllogism, er, wait, I have three premises:

1. It's been said on Meta that **“give me the code” questions should be downvoted, not closed.** (Let's not rehash disagreement in this question, please.)
2. **The close and triage queues do not have “downvote” as an option.**
3. **Many of the questions I encounter are “give me the code”** questions (without any redeeming characteristics, either).
4. **Therefore, I cannot take the proper action from the queue.**

This is inconvenient, because I have to step outside of the flow of the queue to Do the Right Thing.

This has also caused me to fail several review audits: I click Leave Open (because closing is not the proper action), and then I fail because people have closed the question for “too broad” (no! it's well-constrained!), “unclear what you're asking” (no! it's perfectly clear!), or “debugging must provide code” (no! they're not asking for debugging!). I'm aware that audits aren't perfect because they're automated, but this is a specific, frequent problem.

If I want to do the right thing even if others have not, and not fail audits, then my only option is to visit the question itself, downvote it, and then choose **Skip** as my queue action, which is also wrong because it's claiming that I haven't handled the question where I actually have.

The triage queue also has this problem: these questions are *unsalvageable*, but I can't say so without specifying a flag or close reason. (Triage has the prompt to upvote good questions, which also enables a downvote option, but it isn't available at the start.)

---

Anyone who's in these review queues is trying to sort the okay from the bad. As long as not all kinds of badness need closure, there should be an outlet for saying “this is bad in a downvote kind of way, not a close kind of way”. Therefore, **the close and triage queues should offer downvoting as an option,** despite that seeming not to the point.

The downvote button would have the effect of completing the review task (sort of like “I'm Done” gets enabled in First Posts/Late Answers), so effectively a “Leave Open” for close-voting purposes. (But unlike Leave Open, it wouldn't cause you to fail an audit on an actually-closed question.)

Comment: Even though the idea behind Triage is to just sort into buckets, I do support the idea of allowing downvotes for when the question is bad yet no flag is appropriate.

Comment: How would having the option to downvote help with audits, or with doing what the queues are for? You seriously need to flesh out the mechanics a bit.

Comment: @Deduplicator If I push the downvote button, that takes it out of the queue without applying a close vote, like a Leave Open vote. Added a paragraph to discuss the mechanics.

Comment: Oh hey, found a near-duplicate in Related that I didn't in searching before: [Add downvote capability to close review queue](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254687/add-downvote-capability-to-close-review-queue?rq=1)

Comment: what about opening the question in a new tab, downvote, and then close the new tab to come back to the triage queue?

Comment: @Kaiido: "Open post in a new tab" is practically its own review action, which gets annoying from time to time.

Comment: @NathanTuggy I'm not really in the triage thing, but is pressing `ctrl` `click`/ `middle click` +  `ctrl` `w` as long as reading a full post trying to determine whether it should be closed or not ?

Comment: @Kaiido: No, I mean "Open post in new tab because the queue isn't showing enough" is basically right on up there with Looks OK, Skip, Unsalvageable, No Action Needed, Reject, and so on: it's essentially a review action, it's so often necessary. And that frequent falling back on "oh, looks like we have to go outside the queue again" is annoying, as mentioned.

Comment: ah ok, missed the point. But then ,IMHO, the request to have the downvote button inside the review page loses again interest, if anyway, it's part of the process (even an "annoying" one) to go to te post page.

Answer (score 25):

I understand your case for adding the button, so that when someone sees a bad question, their instinct is to take at least some action, so we provide them the correct action to take.  However, these individuals are simply misunderstanding the purpose of triage, and are not using it correctly.

- If you add a downvote button, then it is no longer a triage queue.
- You are now administering treatment, and it is a biased treatment.  **If you can't upvote, but you can downvote, then the review queue exposes questions to a biased feedback.**  For example, a mediocre question which half of reviewers think is good and half think is bad.  Today it gets a mix of close/ok outcomes.  Add a downvote, and it gets a mix of close/ok/downvote.  So votes wise, the triage queue is now exposing the question to downvotes but not upvotes.
- Triage is process intended to be focused and not concerned with other decision not related to the triage process.  There is well established basis for why you have such a process and why you limit the process to only triage actions, and strictly do not involve other decision making processes or actions in that process.
- If people are incorrectly using close reasons, then mechanisms should address that problem directly.  Possibly suspending people from the triage queue.
- I don't think we should add a downvote button just to distract bad reviewers from choosing the wrong outcome.

**What if we did add Vote Up/Down as proposed**

When you click vote up/down, what is supposed to happen?  Are you done with the question then?  You still haven't addressed the issue of whether the question meets the criteria of the close vote reason, which is the purpose of the queue.

Keving wants the down vote button as it allows feedback for questions where they should be left open, but he wants the option to downvote them.  So do we assume a downvote means vote for Leave Open and skip to next question?  Certainly some reviewers will downvote because its a bad question, but that doesn't mean they've thought carefully about the criteria of the close reason, so we certainly shouldn't automatically submit a Leave Open vote.

So you can't assume the vote for the close queue based on a down vote.  This means after a downvote do we still leave the user on the question until they explicitly choose the close reason?  If they were improperly choosing the close vote outcome before, **they will probably still make the wrong decision**.

**If anything, it will be worse, because you are involving them in two orthogonal thought processes:**

1. Whether or not it is a good/bad question and deserves up/down vote
2. Whether or not the criteria of the close vote applies.

These two things sometimes go hand and hand, but as Kevin exemplifies in the premise of the question, they sometimes do not. A down vote does not necessarily mean a vote to close, but on the other hand it also does not always mean a vote to leave open.

**This is exactly why triage is a focused process.  Your mindset is not supposed to be on whether its a good or a bad question.  It's supposed to be on whether or not the criteria for the close reason applies.**  Those sometimes go hand in hand, sometimes not. *Sometimes a really "good" question simply doesn't meet the site's criteria, and the purpose of the queue is to focus on the criteria of the close vote.  If you want to vote up/down on questions, the close vote queue is not the place for that.

> I disagree with this answer, because it's basically implying that I
>   can't walk and chew gum at the same time - Jean-François Corbett

The premise of the question was that down votes should be added so that people who are currently choosing the wrong outcome will instead click the downvote.  I framed my answer under that premise, and the proposed feature being unable to solve that problem.  So if you disagree with that implication, then it is the premise of the question you disagree with.

**A Better Meta Question**
Would not be a feature proposal, but a discussion post regarding the root problem, which is the failed audit where the asker believes they shouldn't have failed.  This would allow everyone to brain storm on a better way to address the problem.  My answer focused on why the proposed feature does not address the problem.

Comment: We don't need to 'just' add a downvote button, we can have an upvote too. Infact, we already do this if you are the third "Looks Ok"er. We're also not forcing people to vote, just giving the option. The barrier for completing a review will still but clicking one of the 3 buttons.

Comment: @DavidGrinberg I've added a what-if analysis for if we did add up/down vote buttons.

Comment: I disagree with your analysis, as per the notes in my comment. Up/down votes would be neither final, nor mandatory actions. You still need to 'triage' the question. We assume nothing. Downvote means downvote. This allows us to leave open 'gimme deh codez' (because they shouldnt be closed) and still downvote because they are bad.

Comment: @DavidGrinberg I never said votes were mandatory and that is not a premise of my analysis. What is relevant is that some users are choosing the wrong close vote outcome, and that is the premise of the question.  Adding Up/Down buttons only serve to further that confusion.  It does nothing to improve these users behavior.

Comment: @DavidGrinberg "This allows us to leave open 'gimme deh codez' (because they shouldnt be closed)" **You already have this option, it's called the "Leave Open" button.**  Nothing changes that. If you're not using it properly, adding more irrelevant buttons just to give you an alternative is not going to change the fact that you're improperly traiging the question. As you said "You still need to 'triage' the question." and adding more irrelevant buttons isn't going to change the fact that some people don't know how to triage properly.

Comment: Its _not_ an alternative though, its an addition. You say `When you click vote up/down, what is supposed to happen? Are you done with the question then? ` Sounds like you believe that this will be a terminal move. it wont. I shouldn't need to hope im the 3rd person to say "looks ok" on a terrible question just so I can downvote it. People won't be confused by the up/down vote buttons on the review just as they arent confused on the main site. The purpose of triage still remains clear.

Comment: @DavidGrinberg No I don't believe it would be terminal.  I addressed both possible implementations in my analysis.  If you make it terminal, then whatever assumption you make is invalid, because the two decisions of whether to up/down vote and what close outcome is are orthogonal. So it is invalid to make an assumption.  Therefore as I said "This means after a downvote do we still leave the user on the question until they explicitly choose the close reason? If they were improperly choosing the close vote outcome before, they will probably still make the wrong decision."

Comment: @DavidGrinberg I'll use your terminology of "addition".  **The addition of up/down vote buttons will not change the fact that people are making incorrect triage votes.**

Comment: @DavidGrinberg "People won't be confused by the up/down vote buttons on the review just as they arent confused on the main site. "  The premise of the question was that people ARE confused about vote outcomes, and the addition of up/down votes was a suggestion to improve that problem.  It's not whether or not we can add up/down votes, but whether or not we can address the problem of people improperly using the close vote in lieu of a downvote.

Comment: I disagree with this answer, because it's basically implying that I can't walk and chew gum at the same time.

Comment: This answer doesn't solve the OP's problem of getting review audit failures. OP does have a point that while "leave open" is really the correct review action (after downvoting,) not letting people downvote is biasing them towards the 'incorrect' review choice, which is then creating bad audits. Of course, this also raises the question of whether the "don't flag/vote to close 'give me the code' questions" policy was really the right choice. If reviewers are so frequently voting to close them that review audits are commonly choosing that as the correct action, maybe it should be.

Comment: @reirab I addressed the topic of his question, which in the title is "queues need a downvote option" by giving specific reasons why that would be a bad solution. If he wants to post a question that focuses on the problem of failed audits in this scenario he is welcome to.  The premise of the question was that adding downvote button would solve the problem, and my answer attempts to address why that 1) Would not solve the problem 2) would have bad side affects.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCorbett The question already established that some people are choosing the wrong close votes which is the cause of the problem.  What do you not understand about that?

Answer (score 21):

"Too Broad" is perfectly applicable to homework-dump questions (whether or not they are actually assignments in a class).

They're **asking for the entire software lifecycle** to be done for them -- requirements gathering, architecture, design, implementation, testing.  Plus explanation of all the foregoing, since SO answers are expected to explain themselves.  That's very broad.

Questions which ask for help with only one of the above, with clear and narrow scope, are fine, and don't need to be downvoted either.

Comment: Though I don't see how this addresses the question, I agree.

Comment: Homework-dump questions usually have perfectly designed requirements, simply architecture, and do not require a testing strategy. If you're going to use "too broad" as a catch-all close-reason you don't need to be duplicitous about it.

Answer (score 11):

I say yes, let's add those upvote/downvote buttons. Why?

Though the correct, intended primary action for a clearly worded, well-scoped "gimme the codes" question is arguably (and this is not the point I'm looking to argue):

- Close queue: <kbd>Leave Open</kbd>*
- Triage queue: <kbd>Looks OK</kbd>

there is **nothing wrong with allowing the reviewer to *also* apply a correct, secondary action on the side,** such as voting.

In fact, making it difficult (not impossible, just really, awkwardly difficult) for the reviewer to do what is right at the top of their mental stack when it is the glaringly appropriate thing to do is what I would call **obstructionism**.

In both these queues, we already allow such a secondary action, namely commenting. Are reviewers getting all confused by this? Would anyone argue that the option to comment is causing reviewers to make crazier decisions than otherwise? No! It works just fine and as intended.

Let's trust that reviewers can both walk toward the primary destination and chew gum at the same time.

<sub>* though I'll be the first to admit that I may have occasionally and completely accidentally hit the Close button on zero-effort questions. Whoops!</sub>

Answer (score 8):

This has been implemented now.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I don't know about the CV queue (obviously), but in Triage, <kbd>Looks OK</kbd> is in fact strictly the correct option when there's nothing to close it for. It *is* OK — there's nothing that can or should be done for it — it just isn't a good question.

Also, [there's nothing wrong with Skip](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252195/there-is-no-shame-in-using-skip), even when it results in duplicate review handling. I would, however, recommend taking a policy of either a) keeping your audit radar up and opening suspiciously auditorious posts in a new tab to double-check or b) simply scrupulously posting whenever you get a bad audit. Either will avoid the problem of skipping all the things, and the latter has, I believe, been recommended by moderators at various times, although I strongly doubt anyone actually carries it out.

Comment: Yes, I agree that Looks OK/Leave Open is the current correct action. My argument is that (1) people want to mark bad posts, so if they can't downvote they'll reach for close incorrectly, and (2) Leave Open makes you fail audits if the real question is closed. (Don't know about Looks OK for Triage; I haven't spent as much time in that queue.)

Comment: There *is* something wrong with Skip for this purpose: I want to explicitly vote that this question should **not be closed** (only downvoted). If I Skip, it stays in the queue and will likely attract more close votes.

Comment: @KevinReid: Then either a) distinguish audits from regular and skip only when it's an audit or b) make a fuss about the bad audits. Shog has expressed his distaste for downvotes in the two queues in which they currently exist already, so it seems unlikely that option c) here will be implemented.

Comment: Perhaps I'll make a fuss as applicable and see what happens, then.