# Specific hard-to-review question

Tags: discussion, review-queues, specific-question, triage

## tl;dr

There was a question in triage with very high disagreement among the reviewers.

## Related meta questions

The most relevant I could find was [Close and Triage queues need a downvote option. No, really](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/291651).
However, I'm not here to request that feature but to ask how to deal with the current situation.

## The question

[The question](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/14760471) was very basic and OP quickly acknowledged

> so stupid i haven't thought about that

once the obvious had been pointed out to them.
It gathered (deservedly, imho) a total of ten downvotes before deletion and had been closed as too broad (unfittingly, imho).

[image: screenshot of now deleted question]

So, let's check the criteria:

#### Can the question be understood and answered as-is?

Yes, definitely.
It's very clear and easily understood.

#### Should it be improved by edits?

Nope, not much an edit could improve.
It's fundamentally flawed but well executed.<sup>2</sup>

<sup>2</sup> OK, the English and the semantic markup are imperfect but an edit would not *make* it “clear and answerable”, it already *is*.

#### Is it unsalvageable?

Well, kinda.
But none of the flag reasons apply.

- *Spam or rude?* Definitely not.
- *Duplicate?* Unlikely, too specific.
- *Unclear what is asked?* Nope, perfectly clear.
- *Too broad?* There is pretty much one possible answer and it's very short. Does definitely not apply, unless I'm overlooking something big here.
- *Off-topic?* Does not ask for off-site resources, is definitely about programming and there is no code to debug.

## What I did

As outlined above, reading only the words “Looks OK”, “Requires Editing” and “Unsalvageable” my gut would be to go with the last one, but when not ignoring the descriptions of the options (and the requirement to flag any unsalvageable question) only the first seems reasonable in any way.

Thus I chose “Looks OK” (and downvoted).

## The result of the triage review

While the “consensus” was indeed “Looks OK”, a breakdown of 3/2/2 does not feel really encouraging.
Apart from the fact that I would not call that a consensus, it raises doubts whether I did the right thing.

Did I?
If not, what should I have done?

## The subsequent closure

As mentioned above, I feel that the “too broad” reason does decidedly *not* apply.
The flavour text states:

> There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.

- “Do `percent = 100-percent`.” is pretty much the only possible answer.
- This answer is definitely not too long for this format, it even fits in a comment. (As has been demonstrated.)
- There are no sensible details to add. It's perfectly specific.
- There is only a single issue. Nothing to isolate here.

Am I mistaken?
If so, please enlighten me as to how this reason applies.

## Clarifications

I stated this in the comments, but it became crowded down there:

- I am aware of the skip button.
  The problem is not that I was unsure *during review* but when looking at the review again afterwards (which I quasi-randomly-routinely do).
- I don't have strong feelings about the *deletion* either way.

Comment: A question can be on topic but not useful so in a sense a highly down voted open questions is one of the results we should see.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Reviewing some awful questions is just a waste of time, can we have a “no comment” close reason for these?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261858/reviewing-some-awful-questions-is-just-a-waste-of-time-can-we-have-a-no-commen)

Comment: @NathanOliver Yes, this was pretty much what I expected when reviewing but not really how it turned out. Thus, this question.

Comment: Also, once you reach 3000 reputation, you can vote to close with a custom off-topic reason, like *I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has been resolved in a way that is not likely help future readers.*

Comment: @Glorfindel The typo close vote also covers *resolved in a way not helpful to future readers.

Comment: That's true, but it's hard to classify this as a typo (even a 'mental typo'). We used to have a 'lacks minimal understanding' close reason (before my time) which would fit here perfectly.

Comment: @HermannDöppes Yeah the closure was unfortunate.  I understand why they did it and I do not think it hurts the site to do so.  It really boils down to do we want to keep not useful questions?

Comment: @Glorfindel Do you refer to the “What's a mouse?” answer? Because I don't think it really applies and all the other answers seemed to be unfitting as well.

Comment: @Glorfindel A “lacks minimal understanding” I might have bought. Doesn't feel perfect but close enough. (Alas, it was before my time so I can't properly judge how well it fits.)

Comment: @NathanOliver So, it comes down to “I did the right thing.“ and “It was closed with that reason because people wanted to close it and a proper reason was unavailable.” (I didn't complain about the deletion, btw. It is not useful to anyone and just clutters the site. No reason to keep it.)

Comment: I think the OP of that (Meta) question was in the same sort of doubt as you. I'm not saying that Too Broad is the right kind of close reason for this question. It's just not something that we want on a quality Q&A site like Stack Overflow. It must be deleted, and the end is more important than the means.

Comment: @HermannDöppes Basically. In order to delete a question it needs to be closed so even though the reason was not 100% correct it was a means to a end.

Comment: @Glorfindel So, you're saying I should have flagged it to as too broad (or any other least inappropriate flag)?

Comment: Everyone who picked "Looks OK" was wrong. At a minimum, the question required editing. This isn't controversial.

Comment: @HermannDöppes there's no harm in using Skip, although that would move your problem to later reviewers. The Stack Overflow system isn't built to handle outliers like this.

Comment: @Glorfindel Yep, I skip reasonably often (or so I hope) but this seemed like a clearer case to me than it apparently was.

Comment: @CodyGray Then the description of “Requires Editing” is deceptive. The question *is* clear and answerable. And the description of “Looks OK” is deceptive, too. The question *can* be found (if you search for this weirdly specific thing), understood ans answered as-is.

Comment: Yeah, the descriptions are deceptive. We've brought that up before. No one wants to fix it. Use the description on the buttons themselves. Does it require editing? But honestly, in this case, I even disagree that the question was sufficiently clear in its original form. I certainly don't know what it was trying to ask. I could *guess*, but that's all it would have been. Someone else might have had a different interpretation, and I couldn't legitimately tell them they were wrong. That's a clear case of "Requires Editing" to me.

Comment: @CodyGray I assume “We've brought that up before. No one wants to fix it.” means “SE doesn't want to fix it, but parts of the community do.”  If so, is there an official reasoning as to why this will not be fixed?

Comment: Yes. They aren't convinced it will make any difference. No one reads that text anyway. [This is literally what I was told when I brought it up in one particular case](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/332546/adopt-a-consistent-policy-on-what-requires-editing-means-in-the-review-queues). It has since been *partially* modified, by adding a link (which virtually ensures no one will read it all), while apparently leaving the rest of the confusing guidance intact.

Comment: @CodyGray I have read that text quite often, actually. (Whenever I'm unsure, often followed by skipping) But I overlooked the link, apparently. Before reviewing triage again I'll take the time to read it. Does it reflect the current community consensus?

Comment: I don't know, I haven't read it. :-) (More seriously, it is very difficult to determine what the community consensus is. Do you do it based upon Meta upvotes? There are some obvious problems with that, not the least of which is that people upvote things that accurately describe what they perceive as the status quo, but may not necessarily agree with policy-wise. But I guess that a Meta FAQ is about the closest you're going to get to consensus.)

Comment: Close votes shouldn't be used as super downvotes. If a question is low quality, not useful, by all means, downvote it, maybe even delete vote it, but closing it isn't necessary and often sends the wrong message.

Comment: @KevinB You cannot delete vote unless the question is closed.

Comment: Why was the question removed? Shouldn't it remain on hold for a few days? Or was the question removed by the author?

Comment: it was removed by 3 users with enough rep to do so. It can be delete voted before being closed, if it doesn't have a positively scored answer and is downvoted. ***Still doesn't justify closing a question as too broad when it clearly isn't.***

Comment: @giusti It was deleted by 3 20K+ users

Comment: @KevinB Then where is the delete link on [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41408676/how-to-return-a-map-type)?

Comment: I was wrong, so don't delete vote it. Still shouldn't vote to close something just because it isn't useful. that simply isn't a close reason. If the question truely was not useful, and doesn't have "useful" answers, it will be deleted anyway.

Comment: @KevinB True.  But the question remains, do we want to keep un-useful questions around.  If the answer is no then we need to close them in order to get them deleted unless SO decides to make a change.

Comment: No we dont, and all we have to do to uphold that is simply downvote it.

Comment: down voting is only enough if it never gets answered.  If it gets answered and that then it is not deleteable and down voting an answer just to get the question deleted is a big no no.

Comment: Is an answer to a not useful question useful? If it is, then the question should remain. If it isn't, it should be downvoted. you'll get your precious rep back later.

Comment: every time I ask myself in review "what should I have done?" I find the answer here: [There is no shame in using “Skip”](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252195/839601)

Comment: Relevant: [**If you need to bend a close reason to fit the question in order to justify closure, the closure isn't really justified.**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/338846/4639281) cc@KevinB

Comment: Apply common sense and ask yourself how mankind would possibly benefit from preserving this question. Is the question of the slightest bit of value to anyone, including the OP? If not, then _it doesn't matter how you moderate it_. Close it or delete it, then move on. Moderator policies be damned - common sense wins. (In before the meta crap-huggers start waving their dung-shoveling pitchforks at me.)

Comment: @Lundin *starts waving dung-shoveling pitchfork*, it isn't about hugging crap, it's about keeping sanity in the system. If we throw the rules out the window for one situation and promote abuse of the closure system, then <- insert slippery slope statement here ->

Comment: @Lundin it is also about not wasting our votes and effort on something that obviously is not worth it. It is a really easy to answer *on-topic* question. The reason there is so much push back against the question is because the answer is so brain-dead obvious that it truly is useless. But we don't close questions because they are not useful. That's what downvotes are for.

Comment: I have to say, if you even possibly think something Looks OK, you shouldn't skip it.  I take Skip to mean: I don't understand the problem domain enough to choose any of the other 3 options.  I don't think Skip means: I am too afraid to answer since my peers might disagree with me.

Answer (score -1):

> Did I [do the right thing]?

**Yes**. "Looks OK" was the correct action.

> Am I mistaken?

I agree that the question should **not** have been closed. However, closing the question for *any reason* is [a necessary step](//stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) to enable delete votes for non-mods.

Copying from [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/339464):

> For example, in Triage, clarify a few things:
>
> - It is *completely okay* to both downvote and review "Looks OK" on the same question.
> - "Requires Editing" should **only** be used if a decent edit could be made by **2K users**, not the OP.

<s>Finally, if you observed it being deleted, and you *strongly* believe that it shouldn't have been, custom flags are your friends for getting it undeleted and reopened!</s> Yeah, that question sucks. The previous advice still applies, just not for this question ;)

Comment: Re: "necessary step": [**If you need to bend a close reason to fit the question in order to justify closure, the closure isn't really justified**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/338846/4639281). Yes closure is a prerequisite for deletion, but that doesn't mean users should abuse the closure system to reach that end. If a question does not warrant closure, it does not warrant closure. End of story.

Comment: So I have a similar question, and I think the answer is the same, but I thought it would be a good idea to ask a dumb question about dumb questions. "questions that can be found?" -yes, "understood?" -yes, "answered as-is" -yes... Looks OK so far... But if the question seems to be coming from someone too stupid or lazy to do a simple google search, does it still Look OK?  Whether or not it is a good, hard or interesting question does not seem to be a criteria.  Here's a specific example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45514153/mpich-1-xx-version-needed-for-cluster-computing