# Why are closed posts often useful?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

I've found when I use Stack Overflow, some of the most useful posts I've found through Google searches are typically closed for a variety of reasons.

I did a quick survey of popular questions:

- [Is There A Good Natural Language Processing Library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/870460/is-there-a-good-natural-language-processing-library) - closed as not constructive - 20k views
- [Auto-update library for .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/691663/auto-update-library-for-net) - closed as off-topic - 30k+ views
- [What Is Object Serialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/447898/what-is-object-serialization) - closed as too broad - 54k+ views
- [Container Class / Library for C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/305611/container-class-library-for-c) - closed as off topic - 20k+ views
- [JSF implementations and component libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2167509/jsf-implementations-and-component-libraries) - closed as not constructive - 16k+ views

More:

- [Can Somebody Explain jquery Queue To Me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1058158/can-somebody-explain-jquery-queue-to-me) - closed as too broad - 50k+ views
- [When Do You Use The *this* Keyword](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23250/when-do-you-use-the-this-keyword) - closed as not constructive - 35k+ views
- [Auto-Detect Mobile Browser Via User Agent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1005153/auto-detect-mobile-browser-via-user-agent) - closed as too broad - 228k+ views

Please note: I don't post the above links so the community can nit-pick and rehash old decisions.  I just want to give a sample of the **type** of post I have questions about.

Comment: This particular post would've been a whole lot more useful if it had those examples...

Comment: Working on it!!

Comment: Looks like you're well on your way to becoming your own example.  Anyway, to address your question, because most of the voting is driven by those who have strong personal feeling about what they want the site to look like, **rather than** those engaged in trying to solve the types of real-life problems you are.

Comment: What % of closed questions are useful? By what measure do you define "often"? Finding (old) off topic questions often, only indicates you often search for things which are off topic on stackoverflow. Note also: What was considered on topic has changed over the years - becoming more strict.

Comment: Because they have appeal. See [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254933/answering-questions-which-ask-for-effort-guidance-not-spoon-fed-solutions/254941#comment21612_254941).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[What is object serialization?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/447898/what-is-object-serialization) is not really too broad, unless you choose to interpret it that way. The bigger problem with it is that it tends to attract **very low-quality answers** restating what has already been said (or just posting tangentially-related links). With these removed, the system has automatically *[protected](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/04/changes-and-guidelines-for-the-protected-question-status/)* the question, which should suffice - I've reopened it.

The rest of these fall into a category loosely referred to as [recommendation questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393/what-exactly-is-a-recommendation-question/254394#254394). They *can* be very useful... **They can also be magnets for spam and other low-quality answers**, and one often finds the information contained in them **woefully obsolete because *no one cares enough to edit the answers***. A few of these are lovingly [preserved with special locks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/118945/best-c-c-network-library), but for the most part they get closed and ignored because *no one wants to maintain them*.

Note that it is possible to *ask for a solution to a problem* without explicitly asking for a *tool recommendation* - this not only removes the primary defense of shameless tool spammers, it also encourages answers that explain *how to solve a problem* rather than just throwing in links.

We're currently experimenting with [a separate site for these questions](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/), complete with [very strict rules](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/455/how-to-ask-and-answer-software-recommendation-questions-aka-the-ground-rules) for how questions must be asked and answers written - it remains to be seen whether or not they're able to avoid the problems that arose on Stack Overflow.

Comment: I have often thought that a popular but off-topic question just means it's on the wrong stack exchange site.

Comment: The [.NET auto-update question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/691663/auto-update-library-for-net) seems like a good example. At first glance, it looks like a good question that could be made on-topic just by removing the word "library" from the title; but all the answers are basically just link lists, and the accepted answer -- which looks authoritative at first -- suffers from a *bad* case of link rot. (I've no idea why Microsoft apparently decided to pull their AppUpdater component off the web, but it seems they did.)

Comment: @fortmac: Some questions are good and interesting as questions but awful on a Q&A site.  Because Q&A-site questions are indexed by Google and whatnot, recommendation questions often just become lightning rods for scumbags hawking their crap.  And it's hard (it requires a deep investigation in many cases) to see whether an answer is this kind of spam, whether it's honest, or whether it's somewhere in between.  Ask that stuff on IRC or something instead.

Comment: @tmyklebu I love that you brought up IRC.  Thats usually my goto for legit dumb questions that can't be answered by search engines.

Answer (score 4):

Because StackOverflow has rules about what sorts of questions are or aren't within the scope of the site, and there are plenty of useful questions that are nonetheless not within the scope of the site. For instance, a question requesting information about how special relativity works, even if it were an entirely reasonable question, wouldn't be on-topic for SO because it's not about programming.

While those questions are about programming, they're off-topic for other reasons: being too broad, primarily opinion-based, or asking for a tool, library or favorite off-site resource. There are plenty of questions that are broad, primarily opinion-based, or asking for a favorite library that are great questions! Just not great questions for SO.

If you want to argue that a specific type of question currently against the rules *shouldn't* be, that would be a reasonable post for meta.SO (unless it's already been asked to death, which would likely be the case). But all of those linked questions are pretty clearly at least one of those things.

Comment: Yeah I'm not trying to advocate for a rule change or anything, I just wanted to understand more about the mechanics of SO that allow for super popular posts that are also off-topic.  The popularity != quality argument seems appropriate to me.

Comment: @fortmac One thing I wanna note that noone has said yet is that these questions are pretty old 2008/2009 and stackoverflow (having started in august 2008) hasn't had strict rules for what's on/off topic back then. It was later on that the rules were better defined (they were necessary with the growth of the site) and these questions were closed.

Comment: @RaphaelMiedl Thats interesting.  I tried to sort by the most popular questions on SO then ctrl+f 'closed'.  It's worth noting that old posts would both have the most views and be subject to different community standards.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for this is that Stack Overflow has developed some topics that are off-topic. The reason for this being that the community has seen a problem with that topic, whether that's attracting spam or just not about programming, or something else.

**Popularity does *not* equal quality or on-topicness.** And probably some of the most popular questions Stack Overflow has are closed. The reason for this is that sure, maybe that *one* question is useful... but when people see that question they say *Hey, why don't I ask a question like that?*. And then it ends up overrunning a site.

You see, it's hard to say that it's okay to ask about this topic if you're one question, and say to the rest that you can't ask that. So while those may be popular questions, the community feels that that shouldn't be on-topic here. So then they close all the other questions like that so we're not being hypocrites.

And as long as these questions retain some *useful* value, they won't be deleted. Which means that other people can still see the question, and see the answers.

Comment: Am I off the mark to say that your answer boils down to 'Its okay for the rules to be broken once and a while, but we still need the rules to guide us in the right direction' ?

Comment: @fortmac That's kind of what I was saying, yes. I think Joel was talking about this in some podcast... basically what I'm trying to say is these questions were asked before that rule was invented, and so if it wasn't crap it just got closed and left alone since it was useful.