# Do popular and helpful "off-topic" questions reflect an "issue?"

Tags: discussion

I have had this experience several times:

1. I google a problem I'm having.
2. One of the top google results happens to be a question posted on StackOverflow.
3. The StackOverflow question is wildly popular. Tens of thousands of views with dozens or tens of dozens of upvotes and several answers. Some of the answers also have dozens or tens of dozens of votes and much discussion and helpful commentary. Apparently, a question and answer set generally very helpful to lots of people.
4. Then I notice the question is "Closed as Off Topic" by five high rep users.

### Question

> **Does the fact that popular and helpful questions are "off topic" reflect an "issue" with what is considered "off topic?"**

Isn't the fact that the question and answer set appears to have been helpful and recognized as beneficial and valuable on its face, merit avoiding the "marking" of that question with any form of "social stigmata?"

Comment: For example? We can tell you about the specific question if you tell us which one it is. It's also possible the question was closed incorrectly.

Comment: Is it also an older question, from when the standards for on-topic were different?

Comment: This discussion has been had in the past, it was a terribly bloody battle. For better or worse, the general consensus that emerged back then was "no, it doesn't reflect an issue, popularity alone doesn't indicate on-topicness". New off-topic questions tend to not even get to that point anymore because they're closed down before gaining a lot of popularity.

Comment: @durron597: If it's okay, I would prefer to address this issue as a general matter. Surely, you can agree that my description does happen from time to time, correct? If lots of people want an example to "prove" it does happen, I could provide several. But for now, can we all agree it does happen and let's discuss the issue generally?

Comment: @Pekka웃: You wouldn't happen to be able to locate a link to that prior discussion would you? I would love to read it. *"...popularity alone doesn't indicate on-topicness?"* That seems odd to me that the focus should be whether it's *on topic* as opposed to how much it helps people who need help.

Comment: @Mowzer Every "off-topic" close reason is there because those categories of questions don't generate good content in a Q&A model. You have to draw the line somewhere, and "this may help someone" allows *far* too much through.

Comment: Here's a [list of the highest scoring non-deleted non-duplicate closed questions](http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=closed%3ayes%20duplicate%3ano). Basically those kinds questions don't work on Stack Overflow because there is no concrete answer and they generally attract opinionated answers and spam. If you could see all of the deleted answers to those questions you would be amazed.

Comment: Extremely related https://blog.stackexchange.com/2012/01/the-trouble-with-popularity/

Comment: Is there something like talk.SE.com? For the opinion based content, and everyone will be happy.

Comment: @Mowzer: We have guidelines about topicality for a reason, which is to keep the site very specific in its focus. We don't want off-topic questions asked, whether they'll be popular or not. There are other sites within SE for other topics. This one is about programming and programmers tools, within a narrowly defined set of guidelines, in order to keep that focus.  Also, guidelines evolve over time, and many older questions were on topic when asked (because other sites didn't yet exist, for instance), but are not appropriate now.

Comment: @klenium: [We already tried supporting those questions, we even gave them their own site. Sadly, it didn't work out.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/200144/288751) / [Please stop using Programmers.SE as your toilet bowl](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/73382/288751)

Comment: I think what you are asking is in order to keep the web social and stackoverflow.com social as well, is to let the users decide what is or isn't important and not the 0.001%ers who always manage to screw it up usually do to some form of short sightedness.

Comment: @klenium If you would like to have opinionated discussions, try a [chat room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/)

Comment: @RetroCoder: SO was never designed to be social, so I'm not sure that's really relevant. (That said, in practice, the users *do* decide what is or isn't important. They do so through a heavily-intermediated process involving upvoting users who then get enough rep to close-vote and other users posting meta discussions that bring wide community agreement.)

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/broken-windows/info

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256818/why-are-closed-posts-often-useful

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### This question cannot be addressed in a general way.

There are many types of highly voted, closed questions:

1. Blatantly off topic questions that are also locked, such as:

   - [What is the best comment in source code you have ever encountered?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/184618/what-is-the-best-comment-in-source-code-you-have-ever-encountered)
   - [Using a piano keyboard as a computer keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5928061/using-a-piano-keyboard-as-a-computer-keyboard)
2. Questions that used to be appropriate, but no longer are, as we've had to tighten up site standards.

   - These questions are very often tool requests:

     - [How can I profile C++ code running in Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/375913/what-can-i-use-to-profile-c-code-in-linux)
     - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1516720/git-gui-client-for-linux
   - Or very opinion based, such that everyone has something to say:

     - [Best practices for API versioning?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/389169/1768232)
     - [Table Naming Dilemma: Singular vs. Plural Names](https://stackoverflow.com/q/338156/1768232)
   - Or so broad, that everyone has an example:

     - [Creating a memory leak with Java](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6470651/1768232)
     - [What are the pros and cons of the SVN plugins for Eclipse, Subclipse and Subversive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61320/what-are-the-pros-and-cons-of-the-svn-plugins-for-eclipse-subclipse-and-subvers)
3. Questions that were inappropriately closed by high rep users. Here are some questions that are currently open but have been closed at least 3 times:

   - [What is the "-->" operator in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1642028/what-is-the-name-of-the-operator)
   - [How to pair socks from a pile efficiently?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14415881/pair-socks-from-a-pile-efficiently)
   - [Why is executing Java code in comments with certain Unicode characters allowed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30727515/why-is-executing-java-code-in-comments-with-certain-unicode-characters-allowed)
   - [Cycles in family tree software](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6163683/cycles-in-family-tree-software)
   - [Which is faster: while(1) or while(2)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24848359/which-is-faster-while1-or-while2)

So, to answer your question. We do the best we can. As a community, we will not always agree on scope. If the disagreements get too bad, moderators will lock posts to prevent close/reopen wars, but leave useful information around and available. The hope is that the [Wisdom of the Crowd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wisdom_of_the_crowd) will ultimately win out, with some sage input from moderators and staff in extreme cases.

Comment: [What is the best comment in source code you have ever encountered?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/184618/what-is-the-best-comment-in-source-code-you-have-ever-encountered) proves your answer as far as I'm concerned.

Answer (score 6):

I don't think this represents an issue.

Questions that are "clickbait" are by their nature going to be wildly popular (especially going off of views). A good example would be asking:

> Which is better: C#, Java, or PHP

Which would be closed as opinon-based instead of off-topic, but the question could also be:

> What is the best unit testing library for X?

Which is asking for a resource reccomendation (an off-topic reason).

Both of these questions do not fit well with a QA model, as there is no "right" answer (and more importantly, no "wrong" one). They will generate lots of heated debate, potential spam, nonconstructive comments and other undesirable content.

So even though these questions will generate lots of attention (and probably votes), they are actually *bad* questions for the site, and are correctly closed.

To your edit.

These questions should absolutley still be closed. (note that I said *closed*, not *deleted*). If policies are not enforced uniformly, similar questions will be seen as OK. This already happens ("but, a question from 2008 like mine was upvoted!") and would get far worse if new questions were allowed to stand just because people liked them.

Comment: It's clear: PHP

Comment: @klenium Lol, now we need a C# and Java comment so we can settle it once and for all through comment votes :)

Comment: Yeah. And that's why off-content should stay off-content.