# Should this specific upvoted question asking for guidance be closed?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10252679/how-to-program-a-virtual-machine

> Lately I've been doing a lot of work in virtual machines, and so I started looking into how they work. I understand the broad strokes, and I am a pretty experienced programmer, but I can't really think of how I would write a similar program (VM)
>
> So how would one go about starting such a process? For argument's sake, let's say that I wanted to just make some generic x86 machine that could run some distro of Linux. Where to begin, or what are the general concepts?

This question thus asks about directions. According to [Answering questions which ask for effort guidance, not spoon-fed solutions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254933/answering-questions-which-ask-for-effort-guidance-not-spoon-fed-solutions), I should flag to close. However I'm hesitant because both the question and the answers are quite upvoted, despite the accepted answer being of the "Your answer is in the following list of castles" type.

Should this question be closed?

Comment: Please note that you can post this kind of questions also in the [SO Close Vote reviewers chat room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers)

Comment: Thanks @rene, I didn't even think about it! I'll make sure to bring it over there next time (I think there's a special guideline in the rules for that kind of question).

Comment: That's not the first we see such situation where 'general concern' question really interests the community but doesn't match the current SO rules and even where upvotes continue after the question has been closed, showing that the subject is pertinent. Maybe something should be done to allow such question in a manner or an other..

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Yes, without doubt, it's far too open-ended and broad.

The fact that there are upvoted answers, or the question itself is upvoted, does not in any way mean the question should stay open.

As it is an old question, that probably explains why it stayed open.
In the beginning, SO guidelines for topicality, focus and generally everything were very loose to non-existent, and as the site grew and we gained experience corrections were made.

Comment: I see. I was afraid others saw something good in this question I didn't.

Comment: @Kyll Don't get mistaken into thinking that good means the same thing as site-appropriate. Questions get upvoted when viewers think the question is good. Questions get downvoted when viewers think the question is bad. Questions get closed when viewers think the question is not appropriate for SO. (That is, assuming nobody is mis-using the votes.) I agree with the closure, but I still upvoted it, because despite SO not being the right site for the question, I do think it's a good question.

Answer (score -4):

The rules are meant to facilitate the Q&A. If the Q&A is proceeding along very nicely despite breaking the rules, I don't see why it should be closed.

If the rules don't make sense to a given situation, then maybe the rules need to be changed or bent.