# Is it ok to downvote simple data structure type of questions?

Tags: discussion, downvotes

Is it okay to downvote a question just because a question is related to a simple data structure?

Questions like:

- What is `HashMap`? In what case might you want to use `HashMap` in an
  app?
- What is `ArrayList`? In what case might you want to use `ArrayList` in an
  app?
- What is `Map`? In what case might you want to use `Map` in an app?

All the questions like school level questions.

Comment: You're free to vote how you want. Also such questions should probably be closed as 'too broad' - good answers won't fill a whole book, but a whole chapter in a book, anyway.

Comment: It is also ok to downvote questions that abuse inline code formatting. In what programming language would you write `simple data structure` as an identifier?

Comment: I think it depends @Cody, if it's their first post then it's probably a bit harsh; I'd edit it out. If it's their 10th post then sure, why not. I'd normally go through all past questions and see what needs to be edited/closed.

Comment: Yeah, I don't believe in this silliness about downvotes being "harsh". They are our means of rating content. We don't have a "meh" vote.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> All the questions like school level questions.

I don't think you should vote to close questions based on how hard they are. One person's challenging problem is trivial to another person—remember you were not born with the knowledge of when to use `HashMap` over `ArrayList` in your code.

- For linked lists [people asked that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2429217/under-what-circumstances-are-linked-lists-useful) and it was very well received. While answers are not as you'd say—complete, they're very useful. The question and answers have over 100 upvotes.
- That said, [what is a hash map?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3886167/1348195) got closed as not constructive. However, [it has an open duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2592043/1348195) which has several upvotes.
- Are [generics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77632/what-is-cool-about-generics-why-use-them) harder than collections? That question and answers got 100 upvotes so they must have been useful and not at all subjective.

So, all in all, if the question is *asked well* I would not close it just for being basic, or covering a basic language construct.

Of course, all in all you're still free to vote however you feel like.

Comment: I agree with some of this, especially the beginning. But the fact that a question or its answers gets a lot of upvotes does not necessarily make it a good, on-topic question for Stack Overflow. Questions that are *interesting* to lots of people (like, "What is your favorite text editor?" and "Big ol' list o' hidden features in Emacs") tend to attract more than their fair share of upvotes, yet remain bad questions. We call those bikeshed questions. Anyone capable of rational thought has an opinion about what color to paint the shed. They don't necessarily have expert advice to offer.

Comment: @CodyGray you know what, you convinced me that arguing based on the number of upvotes was probably not the best move. Although I still think this answer stands without it.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum thanks for replay. but i saw some _High Reputation_ guys asking this type of silly question. and users suddenly _downvote_ the question.

Comment: @SimplePlan there is no one size fit all for deciding if a question is on-topic/off-topic , some "high reputation guys" are notorious for asking bad questions.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum ohh now i get it. thnx

Answer (score 3):

[When is it justifiable to downvote a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252677/when-is-it-justifiable-to-downvote-a-question?rq=1)

Any of those asked as is, or probably if you manage to ask it at all without answering it yourself (because it should be fairly easy to find / argue an answer oneself), I'd say classifies as "Doesn't show research effort" (so downvote worthy IMO).

You can probably say "Is not useful" (which is pretty subjective), but really the problem you appear to have is that it's a "school level question" - we were all on that level once - should we not create a database of programming questions that will be useful for programmers of all levels?

Side note - The "in what case" part is probably too broad.

Comment: i am agree with _"school level question" - we were all on that level once_ but i saw some _High Reputation_ guys asking this type of silly question.

Comment: You can have a high reputation and still be a noob. For example, say I'm a Java programmer and have earned all my rep that way. Now, I'm going to learn Ruby but I don't know a damn thing about it. I'm going to ask some pretty basic questions. Judging by my reputation would be misleading. The only thing that tells you is that I'm experienced at how Stack Overflow works, not that I'm an expert in all programming languages. That's another good reason why we need to allow questions that seem "too basic"—we are all novices at *something*. @simple

Comment: @CodyGray ya exactly. Thank you very much for your concentration.

Comment: @SimplePlan Cody makes a good point. Additionally, generally the amount of reputation someone has shouldn't matter - either it's a good question or it's not. But I am personally a bit more inclined to downvote a high rep user if they do something **wrong** (as in not conforming to site guidelines - not if they just ask a basic question though), because they should know better.