# Is a downvote justified when

Tags: discussion

I've debated with a developer over on Stack Overflow and reviewed the profile of user A. In terms of good nature & information to resolve problems/questions which arise on Stack Overflow, is it a justified downvote when:

The answer does provide the necessary information to resolve the OP's problem, but the code given in the answer is using the incorrect library as originally posted. That is, "Hey, you're using the MySQL library. Here's what it should look like 'insert MySQLI code"?

Is a downvote justified on that alone? As other answers provided by User A is of the same caliber, some of which are only a conversion between libraries and off topic to the question (still receiving +3/4 upvotes).

Comment: Link please. It's hard to understand what you're talking about from this description.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25026373/php-why-my-while-loop-echos-only-one-item-while-i-have-3-items-in-mysql/25027282#comment38922337_25027282 @EJP

Comment: possible duplicate of [When is it justifiable to downvote a question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252677/when-is-it-justifiable-to-downvote-a-question)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For the most part, people can vote how they like for whatever reason.<sup>1</sup> The guidance on a down-vote on an answer is

> This answer is not useful

It's really up to the voter to determine what "not useful" means.

That said, you should really vote on the contents of the answer. Voting on something a particular way based on who wrote it tends to go against the purpose here.

---

<sup>1</sup> Serial voting, or using sock-puppets/voting rings to commit voting fraud excepted.

Comment: Perhaps so, but it's a justified down vote when examples code is using unrelated libraries. Am I right?

Comment: If you feel that that makes the answer "not useful", then sure.

Comment: @DarylGill Why do you think there is some absolute authority on the justification of down votes? Stack exchange sites use crowdsourced evaluation: it is expected and desired that different users will bring slightly different standards and evaluations.