# Asking for money in profile

Tags: discussion

Is it not spam to ask for money in your profile like this: https://stackoverflow.com/users/4099593/bhargav-rao

Comment: Does not appear a duplicate.

Comment: @User666: _Does not appear a duplicate:_ Then please explain _why_ you think that it isn't a duplicate.

Comment: Cause its not paypal.

Comment: @User666: It that such a big difference? I think that the accepted answer on the linked question also fits your question very well.

Comment: Also see the answer here https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/281422/73226

Comment: Not really but the duplicate filter never picked anything up when I was writing it.

Comment: I must admit to being curious as to whether people ever actually tip in this way.

Comment: iirc @MartinSmith, Martijn Pieters had someone buy something from his wishlist

Comment: I've not added that to spam, nor was that my intent. Do inform me if you want me to remove it. I'll gladly remove it.

Comment: I was just wondering you know as you were a moderator and all, perhaps you should be getting some of the add revenue instead?

Comment: When talking about spam, please make sure that you use the term correctly: [Spam is an unsolicited commercial advertisement](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260641/2675154).

Comment: @User666 Elected moderators are volunteers, and not employees. (In any case, what does that have to do with tip links?)

Comment: You refereed me to a question on spam to give me a opinion on what is spam, epic thanks.

Comment: @User666 [Moderators do not earn a salary, we are just volunteers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/169205/do-moderators-earn-a-salary/169210#169210). We spend a lot of our time working behind the scenes and cleaning up Stack Overflow so that you all can enjoy. :)

Comment: @MartinSmith I got it [once](https://twitter.com/BhargavHS/status/708199014743744512), Martijn has got it many times. (Aside: Now that the wishlist has become famous, because of this meta post, I might get one more! Who knows :p)

Comment: And I suppose this question is totally unrelated to the fact that Bhargav Rao just deleted one of your (non) answers? http://stackoverflow.com/a/43572005/19679

Comment: No its the reason why I read his profile or did you think out the millions of pages on the web I just happened upon it by pure chance?

Answer (score 29):

As [has been stated before on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/190877/is-it-acceptable-to-solicit-money-on-a-user-profile), this is absolutely fine. It's not spam, nobody is trying to trick you, and nobody is forcing you to pay anything. You're just given the option, if you decide to do so, to reward someone you think provides excellent contributions.