# Veterans, have you ever received gratuity through SO?

Tags: discussion

This is something that has been on my mind for a while. I've seen a lot of users who have placed links to PayPal, Patreon and so on, on their profile page, for other users to "say thanks". [One such user has even placed their BTC address](https://stackoverflow.com/users/137317/u0b34a0f6ae) on their profile.

Do you actually receive money through these channels? If yes, and if you don't mind my asking, how often have you received it?

Comment: I haven't received any money (nor asked for any), but received three cool items off my Amazon wish list. Twice from fellow users with a relatively high reputation and one from someone anonymous. (I just remembered that I *think* I forgot to thank one of the two, btw, due to very stressful circumstances at the time... so if you are reading this: thank you! ♥♥♥)

Comment: A couple of cases are mentioned in the comments here https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/348325/73226

Comment: I've had an Amazon wish list linked in my profile for a couple of years, I received a small gift once. OTOH, veterans (like Martijn Pieters) have received many gifts. It's not that frequent, but it does occur in some rare cases.

Comment: I have an Amazon wishlist in my profile and people have sent me items from that list, yes. Many of them anonymous! It is always a surprise and it doesn't happen all that often.

Comment: You mean, apart from the death threats?  :)

Comment: I guess at this point I should also ask, when you'd consider it appropriate to place those links on your profile.

Comment: I don't think there are any strict or loose guidelines for posting these on your profile. Then again, if a low-impact user had something like this on their profile, I'd find it somewhat ridiculous. Then again _again_ it ultimately doesn't matter, I don't think you have anything to lose by posting a donation link on your profile. One should preferably be tasteful, as always. (Actively pointing others to said links, on the other hand, would be a huge no-no!)

Comment: There is a very broad tolerance for profile and avatar content here. As long as it is not offensive/adult themed, it is OK. People sometimes use them to say how terrible Stack Overflow/Exchange is, and that's fine too!

Comment: I added an email to my profile six months ago. So far, I just got three emails, one of which really made my day: it was a very kind user who thanked me for an answer and did it in a very pleasant way. I thought that was worth more than a lot of money :)

Comment: Oh, we moderators receive a lot of colorful mails that really make our day. (Especially when we ban someone or delete something). Need to create an album to share those.

Comment: I have an email in my profile page. The only thing I got so far was "Why don't you go suck a dick and get aids?". Huh.

Comment: @DanielKamilKozar Seriously what did you do to deserve that? :P

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ : I told somebody to make an MCVE for his question and he threw a mad fit saying that we're all so elitist and using acronyms nobody understands. That's about everything that I remember, though I'm sure there must've been more.

Comment: It never occurred to me to post my wishlists in my profile. I'm going to put mine in, in a minute. But then there are charities I'd like to push even more. But then they're mostly political so I could alienate people who were about to give me something. Now I'm going to get nothing :(

Comment: @DanielKamilKozar are you aware of the [magic-links](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/94000/209901) and that you can say `[mcve]` to get this beautiful text --> [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](/help/mcve)?

Comment: @fedorqui : I wasn't, and always had to look at the help page to actually get the link. Thanks!

Comment: @DanielKamilKozar now I deserve some gratuity :D

Comment: @fedorqui Damn... that's handy. I always believed that was possible. I just didn't know the syntax.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ indeed it is. Note it just works in [so] (not even here in Meta). That list of magic-links is pure gold, it contains many useful ones.

Comment: @fedorqui [No, I do.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92060/add-data-se-style-magic-links-to-comments/94000)

Comment: I once got a guy who emailed my work trying to get me fired. At least someone out there is thinking about me :/

Comment: @Will yours was a great suggestion, my fingers are glad you asked such feature to be implemented!

Comment: Also, magic links work all over SE, like `[meta]` always points to that site's meta and `[tour]` points to that site's tour.  For example, here, `[meta-tag:feature-request]` links to the [meta-tag:feature-request] tag.

Comment: @Will: I always enjoyed the election debacle of 2014. https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/14639276#14639276 https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/14639290#14639290 
https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/14639333#14639333

Comment: @BhargavRao 'Need to create an album to share those' - please do this:)

Comment: Hah, I'll get some when I'm free @thingy. Need to search through the mails (as I've put my personal mail on my profile where I get 6~7 other mails per day)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit hah! I wish the guy who emailed my office was that nice.

Comment: @Will: Do tell :D

Answer (score 33, accepted):

*(Not sure whether I count as a "veteran", but this is my story.)*

I actually received GB£50 once, through the Paypal "donate" button on my profile, but it was from a chatroom user with whom I was acquainted and who was apparently engaging in a random act of kindness (one that I've never really understood).

I immediately refunded it because I felt guilty — my "donate" button is really just meant to be a joke, a bit of fun at the expense of those who put one on their profiles and expect to become rich from it (and the tongue-in-cheek result of me, like you, [asking whether it's appropriate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/220177/155739)). Maybe a little ironic.

It has not happened any other time. I actually removed the button at some point (probably around six months ago); the thing was up for maybe a couple of years.

Comment: You still have the donate button on the page linked from your profile though :-)

Comment: @Dijkgraaf: True.

Comment: Pretty certain six-plus-some years is veteran. In Logan's Run, we'd already be hunting you. But, then again, in Logan's Run, I'd already be dead. A *long* time ago :-)

Comment: BTW , Is that profile pic real?  :P

Comment: Is it "real"? Yes, it is *really* Emilia Clarke. Is she a C++ programmer? I'm not sure, but I doubt it. @cjmling

Comment: It's not irony if there's no context to distinguish it from the "normal" act.

Comment: @GertG: What do you mean?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I'm a member of Facebook, but it's really just a tongue-in-cheek comment on all those others who hope to give their puny lives meaning through social networks. :-)

Comment: @CodyGray: Ouch. I've seen so many hours of her on television, and all it takes for me to not recognize her is a different make up. Ugh.

Comment: *'Not sure whether I count as a "veteran"'* <-- wait, what? Who's a veteran if not you?!

Comment: @paxdiablo: So would I :(

Comment: 'random act of kindness' - nah. Weed, or possibly tequila, are more likely explanations.

Comment: @ThingyWotsit: If I properly recall their identity, Doom Bar is the most likely culprit.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit that is also possible:)  Also, you should have spent the 50 on beer while you considered whether to return it or not.

Answer (score 22):

I've gotten *most* of my swag (Jackets, stickers, coffee cups, games for the kids etc) from Stack Overflow itself <sup>(a)</sup> by virtue of getting my ugly mug on the front page of users, I guess.

I think one guy found me through SO and asked if I could review their `awk`-based stats package on my blog, donating a small token in exchange (*not* buying a favourable review, I made that clear up-front).

Not sure how much value for money he received as I shut my blog down about a year later (technically, it's in transition from the old host to a new one but we all know what that *really* means).

However, I may put a link in my SO profile in case anyone suffers some form of brain damage and decides to pay for what I'm offering gratis. I don't really need payment, since SO is just an opportunity for me to foist my knowledge/opinions onto a large group of people, without having to go on the lecture circuit.

Even with that link, however, it's safe to say my dream of living off my web presence and sunning myself on the beaches of Perth would remain a dream for now.

---

<sup>(a)</sup> My wife, of course, is miffed because she thinks *she* should be getting some of the swag, given it's she who must put up with my addiction :-)

Comment: Games for the kids? What kind of games has SO offered as swag? I haven't heard anything about these.

Comment: It was a hockey sack (spelling?) thing. Just a small 10" x 6" board with a hole in it that you elevate to 20 degrees or so then try to throw a little rice-filled square ball through. More of a desk toy really and I cannot for the life of me remember what it was for. Probably extreme control in the face of unrelenting "do my homework for me" questions :-) And now you've got me doubting my own memory, I may have to trawl through the emails tonight to verify.

Comment: Ah, [Hacky sack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hacky_sack). Although they're not usually provided with boards; you typically just kick them around with your feet. The board makes it sound more like a miniature [cornhole](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cornhole) game, with a [bean bag](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bean_bag) as the playing piece. Interesting, though! I've never seen one of these with the SO branding.

Comment: Wife compatible swag…that would be a suggestion to Stackoverflow.

Comment: @CodyGray: yes, it was a desk-toy cornhole toss.

Comment: Perth? _Perth?_ Pff, Eastern Australia ftw.

Comment: When do SO send T-shirts, coffee cups, stickers etc. ? Is there any criteria for that? I never received any :P

Comment: Hasn't happened for quite a while, it may have just been something they did for a while while they were ramping up.

Answer (score 12):

I did once get a friendly and personal 'thank you' email from somebody. It was a bit awkward since my email is not on my profile page (for a reason), and the person probably had to use combination of google and guessing to get the mail delivered to me. But it was a nice gesture. :)

I never actually considered adding a paypal link to my profile, and I doubt if it would give me a long-term motivation give more, or more elaborate, answers, unless it would be so much that it could be considered a job. :p

Answer (score 9):

Sometimes the perks can also come *out of the blues* without an explicit link on your profile. I once got this mail from an agency that was doing some market survey at the time. I guess they got my email through the github profile linked to my SO profile.

[image]

It was a bit surprising to me at the time as the said agency was based in a different continent. It was nonetheless exciting. I took the 30-minutes-or-so survey via Skype and got the gift card a few weeks later.

Comment: I enjoyed the "blues"/blue pun :)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Great observation. SO should create a "clairvoyant" badge just for you :)

Answer (score 8):

I've had a couple of very nice emails, and it really is lovely to receive those, though I end up not replying for ages and then feeling guilty. I've also had about an equal number of emails asking me further questions rather than posting another question on SO or the relevant SE site, and I just deleted those.

I'm tempted to put wishlists in my profile now out of curiosity, though if I'm going to do that, I'm going to put some of my favourite charities there too. If nothing else, there's no shipping charges with donating to them.

Like Moses Koledoye I've also been asked to take part in a survey with vouchers as a reward, though SO isn't the only way that such researchers have found me. TBH, I decide whether or not I feel like helping much as I do with surveys that don't have rewards. The one that found me through SO seemed to be purely commercial market research without any benefit to the community so I didn't bother.

Answer (score -14):

I have never had people just want to give me money. I have had many offers to do consulting. I get people who call me up because of my answers on StackExchange at least once every week or so. [I assume it happens pretty often when you're ranking high.](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/78/year/dba/2017-01-01/2639#2639)

My normal rate is $150/hr. Most of the people that call me up are consultants or programmers looking for a quick fix. I quite typically discount my rate to $100/hr, and after an hour or two of work they're good. It is what it is. A lot of people have proprietary data and don't want the problem or their name attached to a question that links them to a client.

I go hard on DBA.SE though. I'm after 20k and a gold PostgreSQL badge. And that's not easy because the community and culture there isn't exactly healthy.