# How about paying content makers?

Tags: discussion

I don't have a good model for this as yet.. I'll be thinking about it.  But I'd like to hear the community's thoughts on it.

Content creators/curators on SO (and SE in general) are the driving force in these communities.  So, what's the value proposition?  Why should I, or anyone, continue answering questions?

The value for people with questions is clear:  an answer to their question.

The value to SO is clear:  ad revenue.  Teams revenue.

What's the value to the answerers?  We've spent anywhere from months to decades accumulating knowledge.  Why should we dispense it willy-nilly, without compensation?  It takes time (money) to author a well-thought-out response.  The community is established.  The revenue streams are present.  It's time to start compensating the talent.

This is a starting point for a discussion.  Not a proposal.  Per Alexei's comments:

> @SamAxe the question in current state is very confusing: are you interested why
> people contribute to SO now? do you have sensible proposal for paid
> content (including curation concerns)? are you simply want money right
> now?

So, yes, I am interested in why people contribute now?  Altruism is certainly worthy.  But is there more?  Clearly StackExchange (the company) feels that its platform creators deserve more than altruism.

And no, I do not currently have a sensible proposal for paid content.  How could I develop such a proposal without a stakeholder discussion first?  I'm not even sure such a proposal is worth developing.  12 down votes and 0 up votes right now.  It appears the Meta community is not even interested in the discussion.

And again, no.  A money grab is not my intent.  I do not currently need any financial assistance.  I'm feeling under-appreciated by a company I give a considerable amount of time to.  My content is clearly valued, but I feel like me, the individual, is not valued at all.  I've put umpteen hours into helping build this community.. as we all have!.. and has SO sent me a T-shirt?  Or you?  Have they taken the time to register as a 501.c (or the equivalent in other major contributor regions) and figured out how to offer us a tax break for the cost incurred in helping build the community?  Or a personal email - "Hey, thanks so much for the effort you've put in...".  No.  You mention it and it gets all very Atlas Shrugged.  Shut up and do your part.  Or quit.

Another equally large part of the purpose of the conversation is to talk about how a paid-content mechanism could improve the content.  Again, I have no plan. This isn't my community to dictate to.  But I know that a person that feels appreciated is likely to go the extra mile so to speak.  To produce content that is superior.  Just looking for the discussion.

Comment: *Why should I, or anyone, continue answering questions?* --> you are not obliged to do so

Comment: Aren't there other networks that do this?

Comment: It's not about obligation is it.  It's about acknowledging the worth of the people who are keeping SO in business.

Comment: Are you suggesting that the money should come strictly from Stack Exchange, or are you suggesting that other users should be able to (or required to) pay for answers?

Comment: This model is not new.  1.  Offer something for free on the Internet.  2.  Figure out how to make it as addictive as possible.  3.  Advertise to the audience so created.  4.  Profit!

Comment: @CodyGray: I'm not suggesting anything right now other than content creators should be compensated.  The source of that compensation is up for discussion.

Comment: How about just trying to avoid alienating the content creators and curators?  Wouldn't that be a good start?

Comment: @TemaniAfif: perhaps for some.  How exactly do any of those things put food on the table?  Put another way, why would I continue to spend time answering questions when I have a good job and the opinion of others (reputation points, whatever that is) means absolutely nothing.  It's not a digital currency that can be traded.  Again, I reiterate, What is the value proposition for people to answer questions?

Comment: The value proposition is this: 1.  I get better at software development every time I wrestle with someone's question.  2.  I get the satisfaction of helping a fellow human being.  3.  I get to utilize the resource so created to assist me in my own programming efforts.  Oh, and did I mention this resource is free to everyone who wants it?

Comment: Right.  Then SO shouldn't mind shutting off it's revenue streams.  If altruism is the end-all be-all then SO should stop making a profit, eh?  No, altruism is fantastic - but anytime someone is treated as the commodity without compensating them... well, that doesn't usually turn out well and is generally frowned upon.

Comment: The revenue streams are what pay for the programmers, the equipment and the electricity that keeps the site running.

Comment: Exactly.  Someone does a job and gets compensated for it.  Not unreasonable.  Why does the job of platform creator deserve monetary compensation, but the job of content creation/curation doesn't?  True, without the platform there would be no content.  But without content the platform is useless.

Comment: `But without content the platform is useless` -- A meaningless hypothetical, since there are still apparently plenty of people willing to contribute content who consider the altruistic motivations sufficient.

Comment: Fair point.  Since I appear to be the only voice expressing this view it is entirely possible I've missed the mark.  Anyhow, for me personally, the value proposition of SO is waning.  I don't expect SO to change just for me.  But I do wonder about the one-sidedness of this discussion.  Have all the people that feel exploited in some manner by SO already left?  Mabey I'm just slow on the uptake.

Comment: If the value proposition is waning for you, just stop contributing. There are more like us waiting on the wings to replace us at the first chance.

Comment: Yes, thank you yivi.  That is one choice.  Just trying to have a discussion.  Communities aren't built on "if you dont like it, quit".  They are built on expressions and discussions and change where appropriate.

Comment: @SamAxe I think you need "I'll be thinking about it." first - the question in current state is very confusing: are you interested why people contribute to SO now? do you have sensible proposal for paid content (including curation concerns)? are you simply want money right now?

Comment: Related: [Offering actual money as a bounty?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25615/offering-actual-money-as-a-bounty)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: thank you.  I've tried to address your questions in an edit.

Comment: _Why does the job of platform creator deserve monetary compensation, but the job of content creation/curation doesn't?_ This is the exact same reason people are constantly coming up with when we speak about Open Source, you realise? Some needs money out of it because they are doing this for a living, and that the infrastructure, the maintenance and so on is not something you grow for free on a tree.

Comment: @yivi Are they really waiting in the wings? There's room for plenty of answerers here. Please let them know that they do not have to wait. :-)

Comment: I think this question is closed for the wrong reason. I think it's much more probable a duplicate. Surely that idea already occurred to someone else before. Nevertheless can't find one with a quick search.

Comment: see also: [What makes you improve this board so much?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/305524/839601) and [Why do you stay?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/386639/839601)

Comment: Hey @SamAxe I also had the same concern. I was trying to form a business model. Why don't we take money from question-askers and give it to the answerers?

Answer (score -22):

Obviously there's been some discussion on this topic in the past - and nothing's come of it.  I understand that paid bounties are a minefield - as are paid answers.  So how about looking at it as less of payment/compensation, and make it about an expression of appreciation?

How about a button/icon next to the voting buttons that lets people buy you a coffee?  Did you find this answer useful?  Click the button to donate $1 to the author.

Comment: No, for the same reasons we don’t want the other forms of monetary compensation. It radically screws incentives which will have serious consequences for the platform. No money involved in any way, please.

Comment: Pizza tokens?  If it's PHP, I want a 12" deep-pan with filled crust.

Comment: What incentives?

Comment: Expression of appreciation in monetary form usually only delivers negligible amounts of money. Sometimes not even worth the effort to set up a payment system. The effective hourly income from this would surely be << $1. It's not enough of an incentive really then and you can as well scrape the whole idea completely.