# I lost 2 points of reputation because of someone's opinion that doesn't even answer my question?

Tags: support

This community seems great.  There are, however, ignoramuses here too.  Here's the link to my latest question:

[logcat reports no such table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27668801/no-such-table-promises-when-calling-activity-tries-to-access-sqlite-database)

I've seen questions where people show you how to look at your sqlite db, and I will look those up (started new job...  time is valuable!) - in the meantime, this guy just wants to be obtuse and vote people down.  Besides - my question IS valid, even not knowing how to look at the db just yet.  I had created it in Excel, copied it to Access, then used a conversion program.

Ya'll please help!  I'm not asking you kick this guy off (or do what you think), but this is ridiculous!

Happy New Year!

Joy

Comment: Well, you really should be looking into the guidance on [how-to-ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) specially on [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Those down and close votes are well spend I would say...and expect some more coming now that you pointed out your question here on meta...

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/269350/839601

Comment: see also: [When is it justifiable to downvote a question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252677/when-is-it-justifiable-to-downvote-a-question)

Comment: If your question is not about *kick this guy off* what do you expect from us? Voting is anonymous so we don't know who voted and the exact reasons for their vote.

Comment: Everybody is allowed to be ignorant here.  We even let users that don't have the slightest idea how to do their job create posts.

Comment: You can surely have a downvote from me too, ( as @rene suggested would happen).  You have, aparrently, had a failed data migration which you expected help with. Dumping a wall of code with no files, tables, metadata, environment is next-to-no use.  Worse, you either could not be bothered to debug, (indolent), did not know how to debug, (incompetent), or did some debugging but did not tell us what you found, (discourteous and disrepectful).  Which is it?

Answer (score -10):

You lost points because you posted a bad question.

Comment: Good question though I see I had left out the code to create the database when I last worked on it.  If one doesn't ask questions, one doesn't learn no matter how other "advanced" people think of their question!  Thanks for your input.

Comment: This answer isn't actually any help. *Why* is it a bad question? How can the OP improve it?

Comment: The OP left almost everything out except the code-wall dump.  We have no DB config, no metadata, no environment, no debugger, no logs.  The OP has all that and has either done no debugging or, worse, has found out stuff but not bothered to tell us.  Result: downvotes.