# Why what I asked was downvoted

Tags: discussion, specific-question, downvotes

I asked a question a few days ago. It was a legitimate question. But people downvoted it with no reason (that i could understand) whatsoever. I needed to understand the reason at least so that I could correct the mistake that I may have made. After 6 days of hue and cry, and after posting this question, got a few tips from the members here, but I think the concern I had remains unaddressed to a large extent. I need to elaborate I guess.

I did my homework before posting here. I took 15-20 mins in drafting my question, and double-checking all the formatting and language. I wouldn't have made it so big a deal that my question got downvoted had I had enough reputation points(I had 11 at the time I posted my question).

Ever since I've been using this site, at times I come across a few questions for which correct answer has fewer upvotes or no upvotes at all, or sometimes wrong answer or incomplete answer that may use some assistance. I wanted to comment/upvote on those questions but couldn't due to SO policies of repo points. And then I posted my question and got down-voted all the more (lost most points)

So the point is: yes, I do get the logic of down votes in the larger scheme of things. But by down-voting people who are fairly new to SO and do have meaningful and right intentions, are we being fair? It's like beating a child for a reason that she doesn't understand. No matter how much you beat, you can't make her change her behavior. I was suggested [this thread](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252677/when-is-it-justifiable-to-downvote-a-question). You can check my question and I don't fit in any of the criteria that @Denis (with most upvotes) suggests. I know rules, i did googling before posting question, i drafted it properly, I was not lazy, and moreover the problem was such that other people may face in future.

**Possible Change:**
I think it's ok if question gets downvoted (posted by newbie or otherwise) if it's bad, as long as someone gives a rationale (that too if newbie asks). One line reason doesn't take too much of your time and gives the member a chance to correct the correctable mistake. Moreover, if someone in a one liner explains why they downvoted, and the person who asked the question corrects it, the other viewers can notice the correction and negate the effect of downvote by upvoting the question (which they may or may not do otherwise). It will only help in larger context by removing the effect of a mistake that no longer exists.

When my question was downvoted, I was puzzled, asked why, but no one responded. **If you're so concerned for the future SO user that you contribute towards filtering the good content from the bad/useless one, you can be caring enough for the current user as well.** It should be as much about supporting the community and your well intentioned new colleagues as it should be about creating great content for future colleagues and enthusiasts.

[This is the question that I had posted.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28148719/how-to-show-hidden-part-of-an-image-which-is-inside-a-fixed-height-div-using-ju)

Shouldn't community members help each other out?

In all fairness, I do appreciate a platform like SO meta on which I at least can talk about the issue and get more experienced colleagues opinion.

Comment: Though your this question is offtopic, but that question is probably downvoted because those user didn't understand your problem clearly. You should avoid question like "why I got downvoted" even support cannot answer why someone behave like they do. I often get downvoted for no reason, if a sincere person downvote you, he will ask his clarification for sure. don't worry and move on.

Comment: I think your question is downvoted because of this: "I seek your advice in finding a better way to do this using css transitions." That's not a good question. Please ask specifict questions if you have a problem. SO ist not a code review site.

Comment: @Lutz Horn i didn't want anyone to review my code. I gave my code to show an inefficient way of achieving something. I needed to find a better and more efficient way. that's where i needed advice.

Comment: @Sumit Gupta point taken.

Comment: @Rahul That notice of the title change by 200_success. He made the title more than a code review, which is off-topic. Now it is an attractive title.

Comment: `putting someone down` means something very bad

Answer (score 6):

I'd not have downvoted your question, maybe I would have voted for closing it, because it is "too broad". Regarding the downvotes, I think this quote is not what makes people like a question.

> I seek your advice in **finding a better way** to do this using css transitions.

(emphasis mine)

That is a very broad question. You should ask a specific question.