# Why is this question downvoted?

Tags: discussion

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28885559/progress-view-updated-from-nstimer

It is not my question, but I don't see any major issue  with it.
It looks to me that the down vote is simply because the OP doesn't know how to do it, which is why he is asking in the first place.

Or is it because the problem would be considered by the programming community as one that is really easy to solve so if the OP asks, he is lazy?

Comment: Long answer: People can downvote for whatever reason they want.  Since my mind reading helmet is broken, I don't know.  Short answer: I don't know.

Comment: Same reason this question is downvoted:  who the hell knows.  That said, a single question getting a single downvote, I don't really think that warrants a question on Meta about it

Comment: But now I can take advantage of recursion, because this one of mine is also down voted by 3 already and still counting.
There is a lot of questions (like that one I linked to) serially downvoted and I want to know if I am missing something or  not.

Comment: @EarlGrey your question here is downvoted because people think coming to meta for ONE downvote is pointless. And you can't get trends from voting on meta, since voting on meta is different.

Comment: @EarlGrey A single downvote on a question is not "serial downvoting".

Comment: By "serially" I meant that a lot of questions with comparable quality of the referenced one immediately get a -1 and it's difficult to see why.

Comment: That question... is pretty close to downvote worthy, if not downvote worthy. Its in the "How do I do this feature" category, which isn't really a good question most of the time.

Comment: @EarlGrey you are using a different definition than is commonly understood and that may lead to confusion.  Serial downvoting, as it is understood on meta, means "one person down voting several posts of one other person (in a short time frame)".  Trying to redefine that is not going to help you communicate your question. I should also point out that bringing up any post on meta will amplify any voting patterns on with a critical eye.

Comment: Sorry about that. I will use the term properly from now on.

Comment: Stop downvoting this question and acting like snobs. Dude asks (in original way) if there are some 'hidden' rules here that more or less guarantees you downvoting. The answer is no - the question must have at least some educational value and quality, around some interesting or significant issue. If you write something like 'my code doesn't compile' this will look stupid and 'disrespectful' for the dear SO community ;)

Comment: @GiorgiZautashvili and if we're not being snobs but downvoting because this has been asked TIME AND TIME AGAIN, with the SAME answer everytime? I'm still allowed to downvote for someone who doesn't research properly for dupes, am I?

Comment: Rest assured that I read reasons for down vote many times. I am not a perfect being though and the lack of research simply did not click in my head. I simply assume in goodwill subconsciously that there is always research. That's why it did not click...

Comment: @Patrice We are millions and at least thousands of us will have the same questions. Sometimes it happens so that a couple of guys (from thousands) do not do enough research for some reason and just post it on their favorite community website. Let's give dudes a calm answer and also kindly let know that the same question has been already asked. This would avoid some nerves and also stupid discussions like this one. Cheers!

Comment: @Patrice I typed in the title, and then I checked EVERY suggested similar question's content. After reading it, I saw that there is no identical question content wise and I continued with the body. So much for your "many times."

Comment: @GiorgiZautashvili I think that you just infer tone to what I was saying. My emphasis was in NO way because I was mad, I was just putting emphasis for the sake of emphasis. When it's the X time I see the same question, with the same answer to be given, yes, I think downvoting is warranted. Seeing the result here, I think community is pretty much on that side... no?

Comment: possible duplicate of [When is it justifiable to downvote a question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252677/when-is-it-justifiable-to-downvote-a-question)

Comment: @GiorgiZautashvili That's not what SO is about.  SO is a place to ask quality, clear, well reserached questions.  Not a place where any question, regardless of how terrible, is acceptable.  If you want to participate in a community that doesn't clean up its trash, and instead allows everything, there are lots of them out there, but SO isn't one of them.  SO is a place where low quality questions aren't welcome, but where high quality questions get quick, quality answers.

Comment: @Servy I see, and agree of course. But this particular question wasn't so terrible and didn't need discussion among ten members. One could just comment that it's an inappropriate and duplicate question (if he/she didn't want to answer it directly) and the author might delete it completely.

Comment: @Patrice, by calm I didn't mean the opposite of mad, but something like what gnat posted above

Comment: @GiorgiZautashvili You're quite right that this question doesn't merit the attention that it's gotten.  It's just not that interesting (one way or the other).  That's one of the main reasons for the downvotes on this meta question.  People just don't think it's an interesting enough question to discuss.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> ### Title which vaguely names a particular task.
>
> Sentence about my whole program.
>
> ```
> [Code whichHasSomethingToDoWithTheTaskNamedInTheTitle:NO];  
> NSLog(@"Hi, Mom!");
> ```
>
> Sentence describing the next bit of irrelevant code:
>
> ```
> - (void)ofPertinence  
> {
>     NSLog(@"How about them Dodgers, eh?");
> }
> ```
>
> Actual -- though still not particularly precise -- description of the task I need to perform. Grammatical question to make it clear that I'm asking how to do that task. Unnecessary proffering of gratitude.<sup>1</sup>

This isn't a particularly good question. It does not explain [what the asker already understands](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/179114/), and it certainly [wasn't researched at all beforehand](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=nstimer+uiprogressview). With some editing, I suppose it could become a good search target -- the answer is solid enough -- but it doesn't seem worth it when there's at least two other questions, easily found, with essentially the same information.

---

<sup>1</sup> [Why is it considered rude to say 'thanks in advance'?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98149/why-is-it-considered-rude-to-say-thanks-in-advance)

Comment: Inspirational: [Question title that doesn't describe the problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/41976)

Answer (score 10):

It's downvoted because the person that downvoted it felt:

> This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful

Comment: Thank you, I am curious, is it your assumption (I agree there is no hint of effort or research) or you actually know that for a fact?

Comment: @EarlGrey unless he's the downvoter, HOW would he know? he's just copying the text in the downvoting arrow's tooltip...

Comment: My though was, maybe moderators have access to internal data. I am using SO for 4 years and I didn't know about the tooltip. The UX leaves a lot to be desired.

Comment: @EarlGrey Servy is not a moderator (no diamond by his name) so even if mods knew... he wouldn't

Comment: @EarlGrey When you place a downvote, you don't have to input why you downvoted, so mods wouldn't have any more information than you do.

Comment: @EarlGrey Moderators are given mind control powers now?  Damn!  I guess I'll have to run this year.