# Change to the down vote point system

Tags: feature-request, answers, downvotes

We all know down voting a question (Q) is free - and long may it stay so.

And we all also know down voting an answer (A) costs the answerer 2 rep and the down voter 1 rep.

If the latter was changed to say `{answerer:2; downvoter:3}` this would certainly reduce down voting answers.

Comment: What does this change benefit?  Why would the person downvoting be penalized more than the person who answered? We want people to use their downvotes on low quality, poor answers - this would dissuade people from doing that.

Comment: Why not????????

Comment: You aren't providing any reasons, why this is a good idea to implement.  _Why not?_ isn't really a reason. It's typically helpful to include reasons why we should implement a change, especially a big change to how reputation works.

Comment: *"why not????????"* is not an argument.

Comment: If anything we should be encouraging **more** downvoting on wrong answers.

Comment: @ChrisF [Yes, indeed!](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252740/1842065)

Comment: Take your downvote.  Take it, and like it.

Comment: @Patrice No you don't - when English football changed the win/draw/lose scale from 2:1:0 to 3:1:0, was I consulted? No. Ask them why they did it - 'to improve aggressive football'. Downvoting is too easy and most answerers feel very angry when down voted - the DVer gets away lightly. This way the ASWer may feel grieved, but will draw some solace in the fact that the DVer will be feeling worse.

Comment: _"...was I consulted?"_ Were you a part of the group making the rules for English football? No? Then why would they need to consult you? Here, we are _all_ part of the rule changing process. To get something changed, you need to _convince other members of the community_ with facts and arguments for why your proposal is a good idea. At the same time, you need to convince _the SE team_ that it's worth the development time.

Comment: you *can* get your rep back a) leave a helpful comment, then remove the DV when they edit/fix the problem b) if/when others DV it badly and they delete the answer c) ask good questions d) answer good questions e) for bonus points, answer bountied questions

Comment: I bet the guy who first proposed the change to football had a better presentation to the others he had to convince than *"why not????????"*

Comment: yeah... you guys aaren't all biased because if this became the law and it was backtracked you'd all lose a LOT of rep...

Comment: @JonMarkPerry Actually, I peronally wouldn't care. All the answers I've downvoted that are still live, which are very few, were 100% worth the downvote and I'd downvote them more if I had the chance. I personally _do not_ see how this would be helpful to the site or to increasing the quality of questions and answers, and you are making little to no effort to prove it would be a useful change.

Comment: Making personal attacks against your opponents rather than giving evidence to support your recommendations is not a good way to convince anyone that you're right.

Comment: lol, its actual quite hard to get downvotes on answers; those who do deserve it.

Comment: why should the system discourage downvoting LQ answers?

Comment: Furthermore, looking at your answers, those with downvotes look like they deserve them.

Comment: **A)** I disagree with your suggestion, which on face value would be detrimental to the site, and you've not provided a rational argument to the contrary; **B)** You seem combative even though folks are just giving feedback, and you provide no constructive arguments, nor seem to accept *anyone* else's logic; **C)** You have yet to even tell me why this is a good idea and why it will *improve* the system, a basic bottom level requirement for a feature request, especially as you suggest changing a *major* element of the site - voting (up and down) is a part of the *core* of how Stack works;

Comment: **D)** I believe you propose this change because you receive a lot of downvotes. It is terrible that (if) you would happily push rep loss to your *fellow users* to avoid your receiving it, and rather than simply playing your part in the community by improving your questions and answers. Take this question and answer of yours as an example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28977240/javascripts-interpreter - it is a poor question, and that and your answer helps no-one to be honest. Seems there is no time, thought, or much effort put into them at all.

Comment: to risk someone getting the wrong stick end, and to play the Avacado of the Devil, how about {3:1}, i.e. the answerer -3 DVer -1

Comment: @JonMarkPerry That was basically what I was stating in my answer (besides pointing out all the flaws in your question)

Comment: @JonMarkPerry I think you meant "play Devil's advocate".

Comment: wow, -55 ... it seems the community is thoroughly rejecting your proposal

Comment: @cad did you really bump a 2 year old proposal to the front page for minor grammar fixes?

Comment: @Magisch :O Oops, wasn't aware of that. Just surfed around and found this one to make it better looking. Sorry.

Comment: @cad D: Take care in the future please to only edit relevant and current things unless your edit makes them relevant and current again.

Comment: @Magisch Alright, I will. Anyway, in which "front page" exactly did it show up?

Comment: @cad On http://meta.stackoverflow.com/ default home page a question gets bumped to the top of it if its a) posted, b) answered, c) edited.

Answer (score 25):

In my opinion, downvotes on answers are **way more rare** than downvotes on questions, yet you suggest to increase the penalty on the downvoter of the answer rather than suggest a rework on question downvotes (which would have at least a little more success than this one.)

1. Currently, it costs 0 rep to downvote a question.
2. It also costs 1 rep to downvote an answer.
3. Downvoted material causes the poster to lose 2 rep per downvote.

Therefore, the way I see it, your suggestion should be to **increase** the penalty on the poster whenever an **answer** is downvoted because currently, answers are only downvoted for the following reasons:

1. Revenge Voting
2. Very wrong answers
3. Answers that do nothing to answer the question
4. Incomplete Answers
5. Spam / Offensive
6. Answers with only code/links without a speck of explanation.
7. Unreadable Text (Including, but not limited to: lack of punctuation, ALL CAPS, several spelling issues, severe formatting issues (especially with code), etc)
8. (On Meta **Only**) Disagreement with the answer

Otherwise, downvotes on answers are very few for any other reason. Therefore, if you have a ton of frequently downvoted answers, it is probably because your answers contribute almost nothing; the -1 rep penalty is enough to dissuade most people from just downvoting answers because they can.

Comment: Revenge votes by the way are rare.....

Comment: _"Revenge votes by the way are rare..... "_ Not that rare really. But fixed automatically from a system engine's script.

Comment: How about DVing is only allowed **if theDVer leaves a comment**, and the DV can in turn be revoked by peer pressure?

Comment: @JonMarkPerry: please search this site regarding DV only with comments. As noted, this has been debated to death, and likely will result in many worthless comments, such as `"down-voted answer for yucks"` and such.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ - I meant a random votes here and there that are not caught by the system's script

Comment: @JonMarkPerry Look, if you seriously cannot avoid/take downvotes on your answers, please do not post them rather than annoy us all with a suggestion that no sane person would accept.

Comment: i have never posted a deliberately wrong answer. in fact i was quite surprised they were dv'ed. can u take dv's - what's the secret?

Comment: [One of your answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27499217/span-css-is-not-working-properly/27499398#27499398) - That must've originall fell under the 7th item based on the comments. Also, you just gave a blob of txt without explaining it. I see nothing wrong with the downvotes on the post.

Comment: `"can u take dv's - what's the secret?"` -- provide a lot of answers that get UV'd. Then just ignore the DV's, or better, focus on improving your DV'd answers so that they get UV'd.

Comment: Also, @JonMarkPerry, **Deleting all your downvoted answers** ***could*** **get you an answer ban much faster and most certainly do not help you when it comes to answer bans.** I've noticd you deleted two of your downvoted answers today (don't ask how), so I thought I'd give you fair warning.

Comment: you get a badge for it - 'peer pressure' if its score is -3 or less, so that would be a tad hypocritical

Comment: I **strongly** recommend you read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/answer-bans) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). @JonMarkPerry The former links to the article on answer bans, the latter links to how to write a good answer; seriously, its not hard, just pay attention and don't answer unless you **know** it will solve the problem.

Comment: Lastly, everything I said in this post mainly applies to answers; there are a few more reason why questions are downvoted, but you do not  seem to have a problem with that....