# Should I downvote an answer only on its quality?

Tags: discussion, downvotes

Is it fair to vote down an answer in the below circumstance?

- User A has posted a problem but has **NOT** mentioned what he/she has done so
  far to solve it.
- He/She received some comments from other users to append what he/she has done so far.
- User B has posted the solution for entire problem without giving a chance to user A to append what he has done so far.

Suppose the answer is indeed the solution to the problem, is it fair to downvote it just to discourage the answerer(User B) givng a free solution to the problem?

I have gone through this [stack-overflow question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252677/when-is-it-justifiable-to-downvote-a-question?s=1%7C2.1445) regarding when is it justifiable to vote down a question but did not get what I am looking for.

Comment: All solutions are free here, no?

Comment: I agree but some work is expected to solve a problem before posting a question right?

Comment: No...you should up/downvote on the *quality* of the answer only. Simple really. If you have a problem with the *question* downvote *that*.

Comment: Yes, showing your research and attempts is expected, I just don't understand why using the word *free*, seems redundant...

Comment: Some people feel it is justified to downvote answers on questions that are just ridiculously lazy/could be solved by 10 seconds Googling/etc. Whether this specific question fits the description, I do not know.

Comment: @brasofilo : Please feel free to the edit the question then.  couldn't think of anything else. I meant `free` in that no background work is given the the asker.

Comment: While I believe it's a issue that people provide answers for questions that shows no effort / lacks certain basic things, it's really up to each individual user whether he/she/it wants to provide a answer, so no, you shouldn't down vote the answer unless it's faulty in someway, but you could do what I do, leave a comment on the answer explaining that you understand it's up to him / her to answer, but you think it's a bad idea  to provide answers to these kind of questions because of ... and so on.

Comment: When questions that show an extreme lack of research get answered, I usually comment on the answer, suggesting a close-vote instead of a answer, next time. When possible, I close-vote as dupe, too. That said, it's rather frustrating to see _high_ rep users feed on such basic questions that should just be closed.

Comment: @brasofilo : Changed the title. Hope it makes sense

Comment: I take it with point 2 you mean to downvote an answer that is posted before it is even clear what the question is about? If so: the vagueness makes me not vote at all - yet. It is still a possibility that the answer IS valid, its just not for certain yet. If I'd downvote and then later I discover the downvote is unjust, I wouldn't be able to correct it unless the answer is edited.

Comment: What is vague to you and me perhaps is not vague to someone else though. Some people can make a click a lot quicker with less information because they quicker latch on to what is important in a question and can ignore red herrings and fluff.

Comment: The attitude of punishing answerers for the OP's mistakes eludes me. Why not keep a positive attitude and think that **a great answer might educate the OP, and they'll be able to post a better question next time?!** Do you want to create a community of elitist rectal orifices, or are we here to help and spread knowledge?!

Answer (score 5):

You should *not* vote down answers based on the quality of the question. You don't vote down questions because the answers are of dubious quality, do you?

Answerers are likely to see that as unfair (and rightly so) since they're doing their best to help out the community and, honestly, without answerers, SO would collapse.

If you have a problem with the question, *that's* what you should be concentrating on. Quite often, even an ambiguous question can get good answers.

For example, if the question has some information lacking, I would frequently answer it in several ways at once:

> If your error states the the zorkmid is missing, you need to insert it between the xyzzy and plugh devices. However, that won't work if the error is instead to do with twisty passages. In that case, follow the left wall of the maze to get out.

Now that answer is full of strange words but what I'm getting at is, if there are only a few possibilities for which way the question can be interpreted, and answer can be exceptionally good even *without* the required information.

And frequently, people don't post what they've done so far because they're either sure it's irrelevant because it didn't work, or they genuinely don't know where to start.

I've answered many question of that latter sort in such a way that I *give* them the way to start (rather than just providing a solution).

Answer (score 2):

I generally down vote questions on

- Question with low quality
- Discourage questions with less information

And answers on

- Discourage answers which are spam/irrelevant
- Copy paste answers from some other posts without proper credits (Hard to find unless you have seen most of them)

To answer your question, is it only because of low quality -> Big YES, should be diligent in this and downvote ONLY based on quality.

Comment: +1 because this answers `how to downvote an answer based on quality?` but didn't answer `is the downvote based only on quality?`

Comment: Are you saying you downvote answers because the *questions* they answer are of low quality? Or are those first two bullet points reasons for downvoting the question only?

Comment: 'Cause, if it's the former, I'm not a big fan of this meta question, so would feel compelled to vote down your answer. Just joking :-)

Answer (score 2):

You should be voting on answers based on how *useful* they are.  There are lots of factors that impact how useful a given answer is.

If the answer is wrong, that's generally going to mean that it's not useful, but that's not the *only* thing that can make the answer not useful.

If the question is just a requirements dump, or a code dump followed by "plz fix", then an answer that just dumps some code (whether its working or not) is highly unlikely to be a useful answer.

If the answer is full of correct information, is well written, clear, etc., but fails to actually answer the question, then it's not a useful answer (in context) *even if it's a high quality answer*.

So at the end of the day your votes on an answer should be based purely on whether or not a given answer is useful, but the context of that answer *is relevant in determining if it's useful*.  Major problems with a question very often mean that it's impossible (or at least extremely difficult) to post useful answers to them.  **This is why we close questions** with major problems, because these problems with the questions *mean that the answers are very unlikely to be useful*, no matter how well they're written, or how technically correct the facts within it are.

So while you shouldn't just downvote an answer without reading it because a question has major problems, a question having major problems *is highly likely to result in its answers not being useful*, so seeing downvotes on answers to problematic questions should not surprise you, even if those answers don't have technically incorrect information.

Answer (score 0):

I down vote answers that I don't think are optimal. That could range from *this is a pretty inefficient way of going about that* all the way to *this is just downright foolish and dangerous*.

If I feel like an answer is headed in the right direction, I find it much more productive to leave a comment to the author indicating where else they could go with it, what else might be worth including, and where the answer could be better if more time was put into explaining something.

There are exceptions of course, if it's clear to me that the answer isn't a good faith attempt to answer the question, I might down vote. I'm not very fond of snark or rhetoric, even if it *does* technically answer the question.

The other thing to watch out for is [questions completely changing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions) after an answer was written. Watch out for that when you see several answers that positively make no sense in the context of the question.

Everyone does it differently. I try to encourage people to do more when I see that they've probably got the skill, but I've got a healthy dislike for shenanigans on the main site. If it's a good faith effort, it's probably not worth a down vote, but they're your votes and you should use them in the manner that feels right for you.

Comment: I have been using downvoting as a disincentive to speedy answers on unclear questions, but I think this might be a better solution http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/310663/a-proposed-test-solution-for-speedy-answers-to-certain-off-topic-questions