# How to lure professionals to Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion

Although haters may slander PHP forever, one cannot deny the fact that [most of the web](https://w3techs.com/technologies/overview/programming_language/all) is powered by this language,
including portals like Facebook, Wikipedia, [WordPress](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WordPress), [Vkontakte](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VK_%28social_networking%29)
and - much more important - a lot of lesser grade sites, written not with proprietary frameworks, like the above, but with Open Source libraries and tools.

- By 2016 PHP evolved into a mature [OOP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming) language, with many up-to date mainstream features borrowed from other languages.
- Several mature frameworks are on the scene, offering industry-standard solutions or the tasks like authorization, database access, [REST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_State_Transfer) services, etc.
- PHP exists in a strong and lively ecosystem, its [package manager](https://getcomposer.org/) offers thousands first-class libraries.

From all the above one could tell that there are a lot of PHP professionals around, who are using modern tools and practices. But...

*looking into PHP tag on Stack Overflow, one would say that it's an awfully outdated language, stuck in early 2000s, with every single task performed manually, by means of re-inventing the wheel in the form of an ugly, hasty, untested and unsafe on-site sketch.*

So I suppose it is because PHP professionals seldom have time to answer questions, leaving the field for the *enthusiasts*.

Yes, formally we have top-grade PHP contributors on Stack Overflow.
But they all took refuge in the chat room and you seldom can see them answering a question.

I cannot tell for the other tags but I suppose the situation is similar for all the widely-adopted languages and technologies.

So the question is: how to make Stack Overflow a desirable platform for sharing knowledge?
How to make it home not only for people interested in the virtual points and badges, but for people, whose interest is different - for those who have the knowledge and are willing to share it?

Comment: Well I don't know if this would help, but maybe we should allow more complex and slightly bigger questions, which we don't just close with too broad (Of course the question has to be good). So we should clearly signalize that we allow such questions and then professionals might have a bit of a challenge to answer such a question and it won't be one which can be answered within minutes or even a day with just "RTFM".

Comment: " one cannot deny the fact that most of the web is written in this language" Do you have a source for this?

Comment: Also, is your question solely about how to make the site better/more desirable for PHP devs?

Comment: I think the post is just using PHP here as an example @TylerH. The real question isn't if PHP is a language worthy of having professionals, but *how to make Stack Overflow a desirable platform for sharing knowledge* in general.

Comment: Yeah, we need to bring in the pros, Atm my reaction when I see a post tagged [tag:php] is [exactly this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uhHvv.jpg)!

Comment: @Tunaki No one has called into question here whether PHP is a language worthy of having professionals. I asked if the question was about making Stack Overflow better for PHP devs, specifically, or if it was just about making Stack Overflow better in general.

Comment: YCS, at this point, it's probably already too late. The general culture of the PHP tag (and many others) is to reward low quality questions with low quality answers.  There are just too many active users who value each other's low quality contributions, so they continue making them.  SO works when the majority of the voting base is make up of knowledgeable users that value quality contributions, and vote accordingly, thus teaching other new users to do the same.  It's a cycle that feeds itself, so the better the community the better it gets over time, the worse the community the worse it gets.

Comment: @Rizier123 I suspect for most of the major tags it's just the latter.  Since even very active users are still only able to see a fraction of the questions asked, they're often not seeing many of the good questions.  If enough of the bad questions were weeded out such that all of the experts actually saw all of the good questions, there would probably be more than enough of them (outside of niche topics).

Comment: @Servy Or we just change the "weight" of votes or actions for knowledgeable users and fix it that way.

Comment: @Rizier123 If you mean weight it by rep, that wouldn't help; that's part of the problem.  Users are able to get tens of thousands of rep posting lots of low quality contributions, and many experienced people get fed up and leave before too long.  That's the problem here; the established active user base, and high rep users, are people that value low quality contributions, and reward them.  So given that rep isn't a good indicator, how else do you plan on actually determining which users are actually voting on quality content and which ones aren't?

Comment: "*Yes, formally we have top-grade PHP contributors on Stack Overflow. But they all took refugee in the chat room and you seldom can see them answering a question.*" If they're not answering questions, then they're not really on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @TylerH To me it's rather a trivia, but for example this survey, https://w3techs.com/technologies/overview/programming_language/all

Comment: @NicolBolas That's just not true.  There are things you can do on SO besides answer questions.

Comment: @Servy: SO is a Q&A site. Google finds SO's questions and answers, not chat stuff. Whatever happens in chat may help a couple of people, but it will *only* help those people who deliberately go into chat. SO's primary goals are not served by chat.

Comment: @NicolBolas Sure, but that doesn't mean that they're not on the site, it just means they're not providing valuable contributions.  You don't have to be providing valuable contributions to "be on the site".  The vast majority of the people on the site aren't providing valuable contributions, even if they *are* posting answers to questions.

Comment: @TylerH https://w3techs.com/technologies/details/pl-php/all/all 82.1%

Comment: @DavidPostill Thanks, YCS shared the same source above.

Comment: @DavidPostill A little nitpick, PHP is a popular language among the webservers whose stack we know about. Most Java/Node/Python/Etc servers you simply don't know about because they don't reveal this information.

Comment: @NicolBolas I suggest you re-read the statement of mine that you quoted.  You're arguing the exact point that I made.

Comment: Well, we could start by making our questions worth answering to begin with...

Comment: @BoltClock I think your definition of "we" is problematic.

Comment: FaceBook does NOT use PHP. It uses a different language and a different toolchain with its roots in PHP.

Comment: @torazaburo 1. it was using pure PHP by the time when it become no.1 social network. 2. Your idea on the difference between Hack and PHP a bit exagerrated.

Comment: "Yes, formally we have top-grade PHP contributors on Stack Overflow. But they all took refugee in the chat room and you seldom can see them answering a question." Oh.

Comment: @Servy Can you provide evidence that people are amassing tens of thousand of rep points with low-quality answers?

Comment: @torazaburo Well given as quality is a subjective matter of opinion, it's impossible to prove either way.  It's my opinion that the contributions of many of the active users that I've come across are of low value help vampire food, but at the end of the day the fact that lots of people consider feeding help vampires "helpful" when I don't isn't a matter of fact, it's a matter of opinion.

Comment: @Servy If someone reaches 10K I'm sort of willing to give them the benefit of the doubt and believe that they are making a reasonable contribution, with the exception of the guy with one answer with hundreds of upvotes, but I don't think that happens much these days. I think rep whores are more hanging out in the high hundreds and low thousands.

Comment: @torazaburo You shouldn't be just assuming anything about the quality of someone's post base purely on their rep.  Like I said, I've seen lots of people with lots of rep doing little more than feeding help vampires.  If you think that's not a problem then I doubt there's much that I could say that would matter.

Comment: @selvy It may be a problem as you say, but even if it is, that's merely more input into the design of the matrix of qualifications vs. powers. High-reppers w/o gold badges could be given no additional powers, or they could be given limited additional powers. Do you also believe there are meaningful numbers of gold badge holders who are low-quality contributors? In that case, we are left with no metric I can think of for whom to enlist to help stamp out poor content, and we're back where we started.

Comment: Do you people not understand this site at all? The whole point of this is to share objective, verifiable, unique, on topic non opinionated questions and answers. If you remove any of those rather hostile elements out of the equation this site becomes yahoo answers. So in short: you can't. Either you create something new, more community oriented like a forum or you do nothing at all. You cannot change the way it is.

Comment: Struggling to get past the fact this question just looks like a huge advert for PHP!

Comment: I think it's also a matter of attitude. I'm currently in the process of getting my masters degree in C#. Whenever I go into the C# chatrooms or ask a question about it on the site, they gladly help me out in a very friendly way. However, when joining the PHP chatrooms, you're ignored quite a lot and these "professionals" tend to be quite unfriendly very fast. A simple "RTFM" for a professional can be a daunting task for a beginner who hardly knows where to look or simply doesn't understand the manual. And that's something easily forgotten by professionals.

Comment: I have to say `PHP Professional` is an oxymoron and the entire premise of this question is an [*Appeal to Popularity Fallacy*](https://www.logicallyfallacious.com/tools/lp/Bo/LogicalFallacies/40/Appeal_to_Popularity) so I think the entire question is baseless. The fact that SO seems to be actively discouraging the professionals in all the tags from staying around by diluting the value of the fake internet points you question is even more of a moot point.

Comment: The irony, I often see realy bad questions/answers that are upvoted multiple time, while I also see the good ones at zero. [The JQuery-Meme](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19492/292385) comes into my mind...

Comment: Can the title of this be changed? It seems very specific to PHP where as the title seems to suggest a broader issue. Maybe something along the lines of *How to lure PHP professionals to Stack Overflow?*

Comment: Quality be damned, the only thing that matters is eyes - sadly.

Comment: "how to make Stack Overflow a desirable platform for sharing knowledge?" you must be joking, ALL top engineers use SO on an hourly basis.  Note that for comic fields like PHP or Unity3D, you ***ALSO GET*** staggering number of "newb" hobbyist programmers asking questions.  All you can do about this is complain and be bitter about it.  (I constantly whine about the flood of crap questions on Unity3D.)  Regarding the fact that PHP and Unity3D are joke technologies, just get over it.  Take the money and enjoy. It's not real programming, it's scripting. (Trying to "talk up" those fields is funny.)

Comment: I've had questions closed because people were too stupid or didn't have the experience to understand what I was asking.

Comment: @AmyBlankenship or... maybe the question was unclear.

Comment: @KevinB My questions are clear, but advanced. It's gotten to the point where I don't bother to ask, because if I can't figure it out it's unlikely anyone else can help me. And then the people who aren't even able to comprehend the issue will downvote/vote to close.

Comment: @AmyBlankenship yes, that's the same boat i'm in. That's why the majority of my questions are downvoted. but... i don't particularly see that as a big problem. If it's a question that is on topic, not too subjective/broad, and you give it enough time/clarification you'll get an answer eventually.

Comment: @AmyBlankenship I've seen that many times. It is driving me crazy.

Comment: How close are we to the possibility of machine auto-closing for questions? Sometimes I see questions that are obviously dupes, and the question that they are a dupe is one of the top results in the "Related" question list, often with near-identical wording. There must be some kind of similarity score for questions used to generate that list, if it is over a certain threshold, the software votes to close as a dupe (3 or 4 more human votes would still be required). I know, technical solution to social problem, but still.

Comment: @AmyBlankenship Yes!  If a Google of one of my questions doesn't turn up an answer on SO, then there's usually no point to using SO.  My chances of posting a question on SO and then getting a useful answer are pretty low and my chances of getting downvoted by people who don't understand the question pretty high. BTW I'm a professional software developer for 25 years who has worked on some pretty gnarly problems.

Comment: Why don't be silly...all you need is sizable trail of PHP breadcrumbs...that'll lure all of them in.

Answer (score 183):

**Please note:** Following is my *personal* opinion after several years of PHP and [php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php) experience, it does not represent Stack Overflow, or my actions as moderator. Sadly, I'm not going to offer a solution here, so if that's what you're looking for, skip this answer.

Stack Overflow, originally, was a site where experts came to ask each other interesting and engaging questions. The weaker devs were predicted (with great accuracy) to be attracted to the high level information, and participate, increasing their own skill levels.

The issue is that Stack Overflow then became steadily more popular, and especially in tags like [php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php), [jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery) and others, we saw a huge degradation in quality, attributed to a decrease in signal:noise ratio, as well as experts giving up and leaving due to that same decrease.

This is a system-wide problem. Stack Overflow, as the system currently stands, whether by design or not, is a compromise more in-favor of the newbs, than it is of the experts. (Stack Overflow's quality levels are still well above the competitors, in my opinion)

- It takes 5 high rep users to close, and 1 no rep user to answer.
- It takes a user a long time to find and research, and no time to ask and have his question closed and pointing at the right one for him.
- Answerers are expected to answer concisely and Solve The Problem™. Asking "what have you tried" or pointed to google is frowned upon.
- etc

Some of these were out there since the beginning, some evolved because the expert-oriented nature of the site was unfriendly to users.

I don't have a good solution for you. There's no magic powder you can coat [php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php) in and suddenly make it interesting. People don't use PHP because it's shiny, people use it because it Solves The Problem™ and is easy enough to use. And just Solving The Problem™ doesn't really make for an interesting discussion.

This is an advanced stage in the life cycle of any community, what comes next... isn't good. I don't have the solution here, I don't think anyone on the internet does, if Stack Overflow manages to solve this problem, I'll take my hat off and clap.

There is no other expert community that had reach this size before. All of them imploded and died much sooner. We don't have anyone else to compare ourselves to, no one to learn the mistakes of. Which makes this all the harder to implement right. It's a matter of scale, and we would need to think carefully about every step we take.

Comment: You're not even gonna eat your hat? Boo.

Comment: "is a compromise more in-favor of the newbs, than it is of the experts." It wasn't by design: [We feel that the world is awash in questions, but not answers. Answers are the real unit of work in any Q&A system. Therefore, the only logical thing to do is to **maximize the happiness and enjoyment of answerers.** If this means aggressively closing unworthy or uninteresting questions, so be it. Without a community of people willing to answer questions, it really doesn't matter if there are questions at all, does it?](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/a/595/41104)

Comment: At some point of time, we lost the light and helping people became more important that helping create a library of practical programing answers.

Comment: @Braiam I would argue that helping people *is* the light.

Comment: @TylerH when quality is not the goal, why the heck are you investing your time into? You will not make a dent, overload yourself and overwork others for the benefit of nobody. "A strong asymmetry of effort in asking and answering is unsustainable and should be discouraged."

Comment: @Braiam That's what they say. But the system doesn't (fully) reflect that, in my opinion.

Comment: it is rather that system failed to keep original intent when scaling up. Things that worked at 80..800 questions a day just broke somewhere between 2K and 8K q/day. Of course there is a chance that intent changed somewhere along the way and nobody told us. "Let's compete with Reddit - moar postz, moar viewz, moar votez"

Comment: @gnat Yes, that's a good summary of my opinions as well. And I think this is a problem that's worth thinking about, and the earlier the better.

Comment: @Braiam Who said quality is not the goal in helping people? From how I understand the concept of helping people, quality is *the* goal.

Comment: @TylerH If helping people takes priority over quality, then we shouldn't have closing, or deleting, or keeping ourselves in scope. Just help people.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha The world isn't black or white, and neither is the site. You can help people and still moderate the site. Each user is afforded much discretion in how *much* to help people. That doesn't really relate to the fact that the goal of helping people is to improve/increase quality, though.

Comment: @TylerH Right, it's just a matter of priority. You can do both, but not always. What do you do when they clash? All I'm saying is while we say we favor quality, the current system as it is does not favor quality over quantity.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha It depends on each situation, since each person--and their situation--is unique. But I agree, the site/company is clearly (and has been for a while) interested in quantity over quality. They make money with ads and Careers. Those are both services they sell (more or less) to us, the users. The bigger their user pool, the more money they can potentially make. That's the humanitarian problem with corporatism; it's a philosophy to make money, not make the world a better place.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha is not even a mater of "quality vs quantity" is a mater of "helping vs sustainability". No system without quality standards is sustainable over long periods of time. These tend to put too much pressure over the experts and none over the non-experts. We shouldn't make experts unhappy, or they will leave, making the site unsustainable, since if there's no one answering questions, there is no reason to have questions at all, right?

Comment: This is an incredible answer, and I think it pretty impressively summarizes a lot of the fundamental problems with and disagreements about “The Quality Problem” that both answers the specific question (the one about [tag:php]) and a more general one (the state of the site in general). Certainly not surprising coming from you, but still always really heartening to see such a compassionate, nuanced, and reasoned view from the moderation team, especially with such a controversial topic others seem to often avoid addressing (perhaps with good reason). Thank you.

Comment: "*It takes 5 high rep users to close, and 1 no rep user to answer.*" I gave up on moderation tasks like flagging or closing on low frequented tags and sister sites in the network for exactly that reason.

Comment: @Braiam - too bad that quote by Jeff is no longer the focus of the site, hasn't been since about 2013. He has no say or influence so that quote is irrelevant now, ad impressions are what they are focusing on now since they know 99.999999% of the questions have been answered ad nausea-um, they really don't care about the people that made the site what is was, otherwise rep would mean something like it did originally, it used to mean you knew what you were talking about, now it means you ask remedial questions like crazy and those just as ignorant as you up vote them immediately.

Comment: "It takes 5 high rep users to close"  aren't there enough gold badge dupe hammerers for PHP?

Comment: @JarrodRoberson If you think really deep about it, it doesn't make sense. Ads are paid by impression, impressions are obtained by views, views are obtained by ranking on the search engines, search engines rank based on quality. Is just me or somehow your logic wrong or misguided?

Comment: @Braiam the problem is how search engines measure quality, I guess. Probably the most common way is in number of views, as there is not yet a way to do that based on the semantics of the content. In other words, more views leads to more views, independently of how good the thing viewed actually is.

Comment: @JuanCarlosCoto unlikely so. If views were primary measure for search engines then my search results would be polluted by "wildly popular" worthless reddit threads. Luckily, this doesn't happen. I guess search engines somehow learned to dismiss views that aren't backed up by relevant content

Comment: @gnat right, unless the way to determine value is via links to a page. More visible means more links, which means more value? Anyway, there's a point in wondering if the quality drop in answers and questions might actually increase ad-based revenue because of more views, at least in the short term. In a way, as long as there are clicks, it doesn't matter if the content is good, monetary-wise. Which is a big problem in my opinion. Just my 2 cents.

Comment: @gnat "There is a chance"? The whole change in attitude can be directly attributed to the change in leadership and is best summarized by the horribly flawed idea of [the summer of love](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/07/kicking-off-the-summer-of-love/). We went from Jeff's "aggressively closing unworthy or uninteresting questions" to Joel's "The way to get lots of people contributing is to recruit more people to participate on Stack Exchange. The way to recruit more people is to be nice". This is the epitome of favoring quantity over quality.

Comment: While this is indeed a site wide problem - and there's been some great meta posts showing the effect over the years - this is certainly more pronounced in say PHP than it is in say C++. For one PHP certainly is more of a beginner language than C++, but it's also a simple fact that the C++ community is *way* stricter (others might say unfriendly) about low quality questions.

Comment: sh!t @Voo you make a pretty strong point, these quotes seem to show a striking difference in approaches (there will likely be smokescreens that it meant to make more professionals enjoy as answerers but true intent is hard to cover, "get lots of people... recruit more people" - sounds like quantity over quality indeed)

Comment: Hard for me to believe that enforcing quality necessarily implies being mean. Granted, it's hard to be critical and friendly.

Comment: Perhaps the Documentation project can be the refuge for expert users - a place where standards can be met, and truly excellent questions can be referenced. People with knowledge can share it easily, and hopefully the socratic method will kick in - questions raised by the documentation will lead to more questions, leading to answers. Finally, being able to point people to documentation may be a good way to weed out "bad questions" - the ones categorized as too broad, or even sometimes, too specific.

Comment: @Voo: "*the horribly flawed idea of the summer of love.*" You mean the horribly flawed idea of not being rampaging jerks and making our close reasons make sense (not that they succeeded on that last part)? Yes, it was totally the Summer of Love, rather than just being part of a slow and steady decline SO has had for years.

Comment: To the extent this is true, it's definitely a problem with the PHP tag and not with the StackOverflow community as a whole.  In particular, the Java tag appears to have the opposite problems:  (1) the hordes rush to close even legitimate questions, leaving insufficient time for knowledgeable individuals to answer them (bad); (2) searching is trivial and askers tend to be required to clarify questions with stack traces and exactly the relevant code before they get answers (good); (3) Answers that outline a solution without providing code are often upvoted and accepted (good), etc.

Comment: @nicol Clearly making it harder to close questions had no influence whatsoever on the influx of low quality questions that didn't get closed? Unlikely. The fact that tags that are stricter have less low quality questions (compare PHP and C++) also speaks volumes.

Comment: @Voo: "*Clearly making it harder to close questions*" They took away il-specified and poorly-understood close reasons like "too localized", which was basically used as a catch-all close reason rather than a real, easily-understood concept. "*The fact that tags that are stricter have less low quality questions (compare PHP and C++) also speaks volumes.*" That actually undermines your point. If the Summer of Love was truly the cause of the lowering of quality, then C++ would not have been able to maintain its quality. So clearly, that's not the problem.

Comment: @nicol The point there was that strict closing stems the tide of lower quality questions.  You might say that it proves that the summer of love itself was ineffectual and didn't achieve anything, but I'd argue it's more likely that it just caused the community extra effort to achieve the same results as before. Which is why the c++ community which is smaller and was already quite focused on quality had an easier time coping than PHP.

Comment: @Voo: "*The point there was that strict closing stems the tide of lower quality questions.*" And the Summer of Love *didn't change that*. Mechanically, closing was no more difficult after than before. What the Summer of Love changed was the close reasons; that's *all*. So if there was less closing after, then that was because people *choose* not to close questions after. It had nothing to do with the Summer of Love. As you point out, the C++ community kept to its quality. Why not the PHP community?

Answer (score 84):

This question boils down to another iteration of the "whither Stack Overflow" question.

I make no claim to having read or understood all the proposals on Meta on the topic.

But the underlying issue is the massive cruft in questions and answers. The PHP experts you want to attract to the site have no interest in sifting through 100 inane questions to find one they might want to answer. The percentage of such experts that are generous enough with their time to answer the same basic questions over and over again is vanishingly small.

The only solution I can provide is a massive expansion of hammers. Many new hammering rules have been proposed, but few adopted, perhaps out of a conservative mindset involving worries about hammer abuse, unfriendliness to new users, etc. Currently hammers are limited to dups and require the wielder of the hammer to spend undue amounts of time finding the dup to hammer against.

I'd suggest the following hammerability for folks with gold badges in a topic:

1. Hammer any question that could be solved with simple debugging.
2. Hammer any question that could be solved with reference to documentation or a quick search on google or SO.
3. Hammer any **answer** that is not an answer, or misses the point of the question, or is obviously wrong.
4. If the OP has not given the right tags to a question, allow a hammerer to add the tag and then hammer.
5. Hammer any question that is due to a typo or trivial logical or syntactical error.
6. Hammer a dup without having to actually provide a reference, with a reason such as "This question has been answered multiple times on this site", such as questions about how to center a div.
7. Hammer any questions related to munging HTML with regexps.
8. Hammer any questions which are just stupid, or incomprehensible, or ridden with formatting or other errors.
9. Have an un-accept hammer which kills acceptances on ridiculous answers and prevents the answer from being re-accepted.
10. In certain cases allow hammers to not just close the question but also immediately delete it without regard to how many answers there are or how upvoted they are or whether one of them is accepted or not.
11. Allow comment hammering for obnoxious, irrelevant, or pointless comments.
12. Hammer all write-my-code-for-me questions.

In a certain sense, the above represents an expansion of moderator capability to tag-specific experts.

To avoid hammer abusers, remove hammering capability from anyone whose hammers are reversed or overridden more than x% (15%?) of the time.

OK, please interpret the above as a kind of devil's advocate, extreme position. Let me try to position this in more abstract terms.

1. We stipulate that there are far too many poor questions and poor answers on the site. This has the effect of reducing the ability of the site to accomplish its goals. In particular, it reduces participation, which is the question being posited here.
2. The existing mechanisms, including moderation, close voting, down voting, and hammering, are clearly not adequate to solve the problem.
3. Therefore, we need some new approach.
4. The new approach, almost by definition, must involve some mechanism to more readily clean up extremely low-quality content.
5. We therefore need some more nuanced way to define groups of people who have some kind of ability to more immediately and directly deal with low-quality content.
6. In general terms, then, the question is what categories of people we can define that will have what kind of abilities to help clean up the mess.
7. Categories of people could include elected moderators, a new category of elected tag moderators, or self-qualified people based on reputation or tag qualifications.
8. The kind of abilities each category of people would have could be some subset of the items listed in the previous section.

Whatever particular categories of people you prefer to define, or how you define them, or whatever particular powers you prefer to give them, it seems very hard to justify a status quo approach unless you are interested in watching SO slowly decline, considering that the risk of a descent into irrelevance seems much more substantial than the risk of a few posts getting closed or deleted when maybe they shouldn't have.

Comment: I think this goes too far for the site, let alone as a solution to this question's problem, and introduces some hammer "reasons" that are simply the realm of pure opinion.

Comment: You assume a lot of trust in gold badge users.  Also, a lot of this is subjective and much is left to interpretation.

Comment: I'm not against all the suggestions here. But too much too hard generally leads to opposite results.

Comment: @Tyler Basically, moderators already have all these privileges. I assume you do not believe that current moderator privileges "go too far for the site". However, currently moderators are overworked and have no tag-specific knowledge. What I am proposing can be considered to be a sort of expansion of some moderator privileges to other knowledgeable, reputable folks, or, if you prefer, the introduction of a new, "tag-specific" moderator notion. Everyone has opinions; the point is whose opinions we choose to respect.

Comment: @Makoto Not sure about the distrust in gold badges. Getting there is not easy, and evidences a meaningful amount of both knowledge and judgment. We have already given the dup hammer to gold badge holders. Shall we remove that since they don't deserve our trust?

Comment: @torazaburo I don't believe moderator privileges go to far, because our moderators are heavily vetted and their actions are transparent to their peers and often to us, on request. If we suddenly open up moderator powers to thousands of strangers who haven't been vetted at all and who aren't accountable to each other or to users of less reputation, we invite disaster. In short, I don't trust all the gold badge users or 10k users with *carte blanche* moderator powers. Not at all.

Comment: Let's assume then that I'm speaking from the context of, "Oh, there are a lot of users of [insert tag here] that upvote a lot of terrible answers."  If that's the case, then there is a nonzero chance that a user has a gold badge based on their terrible answers.  If that's the case, then we can *immediately* rule out knowledge.  As for judgment, we already have gold badge users overreaching with their powers a bit, and giving them the power to unilaterally *remove* content without others' feedback is worrisome.

Comment: @Makoto Thanks for your thoughts. A couple of things though. I doubt if anyone has gotten a gold badge for a bunch of terrible answers. You devalue the meaning and effort for getting a gold badge. Second, I proposed a way to monitor hammer usage and remove hammer capability from abusers. By the way, if you think current gold badge users are overreaching, then go ahead and remove all their hammers. I for one would be much less interested in involving myself in SO if I were not even able to close obvious dups without four other votes.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha Fine, then let's do a little bit less, a little bit less hard. But at least something.

Comment: A "less hard" version of this sort of thing might be to open up such functionality to gold badgers, but without the unilateral authority. It takes three 20ker votes to delete a negatively-scored answer, for example. What if three hammer wielders could delete any answer in their tag?

Comment: @TylerH Gosh, multiple red herrings in one single comment. So gold badge holders are "strangers"? I'm a "stranger"? I did not say 10K, which anyone can reach; I said gold badge holders in a tag. These people have already been vetted by long, extensive, involvement in SO, please give them some credit. And I did not say "open up moderator powers"; I specifically proposed a **subset** of moderator-like powers.

Comment: And what would you do with answers "don't do that" to the inherently wrong question which shouldn't be asked in first place?…

Comment: We need some of these hammers. But with the ability to decide not to use them in the not-so-clear cases.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha It seems to me that SO is facing a crisis. It will descend into irrelevance, other than as some links that pop up when you do a Google search, within a matter of a year or two. People like myself will leave the site. I wonder what the sense of urgency is about this on the part of the people running SO, whoever they are. It seems to be low. They seem to prefer easing into irrelevance over taking a risk that could give them the potential for a new lease on life. What's the downside again? Some bad questions getting deleted?

Comment: @torazaburo Anyone can reach gold badge, too; they aren't vetted. Yes, they're strangers; they haven't posted a long expose about why they want to have such powers, how they'll use them, what moderation means to them, etc. I give them credit, I trust them *more* than I do users with less rep. But they **still aren't vetted** and so I simply cannot trust them *carte blanche*. No red herrings there. And with the power to delete questions, delete answers, and delete comments, not to mention un-accept answers (which mods can't currently do), there's little difference from moderators at that point.

Comment: @torazaburo I agree with some of these ideas, like the ability to hammer closed questions for more reasons than just "duplicate", for example, but some of these I could *never* be okay with putting in the hands of a single user, let alone a single un-elected user, who isn't vetted, with no oversight.

Comment: @TylerH Then for goodness' sake, propose some reasonable subset of privileges, to be granted to some reasonable subset of people who meet some criteria you deem desirable, to at least move towards solving the problem, or are you simply saying there is nothing to do until SO fades into irrelevance?

Comment: @TylerH Your lack of imagination is quite remarkable. If you don't like the idea of a single "unvetted" user with no "oversight" closing a question, then propose something else--like TWO of them closing it. Or is your suggestion just to do nothing?

Comment: @torazaburo I already provided an answer to YCS' question that more directly addresses it before you posted this answer. That aside, there's no need to attempt to paint this in such absolutes. What privileges various users should have does not answer the question; such a discussion belongs elsewhere. Please don't act like disagreement or taking issue with your suggestion is nothing more than stonewalling; it's dishonest. On top of that, the *ad hominem* isn't productive, either.

Comment: @TylerH Sorry, what is the meaning of "vetting"? Who is doing this vetting exactly? What is the vetting process? Who is being vetted? Are you confusing standing for election as moderator with "vetting"? Vetting is usually done by some third party, who is that in this case? Is there something about contributing to the site for five years and submitting 2,000 answers with a total reputation of 40K, and submitting 1K answers on a particular tag with 2K upvotes that is somehow different from vetting? If not, exactly how do I get vetted? If I get vetted, can I have a hammer?

Comment: @torazaburo [Vetting](https://www.google.com/search?q=vetting&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8). The community does the vetting in the form of checking their participation history and asking them questions on moderation and how they intend to handle various aspects of it. Are you really unfamiliar with the process? I'm surprised, since you expect me to put so much trust in you as a gold badge wielder. Subject Matter Experts are not all qualified to be moderators. Moderation of user content requires additional, non-overlapping skills compared to answering questions on a particular subject.

Comment: @torazaburo You can read more about moderation [here](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/) and [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/204535/a-theory-of-moderation-update).

Comment: @TylerH It is amazing that you continue to confuse extended hammering ability with moderation, even though I clearly indicated the difference. It is amazing that you seem to believe that somehow maintaining a bureaucracy of properly vetted moderators, and never sharing any of their magic powers, or redefining the concept of moderation, or rethinking anything else about the site, is a more important priority than the site dying. It's amazing that you would turn the discussion into one about my familiarity with some moderator election rules.

Comment: @torazaburo: Who exactly is helped by #6? The OP doesn't get helped. The next person doesn't get to find the question it is a duplicate of. SO itself is not helped because anyone who finds the question won't actually get an answer. And the only people who would be able to actually make it a proper duplicate question are the *least* likely people to want to.

Comment: @torazaburo: "*What's the downside again? Some bad questions getting deleted?*" No, the downside is the creation of an oligarchy who unilaterally decides what is and is not a legitimate question based on an arbitrary set of poorly-defined rules. Your suggestion effectively gives gold badge holders carte-blance power to close any question they see fit. And your "fix" for abuse makes it far too easy for a group of like-minded people to strip any person of their power simply by finding and undoing their "hammer"ing. Your suggestion is far too open to abuse.

Comment: @torazaburo: "*The new approach, almost by definition, must involve some mechanism to more readily clean up extremely low-quality content.*" I was with you up until that point. Stack Overflow works best by design, not by clean-up crews. The question/answer format is built into the system, making it difficult to effectively have discussions. And so forth. SO is at its most successful when it *doesn't* need manual fixing. So #4 is wrong; we should instead design a system whereby such questions are not introduced in the first place.

Comment: I agree with the general idea here that gold badge users should have more power than they have right now. Their votes should definitely have more weight than the votes of others. I would even expand that to silver badge holders. My idea: make a close-vote by a gold-badger count 3 for all reasons (well, except dupe) and a close-vote by a silver-badger count 2 for all reasons. This adresses the concern of @TylerH (no single lone wolf with full power) and, I hope, gives attraction to users to close-vote more (since their vote counts more).

Comment: @torazaburo You asked me what I meant by vetting (which is a fairly basic term); I just sent you the link to the definition I'm using. No insult intended. Vetting means checking; it means the same thing in horse racing as it does in employment as it does in politics as it does in moderation elections. You are checking the general fitness of the candidate prior to putting them in a certain position. Not sure how you can be so experienced in vetting without knowing what it is. *Really* skeptical you've done it your whole life if you don't even know what it means.

Comment: @TylerH I didn't ask you for the definition of vetting. I asked you what it was about the current system of moderators that you would consider vetting. Voting is not vetting, not matter how much due diligence individual voters do. Vetting is a process of thorough investigation or expert appraisal, and someone merely reading someone's position statement does not constitute vetting.

Comment: @TylerH (cont'd)  I understand that you place high value on the process of electing moderators, and it certainly does represent a useful filter for those on whom great powers are to be bestowed. What is in question here is some alternative, additional qualification, not involving a cumbersome voting process, for conferring more limited powers on a subset of people in desperate hopes of stemming the red tide. When the building is on fire, and people line up to help pass buckets of water, we do not ask that they be professional firemen.

Comment: The beauty of @torazaburo's idea to leverage high rep users to better  appeal to professionals is that it aligns well with all of SO's apparatus for identifying and rewarding contributions via rep assignment.  Anti-elitist arguments do not apply when the goal is elite levels of performance in answering and moderating.

Comment: @kjhughes: Really? Right now, I am one of 3 gold badge holders in the Lua tag. Under his rules, if lhf and I got together and decided that we're getting too many crap questions about Torch in that tag, we could hammer every Lua/Torch question we wanted, bad or not. If Yu Hao (the other gold badge holder) tried to stop us, together, we could get *his* hammer powers stripped, since it's 2-on-1. The only people who could stop us then would be moderators. It's *absurd* to give normal users that level of authority over the site.

Comment: @torazaburo "conferring more limited powers" Implementing all the things you've listed would give gold badge users *more* powers and authority than moderators currently have. The only thing left for moderators would be suspension of users, basically. Gold badge users could do anything else, including changing the accepted answer or "removing content because it is 'stupid'". If one day I got a gold badge in JS and thought all your answers in the tag were stupid, I would be within my rights and authority to delete them. Surely that seems like a problem to you, doesn't it?

Comment: @NicolBolas: Yes, really.  You've demonstrated better judgement, and I trust that you and others who've reached similar stature here will continue to be as responsible as you've been.  A ramp up in capabilities can be gradual and moderated to further allay your concerns -- such function is already a natural strength of this site, afterall.

Comment: The only downside I see to this is that it biased towards users that already have high rep, and will make it that much harder for new users to gain rep.  I guarantee every high-rep user has answered an astonishingly large number of crap questions and gained a lot of rep of them.  If you automatically remove all those questions (which is fine), it removes a major source of rep for newer users, and just cements the current high-rep users as permanent moderators.

Comment: @kjhughes No. That's not what gold badge owners demonstrate. Gold badge demonstrates that you have considerable experience in the tag. You've answered many questions, and gotten a high score on enough of them. Implied is that you are familiar with other prominent users, you know what the duplicates are, and how questions are expected to look. None of the above says you have any experience moderating, have ever displayed good judgement, or are even interested in power. We don't have a measurement of moderation experience, aside from moderators who are manually reviewed and elected.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha There seems to be a gap in the notions of expertise, participation, and judgement here. There seems to be a view that gold badge holders in a tag are a kind of mutant or idiot savant who may have a lot of knowledge in that tag (except for those upvotes they got by rep-whoring and vampire-feeding), but are otherwise basically unqualified, or at least no more qualified than anyone else, to exercise any judgment about site content, other than hammering duplicates.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha (cont'd) Therefore, even if the site is choking on crap, according to this view, we don't want or need their help, and in fact would prefer to choke instead of taking it, condescendingly telling them to quit whining and keep on casting all those valuable down votes and single close votes and occasional hammers.. We would unilaterally reject (OK, I know you said you're not against all the suggestions here, I mean others) any notion of enlisting their help, and refuse to even consider any limited additional powers, phase-ins, or safeguards. If that's the case, I'm out of here.

Comment: That's absolutely not what I said. The original notion for mjolnir was that "well, these people have been here long enough to get a gold badge, if anyone knows the questions most commonly asked in the tag they have a badge in, it's them". I'm completely and absolutely in favor of our reputation based moderation system. I think that's why Stack Overflow scaled so well relatively to other similar purpose forums.

Comment: @hacksalot - It has only gained in popularity since you left. And where is the competition? What would replace the clear niche this fills? I feel that your outlook is the only thing that will achieve irrelevance and obscurity.

Comment: Other arguments aside, this solution assumes that experts are going to want to spend large amounts of time manually moderating these low quality questions with these new privileges, which seems even worse than answering them. Surely the experts have better things to do

Comment: @aw04 moderating these low quality questions is what hundreds of people are currently doing anyway. There is no sane reason to disregard what torazaburo has suggested out-of-hand. The junk needs to be closed and deleted with half the effort it currently requires

Comment: @Drew I'm not saying it's a bad idea or that it won't help, but having hundreds of volunteer experts moderating thousands of questions a day in this way simply isn't going to solve the issue nor is it sustainable. Experts will get burnt out eventually, others will not do a sufficient job. Honestly the only real solution is to not just let any random person ask a question, anything else is a work-around

Comment: @Drew No coincidence the top rated answer to this question isn't even an attempt at an answer :)

Comment: Fifty users given cv-mod privileges similar to what is suggested here would go a huge way toward closing down the crud. Those users could roam between tags (be generally anchored to their own), could have a rotation, and spare us the grief of 5 grown adults trying to close an Unclear etc question. As torazaburo has said, use your imagination, have some trust, and make this a better place.

Comment: @TravisJ taking my comments offline as they're mostly negative and not really germane to this discussion, PM me if you'd like to continue.

Comment: Actually the current rules do not require the gold badges to find actual duplicates at all, just to claim to find one; I've seen questions marked as duplicates of things that had little to do with the actual question.

Comment: @WarrenDew Are you making this point in the context of the proposal to allow gold badges to hammer dups without specifying the target? Or are you suggesting that the dup hammer concept is flawed because some people will give a bad target? Or are you implying that this validates the notion that gold badge holders should not have extra powers because they can't handle the ones they have? Yes, there will be occasionally be human error. In that case, the question can be re-opened, right?

Comment: @NicolBolas I agree that an Oligarchy would be created. However I wonder if that is in fact a "bad thing". The oligarchy you are opposed to are the same "professionals" that SO relies on to provide quality answers. If an asker does not adhere to the rules of the "professionals", there is no reason for the "professionals" to answer them any how.

Answer (score 62):

In addition to some of the hammering suggested by @torazaburo, we need to discourage people from posting low quality questions. To achieve that, I propose the following:

**When a question is closed, retract all rep gained from all the answers.**

**This will disincentivize people from posting answers to crappy questions, which in turn would discourage people from posting crappy questions.**

As pointed out by others, posting a quick question to SO is sometimes easier than looking it up in the documentation or even search for it. This is what leads to all the crappy questions we have. Once the question is posted, people trying to gain easy rep rush to answer it, even though they know they should be closing it.

If people would know that their answers to crappy questions won't gain them any rep, they'll do the right thing and close it. Once that cycle starts, people will realize that crappy questions don't get any answers, and the quality of all questions will slowly increase.

---

I say all this as someone that used to be very active in `javascript`, `jquery` and `php`. Over time, I was turned off by exactly the reasons outlined by the OP.

I believe that this is all a matter of incentives.
If we sort that out, we can start getting back on the right track.

Comment: Something similar to this was already discussed some time ago: [Remove answer upvotes on questions which are promptly closed as unclear](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/310663) - quite controversial judging from the comments and votes.

Comment: Perhaps limit this to questions closed recently, as in only retract for questions closed in the first week. Sometimes close reasons change, and many questions which were on topic or well received are then closed to adapt to the new reasons and that edge case would effect a large group of users were their reputation to be removed. Especially if at the time they had done nothing wrong by answering.

Comment: The link provided by @JonasCz sums it up quite nicely. And how do you propose to prevent higher-rep users who got upvoted answers from voting to re-open the question so they can keep their rep?

Comment: @FrankSchmitt Since it requires 5 high-rep users to reopen a question, one user cannot reopen the question on his own to get the rep back, which I think would be sufficient.

Comment: @JonasCz That's true, hadn't thought of the requirement for 5 high-rep users to reopen (although I've seen cases where 5 high-rep users answered the same dumb question instead of closing it).

Comment: I completely agree with this proposal. In addition, I would impose an additional automatic downvote on all the answers.

Comment: What is the scope of your suggestion? Would it affect questions that are already closed? What about meta?

Comment: This would be highly detrimental to tags in more serious languages.

Comment: What would happen if a question is eventually reopened?

Comment: @WarrenDew How so?

Comment: @WarrenDew Could you please elaborate? In what way?

Comment: @Matsmath If a question is re-opened the rep needs to be restored.

Comment: The system StackOverflow uses is highly biased towards closures even when they are not justified, because you can vote for the closure from the question, but you cannot vote against the closure without searching through a long close queue.  As a result, in most language tags, the number of questions closed when they should not be closed is the big problem, even if the `php` tag has the opposite problem.  Making the bulk of the community worse to fix a `php` specific problem is the tail wagging the dog.  To improve things, the PHP community needs to fix its own culture.

Comment: @WarrenDew: "*As a result, in most language tags, the number of questions closed when they should not be closed is the big problem*" As a user of non-PHP tags, no it is not. I very rarely see questions closed when they shouldn't be. I may not always *agree* with every closure, but I do feel that the *vast* majority of them are well justified.

Comment: @WarrenDew The relative lengths of the close vote and reopen vote queues demonstrates that very few questions are wrongly closed.

Comment: @Raedwald The problem is not so much questions that are closed through the queue but rather questions that are closed without using the queue.

Comment: For reference, [here's a related thread](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/324320/how-does-a-directly-quoted-answer-get-so-many-upvotes) that would support removing rep from answers to closed questions.

Answer (score 50):

[I've said it before](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/316112/can-we-care-a-little-more-about-quality-instead-of-quantity-please), and I'll say it again: we have an abundance of users who are too focused on their reputation, and don't care enough about the site's quality. Or maybe they do, but their definition of "quality" differs from mine.

Just this morning, I encountered a question whose title was something like *"Remove last array element"* and whose content was something entirely different. Namely: parsing a comma-separated string which could contain a trailing comma (`foo,bar,`) into an array containing each separated element. The OP specified they wanted to remove the single, last empty element.

The OP showed their code (simplification mine):

```
inputString = "foo,bar,"
array = inputString.Split(',')
// now array contains 3 elements, "foo", "bar" and ""
```

What the OP didn't address:

- If the input string always ended with a comma.
- Whether there could be multiple trailing commas (`foo,bar,,`).
- Whether there could be enclosed repeated commas (`foo,,bar`).
- Whether they wanted to fix the problem before, during or after splitting the comma-separated string.
- What they had tried to solve the problem.

Yet over the course of 30 minutes, that question received 9 answers (of which 4 remain) from users having between 80 and 95,000 reputation.

And almost every single one of them answered the question's *title*, without taking a single look at the question. Posting answers like this:

- `array = array.Take(array.Length - 1).ToArray()`
- `inputString = inputString.Substring(-1)`
- `inputString = inputString.Trim(',')`
- `array = array.Where(a => a != "")`

Which is indisputably crap code. It is not reusable, makes fatal assumptions that *will* make it break (and maybe not in the OP's case, but definitely in others'), and it is simply **wrong**. There is one correct answer: leveraging the framework's `String.Split()` option `RemoveEmptyEntries`. Or, you know, use a CSV parsing library.

Apart from it being a duplicate of at least 1000 different questions, the question should not be answered before the OP added clarifications on the missing points mentioned above. The answerers shouldn't have hurried to answer the title, but try to understand the OP's problem instead (and then flag as possible duplicate).

My point with this simple example is that this happens hundreds, if not thousands of times per day. There's not always someone present who wants to carefully review every answer, who asks code dumpers to also add explanation to their answers, who sometimes recognizes copy-pasted text in answers and asks for source attribution, who thoroughly understands the OP's problem and sees that the answerers are misguided.

In other words: there are too many answerers who aren't quite good enough at what they're doing in order to be able to help create a site full of quality content. They might be able to help an OP over a single bump in the road, but they're not helping answer general questions with broadly applicable solutions. And yes, a oneliner can be that. At the same time, there are not enough knowledgeable users who want to review what is being posted, and they can't find the questions worth answering through the sheer volume of low-quality posts.

**But people just want to gain reputation**. They want to "help" the OP by pasting their question title in Google and copy-pasting the first hit. They don't want to spend time engaging with the OP (who might never come back), they just want to jot down some untested, barely working pseudocode that doesn't even address the problem. Because they're "helping", right?

There is no solution, other than to start all over.

Or, maybe there is, like the [suggestion I've supported before](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/322908/this-is-why-not-answering-duplicates-is-more-helpful-than-spoon-feeding/322914#322914): **make questions** from risk groups (new users, low-rep users, users who ask more than they answer) **on hold by default**, until they are reviewed and requests for clarification have been answered. And any people who Just Don't Get It and keep robo-reviewing (as in: vote to open a question that will be closed again quickly afterwards), just get a review ban for life.

Comment: I pretty much agree. And of course people who take the time to ask for clarification, do research, and actually answer the question have a tendency to end up at the bottom of the list, after rehash and non-answer answers get spammed and voted up by similarly clueless users. It's happened to me enough times to make me very hesitant to waste my time by answering any good question I can't off the top of my head resolve in around 4 sentences. Which is a rare question to see.

Comment: Starting over would make it worse. Since we have less and less "experts" posting questions - or at least people who know what they are doing - starting over would just create an even stronger imbalance. However, I do strongly agree with a bullet point in your "said it before link" (ref: more canonicals), and with the idea of increasing barriers to risk groups. We need to focus more on giving incentives to questions from non risk groups or "experts".

Comment: Afterall, who is going to create these canonicals if not for experts? "Risk group" users certainly are not, and the criteria for this creation needs to be different between the two groups. Allowing the type of broad question a canonical requires from a risk group user clearly creates a mess, but when a "expert" (by some metric) creates such a question it can have many benefits as is already seen in dozens of existing canonical posts.

Comment: Bikeshedding is the price of success.

Comment: @Travis but what if you could concentrate the experts somehow, and have them exchange their knowledge? (No, that was a joke).

Comment: @CodeCaster - Sure, but where could we host such an expertsexchange?

Comment: @Travis I don't know, but make sure to hyphenate the domain properly! Anyway yeah, the starting all over wasn't too serious.

Comment: Not that I don't agree with most of what you're saying, but for the question at hand, i.e. how to attract and engage new professional users, treating new users as a risk group seems counter-productive. It's as much a prejudice as saying that SO users with giga reputations must be unemployed and not very talented, or they wouldn't have all that time to spend here.

Comment: @Gert the problem is not attracting experts. Everyone is an expert unless proven otherwise (and you can disprove that with a single comment or post). The problem is the amount of crap questions and crap answers they get. We need to eliminate _that_ problem, IMHO. I interpreted the question's title more as clickbait, and the actual question more like _"How do we get the present experts to collaborate again?"_.

Answer (score 28):

The wall of crap is probably the biggest turn off for a number of people. Stack Overflow gets **thousands** of questions **per day**, and honestly, most of them are worthless. Or off topic.

I'm going to further break down this problem and address one type of question: the recommendation question. Despite being thoroughly off-topic, these questions continue to be asked to this day.

My opinion has been that these questions are very easy to identify. And I will back this up. With programming! [I wrote a SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/481553/recommendation#graph). It does bar graphs! And it finds recommendation questions pretty well (note that I have bar #5 set up as an overflow; it's the questions in the first few bars that are good matches).

I have included some results below (these are not cherry-picked; they are the first results). These are all OPEN questions, and most of them should be closed as recommendation Q's from the information in the title alone (I'll admit it's not perfect):

```
Any open source java library which can parse an EDI file in both ANSI x12 and UN/EDIFACT standards?
Handling and syncing own custom version of an open source library with SVN
Is there a raycasting library in C++ that is simple and open source?
Open source object recognition library for visual browsing interfaces
Cannot open source file: '..\..\basic-tutorial-1.c': No such file or directory
Free or Open Source WinForms UI scraping / automation library
Open source Geoparsing tool for Java?
Performance test tool for GPU drivers Open source Mali/UMP
Open source concept mining tools?
What alternatives are there to the pHash open source perceptual hash library?
Is DLIB a good open source library for developing my own machine learning algorithms in C++?
Open source C++ library for vector mathematics
Building open source library (liblo) for iPhone
Open source Objective C (or C/C++) library for audio to H.323?
Open source tools for testing purpose in Mac OS X
Is there some open source tools for create tile map(IOS with cocos2d)?
Open source XMPP library with BOSH support
I am looking for Open Source Analytics tool for Sitecore. Any idea?
open source "Performance testing and Load Testing" tools for web application
Efficiently generating time index of pre-transcribed speech using it's audio source and open source tools
Is it kosher for me to use HTMLAgilityPack in my free open source C# library?
debugging python setup.py for an open source library - bcfg2
Open source mobile automation tools for Blackberry and Windows
In need of help with setting up the open source library JFreeChart
what are the tools to parse/analyze IIS logs - ideally free/open source?
Is there a Java open source library for managing a NISO/ANSI Z39.19 controlled vocabulary in XML or SKOS format?
Open source requirements management tool
Open source language/library/representation format that allows treating numeric formulas as objects?
open source code for RSA implementation in C/C++ (Use library or write my own)
open source library for calculating 4x4 transformation matrix
open source GUI tool for hadoop?
Open source javascript library rendering comments popup box over page elements
Is there an open source .NET equivalent to the date.js library?
Does an open source markup->HTML tool exist for Confluence wiki markup?
Want the list of languages supported by each font.Is there any open source font library or database listing them?
open source library to convert all popular formats (.doc,.docx,.xls,etc) to pdf or generate thumbnails of firstpage of documents in asp.net
Open source tool for MS SQL to SQL data migration (different schemas)
Is there an Open Source library of some sort that identifies data patterns in a table?
Eclipse plugin or a Open source tool to reverse engineer java code for sequence diagram
BER-TLV open source library for Objective-C
open source libraries for facebook ,emails ,IM
How can I invoke a script at server side using the GUI of the already available open source server monitoring tools like Nagios, Cacti e.t.c.?
is there any open source library to convert doc file to p[df file in ios?
Open Source .net C# library for Real Time transport Protocol
open source svn client java library which can be used in commercial development
Open source e-commerce solution for a tool catalog based around EAV
Is there any open source java library to convert FIX messages to json format?
open source language recognition library?
Is there any open source library is available in android for resizing the image?
Open source wrapper library for all major brokers for submitting orders and getting prices?
Open source tool for zipped file content searching?
Facebook open source project FBCTF not starting after installation?
How would I include open source library in my iPhone application?
Open source spell checking library for Java
Is there an open source tool to distinguish speech from song?
Desperately trying to build open source tools (octave) on a Mac 10.6 Snow Leopard (involves Xcode, gcc, fink)
Open source ER diagramming tool for mysql
Facebook API key for an open source CMS
What's best Python open source library to draw chart?
Which tools is Best to make Accessible site ? open source or commercial?
Is there any open source project using graphviz c++ library?
```

I really need more close votes (I hear mods get infinite close votes `;)`). I have only included a very small subset of all the questions that are returned; there are THOUSANDS more.

Seriously, this query only focuses on one type of question; imagine what could be done if I were to write more queries...

Comment: regarding close votes, a while ago SE mgmt promised to ["start looking at increasing the number of close votes based on rep"](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/320971/839601). But I haven't heard anything about this since. Guess they have higher priority things to do, like getting moar postz and viewz

Comment: "*I have only included a very small subset of all the questions that are returned; there are THOUSANDS more.*" How many of those are false positives? That's the problem with doing keyword-based rejection here; it's way too easy to prevent someone from writing a legitimate question in their title. Thanks to banning the word "problem", we can't even have a question talking about the "Halting Problem" or "Traveling Salesman Problem."

Comment: I do believe that adding more close votes or close voting power or whatever is *not* the solution. Any proper solution needs to be automated; closing and other sorts of things should handle what few things get through the filter. SO needs better ways to stop low quality questions from being asked at all.

Comment: All that being said, I've noticed a number of patterns in the above list of stuff. Rather than filtering out a single word or phase, perhaps a smarter filter would filter questions based on multiple occurances of words/phrases within the same title. And instead of simply making it impossible to ask such questions (which is too easy to avoid and only hurts people who aren't asking bad questions), we send such questions directly to the review queue instead of being posted immediately.

Comment: @NicolBolas You can run the query yourself to see how accurate it is. I'm not suggesting that it be used without supervision, but it takes me about 3 seconds to know from the title of the question is off topic. I think that we just need a moderator to go through the list and close these questions.

Comment: @Laurel: "*I think that we just need a moderator to go through the list and close these questions.*" How often? Every 5 minutes? Every 15? Even if it was just ever hour, would you willing *volunteer* to come to SO and sift through 50 questions to see which ones are a false positive every hour? Moderators are supposed to be *exception handlers*; it's silly to expect this from them.

Comment: @NicolBolas I only mentioned mods because they have infinite binding close votes. I just want to see these questions closed; many of them are old.

Comment: @Laurel closed and deleted ;)

Comment: Your query is terribly inaccurate, and I am glad that users are required to gain oversight before crusading through problems as suggested here. Words in titles are a very weak indicator of the question content. Furthermore, many of the questions pulled are older questions when the closure reasons were much more relaxed. If you were to close everything returned by your query you would just needlessly plow over good content in the attempt to weed out low quality.

Comment: @TravisJ According to [this meta post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254389), we **should** close off-topic recommendation questions. If you don't want to use your CVs that way, fine, but it does not reflect the attitude of the site at large. And I don't know what you mean by "a weak indication of question content". What exactly are questions with titles like "Are there any open source tools for X" asking if not for a recommendation of tools? Also, closure isn't a death sentence, we can always reopen the question if it is edited to be on-topic.

Comment: @Laurel - Yes, we should and do. Unfortunately that isn't exactly what your query was returning. As I said, **it was inaccurate**. If using such a simple metric was possible, it would have already been done - there is just not enough precision here.

Comment: The type of question that annoys me the most are the questions that completely useless but don't fall under any of the close reasons. I downvote them, but i feel like i'm alone in that crusade when some 400k user comes along, answers it, and doesn't downvote.

Comment: @TravisJ Could you clarify what you mean by "inaccurate" then? What level of accuracy were you expecting? The query isn't intended as the final judgement; it's only intended to prescreen questions so that they can be quickly closed by people.

Comment: @KevinB I assume that you are talking about questions where the only one to benefit is the asker. I'm not sure if I'm up to the task of writing a query for that, if it's even possible. In case anyone's curious, I think my next query will target questions seeking debugging help where the code isn't in the question. Link rot helps nobody!

Comment: I don't use my close votes any more. It takes too much time to go through all the different categories and sub-categories. If we had just a three of them instantly available for clicking next to each post it would take a split of second to cast a vote.

Comment: @t3chb0t :( Maybe there's a user script? But I would take your CVs in an instant if it was possible... Tell me at least you downvote to feed the Roomba?

Comment: nope, I neither downvote nor upvote ;-] this time I'm impartial

Answer (score 25):

At the start of Stack Overflow it had better quality, because the most quantity of users were professionals.

Nowadays every [script kiddie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Script_kiddie) knows I can post my `DoesNotWorkException` on Stack Overflow, and I get (for example in `PHP`) instant five answers. And by definition, professionals are outnumbered.

I think we should stop rewarding people for answering bad questions.

Every discussion about similar topics see it from the perspective of a new user. How can we stop new users to do x and z?

Why not turn the perspective? What is if we remove reputation for answering a question, if the question itself is going to be closed?

- [Rep whores](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19522#19522) will notice, and they have no benefit in answering bad questions
- Script kiddies will see they don't get an answer for asking bad questions

Comment: I agree. I wouldn't mind seeing rep reverted for closed questions. But that might lend itself to some abuse. It also doesn't solve all problems (like CodeCaster's post and my comment on it - answers that _are not answers to the question_ because most of the readers did not understand the question).

Comment: This may slightly reduce the rep some of these users gain, however... it likely won't change the behavior. It's still going to be beneficial to the user to simply continue answering terrible questions since a large majority of them don't actually get closed.

Comment: "*At the start of Stack Overflow it had better quality, because the most quantity of users were professionals.*" Exactly! Not only were they providing quality answers, they were providing **quality questions**. Even if every answer to a bad question was removed, that would still leave a bunch of bad questions. What we need are users who are professionals asking more questions!

Comment: @Kevin Easily fixed: Make it so that you don't get any rep if the question itself has a negative score. Answers to bad questions don't help anyone, so there's no reason to reward them.

Comment: well.. you're getting into a gray area at that point. If they aren't helping anyone, why are they staying around... the answer is because those questions aren't off topic and don't fit any close reasons, because having a close reason for said questions often result in more good questions being closed than bad. Still feels like the wrong tool, it would simply encourage answerers to always upvote the questions they answer.

Comment: TBH I have the impression that in the old times Stack Overflow was a lot more tolerant for too broad / off-topic / unsure what you're asking questions.

Comment: @Voo I really like this idea, I would extend it to say you only get rep for upvoted answers on questions with a score of 1 or higher (not including your own upvote for said question). That way, people looking to increase rep will still answer questions that have a 0 (or less) score if they feel confident that the question is going to be well received by the community (eventually). And if it turns out that the question does not get any upvotes then they'll quickly learn to look for, encourage and *show people* how to ask higher quality questions.

Comment: Or all the answerers will upvote, thus circumventing it again.

Comment: @Kevin They are staying around because a gold badge person either has to spend extra efforts to find the right duplicate, or you need 5 people to actually cast a close vote. Considering the large amount of low quality questions being asked every day, it's just not feasible to expect all questions to get closed. Sure answerers could upvote the question (and if you're answering a question you don't think is actually worthy of an upvote, you shouldn't answer!), but it'd be less effort and require less people.

Comment: @tacone yes, it was, because the scope allowed for it and they were typically good/high quality questions. Nowadays such questions are off-topic and the justification is largely that such questions asked today usually suck (e.g. 'list all the jQuery libraries out there for menus')

Comment: [There are currently more than a half million questions with negative score that are not closed](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/493724). But yes I'd certainly agree that you want to hand out rep to answers for closed questions nor negatively scored questions. Both of those attributes clearly indicate low quality questions that should be removed and not rewarded. Not rewarding answering low quality questions would quickly cause low quality questions to not get any answers, thereby removing the incentive to ask them in the first place. I don't really see any downside there.

Comment: @Kevin at least to circumvent this requires more than one repwhore on their own, at which point the +2 or higher question score should attract other users to read it. And then if the newcomers can see what you describe has happened, they can downvote the question back to 1, 0, or even negative to reverse the effect. Alternatively they, or the original answerer(s) can make suggestions/edits to improve the question so the upvotes become justified.

Comment: It would indeed be great if we lived in a perfect world

Comment: For some it may have to start somewhere; https://www.reddit.com/r/programming/comments/2lyeqc/larry_pages_java_question_1996_every_journey/ It is very easy to judge and very easy to be wrong. Punishing a question is never a good idea. I have been searching google while learning new languages and newbie questions and the answers there really help me get to things faster than poor manuals...

Answer (score 16):

Low quality questions proliferate because the whole system is designed to *quickly* turn ignorant newcomers into users knowing how to abuse it and interested in doing so. Even if they start off not meaning harm and are potentially capable to learn better ways.

- Imagine yourself a totally new user. You post some [vague debugging](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/258685/839601) brainfart just to test the water, it gets through, okay. 90 minutes later you post yet another one, and another 90 more minutes later one more and so on, like 4 or 5 or maybe more "questions" this day to pollute the site.

  The next day you come back and discover yourself blocked because of yesterday questions (in case if this doesn't happen, you simply continue dumping garbage at usual rate until you hit the block).

  You also discover that some of your yesterday questions have gotten helpful hints in answers or in comments (you've asked quite a bunch meaning you've got really good chances to get help in some of them). That teaches you that it is indeed worth it to keep asking here.

  Because of that you start looking for ways to circumvent the block - such as creating new throwaway mail account and means to work around an IP address level block if you hit one. This is not complicated; it takes you maybe a day or two to learn.

  You may even share this new knowledge with colleagues or classmates who are also in the need for help - because you're not a bad person after all.

You see, it only took 2-3 days for one to turn from an ignorant well meaning newcomer into knowledgeable, motivated and successful abuser of the system; that's how it works.

---

Granted, they [recently tweaked](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/322265/839601) things a bit to make it less likely to happen *that* quickly:

> [Rolling rate-limits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/243460/165773) kick in faster. Like, *immediately*. If your first question is downvoted and you try to ask another one 40 minutes <sup>*(90 minutes at SO)*</sup> later, you'll be forced to wait at least a day...

This could possibly work; some things I observe indicate that the above change makes some difference. I find it particularly promising how the system leverages lower rep (125+) users into curating content: their downvotes now directly feed into throttling new askers.

The thing is though, as of now there is a large group of prior users who already learned the wrong way and know how well it works. How many of them are there, hundreds, thousands? How long it will take for this group to wear off so that "newer generation" of better educated and used to slower rate askers prevail?

Probably no one can tell. But I think that if the new approach will eventually take an effect, we will notice this by a substantial decrease of questions asked, probably in an order of thousands a day. Because frankly, currently we seem to be getting that many questions that shouldn't have been asked to start with.

Comment: _"If your first question is downvoted... you'll be forced to wait"_ - note if things indeed work this way then paradoxically pushing a poor question into [meta-tag:triage] increases a chance of the asker to hop over this throttling. Triaged questions are hidden and because of that may be less likely to get downvoted. Looks like an interesting case when two features intended to protect from low quality clash

Comment: And of course that established userbase of people abusing the system support each other, upvoting each other's content.

Comment: @Servy [rotten romance](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252077/839601) of help vampires and rep whores is sure at play here. Latter dump their answers at everything that's not closed in a hope to get +15 with accept, and their answers keep teaching abusers "that it is indeed worth it to keep asking here"

Comment: Meh, when all you look for is trash that is all you find. You being someone who is only reviewing, I am certain that all you encounter on Stack Overflow is content in need of removal or negative action and so that reflects on your overall outlook here. It is evident in not only this answer but overall in your commonly snarky comments across meta. Only punishing behavior is not enough, there must be positive reinforcement.

Comment: @TravisJ the way how site looks for those actively asking and answering in popular tags is pretty well laid out in this very question, I merely explain how it happens that so many low quality questions get in. And by the way throttling is not punishing... more like opposite. It is the system that indiscriminately accepts fast rate dumping that actually punishes people by repeatedly pushing them into question blocks. Recent changes do the opposite, they give askers more time to think how to improve and learn to ask better questions and enjoy the site and get real help here

Comment: @gnat - I am aware of the throttling system and its outlook. Perhaps you should read my post on that which prefaced the throttle question you cite here. **[I think that question bans would be more effective as a throttle than as a cutoff.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230857/no-one-likes-quitting-cold-turkey)**. You can make wild allegations, but that doesn't mean there is any weight to them.

Answer (score 13):

It is a major problem that all experts flee the site, this is the first sign of a site dying. And it has been going on for at least 3-4 years on SO, with the quality steadily decaying. Lower quality causes experts to leave, and less experts means lower quality.

I don't think we can fix the SO site, it is far too late. Moderators/developers have actively undermined quality over the years, by making posting rules and close-vote reasons more lax. So I would leave SO as it is: keep it newbie-friendly and crap-tolerant.

One viable solution to keep/attract the experts, is to create a sister-site, with the same concept, same moderation options, same tags. But with some changes to the rules. On the new site homework and beginner questions will explicitly not be allowed.

It would be a site for professionals only. It would be required that you have at least intermediate knowledge of the topic you ask about. Give gold tag users on the expert site the ability to immediately migrate any question back to the main site.

This site would preferably be created out of SO, so that if you have a user account on SO, you get one on the new site as well. Users share rep and privileges between the two sites. We can then require that you have a certain amount of rep to be able to post on the expert site. That way, most of the moderation burden falls on the main site and not on the expert site.

Something radical like this *has* to be done or SO will die. Personally, I would instantly leave SO at the very moment another site steals the whole concept but sets higher quality standards. Given the traffic on SO, I'm really surprised this has not already happened. Especially since a fair share of the SO community consists of web developers, who should have both the ability and the motivation to make such a site. Nobody wants to become a billionaire, apparently.

Comment: I suggested the opposite, but similar idea yesterday :) http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/324101

Comment: @Benjol You'll always get all kinds of crap questions just because people don't understand the site concept. Better then if they learn the SE concept on the default ("newbie") site than on the expert one. The easiest accessible site with the least strict rules should be the beginner one. That way the moderation burden is far lower than it would be if we had to migrate all beginner questions.

Answer (score 11):

**I am sorry to say I think it is far too late.**

When Stack Exchange started, the first users were readers of two very well-known development blogs and were mostly expert, highly-skilled programmers that cared about software design. Therefore, when an expert found the site (by googling for a solution to their problem, or otherwise), they found a collection of questions/answers often written by people that were experts. This tended to result in the expert becoming active on the site.

This still happens in some tags, where there is enough first-class content to keep the experts interested. *The PHP tag is the opposite of this!*

So unless we require all new users to prove they have a degree in Computer Science from a trusted university, I expect that the “quality” of new users will just keep declining.

Comment: "*they found a collection of **questions** / answers often written by people that were experts*" I agree! The main issue is that experts are not asking questions and we need to give them more incentive to do so.

Comment: @TravisJ, I expect the only solution is to ban none experts from the site, but that is hard to enforce.    (Stopping access from developing counties could also help, but would stop a few experts as well as a lot of the rubbish.)

Comment: @TravisJ: "*The main issue is that experts are not asking questions*" Utter nonsense. Experts are asking questions; they're simply being *drowned out*.

Comment: @NicolBolas - Clearly poor word choice on my part. *Enough* questions should have been what I said. I definitely agree that there is a sort of drowning out effect, how could there not be given the current circumstance. Of the last 500 questions *just* asked right this minute I counted only 6 users with more than 10k rep, and only about a dozen with more than 1k rep asking. That said, seeing so many low quality questions does have the effect of making an experienced user not want to add to the "fire hose" of questions already entering the system.

Comment: @NicolBolas -  So I think a two sided approach is definitely necessary. 1) Add incentive for "experts" to ask more questions and 2) Add barriers to stop the fire hose effect from users producing low quality questions.

Comment: @TravisJ: The other thing you have to realize is that... well, professionals just *don't have* that many questions that they can't answer on their own. They're professionals because they can *solve* problems. That's not to say that professionals can't contribute questions; of course they can. It just won't be of any significant quantity.

Comment: @NicolBolas - Yes, it is glaringly obvious that we solve our own problems. I will open dozens of tabs and spend days researching before I break down and ask a question here. Perhaps I should share some of that in a question, or others should - the start of troubleshooting can be rather vague sometimes and hard to nail down. Naturally as part of the problem solving process you narrow it down and eventually it becomes obvious what the issue was.

Comment: However, that doesn't mean that as a group professionals we shouldn't be able to ask broader more theoretical questions in my opinion - best practice is demonized now but it was prevalent at one point. Sometimes deeper questions are rather broad, and cannot easily be reproduced as well - for example examining different aspects of threading/connections/memory use, between code executing in debug versus release in Visual Studio. There is not really a facility for those types of questions at the moment. Those would be more significant.

Answer (score 11):

As a Java developer who has had to do PHP on occasion, I find it striking how different the description of the `php` culture here is from the actual `java` tag culture. Question askers in the `java` tag will get hounded to improve their questions by adding relevant information and removing irrelevant information, if their question isn't closed first. While there are occasional incorrect answers, correct, relevant, and up to date answers are generally sufficiently common for the questioner to have several to select from.

Perhaps the issue is not so much with the Stack Overflow culture, but rather with the PHP culture. Perhaps the issue is that PHP - let's not forget, that stands for "*Personal* Home Page" - is still dominated by amateur enthusiasts, where languages like Java and C++ tend to be dominated by professionals rather than enthusiasts.

Perhaps the actual PHP code in the industry - which as the question asker points out, powers a lot of sites - mostly still tends to be the outdated code that is typical of the answers he complains about. Perhaps the professionals are still just rare, and that's why there aren't enough professionally answered questions to go around.

Comment: PHP stands for Hypertext Processor ;).

Comment: It stands for *PHP: Hypertext Preprocessor*. Personal Home Page was the original meaning though.

Answer (score 9):

As a professional PHP developer who only recently got more active on SO, let me add a dissonant opinion based on my experience.

On one of my first answers I received "helpful" advice from a 8000+ reputation member that I thought was neither here nor there. I nevertheless tried to comply and stayed friendly, but I didn't find it very encouraging to be talked to like a newbie.

I did find the gaining of reputation addictive. On this meta site this is routinely mocked with terms like "reputation whore", but wasn't that whole system put in place exactly to be a motivator? Yet, looking at the "leagues" I find that high-reputation members who haven't been active here since 2015 gain as much reputation per month as I did in my busiest month yet. Logical, since they posted the great answers that people have been referring to for years. But the message I'm getting from that is that I'm joining the party late and will never be part of the in-crowd.

I'm not saying that all the other problems and suggestions for solutions here are not valid. I'm just suggesting that attracting new professional developers might not be helped by the fact that once people feel they're "in", they collectively behave like Statler and Waldorf looking down on the stupid crowd, and by a reputation system that has properties of a pyramid scheme.

Comment: "*But the message I'm getting from that is that I'm joining the party late and will never be part of the in-crowd.*" I'm not sure how you're getting that message. You will certainly never be in the all-time top reputation. But there's no special club or award to be gained for getting into that group. You don't need to be a top rep contributor just to participate.

Comment: Of course I understand that, rationally. And it doesn't actually stop me from answering questions. I'm just trying to explain how the system might have lost some of its motivating power for new-comers.

Comment: Hehe, reputation whore, meet reputation farmer. I personally think that reputation should have a half-life, but that would be a bit like telling French train drivers they can't retire at 45 :)

Comment: @NicolBolas Absolutely there are special clubs:  people with moderation privileges, people with hammer tags, etc.

Comment: @WarrenDew: My point is that your reputation *relative to others* is irrelevant. It doesn't matter that Jon Skeet has so much rep that nobody's ever going to catch him. You don't need to match Jon to reach 20K rep or get gold badges or whatever. Those are based on the merits of *your own content*, not relative to others. The "club" you're talking about has a fixed entry point, and it never moves.

Comment: @NicolBolas Your point is incorrect, because it is much harder to gain a point of reputation now than it was five years ago, and much harder then than it was ten years ago.  Most of the basic questions that everyone needs to know - and thus that gain hundreds or thousands of upvotes - have already been asked and answered long ago.

Comment: @WarrenDew: I haven't had problems gaining reputation recently. While admittedly, I do have a lot of residual rep coming in, I still answer questions, get upvotes and accepts, and so forth. And if the only questions you can answer are duplicates of basic questions... then you *shouldn't* gain rep. Rep is for contributing to the site, and repeated answers aren't much of a contribution.

Comment: @NicolBolas You can certainly still gain rep, though it takes longer without the farming.  Getting hammer tags on any but the most trafficked tags, not so much.  And some of the high (10s of k, not 100s of k) inactive users did get there just through answering basic questions; perhaps you shouldn't be able to do that, but there's still the fact that some did.

Comment: @WarrenDew: Nonsense. Gold badges for less trafficked tags are *easier* to get than the more popular ones. All you need is knowledge in the field and the ability to write a good answer. Less popular tags are also the ones with more unanswered questions.

Comment: @NicolBolas Not true for all such tags.  And the unanswered questions will rarely get you more than 1 upvote, and not even that unless you answer them promptly while the original asker is still looking for an answer.  After all, they're unanswered because they are obscure.

Comment: @WarrenDew: You know, I always thought that the "rep-whore" designation was a fictional construct, a boogieman developed by elitists to rally around and hate. That people who answer anything are simply people who *like* answering questions. That they do it because they enjoy it, not for rep. This discussion is making me reconsider that viewpoint. In my opinion, answering is *the goal*; reputation is merely *gratitude* for your contribution. That's the way the reward mechanic is supposed to work. When gaining rep becomes your goal, your behavior inevitably becomes problematic.

Comment: @NicolBolas Welcome to the real world.  Yes, StackOverflow looks different to people with 339 rep than to people with 180k rep.

Comment: @NicolBolas When you help me and I bring you chocolates, you might not start helping me more just to get chocolates, but the recognition has made helping me a more pleasant experience for you, so you're more likely to repeat it. The whole elaborate system of reputation and tags is set up to keep providing pleasurable feedback to helpers, so that you won't start thinking "pfff, chocolates again?".

Answer (score 6):

I have posted less than 20 questions and 20 answers on SO.  But I am a professional developer and have written increasingly complex systems for over 20 years.  I am not an SO God, but I am a proud and capable software engineer.

I ask questions after I've been banging my head against the wall for a couple of hours.  It may be a stupid error.  Your own stupid errors are the hardest to find.  My questions frequently get downvoted or ignored.  Probably because they're not easy to answer or because they're "poor quality" by a rigorous reading of the SO guidelines.

I answer questions when it's easy to do so or when I've found the answer to a question I've asked.  If I find the answer to a question, I always try to post it.

SO has been becoming less and less useful for me and I've been spending more and more time at CodePlex.  To keep SO useful to me, all it has to do is **Be Useful**.

Answer my questions, preferably by someone who has some basic knowledge of the problem and doesn't just copy-paste my question into Google.  I've already done that, you don't need to trouble yourself in that regard.

Basic courtesy and an upvote of a useful answer once in a while would be nice, but not necessary.  I just need to do my job.  And SO is becoming less and less useful to me.

I think that there is a substantial difference between people who spend a **lot** of time on SO and people who develop software professionally **and** do something non-SO related in their spare time.  I don't think that there is an easy cure for this because the problem is baked into the system.  They're two radically different populations with different cultures.

I think that maybe SO needs to be smaller.  If I had access to a couple of thousand pros in each of my particular areas of expertise, I would get higher quality answers and I would answer more questions.  After all, I get most of questions answered just by asking the people in the offices next to me. When that fails, it would be nice to have a bigger set of offices. ;-)

Comment: "...doesn't just copy-paste my question into Google. I've already done that..." Unfortunately, in doing that, you seem to be in the minority these days. That's part of the problem. Sounds like you may be in [a similar boat to Amy Blankenship, who commented above](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/324072/how-to-lure-professionals-to-stack-overflow#comment351024_324072).

Comment: @JoshCaswell Oh I'm definitely in that boat. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43415004/error-running-hololens-unity-project) got an answer, but I won't lie. Vikas is my coworker. We were on different versions of Unity and one day he decided to upgrade to be on the same version I was, encountered a problem, searched it and *found my unanswered question.* We had a laugh about him posting an answer. But keep in mind, I'd been in contact with *both* Microsoft and Unity for weeks and it wasn't until Vikas decided to upgrade that *anyone* was able to identify the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I hope my contribution to this discussion is well received based on the premises that I am no PHP professional by far or for any coding *yet* for that matter. I wish to be one, and I look up to the professionals that have written elegant solutions and explanations for me to become a better programmer.

The current situation I am noticing, (Stack Exchange is open the whole day on the computer) whenever I see broad, bad, and duplicate questions I treat them as such and don't give an answer, and instead I downvote/comment and move on. But in 50% or even more of these cases these kind of questions still get answers.

**Isn't that the root problem?**

Bad, broad, duplicate, etc. questions that receive answers. Now I was thinking that maybe people that answer these types of questions should also have some kind of punishment? (Sounds harsh maybe since all you are doing is helping the OP, but you are continuously degrading the quality of the site by doing so?)

Again I am no angel; I have had my share of adding low-quality questions and answers which I regret to this day and am already punished for, but I was a newbie who started off on the wrong foot. I am learning every day from the website without even posting questions and answers of my own, but learning from other **good** questions and answers that Stack Overflow provides.

So I propose to do something about the answers that are provided to low-quality questions. If I had the exact idea **how** I would lay it out, but my knowledge and privileges to the site are bare minimum, and I thought that assigning a "non professional view" on this matter might be appreciated.

Comment: "*Isn't that the root problem?*" No. The root problem is that the question was asked in the first place. Also, consider that "low quality" is a matter of opinion. And the fact that finding duplicates is not why people come to SO.

Comment: @NicolBolas I understand your perspective, but I think you can do more against the answers that are given to bad questions. Then people asking the bad questions in the first place? Low quality has a minimum set of standards requirements before it can be opinionated. I agree with the duplicates, you can't force it on people.... it's a tough matter.

Comment: At the end of the day, I don't buy that punishing answers will solve the problem. People post answers to bad questions all the time, here and on forums where there is no reputation system at all. Too many people just don't understand that the people who answer these questions simply want to *answer the question*; posting the answer is *fun* to them. Therefore, the only viable solution is one that stops the question from being asked altogether.

Answer (score 0):

This may indicate that Stack Overflow quality specifically on PHP questions is not sufficient to attract professionals, or even contains certain errors, misleading recommendations, that discourage from looking further. For these professionals, it may not be so important that, say, on C++ maybe the quality is excellent and information abundant.

It is very difficult to attract competent users to generate high quality content at this time. Removing bad quality answers may help, but only a competent PHP developer could do this.

Comment: I keep seeing people, both in answers and in comments, comparing PHP to C++, arguing that C++ questions are of significantly higher quality than PHP questions. That makes me want to either call bullshit, or cry. See, I don't know anything about PHP, and I don't follow the questions with that tag. Never looked at 'em. But I do regularly follow the C and C++ questions. And there are so many low-quality nonsense questions in the C and C++ tags that I think the entire community has concluded we have a *serious* quality problem. So either the claim we're better off than PHP is wrong, or ohmygod...

Comment: @CodyGray: I'm in your boat; I know very little about PHP. However, if you look at the questions in the tag, coupled with the sheer volume of it, I think your feelings will be more towards the "omygod" end.

Answer (score -2):

There have been many proposals to solve the quality problem by "filtering", for example by making tiers of reputation. They have all been rejected, some massively.

Yet a filtering solution would be attractive because it would have the potential to "make everybody happy". I guess that's the reason why it is proposed so often.
The second-most upvoted answer at the time of writing describes the problem as follows:

> But the underlying issue is the massive cruft in questions and
>   answers. The PHP experts you want to attract to the site have no
>   interest in sifting through 100 inane questions to find one they might
>   want to answer.

We need a filter!

I often go to profiles of experts to read the questions they answered, I have found many very interesting Q/As this way. Not that I would be able to contribute to these Q/As, but I think the key for building a filter of interesting stuff is not reputation or another generic metric, but what selected other SO members found interesting.

**I would like to be able to make a list of SO members, and have a tab on the homepage that displays questions that they found interesting.**
To mark something as interesting we could use

- a new button
- the upvote button, with the caveat that it would slightly breach voting privacy, but with the advantage of keeping it simple
- the favorite button, but I think it is not used often enough to be effective.

I would include my favorite experts and some members of a similar skill level and interests, to have both interesting stuff to learn from, and questions to answer.
Experts could add each other to their lists, and share the interesting questions easily.

This would be better than visits to profiles because it is much simpler, and would give more results because it would not only include questions that were answered by these members.
I know there is a feed feature, but I never tried it, and I think it has the same problem that it only includes questions with contributions from the selected members.

Admittedly it would not directly help in luring professionals to SO, but I hope it could help keep the ones that are already here.
It also wouldn't help against crappy answers, only questions.

(If this has already been proposed, please tell me and I'll delete this)

Answer (score -3):

I'm a professional. I contribute to SO. Whenever I face a problem that SO doesn't have an answer for (admittedly, this isn't often), I post an answer and often the question. What I don't do is open the SO homepage.

The "cruft" issue that others are complaining about doesn't actually exist for professionals. I don't see the cruft, because my interface to SO is DuckDuckGo. I see only things that are relevant to me, and not any of the n00b fix-my-codes junk.

So, forget trying to fix the homepage.

**Fix the experience of visiting existing questions and contributing to them.**

The site, currently, overwhelmingly rewards people who write answers while the question is still fresh at the expense of late-comers. That's why my rep is much lower than my "people reached." This is because:

- The answer sorting that overwhelmingly favors old answers makes it unrewarding to provide new (updated, or just better) answers to existing questions.
- Similarly, the accepted answer needs to be updated as well, and not by the question asker who may not be using the site.
- The people who browse the homepage aren't knowledgeable enough to know if a nuanced answer to a difficult question is right or not. The people who know which answer is best are visitors from the internet who are using the answers. They are disenfranchised and cannot vote the answer up.

I'm sure there's lot of other applicable ideas. Please focus on the search engine visitors. They're your professionals.

Professionals also love open-ended, philosophical questions. Quora attracts a huge amount of famous professionals on various topics, because it lets them pontificate and express themselves. SO is extremely restrictive. It doesn't just forbid non-programming questions, but also many programming questions which are "too broad" or ask for recommendations, etc. If you're looking to build *community* (and boost homepage visits), allowing this chit-chat would actually bring a lot of people in. This chit chat won't "lower the quality/relevance of the site," because, the search engine filters all!

Comment: Um, just because you use SO only through search engines doesn't mean that other professionals do too. Also, I disagree that "*Most of the visitors that a late answer gets are from the public internet.*" Maybe you don't know this because you don't visit the homepage, but when you post a late answer or edit an answer, that bumps the question on the homepage. So you're hardly "disenfranchised".

Comment: "*Professionals also love open-ended, philosophical questions.*" Absolutely not. SO being "extremely restrictive" is a *feature*, not a bug. If that turns you off... tough. We don't need people "pontificating" here.

Comment: The "accepted" answer has never been labeled as the "correct" answer except by people who don't read up on what it means. "Search engine visitors" include a vast number of people. I would think that, as they outnumber us in the general population, enthusiast and other non-professional programmers visit Stack Overflow in much greater numbers than professionals.

Comment: +1. Also agree about the homepage. It is useless noise. I don't know why it exists...

Comment: If you only browse the site using search engines, how do you find questions to answer? (cc @cypher) I agree that most of what is presented on my homepage sucks, but it's still the most convenient way for me to find interesting questions to answer. I don't mean to be rude, but it sounds like you and Aleksandr are not the professionals we are trying to attract. We want to attract experts who can provide high-quality answers to difficult programming questions, not people who just want to read their contributions. Yeah, those people get here via search. We get plenty of 'em already.

Comment: @CodyGray "We want to attract experts who can provide high-quality answers to difficult programming questions." If I find a programming question that I can answer definitively, I will do so. To assume otherwise simply because I can't stand the design of the homepage is completely asinine. I don't see how you're going to attract anybody with statements like that, pal.

Comment: Who the heck is downvoting this answer?  It's right on all counts.

Comment: @WarrenDew: Obviously, that would be people who don't agree that "it's right on all counts."

Comment: @cypher Sorry, as I said, I didn't mean to offend you or denigrate your expertise. I actually don't know you, so I couldn't judge your experience if I wanted to. Nor have I evaluated any of your contributions here, so I couldn't even make a subjective and incomplete judgment. Nor do I wish to. I believe you are missing my point. For example, you say: *"If I find a programming question that I can answer definitively..."* Yup, me too. But this is the problem: ***if you can find one***. Increasingly, there are not enough to be found, and no one is able to find them.

Comment: @WarrenDew The people who hang out on the homepage.

Comment: @CodyGray Easy. I find questions to answer by stumbling upon a problem I can't solve, not finding its solution on SO, finding a solution by other (much more labor intensive :) means, and posting that solution. Those are the highest-quality answers to the most difficult questions.

Comment: @AleksandrDubinsky I highly agree with you, we need more people like you who aren't obsessed with rep if we want SO to improve. Browsing meta gives everyone the wrong impression that everyone cares about rep, a lot of us (like me) don't.

Comment: @NicolBolas I edited my answer to address your concerns. In particular, I made my "we need to enfranchise internet users" argument more subtle. But I also know there is somewhere another reason that late answers get very few votes.

Comment: @AleksandrDubinsky: Maybe you don't understand. I disagree with your *entire premise*. The idea that the best, most knowledgeable SO users are drive-by users rather than people who visit the site regularly is both ridiculous and insulting. Your notion that the best answers are late answers to questions is equally not born out by any actual evidence. Is the system de-facto biased against late answers? Yes; you will not be rewarded as much for late answers as earlier ones. But should a good answer be automatically pushed aside just because someone came by with a long one?

Comment: @NicolBolas Maybe we're just talking about different classes of questions/answers. You are talking about the more frequent, *easier* questions that already have great answers (written by knowledgeable regulars). And you're right, they don't need new answers (for now). And you probably see a lot of activity on them and think about them a lot. In contrast, I am focusing on the fewer-pageviews questions that don't have good (or up-to-date) answers. They're the ones I think about, because whenever I hit one I hit a snag in my work.

Comment: @CodyGray Thanks, and I agree with that last part. I have trouble finding interesting questions to answer as well. Most of them can be answered by reading the appropriate documentation.

Comment: @NicolBolas *"The idea that the best, most knowledgeable SO users are drive-by users rather than people who visit the site regularly is both ridiculous and insulting."* I agree, but I don't think that's what he meant. It's certainly not how I interpreted this answer. I don't find the SO search/homepage very useful in finding questions, so I tend to use a search engine (Google, DDG, whatever) and scroll around until I find something related that was posted on SO. I don't consider myself a drive-by user at all, it's just a different workflow.

Comment: As an example: [http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/324261/218125](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/324261/218125)

Answer (score -4):

For the issues of bad questions getting answered for rep:

Make the rep gained from answering a question relative to the question's score:

Not sure exactly what the algorithm would be. <0 question score nets 0  reputation for an answer, regardless of upvotes. 0 score nets some number less than 10 points per upvote, upvotes for an answer are not worth 10 points until the question reaches a minimum upvote threshold.

Certainly there are some issues with that rough draft of an algorithm, but the overall idea is to try to reward good answers for *good* questions, and *not-reward* decent/mediocre answers for *bad* questions.

Answer (score -9):

Stack Overflow is interesting in its ability to help others. And at the other end, this is the easiest way to contribute to open (knowledge) source.

For me Stack Overflow is not about getting quick answers once I post; for me it is like Wikipedia with more features; insight to the general industry trend by the upvotes, ability to better or improve someone's answer based on your experience on the topic.

The questions I usually get about answering or more- just improving, are answered in detail, years back and having usually not much activity. Newer technologies have faster response times to questions; over time most questions are duplicates and naturally should not have an answer and smarter people are answering other things.

Comment: Imagine  Wikipedia had something like several hundred articles on the New York city? And one first linked in google is a copy/paste from Encyclopedia Britannica, 1913. And every single day a fresh college student decides to start an article on the New York city. So now you have a good picture of the Stack Overflow version of Wikipedia.

Comment: @YourCommonSense I agree. SO should let users edit existing answers to make them materially better rather than insisting they write a new, largely similar answer. (I've already been chided for putting this idea into practice.) SO should be a bit more wiki-like.

Comment: @AleksandrDubinsky: "*SO should let users edit existing answers to make them materially better*" Right. Because the "edit" button doesn't exist.

Comment: @NicolBolas This was the message to me from a mod: "Please do not rewrite answers that are not yours; even when you have the best intentions of updating them for the current times." in reference to: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/8693381/revisions

Comment: @NicolBolas Also, please try to be nicer (don't use sarcasm)

Comment: @AleksandrDubinsky: There's a difference between correcting answers and changing them. Your edit tried to do both.

Comment: @YourCommonSense There is nothing preventing people from keeping on adding aswers every day; but most people don't do that most of the time; Aswers become outdated with time sometimes, though some questions dont

Comment: example encountered now on real usage - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32970709/how-to-split-a-rdd-into-two-or-more-rdds lots of others are there which I have encountered as well

Answer (score -11):

How about imposing a quick survey after submitting a question, like:

- How long did you do your own research?
- Did you try debugging?
- Is this for a school assignment?

Comment: Yeah, because everyone knows the rule that survey questions must always be answered honestly.

Comment: I think it's one thing to ignore rules and another to lie. Obviously it want get close to solving the problem but maybe a little closer.

Comment: They were forced to confirm that they read the rules before posting.  Basically nobody does though.

Comment: @Servy I think direct questioning is more effective

Comment: You said you don't think people would lie.  Approximately 100% of them already have.

Comment: @Servy Asking people to "go read the rules" is a TALL order. Up there with asking "have you read the EULA?" Pointed questions (with non-binary answers) are, in relative terms, far more effective. At least, the user will end up aware of the rules and won't get angry if his question is closed.

Comment: When people post comments asking those kinds of questions they're virtually never answered, and people just get mad at the inference that they should actually do those things.  So, no, there's considerable evidence that they *wouldn't*.

Answer (score -12):

Stack Overflow is designed to be a single global community, a centralized source of information. From an information perspective this is great.

From a people perspective, smaller communities are often better. This is evidenced in the non-English Stack Overflow sites (perhaps younger is better as well ☺).

It is fortunate that we have a metric (reputation points) to help us separate the 'users who care', from the 'floaters and newbies'.

I think that if we provided some separations between lower-rep and higher-rep users, then we could gain some of the benefits of a smaller community, without needing to create a separate site.

Perhaps there should be a new **tab on the home** page which only shows questions from **users with >X reputation** (100?, 200?). This can be included in the Privileges database so that new users understand the need to invest in the site before they can reap the greatest rewards.

We have to do something to keep the experts - right? The nice thing about this is that a 'no-rep' expert (prospective Stack Overflow member) can more easily find the good content, and can even go ahead and answer some of them.

Comment: Rep isn't a great judge of posting quality (though it can be helpful), especially for great programmers who don't have much rep. It'd just frustrate them.

Comment: This assumes that all good programmers are already members of the site and have gained reputation over the years. What happens when John Carmack shows up and creates an account to ask a question about a tricky problem he's encountered? This is exactly the type of interesting question that would attract experts and their answers, but in your system, it would be buried on a list of "Bogus Questions" that no one would ever look at, because he has < 100 rep. Also, all of the regular arguments about a community dying when it completely turns inward and becomes insular.

Comment: @ZachSaucier It is at least a somewhat accurate measurement. At least when I look at the "top users" page (most rep) in the tags I frequently visit, I can easily recognize _all_ of the people listed there as skilled experts.

Comment: When I said 'floaters and newbies', I was referring to floaters in life, who have 'just created' their accounts. (1 rep point) If they stick around awhile on the same identity then I think it is easier to manage them.

Comment: @Lundin Looking at the top users is one thing. Assuming that all mid range users in terms of rep are skilled is a flaw, as is assuming all low rep users are bad or ask poor questions