# The life of answering questions on Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, answers, question-quality

You may have noticed recent discussions regarding how best to improve the signal-to-noise ratio, reducing or suppressing low-quality posts from less-invested persons trying to avoid work, and encourage professionals and folks legitimately and politely trying to learn the art of software development.

- [How to lure professionals to Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/324072/how-to-lure-professionals-to-stack-overflow?cb=1)
- [Should Stack Overflow be more restrictive about new user registrations?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/324220/should-stack-overflow-be-more-restrictive-about-new-user-registrations/324227)

(I am not a frequenter of Meta Stack Overflow, so I don't have all the best links.)

My question is: What is it like for someone trying to answer questions at this time? I answer fewer questions than I ask, so my personal point of view is limited.

The folks who really help me out have answered many more questions, and frequently answer questions within 15 minutes of them being posted. How do they do this?

- Monitor the home page?
- Custom search?

And what are the main obstacles for them?

- How easy is it to find good questions?
- What is missing here? Is there anything awkward about trying to answer questions?
- Do you randomly show up and answer a question here or there, or do you sit down and work through systematically?

Can I get answers from people who answer a lot of questions on Stack Overflow?

I'm afraid this question is too broad, but I think it would be good to get an overview of 'the experience answering' and what it is like at this time. So we have a better definition of what the main problem is, from the premise that the folks we are trying to serve are the professionals who can answer questions.

Comment: When i was actively answering questions on SO, i would sit on the home page waiting for new questions to be posted in the tags i'm interested in, and then answer them. Not much to it really.

Comment: I'm not good at the FGITW game so I use a custom search to find questions that have some score/views and no answers in my favorite tags.

Comment: This is a unique quesion that I can see. I am interested to hear people's answers and comments. I can't write quick answers so am better at being on at quieter network times of grabbing questions that have sat around unanswered for a day or so.

Comment: I bounce between the fire hose (all newest questions) and perusing through the highly voted this week list.

Comment: I've become active only about last 3 months, so here is fresh experience. I first look at bounties, if nothing there I look at rare tags (for example most of my answers are for .NET-related stuff, so I look at "mono" and similar tags - there are few questions and answers there). Then I look at unaswered questions which live for at least an hour. If nothing helps - I open home page for "C#" tag (because it's widest - appears in almost all questions I'm interested in) and look there from time to time (most questions there are really "not good" to be honest).

Comment: I have favorite tags set. When I get a bit bored or just need to shift my attention to something else for a bit I hit refresh on the home page and quickly scan down for questions that don't already have answer and might be something I know something about. Then most of the time I find the question is vague or incomplete and ask for clarification which, sadly, often isn't forthcoming.

Comment: +1 for "Fire hose", @Travis J  ;-)

I simply browse to my "tags of experience" and look for unanswered q's ... if it's well worded I smile and click, and if not so much (or has negative score), I close my eyes, pray, and then push the mouse button, secretly hoping the pointer has changed position while my eyes were closed ;-)

Comment: I have tried for well over a year to be productive on here. I have learned that people are rude and have egos, which results in me always getting downvotes when I try to be productive. I then delete my questions to try to save rep, so I can still be helpful, and that ends up getting me in more trouble. I cannot ask questions now, and still occasionally look for people to help, although I do not try as hard as I used to because of the bad experience.

Edit: Even though one of my answers was accepted by the user, I still got downvotes on answers before.

Comment: A few times a day I scroll through the list of questions starting from the end and try to avoid any question more recent than 30 minutes.  Newer questions tend to have others racing to answer them and I don't like to hurry.  Those questions also tend to be lower quality.  By the time they get to 30 minutes the really bad ones are either closed already or have a few down votes.  Most of the remaining questions are just plain unanswerable (not bad per se but the author doesn't have all the details needed) or I don't know the answer.  Once every other day or so there is one I can answer.

Comment: @brad You seem to be claiming that people downvote questions because of their egos. In my personal experience, I find that to be not at all true. I downvote questions that are unclear, show pathetically little research effort, or are simply impossible to answer on a Q&A site (usually because they're asking me to write an entire app for them). I think most people vote the same way. I don't even know how it would make sense to downvote based on ego. I am smarter than you, so I downvoted your question? Why would anyone do that? Why wouldn't they just post the answer? Voting is *quality control*.

Comment: how does it feel to ask questions?

Comment: When I joined the site years ago I still enjoyed answering questions, but now it feels like a waste of time. There's gonna be a rep whore swooping in to get that #1 spot – maybe half of the time by actually putting in more effort, the other half of the time just the fact that they already have 50k rep gets people to upvote their post. If for every question someone will not rest until they supersede your answer anyway, then why take the effort to write something? It's not a problem if you only care about getting answers, but for the engagement of other users than the 1% it's a huge bummer.

Comment: @CodyGray I  always take time to format my posts and make sure they are not bad questions. If people are going to downvote something of mine, they should at least take the time to explain why they are going to downvote it.

Even if my opinion is not true, I speak for myself and my classmates and colleagues who feel this way. It has not been a welcoming community. That being said, the majority of people I know never take the time to help others like I know they could because their perception of it.

Comment: @joren When you tire of the reputation rat-race is when you have to start tackling the more difficult questions, the ones that don't get immediate answers by rep whores. They take a little bit more investment of time and energy, and they don't necessarily net you oodles of rep, but they are more rewarding, both morally and intellectually.

Comment: @CodyGray: No doubt you're right, but unfortunately I don't really have any relevant expertise on subjects that are specific enough. Or maybe I just don't know how to find any interesting questions that no one is answering.

Answer (score 221, accepted):

Update February 2017:

It has gotten A LOT worse.  I keep some canned comments in a post-it on my desktop, and the last few days I've been able to leave one in my clipboard and paste it continuously:

> Sorry, this is not the way StackOverflow works.  Questions of the form *"I want to do X, please give me tips and/or sample code"* are considered off-topic.  Please visit the [help] and read [ask], and especially read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/18157)

That, plus another

> Sorry, this is not how StackOverflow works.  Questions of the form *"Here's a bunch of my code, please debug it for me"* are considered off-topic. Please visit the [help] and read [ask] for more information.

get used on over ¾ of new posts in the [java] tag.  Needless to say I exhaust my daily votes in less than an hour.

As others have noted, it is the total lack of automated filters on posting that is responsible for this.  Even a simple form for low rep users, à la basic Bugzilla with boxes for "Your Code", "What should it do", "What actually happens", etc would go a long way towards stemming the tide.

But I strongly suspect SE's business model depends on raw eyeball impressions, and anything that makes it harder to post interferes with that.

Somewhere along the line the original ideal of being a repository of high-quality questions/answers, as a reference base for the future, has gone by the wayside.

---

In 7½ years I have answered about 90x as many questions as I have asked (1919 to 21 so far). I ask questions so rarely because I almost never encounter problems that I cannot resolve with a simple Google search or careful RTFM. Very often Google leads me to an answer on SO.  I never search SO directly because Google does such a superior job compared to SO's search capability.

As to answering, I have a "session" about once a day of 45-90 minutes and I set up a filter for the tags I'm interested in. Initially I'll scan the filtered list for interesting looking questions regardless of whether or not they already have answers, and contribute where I can.  After the initial scan I wait for new questions to come in.

In a session most of my time is spent:

1. Asking for clarification in a comment
2. Dup-hammering to [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it) (my focus is Java)
3. Asking first-time posters to visit the Help Center and read How To Ask, and explaining why their question is off-topic

I consider myself lucky if I find ONE question worth answering per session, and I usually don't bother with trivial answers where I'd be competing for FGITW, unless the question hasn't gotten any answers and is over 10-20 minutes old.

I only recently learned to adjust my attitude and not take personally the declining S/N ratio.  Whereas before I felt duty-bound to respond to "give me teh codez" and similarly bad posts with a message (see item 3 above).  I now accept that those posts will always be a part of SO.  I ignore them if I can tell from the title, and otherwise I just downvote, VTC and move on, spending as little time on them as possible.  Life's too short.

One thing I'd really like for SO to implement is a better heuristic for duplicate detection.  As a result of SO's success, I'd guess over half of the non-noise questions are now duplicates (my own gut feel, not backed up by anything), but finding the canonical answer is not easy.  A curated list of canonical Q/A for very common questions would be extremely helpful, but I doubt it will happen.

<SOAPBOX>
This will make me sound like an old fogey, but having been a developer since the mid '70s it's amazing how each generation reliably repeats the mistakes of the previous one.  I think SO has the potential to mitigate that by providing long-term memory of problems and their solutions.  However it cannot do anything about the hubris of youth, and the culture that values youth and enthusiasm over expertise and wisdom.  But then, this was an issue in Aristotle's day as well, so there's nothing new ...
</SOAPBOX>

So, after re-reading my post and rant, and the comments and other answers I feel compelled to offer this...

<COUNTERPOINT>
While it is true that youth and inexperience lead to repeating the prior generations' mistakes, it is also true that some of the most important breakthroughs were made by people who "didn't know any better", or tackled an old problem in a new way exactly because they weren't blinkered by the obviously "right" solution.  In other words, some amount of making the same mistakes repeatedly is part of each generations' learning process.  It wold be nice to find the optimal point, but I suspect we'll just continue muddling onwards, repeating mistakes, and occasionally those "mistakes" will lead to novel solutions.
</COUNTERPOINT>

Comment: Ditto, likewise and same here (except for me it's C/C++/SIMD rather than Java). Very good summary.

Comment: Yeah, I can't believe how often the NullPointerException one still keeps coming up...

Comment: I've been programming since the early 90s and I never once thought, I'll just ask someone else...I would use the primitive search engines, books and trial and error to work my way through a problem. I don't understand the attitude of the *"giv me codz now!"* generation *(292 to 5 so far)*.

Comment: For those like me:  
FGITW - Fastest Gun in the West (situation when first answer gets most upvotes)
RTFM - read the fu...folowing manual

Comment: Perhaps we can introduce a "canonical" tag, for posts that are frequently referred to as the originals? This has the added benefit of giving newbies a browseable  repository of "good" questions.

Comment: Why did you put the SOAPBOX tag? Did you mean <kbd> ? Or is there something pun-ny which I am missing?

Comment: @Hackerdarshi, lookup images for "soapbox speech". Or Hyde Park Corner :)

Comment: FGITW implies a lot more than that, @zan. There is a strong implication that, in the race to take advantage of the stated fact that the first answer gets the most upvotes, people post short, crappy, typically only partial answers. In other words, there is a seriously quality issue. Everyone pretty much agrees that a *good* fast answer is a desirable feature. :-)

Comment: @Benjol Thanks! results for "soapbox speech" were enough to understand it.

Comment: Pretty much my experience (Q/A 4/95, with all of my Questions self answered either because noone responded or because I was just documenting the question/answer that I found an answer to somewhere other than SO, and couldn't find an answer to on SO), except I then migrated onto review queues before I lost interest a bit.

Comment: Sometimes I FGITW. But I get a basic correct answer up. Then I edit it to be more complete, or even include screenshots if necessary. If someone posts a correct answer in the meantime and mine is *wrong*, I'll delete mine and upvote theirs. It's possible to go for first answer and not be a dweeb about it. :)

Comment: Trust me you were on your soapbox long before you used the soapbox tag

Comment: @GeorgeJempty It shows?

Comment: So much +1 for dupe detection. So frustrating when you know a dupe exists but can't find it.

Comment: Upvoted because of the last sentence. :)

Comment: Great soapbox rant. Unfortunately each new generation re-invents pre-existing solutions because NIH is a very alluring temptation.

Where's the fun in implementing a well-established, time-tested solution when you can reinvent the wheel and take credit for it?

Comment: Best Answer @Jim, It's like as if I am reading my own thoughts.

Comment: can you give an example of reliably repeating mistakes?  Are you talking about something like i.e. inventing a concept of NoSQL 'by mistake', and then dealing with same very same old issues that were present for decades?  Or something entirely different?

Comment: @Lankymart ... well while I figure out some things, and had taken formal University classes in CompSci, SO has been instrumental in teaching me the ways of OO and design patterns and ways of thinking in ways I had not expected.  It was like taking a personal class with a tutor.  Despite taking OO in college, learning on my own + SO (sharing experience with others) is and was fantastic.  I am a much better programmer/coder than I was before in no insignificant part due to SO and my own effort.

Comment: @Dennis that's partly the point when it comes to SO you get what you put in, it's that simple.

Comment: I started enjoying SE a lot when I started just downvoting/voting to close questions fitting (1).

Comment: Side note: [AutoReviewComments](http://stackapps.com/questions/2116/autoreviewcomments-pro-forma-comments-for-se#) instead of a post-it :)

Comment: @BenjaminW. I could then exhaust my daily vote quota even more quickly. SO has become Quora.

Answer (score 34):

Right now, I have 468 answers and 34 questions. I've learned much more by answering even seemingly novice questions than I've ever learned by asking my own questions. I've also learned much more by *not* asking my own questions, than by asking them. See, whenever I try to write a *very good* question, the answer becomes obvious to me.

> The folks who really help me out have answered many more questions, and frequently answer questions within 15 minutes of them being posted. How do they do this? Monitor the home page?

Yep.

After having set up favorite tags (that I know a few things about) and ignored tags (for technologies I have no interest in), I just visit the home page every now and then look for titles that might grab my attention.

Note that I'm not always browsing tags for technologies I know *a lot* about. I also browse tags for technologies I'd like to learn more about about. I sometimes learn by finding unanswered questions and taking the time to read up on and experiment with the technology -- enough to be able to write my own answer, at least.

> How easy is it to find good questions?

As easy as it is to find bad ones, except for the fact that they appear less commonly.

Sometimes, the quality of a question isn't immediately obvious. A badly written or formatted question may be just that ("give me code please", "do my homework please"). Or it may be something very interesting that the OP just couldn't articulate yet because at the time he wasn't familiar enough with the technology in question. It takes some practice to be able to find these diamond-in-the-rough questions.

Some other times, a bad question will simply happen to attract great answers. Great answers can make a question popular (possibly even the canonical question on the issue) and that popularity will attract more people willing to retroactively improve the question by fixing style issues, grammar issues, removing clutter, and so on. Great questions aren't always great from the start.

> Is there anything awkward about trying to answer questions? Do you randomly show up and answer a question here or there, or do you sit down and work through systematically?

There is something on Stack Overflow that I only managed to realize very recently.

Most question titles sound hard. When I'm browsing through them in the home page, it's almost certain that they will involve technologies I don't know about, libraries I've never used, sometimes even words/phrases I'm not familiar with.

But if you click on them and view the actual question, most of them are actually pretty easy. They involve the OP not understanding the programming language they're using, not understanding a specification well enough, not having read the error message, not interpreting the error message as they should, not knowing how to debug systematically, not picking up on a clue, and so on. (These questions may sound bad, but they give you an opportunity to not only answer, but answer with enough detail to make the OP more familiar with the context of the problem and with techniques and methodologies that could help them solve the problem on their own in the future.)

So for me, the days when I write one or more well-received answers aren't the days when Stack Overflow happens to be teeming with easy questions or questions relevant to my interests. They are the days when I just sit down and say to myself "okay, I'm *really* in the mood to answer something, let's see what's available". If I do that, the questions somehow just fall into place.

Comment: I fully agree that there have been numerous times I have found a solution to my issue by writing a full and proper SO question, so that the question becomes needless.

Comment: It's basically rubber duck debugging, but into the SO question box rather than an animal :)

Comment: "I've learned much more by answering … than I've ever learned by asking my own questions." This is my experience verbatim and the primary reason I use SO. Good answer.

Comment: @Martin, if that happens to me, I write the question regardless, and then the answer too. You never know who else it could help.

Comment: @Benjol I have on occassion (once comes to mind) but often it's frustrating that I put 40 minutes into a good question ad then once I see the answer it appears obvious, so less worth posting... (for someone who spots the answer straight away to be -1ing),

Comment: HA, +1 for solving my own issue while asking a question about it. Pretty sure I've done that a dozen times by now.

Comment: @Martin, isn't the fact that you spent 40 minutes on it proof that, though it seems obvious, it may be just unobvious enough to warrant a self-answered question? This also depends on whether you receive your points back when a downvoted Q&A is deleted, if fake internet points are your thing. I would err on the side of helping, if my questions weren't all about poorly designed highly proprietary APIs right now... Still, 40 minutes rubber duck debugging is better than getting stuck for far too long.

Comment: @Poik The problem with writing a question that's so complete that it answers itself is that, once that happens, it feels pretty pointless in your head afterwards. You have to actually *change* the question and rephrase it in an *intentionally incomplete* way before it can lend itself to a Q&A format.

Comment: @Poik it's more that the answer becomes obvious through the explanation, that someone (other SOers) read the question and then by the end think "well duhh, you do this" but the "do this" part isn't always clear *until* the question is formed. The -1 part is just me giving a (slightly) glib reference, my stronger feeling/point is that through the process of forming the question, the answer becomes more obvious, :)

Answer (score 32):

I've no idea how typical it is! but my approach is generally that I have a number of tags set up, and whenever I've got ten minutes spare (or I haven't got ten minutes spare and just want to let my mind escape for a while!) I'll scroll through the list and see what titles catch my eye.

The tags I watch are pretty quiet, so I don't have the problems that the big tags have.

Titles will either draw me in because I think I might be able to answer, or because I'm curious about the answer to the question / the question in general.

At that point it is the decision to vote up / down / close, ask for comments to clarify, or maybe if the question is off topic, I'll say so in comment and sometimes give the answer there too if it is simple enough.

After all of that, if I've got an answer I'll write it up. Occasionally that can take a while to do, as most of the time answering the question is as much about broadening my knowledge as it is about providing an answer. Which usually starts with 'well that can't be that hard' and ends after a four hour search, and standing up a couple of VMs to see that actually it really does do that.

I've not been here for particularly long, and the SNR is acceptable on the tags I do. I see the frustrations of the off topic posts, but we have a public resource that is generally a good source of information. It is foolish to think that people aren't going to come and use it as the path of least resistance. It perhaps frustrates me more that those with a decent amount of rep feed in to that loop by answering bad questions with bad answers.

I can say though, that having come here originally from answering on MS Answers it is infinitely easier to ask, and receive quality questions / answers here.

Comment: Same approach for me.

Comment: *"It perhaps frustrates me more that those with a decent amount of rep feed in to that loop by answering bad questions with bad answers."* Yes. This.

Comment: @SiHa, how do you think they got their rep? ;)

Comment: @IanS. Indeed. Sad, but true.

Answer (score 20):

I "monitor" SO throughout the day, by simply checking my favorite language page whenever I have a lull in my activity (compiling, running tests, ...).

I do not necessarily seek questions to answer; instead I primarily seek interesting questions (to learn from), and if in the process I find:

- questions I have already seen or I feel should already exist: I hunt a duplicate
- questions I can answer: I answer
- questions I feel I should be able to answer: I work on until I find a satisfactory answer... or abandon and watch for an answer
- questions I cannot answer: I watch for an answer
- interesting questions that have been answered: I read the answers, and sometimes feel compelled to write another answer if I feel the treatment was too shallow/incomplete or missed aspects I judge important

*Note: in the process I might of course edit, ask for clarifications, etc...*

In order to find questions that interest me, I simply watch a particular language tag. I used to watch C++ and C++11, but as I gained expertise and the level of questions went down, I lost interest. I now primarily watch the Rust tag.

Comment: I have a similar process. My "monitoring" amounts to always having a tags page open (`[tag1] or [tag2] or [tag3] or ...`) and looking from time to time whether the tab title has changed to indicate a new question (I sort by newest, but two years ago I sorted by "active" until it was too much, but it was a great way to keep a low traffic tag clean).

Comment: @ArtjomB.: Same here, the tab is pinned and I wait until the color of the bar changes telling there's a new question :)

Answer (score 12):

I get email notifications on my areas of interest. When I start to get bored with the work I should be doing, I scan the StackOverflow mails to see if there are any questions where I could have more fun and procrastinate a little. I choose the ones that are a little bit unusual but aren't going to take all day. I don't care a damn about brownie points and bounties, I'm here to have fun not to earn badges - I got over that phase at primary school. Then when I get back to the day job I feel a bit more energized and come to it with a clearer mind.

Comment: And the one thing that really irks me like mad is people downvoting without saying why. If you want to criticise, do so openly.

Comment: Obviously by having just over 4000 answers you're not in the target demographic of _"users who answer a lot of questions"_. Or so I suppose. Did you really find all those questions just from the mail notification?

Comment: I see how you put that little rant about anonymous downvoting in a comment so people couldn't, in good conscience, justify downvoting the answer itself. Clever way to take advantage of the fact that comment voting is one-way. Honestly, Michael, 99% of what I downvote, I am downvoting it for such a blatantly obvious reason that having to leave a comment would be a waste of my time and an insult to my intelligence. If I see a real, legitimate attempt at an answer that just happens to be wrong, I will *definitely* leave a comment, as will most people. I'll even change my vote later if it's fixed.

Comment: Your reason for downvoting may be obvious to you but that doesn't make it obvious to the person you are downvoting. When I complain about anonymous downvoting it is invariably because someone has downvoted an answer and I would like to know why.

Answer (score 11):

For someone trying to answer questions, I think it's hard.

For me, I have favorite tags set up. I'd like to use the tabs to better organize tags and monitor questions, but the new UI navigation doesn't persist across computers. When you use multiple computers (in my case, 3 - a home desktop, a home laptop, and a work computer) throughout your day to browse Stack Exchange sites, not having the persistence is not that useful. Since the new navigation UI is limited, I typically just hit up the homepage and refresh every so often. Due to the volume of Stack Overflow questions, the homepage doesn't have a banner when new questions appear unless you have applied filters. This does lead to me possibly missing interesting questions to answer.

As far as finding good questions, that's also hard. Many of the questions involve very specific versions of software - languages, libraries, toolkits, browsers. Depending on what computer I'm on, I may not have access to the environment that I need to write a good, complete answer. I think part of this is the nature of Stack Overflow's scope, though.

The worst thing about answering once I find a question I can answer is the Fastest Gun In The West problem. As I'm writing a complete answer, including explanations and links to outside content for more information, I get a notification that new answers have been posted. Before I'm even done writing my answer, much simpler and (what I would consider to be) lower quality answers have already been posted and often up voted. In some cases, these answers are already accepted. I lose my motivation to actually finish my answer and post it.

I'm not nearly as active on Stack Overflow as I used to be simply because it's gotten too hard for me to find questions and then not get beaten to the answer by a handful of low quality answers.

I also think that part of it is that my main areas of expertise - software requirements, design, architecture - are on the fringes of Stack Overflow. There are tags for and questions being asked in my core knowledge areas - [uml gets a handful of questions every few days](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/uml), [requirements gets questions at a lower rate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/requirements), [there are plenty of design questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/design) (but many are at the very detailed level and require knowledge of languages, frameworks, and libraries which I may or may not have), and so on.

I think I would be more active on Stack Overflow if it wasn't so hard to filter questions and have that information persist across computers. I think the absolute hardest thing is to find that narrow sliver of questions that I'm able to answer well. There's still the FGITW issue to overcome, but I think that can be step two. If I can find my areas of expertise, I can probably use my moderation tools to help with question and answer quality.

Answer (score 6):

This question will probably vary widely for each user, but since your goal is to gather such perspectives, here's how it works for me:

When I answer questions, I sit on the home page for several minutes at a time with a custom search (available using the "new" UI):

`css and not javascript and not jquery and not angularjs and not php`

This lets me see CSS questions that aren't tagged with any of the `not` tags, so I can focus on questions that are truly CSS-focused in nature. Without these delimiters, I'd be encountering a lot of questions that are really about JavaScript or AngularJS or PHP that just happen to be tagged with [css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css).

Unfortunately, this feature doesn't yet support live updating, so I have to hit F5 on my keyboard every so often. While I'm not looking for any particular aspect of CSS to come up, I usually end up opening questions that are either:

- Interesting to me and might present a challenge or at least engage me for a while.
- Questions that I think I'll know the answer to fairly quickly if not completely off the top of my head.

I also open questions that I think might be duplicates in order to check and see if I can't find a duplicate target to connect them with.

[css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css) is a pretty popular tag, but not *the* most popular. As such it's fairly common to have to sift through a couple dozen questions before I find one that is interesting and/or doesn't already have 3+ answers.

Sometimes I'll also start to answer a question and find that it's either too difficult to triage in the time that I have (or really requires something I don't have access to, like a question about CSS behavior in the Safari browser for Macs), or I'll find that someone else has provided the same answer that I was going to provide before me. In the latter case, if I can find an alternate way to answer the question, sometimes I'll still do that, but usually I'll just discard my answer and upvote the person who beat me to it.

Comment: *"this feature doesn't yet support live updating*" - Funny I'm using the [meta-tag:new-nav] with my filter tags I want and it updates just fine on it's own?!?

Comment: @Lankymart I believe Meta works fine but the main site does not. For example, I've just tested it and I've had the same list of questions sitting on the page for 30 minutes now. It's a bug I reported when it went live and they said the live-update feature would be coming in the future but didn't give an ETA.

Comment: Works on main site for me fine. Tabs update with new question count and banner shows new questions at top of the list.

Comment: @Lankymart Oh, I'm referring to true live updating like the normal view supports, where questions inject automatically into the top of the list. And btw, my view does not update those numbers on the tab, either. Again, this is only for the complex query using `not`. Queries of just tags work just fine.

Comment: Hmm...ok, didn't realise there's a difference, seems to work just like it did.

Answer (score 4):

What a wonderful question!

I've been a reader and user of Stack Overflow for several years, but only started methodically and deliberately contributing with answers over the past few months. My reason is the "rising tide lifts all ships" mentality. I've been helped so much by detailed and well-written answers over my professional web development career, that now I want to give back to the community.

As @TheodorosChatzigiannakis noted, I also find that taking on the puzzles asked in questions expands my own knowledge as well. It's a great bit of logic and mental exercise and I learn a ton by reading alternative answers and comments.

As far as how I answer questions, I go directly from my profile page by looking up a particular tag that I've chosen for badge tracking. This allows me to stick with a single tag that has reasonable Q/A traffic and in which I'm currently interesting in learning and contributing.

I also to try to help question visibility by adding or removing relevant tags and making functional edits (blockquotes, code blocks, etc.) to make the questions more readable and useful.

Truly, I haven't noticed any signal-to-noise dissonance in my previous use of SO, but now that I've started poking around the review queues, I can see the folks cropping up who simply want their homework done or ask vague questions.

Answer (score 3):

When looking for questions to answer (or, to moderate as what seems more common today,) I just sit on the unfiltered home page and let the built-in filtering based on my previous viewing/answering activity do its job.

---

Early on I used answering questions as a way of expanding the areas that I'm comfortable developing in. I didn't just stick to the things I knew, I instead took interest in the topics people were asking about. That's key, because if you just stick to the narrow areas you're comfortable as a newer developer, you won't expand as quickly and the number of questions that you are capable of answering won't grow very much.

As you grow as a developer, you begin being able to answer questions that are outside of your normal area of expertise, thus allowing you to amass great amounts of rep very quickly through answering questions that aren't strictly beginner questions.

What ends up helping the most is simply being able to diagnose a problem quickly and accurately, otherwise you're only left with guessing. This kind of skillset only comes with repetition, you won't learn it in a book or on an online tutorial. Once you get to this point you'll likely start to get annoyed at questions that don't have enough information to diagnose the problem; hopefully you'll downvote/close them rather than going back to skipping them or trying to guess since you'll then have the ability to recognize that information is missing. But... don't forget to *nicely* request said missing information with a comment.

Answer (score 2):

I answer many more questions than I ask (1708 answers, 5 questions).  There are a few tags in which I primarily answer questions.  I have these saved as "Favorite Tags", and when it's time to answer some questions, I tend to go through that list from the main page, Control-Click on a few of them to open them in new tabs, and then have a look at what's there.  (I think that the new question filtering interface might make that a bit easier, but I haven't looked into it too much, yet.)  These tags are relatively low traffic in both askers and answerers, so there's never all that much of a rush to get an answer before other answerers.  That is, I'm often the Fastest Gun in The West, but the West is pretty slow where I am.

> How easy is it to find good questions?

It's a mix.  Some questions are pretty interesting, and some are pretty bad.  The pretty bad ones are usually either very easy (documentation or a typo), or very hard (unclear what's being asked, not reproducible, no minimal example).

While questions that require consulting the documentation are usually "easy" answers, I don't think they're all necessarily bad questions.  Sometimes it's very hard to know what to look for until you've found the answer.  E.g., if a concept has a specific, but non-obvious, technical name, a quick Google search for that will find a duplicate question or the relevant documentation.

Close voting in low-traffic tags can be a bit of a pain until you have a dupe-hammer, because votes can take a long time to accumulate.  It's also harder to get a dupe-hammer in those tags because of the low traffic (and hence, fewer upvotes on answers).

For the bad questions, I usually vote to close and downvote.  Because I'm in low-traffic tags, the downvote usually pushes things to a negative score, and they get cleaned up eventually.  (I think this is harder in high traffic tags, because it's easier to keep a non-negative score.)

> What is missing here? Is there anything awkward about trying to answer questions?

I don't go looking for questions that lots and lots of people can answer.  I'm active in some tags that are lower-traffic and in which I have a fair amount of experience and (based on reputation) evidently some expertise.  Since there aren't so many of those people in less popular technologies, the *rush* to answer isn't as intense.

*It's actually interesting how quickly some askers get used to quick responses.  In low-traffic tags, I see users posting duplicates of their own questions in an hour or two because they haven't received any responses yet.*

I would also echo some of the sentiments that other users have posted in answers to this question.  I've learned a great deal by answering questions on Stack Overflow.  Answering questions makes *me* a better programmer and (I hope) a better technical writer.  I've written answers that, to my knowledge, have introduced new techniques that demonstrate that things are possible, and that I wouldn't have thought of if it weren't for an interesting, provocative question.

People have been amazed when they realize that the documentation and standards of languages and libraries are freely available online, and that *anyone* can consult them.  Domain expertise isn't limited to those who have been in the field for years.  I try to support answers with quotes from and hyperlinks to documentation when appropriate, in the hope of "teaching a programmer to fish."

Another point that leads to the imbalance between my questioning and answering has also been mentioned by in [Michael B's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/324259/1281433): "See, whenever I try to write a very good question, the answer becomes obvious to me."  When I do start writing a question, I start to anticipate the kinds of questions that people might ask for clarification, or other debugging methods that I might have overlooked, and that often finally gets me into the right part of the documentation that I need.

Answer (score 2):

For me, answering questions is typically a side effect of search for answers.  Unlike seemingly lots of people on Stackoverflow, I don't have time to stay on the site all day, writing epic-length answers, and accumulating tens of thousands of points sometimes in less than a year -- if I were an employer I wouldn't hire such types, but that's beside the point.

As I was saying, answering questions for me is a side effect of search for answers.  Typically I find answers that for me are close but not quite, so I add my own answer based on my own experience trying to implement my solution based upon that answer I found.

Nuff said for now, and let the down-votes begin, because I pissed off Meta once, and it has a memory like an elephant's

Comment: Or, let the downvotes begin because you're passive-aggressively mocking the power users who keep this site from devolving into absolute trash?

Comment: It's not passive aggressive -- it's right there in black and white.  And you have no idea how many "power users" I see that give the shittiest answers to people who know no better

Comment: Yeah, screw all those people who spend time writing good, thorough answers to difficult questions! Who needs them anyway!

Comment: No, screw all the people who accumulate all sorts of "reputation" by answering questions that should be closed.

Comment: For the current incarnation of this answer, I think it misses the mark by straying into meta-retrospection and speculation about employment decisions. Still, it does mention an aspect or two about answering questions that some other answers don't.

Comment: As @BoogaRoo said, this answer shares a meaningful perspective that may be under-represented on meta. It would be improved by cutting the downvote-bait, though.

Comment: I can see why, as an employer, you wouldn't want to hire people who spent time *at work* answering questions. But how do you know they didn't answer those questions on their own time? For example, during their commute, at home in the evenings, or on weekends? What would be wrong with hiring someone who clearly knows a lot of things, has an abundance of patience, and is eager to share their experience and expertise with others? Or would you just prefer developers that have active social lives?

Comment: @GeorgeJempty - I do the exact same thing. You and I are called *Contributors*, see here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1%25_rule_(Internet_culture) .

But SO would cease to exist if it loses the *Creators*.

Comment: Upvoted just to tweak the Meta Nazis.

Answer (score 2):

I've never actually posted a question here, only answers.  The reason isn't that I have no questions, but rather than I can usually find answers by searching, often on StackOverflow.  So I give back to the community by answering questions to help other people out.

To find questions, I tend to do custom searches on tags I have expertise in, because that finds the questions I may be qualified to answer.  On popular tags, there are enough qualified people that you'll get answers within minutes, as is your experience.  Since I don't really need reputation points any more, and because it was frustrating when someone else posted an answer as I was typing mine, as often happens on popular tags like `java`, I now tend to look at more obscure tags like `multithreading`, where there are only a few other people who know enough to provide good answers.

I can look at these tags once or twice a day, or even only every few days, and still see most of their posts, though I'm not especially methodical about it.  And usually even if I answer hours or sometimes even days later, the original poster will still be looking for an answer, since these aren't the sorts of things they'll be able to figure out on their own with more time.  My own time is sufficiently limited that I unfortunately have to skip most questions that will require a detailed answer, focusing on those where I can outline a solution that the original questioner can fill out on his own.

A minor annoyance is people who answer questions in the comments, making it look in the search results like the question still needs an answer.  At least they are trying to help the person asking the question, though.

My biggest frustration is with people who don't have the expertise to answer the questions interfering anyway:  trying to close the questions because it isn't a question they can answer, or because they misunderstand the question, or because they resent the fact that others are trying to understand the topic.

For example, there was a question today where the poster had a problem with his multithreaded code because he was failing to do any synchronization.  Okay, he's a complete newbie with multithreading:  he probably doesn't even know what synchronization is, let alone why its necessary.  But his question was a good one:  he posted his code, he said what the desired result was, he said what result he was getting.  He still got a proposal to close because the question was "off topic", though his question was the kind of coding question that is exactly on topic here.  It might be a duplicate, but it was certainly on topic; unfortunately, there are way too many people here who seem to figure that "if I can't answer the question, it must be off topic".

Another example was a recent question where the asker was trying to understand Java synchronization, and posted code that contained a number of simple functions that synchronized differently.  It was actually a simple question with a simple answer:  in Java, synchronization is on an object, and to synchronize threads, they must synchronize on the same object.

Unfortunately, the question was closed as "too broad", probably because people who didn't understand Java synchronization thought it was multiple unrelated questions - but not before my answer got downvoted, presumably for my having the temerity to provide a simple, straightforward three or four line answer to a "too broad" question.  Avoiding that kind of angst is probably why some of the most knowledgeable people tend to answer in commments instead of in answers.

And now of course the people who think StackOverflow should prohibit new questions and only permit users who are interested in old questions so they can farm their old answers will be downvoting this into oblivion.

Comment: _"his question was a good one: he posted his code, he said what the desired result was, he said what result he was getting"_ - non sequitur. That lacks the most important detail of all: their research. Also, (summarized), _"people want to close questions they don't understand"_ is an age-old fallacy.

Comment: @CodeCaster The code showed evidence of research, which is what is required - and also as much as is provided in recent questions you've asked and answered.  Requiring a complete listing of what documentation you've looked at would just be noise.

Comment: @CodeCaster certainly there can be code that doesn't show evidence of research, but often it does.  Separately talking about all the steps you've tried is not required, and as I noted, doesn't generally appear in your question and answer list either.  If you think more is required, why aren't you doing it?  And of course my rant exactly answers the question about what gets in the way of me as someone who posts answers.

Comment: The question here is _"How do you find questions worth answering"_ (which on its own is a bimonthly recurrence), not _"What do you hate about answering questions"_. And yes, showing research _is_ required when asking a question, see [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). That doesn't mean you need to post a list of links to SO Q&As you've read, but which steps you took into solving the problem so people can understand what one has tried. If no research is shown, chances are it's a duplicate of the first Google hit for the question's title.

Comment: @CodeCaster Part of the question is "what are the main obstacles for them [people who answer questions]?"  That's the part I'm answering.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to some of the strategies already described, I use [the RSS feed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3403/rss-feed-of-your-favorite-tags) in a Firefox Live Bookmark for my usual haunt, the [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) tag. When I'm idle for a bit, I'll drop it open and skim the titles, opening ones that look interesting or are likely duplicates (I have the gold Java badge).

Answer (score 1):

Does anyone mind me answering as a complete n00b here?  *(Braced for downvoting into oblivion!)*

While I haven't been registered for long, I've been looking at SO for years.  In my working life over the past 12+ years I've been in and out of IT, though mostly in it, across varying disciplines.  In the past couple of months I've been yearning to create a few mobile apps, and decided it's time to give it a proper go - I want my work prospects to change.  When I've been looking into this, SO has been one of the first places that comes up with every search, so I had to join.

Presently I find myself looking through the newest questions list most of the time.  If I get bored of that I move on to some favourite tags.

**How easy is it to find good questions?**

I can only echo what most people have said about duplicates.  Within a few pages of the recent questions you can find very similar questions repeated.  If people searched properly, they'd find them and wouldn't need to ask them again, but then, this is the age of instant information - so few people I know actually go looking for things, instead they want someone to tell them immediately with as little of their own input as possible.

**What is missing here? Is there anything awkward about trying to answer questions?**
Sometimes it feels as though, because I'm new, nothing I do is going to be worthwhile.  I answered one question and someone just came along and told me (along with everyone else who had contributed) not to answer subjective questions.  That rather put me off answering any at all for a short while.  The person who asked the question seemed to have a lot of experience in other fields, but asked about differences between two ways of working that they weren't familiar with.  I answered with real-world examples as to the main differences.  It was a broad question, which is rather frowned upon, but someone with IT experience wanted to know enough to help them make a decision, and I contributed to that.  I hope they have made the decision best for their situation now.

Having seen and used lots of solutions on here in the past I figured SO could be used to get advice, even for someone new to it.  From the outside it had looked like a nice, supportive community full of very useful information.  Having read some (a minority) of responses, it feels like I'm back at work.  I have a colleague who has a serious problem with me being a woman but doing the same job as him, so he treats me like an idiot and as though his word is gospel.  Yes, I appreciate that some questions on here don't need to be asked, and only exist because of laziness, however, sometimes it feels difficult to phrase either a question or an answer to suit those who are going to chime in first, so I don't bother.  I have little experience in things compared to many others but I think the vast majority of people are here to learn.

I was all set up to ask a question on SO regarding Android Studio, but my experience of answering put me off, and I, after many hours, deduced part of the problem myself.

**Do you randomly show up and answer a question here or there, or do you sit down and work through systematically?**

For me it's still a case of looking at questions mainly, but I show up here and there to check the newest ones - it all depends what I'm doing and whether I have time.  My job rarely includes any programming, so if I don't have time to work on development at home, it's unlikely I'd be here during work hours.  That said, I did use SO to solve an SQL issue at work (which was immediately rejected as the problem by aforementioned colleague).

I'll stick around answering questions when I can, and I'm sure I'll learn a lot from it too.  Some of us newbies aren't trying to get everyone else to do the work for them, we aren't misguided or lazy, we're merely looking for a community to support our endeavours.  I hope I can find that here :)