# What to do about the flood of low-quality (homework) questions on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, low-quality-posts, quality-filter

### Disclaimer

This is my first question here. I've done quite a bit of research (~2.5hrs of googling and searching the other questions here), but if I've missed anything, I'd be thankful for feedback. I realize it's a rather broad question, but I hope I made clear what I'm asking for. The reason for this question being that broad and extensive is the simple fact, that I'd want a discussion on how to handle the problem, not on a specific feature handling a portion of the problem. Sorry for the extent of this question. I've attempted to make it as clear and precise as possible, by collecting a bit of info.

My questions is pretty simple, yet answering it obviously isn't:

### What to do about the flood of low-quality (homework) questions on Stack Overflow?

What I'm referring to is the kind of question where OP was simply too lazy to do the least of effort to research - and I'm not even referring to the extreme as suggested in this [question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), but where the first hit on google already answers the question - didn't try anything on his own, asks questions that are useless for anyone except himself, unanswerable due to lack of information or just posts a plain request for code. There have already been various questions regarding smaller sections of this topic, like [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274630/should-we-add-a-do-my-work-for-me-close-reason),or [this one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291531/many-question-askers-seem-to-only-want-the-code-not-to-understand-how-to-solve), or ... I think you get the point.

I realize comparable questions have already been asked, so let me make it a bit more clear:
This question is **not** about how to handle asked questions, but how to prevent them in the first place. Or alternatively handle them in a faster way. I realize, there's [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256003/on-large-communities-decaying-over-time-being-nice-or-mean-and-stack-overflow), which pretty much covers the same topic. So why do I even ask this possibly duplicate question?  Looking through meta, I get the impression things got worse, and looking at the questions that are posted, I see my suspicion confirmed. The original question dates from two years ago and the proposed actions don't seem to show any impact. The question I want to ask is thus not: "should we be nice or mean?", but "are we mean enough?". That's not a desirable behavior, but in this case the end justifies the means.

### Damage to the community

This kind of low-quality question is quite likely ruinous for SO. In fact I've paused my presence here for several months because of this kind of questions and I bet [I'm not the only one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/324072/how-to-lure-professionals-to-stack-overflow?cb=1) (though I don't consider myself a professional or anything close to it) or [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252506/question-quality-is-dropping-on-stack-overflow) or [this one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252756/are-high-reputation-users-answering-fewer-questions). Not only that they start to deter those who use SO in a "proper" way (sry, couldn't think about a better description), but they reduce the overall quality of SO and reduce the attention on good questions. In addition the damage for OP himself due to rep-vampires is quite considerable as well.

### Current way of handling low-quality questions

The main-problems here (at least IMO - I may be wrong) are:

- Most users don't have the slightest idea about how the site is meant to be used or the policy of SO. I don't even remember how often I've linked the help-center or [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) to a question or the answer of a help-vampire.
- the simple fact, that the proposed actions are simply to ineffective:

  - downvoting: usually this kind of question is asked by low-rep users that quite often have a score of 1. Downvoting doesn't change anything with their score. I don't recall where I read about the mechanism of how question bans are triggered and can't find the precise formula, but it's definitely triggering too slow for someone, who just dumps a few questions.
  - close voting: it takes one low-rep user to ask a question and 5 high-rep users to close it. Obviously this is to the advantage of the new users - normally I wouldn't care, but with the shift of the ration: low-rep users:high-rep users this slows down handling questions of low quality extremely
  - leaving a comment: that kind of questions is usually [beyond help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37623791/having-a-method-print-and-return-a-value-back-to-main-in-java).

I like SO. It has helped me learning coding my self, and I like to help other users. I don't mind answering a good question, be it from a newbie or some one who's been coding for several years. But I'd rather not watch SO going further down the path it's currently on and slowly mutating into a mixture of a free homework service and tutoring for pupils that are too lazy to do a bit of work on their own.

So:

### What can we do to improve the overall situation and reduce this behavior?

My suggestions would be:

- Clearly stating some of the most basic quality requirements for a question in a way comparable to how the [tour-site](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) is designed, but more compact and simply make sure a user who wants to ask a question actually reads it. Sounds like a bit of a hassle for the user to me, but it would at least reduce the problem a bit (hopefully). This would require quite a bit of tact to work out. I know they are stated in the help-center, but honestly, no freshman will ever read them there - most people don't.
- Overall a harsher dealings with problematic kind of behavior. I know it doesn't sound nice and neither is it meant to be, but this would allow filtering out the users who cost SO the most in terms of reputation and answerers. This would include both help-vampires and the people asking questions. This wouldn't prevent that kind of behavior in the short term, but send a message that'd be clear enough for new users to understand what is expected from them. What comes to my mind would be:

  - altering the close-vote mechanism. Faster closing of questions, probably via a new close reason would help speed up the removal of such questions.
  - speeding up question bans based on the rep of a user
  - a temporary ban, that triggers faster, but only lasts a specific time. Probably related to the above mentioned close reason
  - discouraging people from becoming help-vampires. This could work in a similar way via flags and answer-bans or other penalties.

I realize all of these are borderline rough towards novices and thus might discourage users from joining. My personal opinion on this is that SO slowly mutates into something that'll make it die. I'd rather watch a few users leave, than see this site die a slow death by students that are not willing to follow the sites guidelines. IMO SO is simply to lax when it comes to this topic. I know noone wants be mean, and neither do I, but this issues is slowly getting more and more serious and quite likely the end of SO - or at least it's positive reputation as a site for professionals and enthusiasts - if not stopped.

Any comments, opinions on my suggestion or other suggestions on how to deal with this are welcome.

**EDIT**:
This question is **not** about any feature like close-votes, but an overall harsher approach on implementing the policy of SO to prevent a further degradation in terms of quality. This question is **not** specifically about homework-questions, though they are quite often not fitting the quality-requirements, but aimed at low-quality questions overall. IMO the fact that quite a number of new users join the community every day, due to the reputation of SO, has imbalanced the impact of novices compared to more experienced users, which leads to some quite undesirable consequences. The point of this question is to find ways to get the message that not conforming with the policy of this site is neither appreciated nor tolerated as soon as possible - ideally before they even ask a question - and take the related actions in a - admittedly - less permissive way to make this clear.

**EDIT #2**
Regarding the suggestion of simply using up all votes and hope that changes anything, [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/324261/4668606) already shows quite a bit of the frustration that is involved in this kind of question. The author of the answer is quite a bit older than me or the average user on SO - and thus most likely more relaxed when it comes to this kind of behavior, than me - and still gets frustrated by this kind of question. My personal feelings about the standard low-quality questions and their authors go quite a bit beyond disapproval and again - I doubt I'm the only one. Most users simply ignore low-quality questions and just move on. Though I'd love to take that path as well, a problem won't cease to exist, just because you close your eyes. Turning SO into a dump of low-quality questions is in no ones interest and should be prevent with (nearly) all means. I'm not talking about introducing another feature to SO, but ways to alter it's reputation, since what it turns into ATM isn't what we want SO to become. This quite likely involves being rather inconsiderate towards new users. But letting SO further degrade is no ones interest, neither new users nor the more experienced ones.

Comment: We've had this discussed ***so many times*** already that it's starting to get exhausting.  At least, let me ask this clarifying question:  why do you feel that the current options that we have (downvoting, voting to close, and commenting) are truly ineffective?  Just so you're aware, a question isn't bad *solely* because it's a homework question.

Comment: Well, it is not like it hasn't been brought up before dozens of times in the past week.  Happens ever year around the same time, the flood of students finishing their end-of-year projects is rough on everybody.  Their summer jobs start about now, it will be moderately better tomorrow.  The only thing I wonder about if this year was worst than 2015.  Not sure I saw it, late April + May 2015 was *nasty*.  Or I'm just getting to used to nasty, that's quite possible.

Comment: @Makoto As pointed out in the question already, the number of questions of low quality isn't reducing in any way and the effects of that are visible in quite a lot of places. By ineffective I don't mean they are entirely ineffective, but simply ineffective to prevent the drop-off in terms of quality. And (as well pointed out in the question) I don't mind if it's a homework question. I mind the extreme low quality of the some questions. I've just added the homework topic, because there's a pretty obvious correlation between the one and the other.

Comment: I don't think there's a difference between a student asking us to do their homework for them and a professional asking us to do their job for them.  In terms of the broader quality discussion, there's a *lot* of topics on those floating around as is...

Comment: @Makoto What makes you think that I think there is any difference between the two? And as for my question. I'm not asking for any feature in particular, as with the other questions I could find, but for an overall strategy to prevent this behavior. I'm not asking about introducing a new close-reason or another way to indicate the user his behavior isn't wished-for, but a way to get this message a bit further, be it directly or indirectly

Comment: First step: use all your votes, every day when active.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis to achieve what? Replace one rep-vampire by another and one asker of low-quality questions by another? Especially for new users this isn't exactly helpful. The point is to get the message across that this kind of behavior is neither appreciated nor tolerated on SO. The number of users that don't care is simply too large compared to those who care to make voting effective. I've encountered a variety of bad questions and answer receiving upvotes. Which leads to the logical conclusion that somethings out of balance and thus needs to be rebalanced in one or another way.

Comment: I don't see anything new in this post nor anything that would help to stop on-account-per-question folks.

Comment: I haven't been around very long, so I was wondering... Does it get better during the summer? There must be a lot less homework when school's out, right?

Comment: @Laurel it gets better, but it doesn't stop. The homework-questions are only partially related to the overall problem.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov the point of the question is about a harsher policy against low-quality question askers, not some tiny new close-reason. And the point isn't to stop on-account-per-question folks, but to make clear that posting low-quality questions on SO isn't tolerated and get that message across before the question is even asked.

Comment: @Makoto I'd say a "good" homework question probably either is impossible to differentiate from a good non-homework question, or is is an otherwise good question that merely says it is a homework question (which probably ought to be edited out for the benefit of all involved).

Comment: I've said this a couple of times (and got downvoted a lot) but I think that new users whose first question is closed should get very specific  information about what was wrong with their question. I'm convinced this will lead to fewer people creating a new throwaway account for every question they have. The problem is, someone has to take the time to spell it out to them, and unfortunately "ain't nobody got time for that".

Comment: @m69 may be right in some cases, that this may help. The problems here are the ratio of bad questions to people who actually care/are experienced and in fact it would be the askers task to inform himself on the rules. In addition after some time most users experience a bit of frustration when pointing out the same problem with a question for the 100th time. I hate to admit I've noticed myself becoming more and more sarcastic in comments of the kind "try to google for the answer first" or "please read  <insert help-center link>".

Comment: "How is your IT homework going?", "Fine - there were a couple more SO nag screens to click through than last week, but I could still post my homework copy.  If some mark has not answered it by Wednesday, I'll maybe look at it myself.  Bar's open - wanna beer?".  Sure, if you're buying!"

Comment: @m69 'I think that new users whose first question is closed should get very specific information about what was wrong with their question' - how could that be done?  They won't read it - the only information they need is binary.  If(the question is closed) then myAccount:=Taccount.Create();

Comment: @MartinJames that's a part of the behavior I want see handled in a stricter way. Be it a homework question of that kind, or asked by a professional, this kind of question shows what happens to SOs reputation. Where this ends when it's over isn't exactly a nice place. SO is slowly building a reputation as a "post your homework and some nerd will do your job"-site. Either there's something done against this reputation, or SO ends as exactly that. And at that point the more experienced users will leave and what's left is dead from a practical POV.

Comment: @Paul: "*SO is slowly building a reputation as a "post your homework and some nerd will do your job"-site.*" It seems to me that this has always been true. SO earned that reputation long ago. In any case, as William pointed out, it's not homework questions that are the problem. It's bad questions period, whether due to homework or not. Focusing on just homework questions is not helpful.

Comment: @NicolBolas I know it's only part of the problem. Never the less it's a part of the greater problem this question addresses. And out of the period the load just reduces, but it's still quite a large percentage. And the stronger SOs reputation as homework-site gets, the larger the damage from that reputation. I don't mind answering a good question, be it homework or not, but linking the same sites, giving the same comments and closing the 100th "no effort"-question is annoying. IMO this site is not strict enough about it's policy - which leads to no good.

Comment: The pattern is: people on Meta talk about the problem; people come up with possible solutions; they get ignored by the SO team; rinse, lather, repeat. There are more productive uses for one's time.

Comment: @Pekka웃 well, it's at least worth a shot. There isn't much more to do, unless the situation magically changes by itself.

Comment: I still stand by may [opinion](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/216677/213957) going back two years.

Comment: You know what the problem is? The over-the-top negative responses from people like yourself. If you don't like the questions, don't look at them, and don't answer them. It's that simple. Meanwhile, us peasants with lower reputation will be happy to answer them, doing a couple of things in the process; Not only do we help these people get an answer to their questions (the very reason for this site's existence), but if our answer is accepted, we are rewarded with a rep bonus for not a whole lot of effort- 15 rep means a lot when you have <500. It's a win-win until people come complaining.

Comment: And if you're worried about people cheating by using the help of the SO community, people already cheat without it. If you think a **specific** question involves a loss of academic integrity, use the criticism methods that are already in place on that question, or again, just don't answer it.

Comment: @RobotKarel314 you're ignoring a few details within your win-win. It's rather win-win-loose. I know it's nice to gain rep by answering simple questions - I've been here for ~1.5 year now - but the purpose of the site isn't to function as a tutor for coding-newbies that aren't capable of googling. This kind of questions is quite likely ruinous for SO due to the low quality of both the question and the answers, that are given. The damage to SOs image isn't that small to simply ignore it. The negativity comes from the simple fact, that these questions are not what was SO was made for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> That's not a desirable behavior, but in this case the end justifies the means.

No it doesn't. Toxicity doesn't help anybody. I may be in the minority for thinking this, but it's the community's job to handle bad questions. The whole reason why this site works in the first place is because of the community ethic and the moderation tools given to us that help us close and fix bad questions. If everybody's complaining "wah there are too many bad questions" instead of moderating, then of course it's only going to get worse.

You claim to want to "prevent" bad questions from happening yet all of your suggestions are just variations of rate-limiting or punishing people who ask bad questions. I mean, you claimed to spend 2.5 hours researching the issue, and yet you missed the fact that this has been discussed to death. You even linked to questions, one of which you admit is a possible duplicate. The irony is palpable.

I understand your frustration, but writing an essay on Meta complaining about bad users and help vampires only begets negativity. If you want a more positive atmosphere, change starts with you. So stop wasting energy complaining and start being a better role model.

Comment: The question itself is about developing a stricter policy and tools to enforce it. I just suggested a few tools to do so and am open to other suggestions. The point is to get the message across that violating the sites policy is not tolerated. I'm not asking for more toxicity in the first place, but ways to increase the impact of the community on the choice of questions and answers. As for the "possible duplicate question": I think I made pretty clear, why I asked the question. As for the role-model suggestion: the impact is just too small. Never the less: thanks for the feedback.

Comment: We already tried that and used to be able to handle it.  Not anymore, we're off by a fat factor of two.  If you have practical ways to double the number of people that do this then don't hesitate to mention them.  Always better than the inherent toxicity in complaining about their performance.

Comment: @HansPassant well, the impact of the community obviously depends on two factors: percentage of people that care and how fast actions lead to consequences. If the percentage decreases, obviously the second factor needs to increase to keep the balance. The point about the toxicity is cutting both ways. The more low-quality questions, the more toxicity amongst established users, the faster the new questions get nuked, the more toxicity against new users. Personally I think this shifted quite a bit towards the former, which isn't desirable for a community that builds upon it's experienced users.

Answer (score -2):

I realize this is sorta beating the proverbial horse, and there's already an accepted answer, but since I don't really feel like duplicating the topic again, and I know my opinion will be ignored anyway...

I feel like the OP has an excellent point, even though I might not concur with the approaches to address it. As someone who used to participate in the community, but dropped out primarily due to the refusal of the site to address this problem, I feel like the "accepted" answer ignores the other aspect of toxicity: namely, that toward the community itself, by creating a toxic environment for identifying pertinent, constructive questions to contribute answers toward. Moderating is, of course, a non-answer / disingenuous dodge of the entire issue (ie: if the deluge of low-quality questions from "new" accounts is creating toxic overhead for the would-be "valued" participants in the community, then creating more overhead for those participants to also try to manually keep up with filtering out those "new" accounts is an absurd and counter-productive non-solution).

That being said, I don't think banning is a particularly good solution (either automated, or through community feedback). A better solution is probably some sort of loose "tier" system for questions, with an opt-in system for users (ie: you could opt-in to only seeing higher-quality questions with filters and such, where "higher-quality" was a combination of the rep of the poster, and up-votes from the community, etc.). That would allow higher-quality posts from newer users to still potentially get higher visibility, while removing lots of the potential toxicity for users browsing the site for higher-quality questions to potentially contribute on.

Anyway, that's my thought, for whatever it's worth.

Comment: A bog for low-quality questions has been suggested many times before.

Comment: I'm not really suggesting that (at least in so far as we're not characterizing SO on the whole without any way to filter as a giant bog for low-quality questions). But the point is still taken: the glaring problem has obviously been discussed many times before, and there doesn't appear to be any impetus or will to try to fix it. I just wanted to echo the OP's concern, and express that I didn't think the accepted answer was actually a solution to the problem in any plausible sense.