# How does a directly quoted answer get so many upvotes?

Tags: discussion, voting, duplicate-answers

This answer, https://stackoverflow.com/a/37595293/1011527 is a direct quote (and says so) of another highly upvoted answer. Shouldn't the reference at least been in a comment and at most duped as it is now?

Comment: I agree. The user should have tagged the question duplicate rather than answering it.

Comment: There aren't any voting rings or other shenanigans around that answer. Comments seem to praise what they wrote before the quoted section: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37595223/is-it-a-good-idea-to-have-an-ajax-request-every-5-seconds/37595293#comment62675627_37595293 and they provided proper attribution, so the answer itself isn't in violation of any rules.

Comment: Good to know @BradLarson, I wasn't sure.

Comment: @BradLarson Agreed. However, I love it when I get downvoted by a certain YCS everytime I post an answer where he gives it the gold (fact), I just love it. One gets mega upvotes, while another gets the "other" half of "the stick", *just lovely*.

Comment: This is another good point in favor of removing answer rep for closed questions, I think.

Comment: **meta mob** is doing its work. that answer got 7 downvotes and 1 upvote. between the time this question was posted and i commented.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Sounds like a problem easily solved by not answering dupes :P

Comment: @DavidG Doesn't what you said apply to this question? *hahaha!*

Comment: Personally, I find that if there's nothing to be added that hasn't already been said (in a possible dupe), then they should have voted to close the question. I on the other hand, have been downvoted for not having closed a question, where it was clear that the possible duplicate did not cover all of the problems in OPs' (in plural form) code. This comment in its own right, is a form of "answer" to the question; wouldn't you agree?

Comment: Now, that the question in cause has vaporized is there a chance to re-open the one which was quoted? Would be a shame to loose that thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10028770/html5-websocket-vs-long-polling-vs-ajax-vs-webrtc-vs-server-sent-events

Comment: I don't think it will get lost because of the shear number of votes @Vickel

Comment: Now let's get the Meta mob doing *productive* work, namely reopening [the master question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10028770/in-what-situations-would-ajax-long-short-polling-be-preferred-over-html5-websock), which, like so many questions, got closed because of a too-literal interpretation of the rules. "Oh no, this might involve an opinion—close it!" For those still uncertain, [please read](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/).