# Mjölnir doesn't work when changing tags after close "vote"

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, duplicate-questions, vote-to-close, dupehammer

This question: [C++ wrapper class holding raw array of non-trivially constructed objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37862260/c-wrapper-class-holding-raw-array-of-non-trivially-constructed-objects), is a duplicate (at least according to my reading) of the other question. I saw it was C++, checked the dupe, remembered I had Mjölnir power, reread both questions, verified they end up in the same answer, and closed. It didn't close the question immediately, and I noticed there was no C++ tag. I then added it (well, removed the irrelevant `gcc` tag). To my surprise, there is now no way to insta-close this although I have Mjölnir power.

I can also not retract my close vote because then (IIRC) I won't be able to vote to close again.

Is this intentional, should it be fixed, etc.?

Comment: Only the tags that were present in the first revision of the question matter for dupe hammer.

Comment: @Bakuriu That got changed, and it's now any tag not added by the hammerer themselves.

Answer (score 55):

You cannot dupehammer a question if you added the tag (for which you have the gold badge) yourself. This is [intentional](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/268281/295232), to prevent people from (wrongfully) adding a tag in order to abuse the dupehammer.

Comment: Right, kind of makes sense. I seem to remember a time where the C++ tag was a synonym for the C++11 tag.

Comment: Right. Removing this pointless restriction was one of the points in my  proposal to expand hammering in [this answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/324072/how-to-lure-professionals-to-stack-overflow/324090#324090). This restriction appears to be based on the mystifying mentality that gold-badge holders are mentally unstable and might at any time go berserk and start indiscriminately hammering questions left and right after adding the tag they hold a gold badge in. Remember, questions can easily be re-opened if necessary, often with one click, or by voting, or by a moderator.

Comment: Does it work now if the tag was added by someone else? Or does it still consider only the initial tags?

Comment: Common cases include JavaScript questions which are not tagged as such, but only have tags such [tag:regexp] or [tag:nodejs] or [tag:ecmascript-6].

Comment: @Oriol as per the question linked in my answer: the *current* tags, excluding those added by the dupehammer-wielder.

Comment: @torazaburo Maybe write one specific feature request for this issue, instead of the entire list you proposed 'over there'?

Comment: @torazaburo There is [one user](http://stackoverflow.com/users/27535/gbn) with enough upvotes for a gold badge in the tag [duplicates](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/duplicates/topusers). I couldn't blame them for abusing that one. They still need 195 more answers to get the gold badge in that tag though.

Comment: I have occasionally observed a gold-badge user to misuse Mjolnir in cases where they didn't need to add the appropriate tag (details omitted to protect the guilty).  It's not so unreasonable that dupehammering should require a different person to decide the subject area of the question than the one who hammers it.

Comment: Misuse is inevitable. Everyone makes mistakes, especially when making subjective decisions like whether a question is a duplicate. The proper question is not, "Will gold-badge holders make mistakes?", but rather, "Will people use this in good faith, and either correct their own mistakes when made aware or allow the system to correct mistakes using its built-in processes?"

Comment: @JohnBollinger Then punish the abuser. Should we stop accepting posts because some people use it as an avenue to post spam?

Comment: @Rob because the admins don't want to bother punishing.  That takes work.  One person can edit the tags, and if even one other Mjolnir user things it should be closed it gets closed.  The problem is minor: the fix, could cause  hassles for admin staff.

Comment: @CodyGray - *misuse* is not the same as *mistake* there are important semantics that make the first *intentional* even if not *malicious* the second one does not imply either.

Comment: The restriction is pointless. It's trivial to work around if I'm determined to do so: I can open the page in another browser, suggest a tag edit as an anonymous user, "Improve" the edit with my gold badger account to unilaterally accept it, and then hammer the question. **And this wouldn't be any easier or harder to detect** than me just editing the tag in myself.