# Why is there no “author of the question did no research before asking” flag?

Tags: feature-request, flags

I see a lot of questions that apparently are flagged, because the author of the question didn't just google the title of his question instead of asking on Stack Overflow, or didn't try to find a solution on his own (and thus didn't present any description of what he has tried).

Yet, all the flags on those kind of questions are either "unclear what you asking" or "too broad". I think those two options fail to explain to the author of the bad question what is wrong with that question. Often someone will point out in comments why the question is being downvoted and flagged, with a link to [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/) or [How to ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), but that just generates a lot of slightly different explanations on every such question.

I think a separate flagging option would be great to deliver the message "you should do your own research before asking" to newcomers. Am I wrong?

Comment: The usual answer to "why ru downvtez!" is "look at the tooltip on the down arrow". Though I agree, perhaps it should not be a tooltip but plain text - a bit bigger maybe. And possibly bold. Blinking. With a marching-ants border.

Comment: Typically these kinds of questions can be closed with dupe votes - if it's really a case of no research

Comment: I sometimes use an autocomment that links to [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252677/when-is-it-justifiable-to-downvote-a-question)

Comment: Should we expect new brand users to have researched SO before asking @Rob ? The doubt just came to mind...

Comment: I expect brand new users to have not researched SO before asking.   Why? Experience. That's why I run out of down and close votes so often:(

Comment: The irony of this being a duplicate.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You don't need a flag for that, and we don't *want* you to flag that. When the question "does not show any research," a downvote, not a flag, is appropriate. In fact, that's what it says in the tooltip when you mouse over the downvote button.

One of the standard reasons we decline flags is:

> Flags should only be used to make moderators aware of content that requires their intervention.

This situation doesn't require moderator intervention. We *can't* intervene in all such situations, as there are countless bad questions posted every day. That's part of [why we have community moderation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/site-moderators): to spread the load of handling routine tasks, instead of dumping thousands of them on [just a handful of people](https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=moderators).

**tl;dr If a question lacks research, downvote it. If closing is appropriate, vote to close. Please do not flag it simply because it lacks research. We'll just decline the flag.**

Comment: [*We feel that the world is awash in questions, but not answers. Answers are the real unit of work in any Q&A system. Therefore, the only logical thing to do is to maximize the happiness and enjoyment of answerers. **If this means aggressively closing unworthy or uninteresting questions, so be it.** Without a community of people willing to answer questions, it really doesn't matter if there are questions at all, does it?*](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/a/595/41104)