# Should we vote for the history of questions or answers?

Tags: discussion, voting

I know some of voting guidelines [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252677/when-is-it-justifiable-to-downvote-a-question), but my problem is: Should we vote a question/answer based on the original version?

Vote for current version only seems the most fair standard, but consider a case: a user wrote a very poor question (for example, poor grammar, unclear and needs guessing), and then someone helped the OP to edit the question and become a useful one.

Imagine if I just upvote the question based on the current version, am I upvoting a user that posts low-quality contents? Am I encouraging users to post crap questions? Is the edit history a factor in determining my vote?

Comment: You may up-vote it as the user intended to answer it that way, (its just that he had bad English, we don't down-vote for that). As far as its understandable & correct up-vote. _We ain't grammar Nazis!_

Comment: You may not @AniMenon but I very much downvote for poor spelling/grammar. It is expected of users to have someone proof-read their question before posting if they cannot produce coherent sentences and proper spelling on their own. At least somewhat.

Comment: @Magisch If able to read this, you got me.
Now this sentence I wrote has a minor error but you got what I meant. So answers are important not the grammar.

Comment: @AniMenon If you can't spend the effort to make your question properly readable (without causing eye rolling and eyesores) and properly spell check your question, why should I bother with anything but a downvote and moving on? Maybe because im feeling like it that day I'll edit some of the bad stuff into shape, but downvoting and moving on is a completly reasonable response.

Comment: If you only voted on the original quality of a post then what would be the point in asking users to improve them at all? What would be the incentive?

Comment: Besides the obviously contentious point about voting on posts based on their original revision only, I totally understand the dilemma of allowing users to depend on the community to polish their bad questions into good ones over and over again. There was a question posted about a topic only I was in a good position to answer, that I missed simply because it was written so poorly it was completely voted off the front page until someone edited it into a stellar question. Had it not been for that user asking, such a question would not appear again as a duplicate until several months later.

Comment: But what about users who repeatedly ask on-topic but poorly-written questions and show no signs of improvement? Should we allow them to continue asking questions that just toe the line between on-topic and unsalvageably bad, and continue depending on the community to polish them up for them every single time? On the other hand, if a question is so poorly written to the point of being unintelligible, the odds of it even meeting the guidelines are vanishingly slim anyway.

Comment: @Magisch I said "You may up-vote" if the intend is understood & feel the answer to the question is right. I think down-vote for an answer which is right(except for the grammar) is bad. And yes for the question a down-vote is fine.

Comment: @AniMenon If I find an answer that is good enough for me to want to upvote but has enough spelling errors to make me unwilling to do so, I usually fix these quickly since I have the full edit privilege.

Comment: Good. And then up-vote maybe :)

Comment: Well, you're never obligated to up vote anything. If you know a particular user keeps making low quality posts and feel that up voting them once someone else has fixed them would be encouraging bad behavior, you can always just skip it.

Comment: @BoltClock I wonder if a quality filter could be put in place that looks at the number of edits and the amount of the question they change.  If a user is getting a lot of community edits or the amount of material that is being edited is a lot then that could be suspect.

Answer (score 4):

> am I upvoting a user

Stop. You are *never* upvoting (or downvoting) a user. You are always voting for content, not the person providing it.

Content lasts. People don't.

Comment: I'd be interested to see SO go one day without showing you user names or their score, and compare people's voting habits / amount scored with when they know who's posted....

Comment: False. The vote might affect the question/answer, but it also clearly affects the user. If this were not the case, reputation would simply not exist; nor would question bans or privileges. If people continuously post nearly incomprehensible questions, I don't see a problem with holding that against them just because other people did their work for them.

Comment: @WilliamKappler: Votes *affect* the user. But they should not be made *because* of the user. They should be made due to content alone. You downvote a question if it has incomprehensible content, regardless of how many such questions the person has made in the past.

Comment: The fact still remains, the original user is 'rewarded' for upvotes, encouraging bad posts (assuming they're always salvaged by others).

Comment: @Rob: Irrelevant. The purpose of voting is to signal to others about the nature of some content. If the question isn't bad *now*, then the question shouldn't be downvoted. Just like if a question isn't off topic/too broad/whatever *now*, then the question shouldn't be closed. The whole point of allowing editing is a recognition that bad content can be improved. We shouldn't change our behavior because of the bad behavior of others. If you want to stop bad posts, stop them *before* they get into the system.

Answer (score -3):

If you can understand the question why it is with low-quality content? You should understand that there are many users who do not know English from their birth. Moreover, in many countries English lessons are poor in schools, and it is a very common situation that somebody starts learning the language (real learning) just when he or she starts to work as a programmer, or at university. And sure they have questions about programming before they reach even middle level of English. And moreover - Stack Overflow it is a good place to boost the language.

I know this because I'm also not a native speaker and English was a big problem for me =) And sure, three years ago, when I have my first account on Stack Overflow (its credentials I 'successfully' forgot), and I needed an answer for very important question. I wrote it in a very bad way, and received many bad comments and sure, downvotes. The result was - I haven't received any help.

To sum up: Be more forgiving in attitude to the grammar. Often you don't know how much time a person used to translate it to English from his native language.

Comment: Im not a native speaker either and I do make and fix mistakes plenty. But if your post is barely readale or just an eyesore, I will obviously downvote it. If you can't for the life of you speak coherent english, either don't post on here or find someone to proofread at least a bit.

Comment: @Magisch I wouldn't be so fast on downvoting just because of grammar, even if it is downright horrible. If editing the grammar is only thing that stands in way of question or answer to be proper (good) one, then just edit the horror, and let it be.

Comment: @Magisch I once stumbled upon answer with such horrible English I could not understand a word. But the code was the only one that solved the issue properly. All other answers were moot or horrible suggestions and workarounds. So I completely edited the answer (basically, removed all English parts and added my explanation) and upvoted it. Because it provided solution. A good one. At the end that was what really mattered. Otherwise, someone might have downvoted it, deleted it, and really helpful piece of information would be lost just because author cannot put a two English sentences right.

Comment: If the code solves the issue, more power to them. You can't do nearly as much for an answer that you simply can't glean *any* meaningful information out of.

Comment: @BoltClock Can't argue that.

Comment: `If you can understand the question why it is with low-quality content?` There are *lots* of things that contribute to the quality of a quesiton.  Clarity is only one of them.  Additionally, just because you can managed to decypher what the question is asking after considerable effort doesn't mean that the question is *clear*, it just means it's not *unsalvageably* unclear.  We want posts here to be great; we're shooting for a higher bar than "barely decipherable".  The votes are not a reflection on the author as a person, merely of the quality of the question.

Comment: If the OP cannot communicate effectively in English, let him or her find another site where he can work in a language he is comfortable in. At a minimum, the OP can run his post through an English grammar/spellchecker. The idea that SO has a function as a language-learning environment is frankly absurd.