# Needs More Sportsmanship

Tags: discussion, status-declined, badge-request

We encourage upvoting competing answers to questions with a badge: Sportsmanship. It's been awarded a fairly pedestrian [2090 times](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/805/sportsmanship), as of this question. But once you upvote 100 competing answers, you lose all incentive to do so (outside of, you know, morals. pfft.)

I think SO needs more sportsmanship at all levels, so I'd like to simply propose two additional badges for this:

- A bronze badge at upvoting 20 competing answers. 20 is a much more easily achievable level than 100. Naming ideas collected from comments/answers: Team Player (2x), Assist, Common Courtesy, Cooperation.
- A gold badge at upvoting 500 competing answers. There are suggestions for 250, but the 5x gap seems pretty common in badges and a lot of the other gold badges involve doing something 500 times. Doesn't have to be easy! Naming ideas collected from comments/answers: <s>Altruistic</s>, MVP, Selfless, Commender, Paragon, Paladin, Chivalry.

Comment: I'd prefer terms like "Team Player" and "Altruistic" for Bronze and Gold, personally.

Comment: @TylerH There's already an [Altruist](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/222/altruist), but way to stick to the sports theme with Team Player. Now, who are the ultimate team players? The ones who give *all* the glory to their teammates: the Benchwarmers!

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot Doh, I thought that badge name sounded familiar...

Comment: More sports ideas: Assist (Bronze) and MVP (Gold). *Disclaimer: I don't play sports.*

Comment: @Renan Sounds like somebody's struggling to gain badges.

Comment: Well, I suggest archery.  Tie the vamps to stakes....

Comment: Lol, this is a good suggestion... Besides gold medal for 500, bronze medal with 20 up votes will definitely be tempting to get. :P

Comment: I've upvoted a few competing answers since I joined SO about a year ago, but 100 really is a lot. By the time you get there, badges are probably no longer of interest to you. A bronze badge for 10 or 20 could encourage new users to not see other answers solely as competition to their own answer.

Comment: Same request on Meta SE: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116735/gold-sportsmanship-badge

Comment: I like "Team Player" for the bronze badge; how about "Selfless" for the gold?

Comment: I agree with @m69, I'm pretty adamant about upvoting other answers that I think are useful or contributed in some way, and I've (apparently) only done it 67 times in 21 months. 500 seems excessive; maybe 250? I like the bronze as a way to encourage this earlier on.

Comment: to be fair, I'm 1 of the 2090 who got this badge, and i still vote up other answers,,,

Comment: Badges are "useless", only rep "matters". :-)

Comment: I agree with @briantist - 250 for gold - otherwise you'd be on SO forever to try and post 500 upvoted answers! Like I have 682 answers (now) but when I got my badge i think i had 437 odd, and many were accepted but not upvoted etc... and only ones with votes count! Getting 100 is difficult enough!

Comment: Shouldn't this be on [meta.se]?

Comment: Doh! 2000 only? :-(

Comment: can we know how many candidates there are currently for the 500 badge on SO? 250?

Comment: It's really difficult to get that badge if I am the only one answering a question OR another user has already gave a very good answer therefore I have no reason to answer the question in the first place. It's hard to find a question where two different answers both deserve an upvote.

Comment: 1+ for "*at all levels*"

Comment: @Rachel I still up vote other answers too, I was [mostly] joking about the morals.

Comment: @Barry ah I know, you're forgiven ;)

Comment: I would prefer to see it possible for the sportsmanship badge to be awarded multiple times. On lower traffic tags, its more common that a question will only receive one answer

Comment: Common Courtesy and Chivalry.

Comment: I feel like I'm missing something here. Why is this proposal so massively upvoted? Is it "yay for upvotes and badges and flowers and unicorns and happiness and love"? What problem will this solve? We already have a massive quality problem, votes already carry hardly any value except for popularity, whichever metric that is. What will adding this badge change for the better, and how?

Comment: I support the idea of a simple incentive and sign of appreciation of people who take that much time making my life easier.

Comment: "But once you upvote 100 competing answers, you lose all incentive to do so" Seems like a logical conclusion, but is there any data to support it? Something something, if it ain't broken, don't fix it. Although I don't think this has any negative consequences.

Comment: @CodeCaster I guess every meta post needs the token "In my day, water tasted better. Get off my lawn!" Cheers.

Comment: @Barry no, every change needs explaining why the change is warranted. We don't go around changing things "for teh lulz".

Comment: I strongly suspect that the people who regard the gaining of such badges as an achievement to write home about are not the kind of people who are the most effective contributors to the SO community.

Comment: @martin Archery, you say? http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43672/237813

Comment: Not a fan of MVP. *Very* US-centric, I think — Had to look-up what it means. Plus, seems overloaded in a tech context & confusable with 'Minimal Viable Product'

Comment: There's [a SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/65472/how-close-am-i-to-the-sportsmanship-badge) to see how close you are to Sportsmanship badge. After 7 years on Stackoverflow I see that I only have 230 votes on competing answers. Would a gold badge encourage me to vote more? I'll admit that it probably would. I think the hard part for some users is just answering 500+ questions in the first place. Another quick query on SEDE shows that there are only about 4100 users that have answered more than 500 questions.

Comment: @NVZ You could flag this post for moderation attention and suggest migration.  If it is migrated it should be marked as a duplicate of [my own](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/116735/158428) however.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard If that is the case, I wouldn't migrate it. People will hate me for getting it closed there.

Comment: @Cᴏʀʏ That doesn't show how close you are to getting the badge, it shows all posts you could possibly vote on in order to get the badge. Also, you can vote on multiple answers per question, so you don't necessarily need to write 500 answers.

Comment: There's no need to upvote other answers. The readers do that.

Comment: it's pretty useless tbh. I personally just went back and upvoted stuff from long past answers were the winner of the "vote race to the top" was decided already.

Comment: I would like **Decoubertinian**, from the Olimpic Games founder *Pierre De Coubertin*, for the 250/500 gold badge.

Answer (score 162):

I think that this is a good idea. It is in line with the general outlook of badge design and would just add to an already existing metric. In this regard, I do not think there would be negative consequence.

Naming is hard. I am sure the team will have to roundtable in order to find two good names here.

To riff on your bronze badge, I would suggest *Common Courtesy*.

And for the gold badge perhaps *Commender*.

Regardless of the name, I support this idea.

Comment: Bronze: "Cooperation" (lukewarm version of "Sportsmanship", Gold: "Paragon" or "Paladin" or something like that (i.e. taking "Sportsmanship" to extremes). I agree it would make sense to create such badges, mainly for the symmetry of the idea. I would not hold up high hopes that such badges will actually change _behavior_ much, so much as simply recognize what behavior is there.

Comment: Or "Chivalry" for the gold

Comment: _Congeniality_ maybe ;-)

Answer (score 74):

[I proposed essentially the same thing back in 2011](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/116735/158428). I am still a fan of the idea.  I think the threshold needs to be high, at least 500, or the Gold level will soon be diluted.

I personally I dislike "Team Player" as I have always felt that phrase has a connotation of herd mentality and lack of independent thought when used outside the context of actual team events.  From my earlier Q&A my favorite proposal is [Corinthian spirit](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/corinthian) from [AakashM](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/151211/aakashm), which has a spot-on definition if we wish to build on the existing "Sportsmanship" badge:

> 2. Involving or displaying the highest standards of sportsmanship:
>      'a club embodying the Corinthian spirit'

Comment: Whatever happens to these requests? Seems that it was highly received then and is highly received now...

Comment: Also I like that name! Seems perfect.

Comment: @Barry It is ultimately up to the Stack Exchange administration whether or not to implement suggestions.  Sometimes very unpopular changes prevail or popular ideas are not picked up.  I cannot argue with the overall vision for Stack Exchange however and it has obviously been very successful so those in charge ostensibly know what they are doing.

Comment: Note that, in order to being able to upvote 500 competing answers, you have to post around 500 upvoted answers (depends a bit on the ratio and number of good answers per question...). There are gold badges that are easier to acquire than the Sportsmanship badge.

Comment: I'm curious why "Team Player" makes you think of herd mentality or lack of independent thought. A team player is someone who makes the personal decision (or play) that most benefits the team, often at the cost of personal glory. AKA when you pass the ball to someone else with a better shot rather than trying to score yourself. I don't see how that is "herd mentality" or "lacking independent thought" at all. A team player in all contexts is a *good* thing.

Comment: @moooeeeep I do not believe that is true but rather each up-vote in a Q&A that you answered counts.  This means that if you tend to answer popular questions and you also up-vote competing answers you will only need to have posted a fraction of that amount.  I made a note of this in an edit to my own quesiton but I did not note the source of that information.  If you doubt it I shall try to find it.

Comment: @TylerH Like much inference it is likely personal which is why I stated just that.  I have had "be a team player" used to really mean ignore logic and go with whatever the majority thinks or wants.  I do believe I have seen it used in film or television as a euphemism for being willing to break laws and cheat to forward the goals of a particular group or organization, similar to "being willing to play ball."  Fear not, if you do not agree with me I will not accuse you of not being a team player. ;-)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I don't think the person who used "team player" to mean someone who ignores logic knew what "team player" means, then, because it doesn't mean that at all :-) I'm curious what TV shows and movies you've seen where the term was used negatively.

Comment: @TylerH My memory is poor and worsening so I am afraid I won't be of much help, and it could be a false memory anyway.  If it *really* matters to you I am sure the people on [Movies.SE] could be more helpful than I.

Comment: You are right, upvoting 500 competing answers to serious, distinct questions should be preferred to someone upvoting 500 answers to questions like this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/184618/1025391 - but you are not right, your answer is required to have a positive score.

Comment: @moooeeeep A Q&A like that makes me think this badge would be too easy to "game."  I think there should be a maximum of say three up-votes per Q&A counted.  Sorry for not mentioning the positive score; I usually take that for granted as the community I am most active in is comparatively generous with votes.

Answer (score 21):

I'm sorry but this is not going to happen, at least not for now.

It's not that we don't think it's a good idea, but it's just a matter of cost vs benefit. The code that supports the Sportmanship badge relies on a pretty expensive SQL query to work and before implementing more similar badges we would have to spend some time optimizing or rewriting it. It's not a trivial task and currently we have more important things (by that I mean "more useful for you the users") to work on.

Thank you for the suggestion (and to everyone who voted, answered and commented) anyway!

Comment: What's the argument against tagging with [status-deferred] as opposed to declined?

Comment: @CubeJockey "Deferred" means "we'll almost definitely take a look at this in the future, but not now". It's not the case here.

Comment: Oh okay, couldn't 100% tell by the wording of your post -- thanks for clarifying!

Comment: Despite not being my preferred outcome, should not my [older question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/116735/158428) also be given a [meta-tag:status-declined]?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard only Stack Overflow counts. Most SE staff probably aren't even aware MSE, or any other SE site, exist. :/

Answer (score 16):

There is a logical error in that idea. If there are only ~2000 people who got the silver badge, offering a gold badge at a higher number can only cause at most ~2000 people achieving that new badge. Even if everyone of these people suddenly upvotes 500 answers, the impact on the entire StackOverflow network is negligible.

So it’s moot to discuss the factor between the current silver requirement (`100`) and the proposed gold badge requirement, when the *rarity* speaks an entire different language:

- There are ~2,000 silver badges awarded for “Sportsmanship”
- There are ~300,000 gold badges awarded for “famous question” (which doesn’t even imply “quality question”)
- There are ~30,000 gold badges awarded for “great answer”
- There are ~19,000 gold badges awarded for “fanatic” (which only requires opening the browser each day or writing a small script which does)

Given that rarity, the `100` should already considered a “diamond” or “platinum” level. Or in other words, the problem obviously isn’t that these two thousand people 
might stop there, the problem is how many thousand people didn’t even get there (and that includes “member for seven years” with 100k+ reputation). And I doubt that you can attract these people with a new bronze badge when you can gold badges for things as listed above.

Comment: So in other words, are you suggesting that Sportsmanship should itself become gold and just add tiered levels at... say... 20 (silver) and 5 (bronze)?

Comment: I guess that would go along with Illuminator (51), Legendary (207), Publicist (615), and Copy Editor (2k) being the top-tier versions of those.

Comment: It seems you're making the assumption that, if a bronze and gold badge are added to this badge family, the number of users participating in such behavior won't increase. I don't think this is the case; availability of badges (especially gold badges) is a driving factor in a lot of behavior on the site. The gold review badges are so popular that we have a whole audit system for our review set up to catch people who are roboreviewing for these gold badges. The review process itself was even set up to manage bad edits from people going for the gold Copy Editor badge.

Comment: @TylerH: as I tried to explain in my answer, there are a lot of gold badges *easy to achieve*, but of course, I should have mentioned the Review Badges as well. Some people might consider them even easier than opening the browser each day for 100 days. In contrast, Sportsmanship does not only imply upvoting 100 answers, it may imply writing up to 100 answers that receive at least one up vote as well…

Comment: @Barry: I’m not sure whether I have a suggestion. However, maybe a general review regarding worth and rarity of badges might be a good move. I’m not sure what “famous question” does reward. In most cases, it just implies either “old question” or “beneficiary of catalytic effects (e.g. ‘Hot Network Questions’ list)”…

Comment: It is a ridiculously easy badge to earn, if you are at all interested in earning it (or even just bother to read others answers now and then). Rarity doesn't equate to difficulty here.

Comment: @Shog9: so you’re saying that people don’t try to get it, despite being soooo easy to get? Hmm, that doesn’t contradict my answer. The question suggests that the problem are the two thousand people stopping after getting the badge, but obviously there’s a missing motivation to get the badge in the first place.

Comment: Agree there. But that doesn't make it platinum level, just less motivating. Perhaps a bronze would help there.

Comment: As of this writing, there are 2.6k silver badges for Sportsmanship, 567.6k+ gold badges for Famous Question, 63.6k gold badges for Great Answer, and 29.5k gold badges for Fanatic.

Answer (score 5):

I think if you posted over 100 answers, and still need the badge as an incentive to do such things, then maybe you're doing it for the wrong reasons.

Then again, it should be easy enough to implement so why not.

Comment: I'm one of the few, the proud sportsmen on the site. I don't do it for the badge, but it is nice to have. For me, I just like to show alternative ways to achieve goals that expand on some principles, seeing two different answers helps the asker get a deeper understanding of the problem and trade offs of the solutions.... there are often several equally valid answers to the question, so the upvote to them shows they are good too. It is pretty rare though... I have almost 400 answers but only recently made the silver badge threshold!

Comment: This really could be said for all the badges, or the entire reputation system itself, in my opinion.  Nevertheless we choose to be active on a network that has these features so it cannot be too off-putting. :^)

Answer (score -37):

Even though the badge does exist, I don't think upvoting competing answers is something we really need to promote.

For one, if an answerer thought that another answer deserved an upvote, they probably wouldn't have answered it themselves in the first place; they would have just upvoted the existing answer and moved on.

Answerers make up such a small portion of the people that view and vote on a question that trying to change how they vote shouldn't really have that much of an effect.

If you're just interested in adding more badges so we can earn more badges, by all means, add more badges.  But in this case, I think it's much more likely this will encourage badge-seekers to vote up otherwise not-so-good answers to get the badge than it is to encourage better voting.

Comment: The gold badge would be harder to "game" and few people care about the badge that does exist. Users would still have to answer in order to be eligible so it takes more effort at least. If the other answer is terrible I would hope people would vote accordingly. Yes some terrible answers get the odd upvote but I think the community does a good job in general.

Comment: There are a number of cases I've run across where an answer is good, but only addresses the question from one perspective or gives one solution. If I've got another good way to approach things, why would I not post that and upvote the other answer as well?

Comment: I'm not saying there can't be two good answers to a question.  I'm just saying the voting impact from answerers is minimal.

Comment: @BrendanAbel Of course it's minimal, there is incentive to avoid doing it! The Sportsmanship badge attempts to counteract that.

Comment: Many interesting questions can have multiple good answers.  Many questions that only have one possible good answer are something that should have been googled instead of asked.  (Often the best google hit is an existing SO answer; as SO keeps growing, more and more new questions are duplicates.)

Comment: Completely agree with you @BrendanAbel.