# Make Sportsmanship a gold badge

Tags: feature-request, badges

The badge [Sportsmanship](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/805/sportsmanship) has been around for quite a time now, but only been awarded 2423 times at the time of this suggestion.

Since this badge was created to promote.. well.. sportsmanship, and to avoid vote wars against users having competing answers on the same question, why don't we promote this badge to *gold*?

In a sense, it seems this badge is either hard to obtain (only awarded ~2k) or does not encourage sportsmanship enough.

Comment: Yep, that's an average of just less than 1 award per day in the 7 years since being introduced.

Comment: Strongly related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/323487/needs-more-sportsmanship

Comment: @CodyGray in fact, I just found a (perfect?) duplicate: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116735/gold-sportsmanship-badge on meta.

Comment: No, because it's on the *other* Meta site :-)

Comment: That is asking a different thing than your question. Your thesis is that 100 is rare enough and so few people achieve it that it should be gold already isn't it?

Comment: @MartinSmith You're right.

Comment: I agree that it would be good to encourage upvoting competing answers more, but the level of the badge doesn't necessarily indicate how difficult it is to obtain. For example, in my opinion, bronze tag badges are a lot harder to earn than for example Copy Editor or Electorate.

Comment: The proposal has already been shot down before.  You *might* get somewhere if you ask for the badge to be awarded more than once.  Which still gets you the mileage you are looking for afaict.  With some luck this could make the query less expensive and therefore attractive.

Comment: @HansPassant The proposal in the actual question  is just changing the colour of an existing badge. Not adding additional badges or changing the criteria in any way. Has that been shot down previously?

Comment: There were about 260 awards handed out when the badge was first introduced (259 if my counting and arithmetic is accurate).  That reduces the number awarded since the badge was introduced, but since that's less than 1 a day, maybe it isn't important.  Not all gold badges get one awarded every day — any specific gold tag badge, in particular, is not awarded that often, in general. (Is there a tag where gold badges are awarded daily?  If there is, it must one of the select few like Java or JavaScript with a huge volume of questions.)

Comment: I personally tried to get it, but there are not many questions (which I answered) for which there are other good answers to be voted on. =(

Comment: Note: on meta.SO [sportsmanship has only been awarded 17 times](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/63/sportsmanship)

Answer (score 70):

Why not introduce two new badges for this - one bronze, and one gold - and give it a more formal tier?

- Bronze:  Courtesy, upvote **10** competing answers
- Gold:  Chivalry, upvote **250** competing answers

This gives the hint that users should be doing it more, because a lot of them will receive the bronze-level badge, and realize that it's something that we want more people to do more often.  The gold badge then gives the rest of us something awesome to aim for.

Comment: Ugh, these really need to be named "Courteous" and "Chivalrous", but then that wouldn't match with "Sportsmanship". :-( Also, might want to rethink "Chivalry", given its masculine implications.

Comment: " The code that supports the Sportmanship badge relies on a pretty expensive SQL query to work and before implementing more similar badges we would have to spend some time optimizing or rewriting it."

Comment: @Braiam:  Okay.  Good to know that there's a performance cost with this class of badge then.  Might be a good time to look into this since it's a fairly old feature request at heart.

Comment: Well, that or fixing triage, which you prefer?

Comment: @CodyGray Alas SportsMANship. Fair play? Team player? Teamwork? Objective? Egoless? (Idless/Egoless/Superegotistic?) Socialist?

Comment: @Braiam - Try posting on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sql

Comment: Well, ... Sports **person** ship then (I'm so tired of this). I like the given proposal, though, regardless of whether there can be a consensus for the names.

Comment: 250 competing answers?
That supposes you got 250 upvoted answers... on 250 questions where there are multiple good answers. That's too hard, Makoto.

Comment: @Cœur:  No one said gold badges should be *easy*.  Attainable isn't *easy*.  This badge is definitely attainable, though.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker:  Gotta be honest here:  I'm following the theme of "sportsmanship".  Not everything has to be about the gender of words.  There's no intended gender bias, and I'd rather that be the focus.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker A sportsman is a man. Also I used to think "-man" didn't matter until Hofstadter's [Person Paper on Purity in Language](http://www.cs.virginia.edu/~evans/cs655/readings/purity.html). Although I'd say chivalry is less of a problem in this respect because its context is more gendered and removed--knights were males; athletes aren't.

Comment: @Makoto "no intended gender bias"--ha ha ha.

Comment: If you want an opposite gender related term: "Mother of Charity".

Comment: Female s/w engineer here.  Get a grip, I don't care if it's called Chivalrous  and oh, the "man" in sportsmanship, I can feel a swoon coming on now...not.

Comment: @SList Yes! sometimes words are less important than intent.

Comment: @Makoto What you suggest is what was suggested on meta (https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116735/gold-sportsmanship-badge) back in 2011. It is only related to this topic: changing the color of the current, existing badge.

Comment: Can we _please_ drop the gender debate? This is about changing the colour / category of a badge.

Comment: I'd prefer if we do something in line with OP's request, which is make 100 the gold badge amount, and add a new silver badge at the 50 level. Or we could do a silver badge at 50 and a gold at 150 or 200. I think 250 would be very very rare indeed... At any rate, the fact that the silver badge level is 100 is something we can probably all agree needs to change.

Comment: @SList I would agree that "-man" usually has a low cognitive load. Do you think you might hold a different opinion if, like a stewardess, actress, postal worker (postman), fisher (fisherman), police officer (policeman), etc your job title was gendered--as many such workers (workmen) do?

Answer (score 1):

Or we accept the fact that votes [hardly mean anything](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/299877/266143), and that we don't need to hand out any motivation whatsoever to make more people vote more, because that will inflate a vote's value even more.

I upvote a competing answer if it taught me something, if the answerer approached the problem in a way I hadn't imagined or if it contains the same content as my (would-be) answer (and I'll successively remove my answer if they were first).

On the other hand I expect other answerers to do the same. If they don't, I should write better answers to better questions, not seek some kind of motivation for them to simply upvote my answers because there's something in it ("it" being the voting, not the answer) for *them*.

What *problem* were we solving here again and why would handing out more badges solve that problem?

Comment: Sooo ... all badge should be removed? It that your point?

Comment: https://yourlogicalfallacyis.com/slippery-slope, but for all I care, yes. If we then get rid of robo-reviewers as well, then it's fine with me. Again, I'm asking what problem we're solving by handing out more badges.

Comment: This is not a logical fallacy: you just wrote a pamphlet against badges. I don't disagree with you, I'm just trying to understand your suggestion. Is it to remove all badges altogether?

Comment: I agree. If people vote so they'd get a badge, they're voting for the wrong reason. No doubt the team had good intentions when introducing this badge, but I don't see the need for it to exist.

Comment: Badges is a way to present to the users what is expected of them. [Electorate](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/155/electorate) encourages them to vote on questions, [Steward](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/2279/steward) encourages them to participate in the review system, and Sportsmanship encourages them to upvote good competing answers.

Comment: Badges are* a way ^ But does it really encourage them to upvote **JUST** good competing answers, or all competing answer because ***GOTTA GET DAT GOLD BADGE*** @YSC

Comment: @CraigR8806 I have no idea. But is it related to the issue?

Comment: @YSC How is this not related to the issue??? You want to increase the level of the Sportsmans badge to gold... thus increasing the desire for the badge.  What does this do, it causes people to vote more liberally because they want an easy gold badge.  Yes, it will encourage some to be more "Sportsman"-like.  However, you will also draw a larger crowd of those just drooling hard over the opportunity to get a gold badge by just answering 100 questions and up-voting a competing answer in each.  Also, calls in to question the quality of those 100 answers if they're just there to progress in badge'

Comment: @CodeCaster If votes don't mean anything, where did all your rep come from? :-)

Comment: The intent of the badge was to promote participation amongst users who would not upvote a competing answer simply because it's a competing answer.  By adding more incentives to do this, the stigma of not upvoting a competing answer lessens, and gives participants a reward for doing so.  *That* is the problem, and *that* is how it is being addressed.

Comment: @Makoto and my point is that if users need a badge to stimulate that, those users are probably better left to not voting at all.

Comment: @Jason by people "liking" my answers. :)

Comment: This lends more credence to @YSC's slipper slope argument.  We *already* have badges for voting.  What's the harm in enhancing one of them?

Comment: @Makoto see the last sentence of my answer. I don't want people handing out upvotes because it gives them a badge, I want them to do so because they evaluated the answer and found it a good one. Just like review badges, I don't think this proposal will do more good than harm.

Comment: @CodeCaster:  I don't disagree with that sentiment, but there's only anecdotal evidence and supposition to infer that this is inherently harmful.  Review badges are bad because the system heavily favors activity over quality.  To qualify for a Sportsmanship badge, someone has to upvote *your* answer first.