# Should common (dupe) questions always get downvoted?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

When a dupe question is asked that is commonly asked, should it be downvoted even if it is a well thought out and researched question?

EDIT: I had seen [When is it justifiable to downvote a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252677/when-is-it-justifiable-to-downvote-a-question) before posting this but thought that was too vague while my question is more focused. This also doesn't address the question of questions that are difficult to find answers to even with research.

Comment: if it's a common dupe..... it's not well researched if you don't find the dupe target... no?

Comment: When someone asks a question about voting as brief as this one I'm really wondering that it is they hope to get from the discussion. Are they looking for guidance regarding their own votes? Are they looking for a moderator to step into a dispute? Are they hoping for the community to put pressure one someone who voted wrong (somehow)?

Comment: As always, voting is subjective. I usually downvote common dupes because if they're common, clearly the user should have come across at least one of them during their research of the problem and should have included it as part of their question if it didn't solve the problem.

Comment: @Patrice not always. Many times it can be tough to phrase a search to find an answer.

Comment: @Goose if it's a COMMONLY asked dupe.... it shouldn't be that hard to find, because commonly asked dupes can be found by finding the dupe-target itself, or any of the MULTIPLE dupes already on it... You say yourself "Commonly asked dupe" and "well research". If this was "not that common dupe", and "hard to find"... it's a different deal

Comment: @Goose and if someone comes up with a new way to express it that generally doesn't get downvoted. If googling the title finds the dupe, though...

Comment: @Goose this is where the subjectivity of voting comes into play. I think x is a common and easy to find answer, so i downvote. You find it to not be a common and easy to find answer, so you upvote or don't vote. the system is working. don't worry about how other people cast their votes.

Comment: @Goose you may want to provide an example of the question... I don't think questions with demonstrated research are frequently downvoted...

Answer (score 13):

Part of the research we expect from question askers is doing a proper Google search. If it is a *common* duplicate, as in your premise, a search engine will definitely find the duplicate. Therefore, it is justified to downvote the question — the downvote tooltip explicitly mentions

> This question does not show any research effort

as one of the reasons to downvote a question.

This holds even regardless of other (positive) characteristics the question might have, though these questions usually aren't known for being well thought out.

Comment: As we see here in action right now :-P ...

Comment: See my edit. I disagree that good research always finds the answer. Some answers are tough to search for.

Comment: @Goose downvote tool-tip is "does **not show** any research effort". You can easily see that in action on this particular question. It does not really matter for downvotes if it is hard or easy to find duplicate or answer - no research *shown* is good reason for downvote.

Comment: Don't stop there; flag/vote to close.