# Why don't the downvote tips contains a link to 'When is it justifiable to downvote a question?'?

Tags: discussion, downvotes

As we know, [When is it justifiable to downvote a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252677/when-is-it-justifiable-to-downvote-a-question) contains detailed explanations about downvotes, but the problem is, not all users check meta, why don't we provide a link to that guideline so that everyone knows more about downvotes?

Comment: Do you mean a link *in the tooltip*?

Comment: How do you intend on clicking on a link in a tooltip?..

Comment: Then have it somewhere else. I don't think this is such a bad idea.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The downvote button's tooltip already shows:

> This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful (click again to undo)

That's all you really need to know / consider.

That meta question, while popular, isn't the official guideline / rule.

Comment: I wouldn't mind having a link to that meta question as I'm certain it would encourage *more* people to downvote. Given that the top voted question starts "don't be such a care bear"

Comment: I'm not sure that answer is how SO wants to communicate to their users, though.