# Should I be nice to new users?

Tags: discussion, new-users, etiquette

In the First Posts queue I encountered this question:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38465861/json-result-from-c-sharp-web-api?noredirect=1#comment64335841_38465861

It's terrible, of course. But when I see one of these questions, I try to be exceedingly polite in the hopes that the question's inevitable destruction will at least teach them something. So I posted this comment:

> Please edit your post to show what you've tried and what doesn't work.
>   Don't use images for code, please.

Someone came and commented:

> Ares, don't use the word *please*. It's no support center. It's OP
>   responsibility to provide proper information else just leave it.

I realize the trap that's easy to fall into here. To quote ["When is it acceptable to downvote a question?"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252677/when-is-it-justifiable-to-downvote-a-question):

> Please stop being a care bear, and proceed to be harsher at once.

That's about downvoting and as such is peripherally related to the problem at hand. The point I'm making is that culture seems to be bleeding into other areas of the site. You can see the contention of that point in the comments of his answer.

Is there anything wrong in being nice to users who fail to grasp the tenets of Stack Overflow? I see a *lot* of people commenting on fresh questions with aggression, hostility, etc.

Think of it this way: there will always be new, terrible questions. For every person we're nice to (while still removing/downvoting the question) we potentially create another *legitimate* user on the site. That's another user that can contribute time to helping someone else learn the site, if nothing else. But if we're abrasive, hostile or just generally rude to the new guys, we virtually guarantee that that person will neither learn a lesson nor pass it on to anyone else.

So this is isn't about being nice for *them*; it's about being nice for *us*.

Look, I get it. The bad questions sap the life out of all of us, and the site. But shouldn't we be doing what gets the best outcome (better users) rather than what gets us instant gratification?

Am I wrong to think this way?

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm doubtful it will make a difference one way or the other.

Comment: I write "please" in that context all the time. Read your comment out loud with and without "please." It turns a polite request into a rude demand, in my opinion.

Comment: Meh, honesty comes first. If you can't be honest without being rude, just be honest, don't tell them anything and flag/vote accordingly.

Comment: You've chosen to give the OP some useful advice they can use to improve their post if they choose to do so. That's useful. A criticism of the level of politeness in your comment is not useful.

Comment: You gotta wonder why the phrase used in that quote wasn't "Stop being a care bear..." if it was meant to get rid of "Please"...

Comment: Don't be unnecessarily rude.

Comment: Please don't be unnecessarily rude.

Comment: I can't believe that question you linked to has such a positively-received response. Simply ignoring someone is not going to teach them anything - it's going to make them hate the site and spread the (almost TRUE) perception that Stack Overflow is incredibly rude. Make it a quick one, but give them a general pointer as to what they did wrong at least. Otherwise, you shouldn't be surprised when the problem just gets larger and larger as no one learns.

Comment: @Katana314 Clearly you haven't spent much time helping people improve their problematic questions.  People get *much* more upset when you politely explain what is wrong with their question and how to improve it than if you ignore it.  Also your assertion that the community is being rude for not fixing people's questions for them is simply not merited.  It's *impossible* for us to fix every bad question that's submitted here, and we're under no obligation to fix every unsalvageable question that someone posts.  If you want to have an expectation of such service, you need to pay for it.

Comment: writing-style nitpick:  The way you use the word "please" at both the beginning and end of your comment seems a bit awkward."

Comment: I agree, though my intent was that those statements would be read separately from each other.

Comment: Please be mean to bad **questions**.  Don't try to address a user, it is never appreciated anyway, giving advice is always best left to the [Help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  A link is plenty good enough.

Comment: It's slightly damming that someone feels they need to even ask this....

Comment: "Ares, don't use the word please. It's no support center. It's OP responsibility to provide proper information else just leave it." If could downvote this, I would. Just because the person who asks the question doesn't know how to work with SO most effectively doesn't mean that experienced SO users shouldn't be polite. As a new SO user, I would appreciate Ares' comment.

Comment: `People get much more upset when you politely explain what is wrong with their question and how to improve it than if you ignore it.` I can't confirm that from my experience - I've very rarely encountered *upset* when giving out advice. More often than not, however, polite advice is just *ignored*, making it feel like a wasted effort.

Comment: @Servy `People get much more upset when you politely explain what is wrong with their question and how to improve it than if you ignore it.` Sure, I can confirm this. A person can't be rude to you if you're slamming the door in their face. Your "clearly" assertion was, specifically, *false*. That is exactly what I do and it is nowhere near as difficult as you say.

Comment: @Katana314 I didn't say it was difficult.  I said people get extremely upset when someone tries to help them fix their question; typically more upset than if they get no comments at all.  When they get no comments they just assume the people downvoting/voting to close are idiots, when people explain in detail specifically what they've done wrong, and all the work that they need to (but don't want to have to) do to fix their question, they typically get even more upset at being told what all of those problems are, or that they have to fix them in the first place.

Comment: Maybe I'm some sort of mental defective, but as long as the other person has asked an actual question, and I think I have a helpful answer, I try to help.There's no reason to be a dick to *anybody* as long as they're not being intentionally.mean or trolling.

Everybody was new once, and nobody knows everything. Everybody needs help sometimes, even if they don't know the special SO Police Mandated Question Asking Format. "Please" has nothing to do with it. If you can't be helpful, just ignore it and move on.

Comment: @Servy A) It's easy to assume someone's frustration to be directed at you if you're reading it that way in text and drawing inferences. B) How they respond depends very much on your tone. Many responders on SO are **very** flippant in the way they dismiss answers, perhaps without intending to be. All I can say is that my experience has NOT been the same as yours. Maybe we've simply met different first-timers, or maybe one of us is approaching questions differently.

Comment: @Katana314 I'm saying nothing about it being directed at me.  In fact, it typically isn't. I'm referring at people getting upset with the community, complaining here on meta, etc.  Many people are *constantly* complaining about simply being expected to ask good questions, and instead assume that SO users should feel blessed to have the privilege of being able to answer whatever poorly formed, unclear, unresearched, inappropriately scoped question someone offhandedly tosses on the site.  [For example](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/328269/#comment368713_328269)...

Comment: @Servy Uh...I'm going to refer to A) above here. What Terry is saying amounts to "Don't be a dick to anyone" and "Either be helpful, or move on." and I totally agree with him. If the most help you can give to a poorly formed question is reply "I don't think anyone understands your question, here's a link to a FAQ that can help improve it" then that's fine. If you're bored of bad questions and just want to look at another, that's ok too; no one's paying you. What's not fine is forcing yourself to handle a bad question, and then picking a rude way of doing so.

Comment: @Katana314 What he's actually saying is that *you are being a dick by doing anything but answering a question, no matter how bad*.  And that's just wrong.  He's asserting that people shouldn't be helping question authors improve their questions, rather they should just be trying to answer them.  It's equating point out serious problems with a question's answerability with being a dick, in addition to just asserting that having quality standards in the first place is bad, which is a completely false, and unhelpful, premise.

Comment: @Katana314 `What's not fine is forcing yourself to handle a bad question, and then picking a rude way of doing so.`  Again, most people, such as Terry here, are saying that *anything* you do to help someone fix the problems with a bad question are *inherently* rude.  I'm not saying you need to throw around personal insults to tell someone that their question is missing enough information.

Comment: @Servy `What he's actually saying is that you are being a dick by doing anything but answering a question, no matter how bad. And that's just wrong.` That's...just completely incorrect, and I don't know *how* you arrived at this conclusion. Can you please read his comment again?

Comment: @Katana314 I have read it.  Have you?  Did you notice his assertion that you should always be trying to answer questions, and his highly inflammatory language towards the site's standards and the implication that they're not merited or worth following?  He didn't explicitly *say* those things, he just implied them, but the implication is clear nonetheless.

Comment: @Servy He stated that **he gives a helpful answer if he can**. That is very different from your reading of it. It is highly possible for a mediocre question to not follow all rules, but still be answerable by a knowledgable person. The entire point of those rules is to make questions answerable, so it's totally okay to point to them if a question is *not* answerable, as long as you do so *politely*. The end goal is simply to do something *helpful*. I also did not read inflammatory behavior or anger in his response; just some amount of humor. Do not assume the worst of people's speech.

Comment: @Katana314 A question being answerable is *one* goal of the site's guidelines, it's not the only one.  There's a big difference between questions  you can post *an* answer to, and questions you can post a *useful*, *good* or even *correct* answer to.  SO was built on the premise of creating a place where posts are held to a higher standard.  And while *you're* saying it's helpful to point out how a question can be improved, he's not saying that at all.  I also said nothing about his post being angry, it very clearly is inflammatory; that you think it's funny doesn't make it not inflammatory.

Comment: The first comment I ever got on Stack Overflow was so nasty, over something pretty minor, that I've been reluctant to ask questions, make comments, or even upvote/downvote again. While this is an anecdote, the cliche "you never get a second chance to make a first impression" works both ways.

Comment: Wow, a whole lotta people butthurt over random comments from strangers on the Internet. Did I just climb into a time capsule? 1995 tried to call, but the line was disconnected or no longer in service.

Comment: Not sure why honesty and kindness have to be mutually exclusive... this isn't YouTube.

Comment: Sometimes the nicest thing you can do is down-vote / vote to close, whether they realise it at the time or not.

Comment: Nothing wrong with being polite about poor questions initially. But when they refuse to fix them, either ignore them or vote to close. It's frustrating to see a question left in its original bad state despite multiple comments giving excellent advice on how to improve it. In one question, the OP made a crucial clarification to the question as a comment. Someone said the OP should edit his question to add that clarification. He didn't do it so I finally copy & pasted OP's comment verbatim into the question to make it clearer. Not enough questioners take advice on fixing their questions.

Comment: We are a vast community with many many different kinds of people with different philosophies. People should act as they feel as long as it is `constructive`. Stackoverflow is by no means represented by a few people roaming around just to downvote or discourage people from posting again. These people exist and stackoverflow does a great job responding to removing non constructive comments. Unfortunately this contributes to poor first-impressions/welcomes to the site. In reality for the most part we are a positive and charitable community. It's okay not to be "nice" but you can't be destructive.

Comment: @Dmitry also worth noting the examples you mentioned are indeed unconstructive and would probably be removed if the posts were flagged. Speaking of which it is curious that the link to the thread does not work at this time.

Comment: The attitude out of any other that annoys and frustrates me the most is the one where the OP feels they are owned something, like the world owes them a favour and shows no sign of attempting to resolve the problem on their own. Being pleasant then is a real challenge.

Comment: Meta users, please stop close-voting questions with ridiculous close reasons. It is not unclear what is being asked here, and every discussion question has _some_ form of opinion.

Comment: @CodeCaster the irony of the close votes are not lost on me...

Comment: Common courtesy and goodwill never hurt anyone. That's my 0.02 cents, from a semi-new user at that.

Comment: Be nice to everyone.

Comment: @Servy, that's exactly NOT what I said. I said "If you can't be helpful, just ignore it and move on."

Comment: @baoghal: "The first comment I ever got on Stack Overflow was so nasty, over something pretty minor, that I've been reluctant to ask questions,  . . ." Same here. I had an account here years ago and asked a question that was as specific as I could possibly make it given the information I had, and received such nasty "fu** off" responses that I said "wow SO is just full of assholes" and I didn't come back for a really long time, when I decided to give it another chance. It's been about a week and the jury is still out about whether I'll stick around.

Comment: @TerryCarmen And you also implied, rather strongly, that posting comments pointing out problems with a post, instead of answering it, isn't helpful, by degrading the very idea of having quality standards.  The logical outcome of those two statements is that is that one should not try to help people improve their questions.

Comment: @TerryCarmen I do hope you'll stay. You're on the right track. Be excellent to each other.

 If I didn't believe this was a tractable problem, I wouldn't have posted this question. We can work together to make SO friendlier without compromising its effectiveness as  a knowledge base.

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/379704/what-really-amounts-to-be-nice-to-new-contributors

Comment: @MattK it cost nothing to say please, I would ask my grandchildren to do the same :)

Answer (score 291, accepted):

Yes, [you should be nice](https://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice) to your fellow users. Being rude to someone isn't going to solve any problems all by itself. It is the content that really matters.

Users shouldn't be telling anyone not to use the word "please" in comments, that is rather untoward.

That said, I think you already knew we should be nice to other users (new or otherwise) and simply took issue with this one comment directed at you. I agree that it wasn't really constructive, and so would a mod I assume. So next time you find an off cuff comment like that directed at you, just flag it as "not constructive" and move on.

Comment: I'm asking this because the culture of Stack Overflow frequently comes across to me as "Know all the rules of our site, we'll downvote/close if you don't." It reminds me of the way signs are in Boston: "Know where you're going, and if you don't, go f*** yourself." 

That contradicts the being nice policy.

Comment: @Ares - Policy is only as good as its enforcement. While the outlook is to be nice, in practice getting everyone to actually follow those guidelines can be difficult. I think sometimes people focus too much on the personal aspect of the site rather than the goal of the site which is content. The balance between cultivating high quality content and not hurting people's feelings while trimming content is hard to strike and I think the back and forth there plays out often and sometimes unfortunately gets rather messy.

Comment: I don't believe this is a problem that you can policy your way out of. But I can't help but notice some of the language you used seems to indicate that content and the personal aspect are mutually exclusive, like we can't have both. We can be nice to users AND delete/downvote/close their question. That's my point. The question is of low quality and is unanswerable. I guess my experience working IT changes my outlook. If I responded like many users do here to ANY of the unbelievably silly questions people ask me, I'd be out of a job in a heartbeat.

Comment: When I was talking about the balance between creating content and trimming content, my point was that deleting, downvoting, and closing questions gets taken personally by some users so even without commenting they feel slighted. Even though all of that action was content based, to the user it sometimes feels personal.

Comment: Well, while it obviously isn't anything personal (why would I hold animosity towards someone I have never and will never meet?) if you're new to the site, how would you process it? I think it takes more than just downvoting and closing. Those are just the business operations of the site, as you've mentioned. I've seen a hugely positive response from users when I leave comments that amount to "This question will probably end up being closed, but FWiW, here's a few thoughts for next time..."

Comment: 'just flag it as "not constructive" and move on' ... please..

Comment: I disagree that our universally caustic reception of new users is unhelpful.

Comment: Haha, can we all start calling the "know all the stackoverflow rules" ethos "the Boston system"? (Nothing against Boston-- I believe it's a point of pride with many Bostonians anyway :-))

Comment: @Ares: I agree. I think everything here should have a "Poster was a being dick" link next to it, and getting too many of those would revoke posting privileges for a while. I've been developing software since 1973 and have never found it useful to be mean to anybody who wasn't that way initially. Part of the problem is anonymity. If people had to use their real identity when posting, there would be a lot more civility.

Comment: There are many reasons newbies come to SO...not all have a nice little code snippet that you can pick at. Some problems are more conceptual, others genuinely just want suggestions. Its pedantic to take the A in Q&A so seriously. Obviously, its not a discussion board, but some leniency in regards to question content is warranted. I for one am very hesitant to post questions to this site, since I usually get the uncommented downvote to a question I've spend a bit of time writing out.

Comment: @Bey Its *possible* (though difficult) to write a good question without a code snippet. Even asking for suggestions is fine, *if it is appropriately scoped*. The problem is people asking "How should I make a game in C#?". Not "I've thought of X, Y, and Z specific ways to solve a specific problem, which should I use or is there a better solution?" The latter form is *exceedingly* rare

Comment: Just one caveat. You should be nice to everyone *except* those that suggest you shouldn't be nice. Rag on them all you want :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo: No, you should be nice to everyone *even* to those that suggest you shouldn't be nice. Don’t let them control you.

Comment: My perception of this is that there is a certain "ghetto" philosophy over hacker-related topics, in which a harsh attitude is an integral part of the hacker culture. My position on this topic is that we should always try to be polite, as a foul attitude may push sensitive newcomers to leave. This sort of aggressive attitude to outsiders in membership groups has been historically a cause for broader social issues, and even collapse. By the way, having a bad attitude should be considered a classic attribute of black-hat hackers, not _real_ hackers.

Comment: @Bey A pleasant site *is* more pleasant, but what you're saying is "I have a problem I can't solve, want to ask for help, think some people on this site might be able to help - but I'm not going to ask because I, an adult human, am afraid of a picture of a downvote arrow changing color. This is so scary that I would rather keep my problem than even risk it". It's a tiny speedbump, shove straight past it, do whatever it takes to get to your *real* goal - a solved problem. Imagine the downvote came from a website spider or spambot clicking random links, if that helps. (Might even be true).

Comment: @Ares "*Well, while it obviously isn't anything personal (why would I hold animosity towards someone I have never and will never meet?)*" - if you think of SO as a place for curated content that you work on and care about, someone throwing garbage into your content would give you cause to feel animosity. If you think of SO as a chance to use request other people's time, bad content potentially wastes hundreds of people's time - maybe your time too - you could see it abusively damaging and undermining a delicate system you support, causing you to feel animosity.

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler its not the downvote per se, its the lack of any constructive feedback. Just negativity..and silence. A real waste of 30 minutes of typing and trying to be thoughtful. FYI - I never get this response on MathExchange or CrossValidated. I am a member of several sites and this one is by far the only one I find this problem for.

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler You and I know that downvotes are just a signal that your post needs to be improved, and not to take it personally. But that's tribal knowledge that's _learned by participating in SO_. And if it's learned, then someone has to teach it. We don't teach it. Imagine getting a test back that you failed miserably with nothing but the grade. In fact, they burned your test in front of you because it was so bad. How would you know what to improve? The #1 reason people should be nice is that you could potentially transform a bad asker into a good one. Oh, and be nice on principle!

Comment: @Amy Pellegrini: "My perception of this is that there is a certain "ghetto" philosophy over hacker-related topics, in which a harsh attitude is an integral part of the hacker culture." There is and it's sad because it wasn't always that way. People used to be helpful just because they could. Also when the community was smaller and less anonymous, the person you offended might be your next boss or co-worker.

Comment: // , This is such a Cali answer, for better or worse

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you mean by that @NathanBasanese, can you expand?

Answer (score 24):

Were you to omit "please" from that comment it wouldn't make it, "abrasive, hostile or just generally rude", and conversely, if a comment *were* any of those things, adding "please" to the end of it wouldn't fix it.

All of that said, there's nothing *wrong* with you using "please" in that comment of yours, even though it's not *necessary*, as you claim it is.

Comment: "Please" can definitely take something from "generally rude" to "generally polite."

Comment: @djechlin Or the other way around. Remember that. Please!!

Comment: "there's nothing wrong with you using "please" in that comment" - Not so sure about this... We remove pleasantries from Qs&As. Why should we have them in comments which can't be edited at all? It creates unnecessary noise. A simple "What have you tried, why didn't it work?" solves all problems.

Comment: @Fermiparadox Because comments aren't as formal as posts, there not designed to be permanent reference materials for all readers, but rather a dialog between someone and the post author over how to improve the post, so that the comment can then be deleted.  Like I said, I don't see "please" as *necessary*, but in that context it's not *wrong* or *harmful*.

Comment: @Servy It *is* harmful (even though to small degree) just like "please/thanks" is harmful in a Q or A; it creates noise; wastes reader's  time for no reason. Comments might not be designed to be permanent but often they are. Especially when they contain useful info that can't/shouldn't be incorporated in the post itself. When useful info is mixed with formalities in a single comment, then that noise becomes permanent.

Comment: @Fermiparadox Comments are inherently noisy.  They're not designed to have a high signal to noise ratio, the way posts are.  In fact, part of the design is to move the noise to the comments *to keep the signal in the posts high*, so at a minimum, it's just not a serious problem in comments, the way it is in posts; it's not worth the effort to try to remove that kind of noise from them.

Answer (score 22):

I'd say this is down to personal preference.

As a new user, I definitely appreciate people being polite when I inevitably screw up. Most users will 'grow up' and have more contributions to make later on, and it's probably not a good idea to scare people away.

On the other hand, new people screw up. A lot. And that gets frustrating. We need to be taught not to.

Answer (score 21):

I (almost?) always try to be nice with new users, whether or not I expect that "it won't make any difference". It's the right thing for me, for the recipient, and for other users of the site.

1. First of all, because I want to be a nice person, rules or no rules. And it (usually) gains me nothing to be rude.
2. We may all be tired of dealing with the same mistakes over and over, but for new users it's their first time. I'm still annoyed that a high-ranking mod here on meta responded with "here we go again" to a less-than-perfectly-informed comment of mine months ago. If you don't have the patience to educate yet another newbie, ignore them and move on; there are plenty others to take up the slack.
3. Comments are seen by everyone. Even a well-earned put-down will be off-putting to readers and potential future (new) users, who may not feel like risking initiation by fire.

I don't mean to suggest being a doormat. But "please edit your post to show what you've tried and what doesn't work" discourages abuse at least as effectively as "WHAT HAVE YOU TRIED?".

Comment: Did you mean to write this as a separate answer instead of [editing](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/328334/edit) your previous post?

Comment: That *was* an edit! I had connectivity problems and hadn't realized it turned up as a new answer, thanks for the heads-up. Thanks for cleaning up the older version, @meagar.

Answer (score 12):

I encourage everyone to remember their first posts to SO.  If your experience was like mine, learning how and what to post is already intimidating enough.  To a newcomer: a downvote without explanation is baffling, a snarky comment is discouraging; a constructive comment is helpful; a polite comment is even better.

Not to single out a particular user, but [Bill the Lizard](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1288/bill-the-lizard)'s comments have always been polite *and* informative.  An attitude of "polite and informative" encourages users to (a) return to SO for more questions and (b) helps them become better community members themselves.

Would you want it any other way?

Comment: First thing I did was read the guidelines start to finish, then attempted to write as detailed a question as possible but still managed to fail. Eventually I found my way.

Answer (score 12):

Can I just point out the obvious that sometimes we say "please" because it's better English and makes more sense?

> Please edit your post to show what you've tried and what doesn't work.

Without "please" the sentence just sounds a little odd to me. "Please" clarifies that the mood of the sentence is a command, not a statement. It's grammatically deducible that it's a command anyway, but proper communicating includes some redundancy so that the recipient does not have to read things twice to infer the grammar.

I don't think we should yell at people for communicating clearly because there's an off chance they were being too polite.

Comment: To my eyes, "please" clarifies that it is *not* a command (from a position of authority to an inferior subordinate), and is a request (from someone with no right to order or demand anything - a peer).

Answer (score 9):

Yes you should be nice. But at the same time, if you need to correct them, that's not an issue.

I am basically a new user while I am writing this post. I don't like the fact when my questions are just taken off the site, in fact I would consider it better if they first comment me that I should fix something, then after 2-3 days take it off.

Comment: It's too bad that you're just now coming across Stack Overflow.  A few years ago it was a far less hostile place.  I hope you stick around and continue to help make it better.

Comment: If your questions get immediately taken off the site, it's because at least 3 trusted community members (or a moderator) feel that they are *completely unsalvageable*. There is little point in leaving a comment, because there is nothing that you could reasonably fix. Either the question is completely off-topic, totally nonsensical, or lacks so much information that you might as well start over and ask a new question. If something really had a minor, fixable problem, someone would either fix it for you, or the question would indeed remain on hold for 2-3 days giving you time to edit it.

Comment: @CodyGray It's not that people feel the question is completely unsalvageable... it's that they voted like it was.  There's a big difference.  There have been several occasions where I've edited people's questions with 4 or 5 downvotes and brought it back to life by simply rewording.  I think that people vote to close and downvote without care.  I doubt Dev is referring to an actual deletion, or they would have been notified and given a list of reasons.

Comment: @Brad Downvotes and close votes have almost nothing to do with deletion, except that a question must be closed and downvoted to a certain score before it can be deleted. Obviously downvotes and close votes do not mean a question is completely unsalvageable, but that's not what we're talking about here. Dev said his questions were "just taken off the site", which implies deletion. Had the question been simply closed (put "on hold"), they would have been given a closure reason and plenty of time to correct the problem.

Comment: @Dev It would help if you study the help center first, because a quick look at your answers and questions already shows several things against the guidelines: don't include signatures like "Please help", "Thanks",... If you include links, give a summary of what they are saying so your post is still helpful if that link goes down, and so on.

Comment: @LisaMM I think the problem is that the question got removed and Dev didn't get/read the explanation. (I don't know if an explanation/notification pops up for the author after a question gets deleted.)

Comment: @Max I know, but if they would have studied the help center first the deletion would have been prevented.

Comment: @LisaMM Agreed... we need better training for new users. I would really like to see a new users' first few questions/answers be moderated by higher rep users. Right now, the flood is overwhelming and all rep users are being subjected to bad questions.

Comment: @JeffC We have the First Posts queue for that, or do you mean something else? There is also guidance while typing the question, but a lot of users seem to ignore/skip it, and I wonder why.

Comment: @Dev - I'm disappointed that you've felt so let down.  However, it loks like we're not aware of how to use the site effectively.  [For example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37403811/launchd-is-not-working), why would you 'Accept' an answer if you did not find it solved your problem (as you noted [in the comments](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37404246/2486496) )?

Answer (score 8):

Whether it's about fixing a post on the site, getting a program to run, a fight with your mother-in-law, your car not starting, or any other kind of problem, step one in fixing a problem is **identifying that problem**.

Now in the case of a less-than-perfect question, this can go in many different ways. All in all, try to be constructive. This is not that:

> this post is shite

While this is entirely the other way around and also not pleasurable:

> Welcome to Stack Overflow! I enjoyed reading your first question, so unlike those negative nancies downvoting your question, I upvoted it instead because I don't want you to run away from here. However, could you pretty please with sugar on top actually include the code that you're talking about, and if it pleases you, could you perhaps also include the actual error message instead of *"it dosent work"*? Thank you, and I hope you'll have a nice time on our site!

I mean respect goes both ways. When an OP posts *"This doesn't work [code dump]"* they obviously haven't read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), or they couldn't care less and just want their damn code fixed. Don't spend an extreme amount of effort in such cases, a short comment in the form of

> Please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

or in Markdown:

> Please read [ask] and provice a [mcve].

will suffice, especially when followed with advice specific to the question to show the OP what *exactly* is missing from their question.

Of course leaving such a comment does not take away the need to close- and downvote where appropriate, so don't leave comments *instead* of voting.

Now in identifying a problem, there's another problem. Some people can't take any form of criticism. They take it as a personal attack or an attack on their honor. They don't want to hear that they did something wrong, and instead become angry at the person telling them that they did something wrong (for example omitting the actual error message, due to which the question is unanswerable but for those who actually want to run the OP's code by themselves). Ignore such people, run away. You're not going to educate them, and they'll even begin to tempt you to lose *your* temper, which is always a bad thing.

Also note that textual communication is *hard*. From [How to not get a question answered, by Eric Lippert](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2008/02/20/how-to-not-get-a-question-answered/):

> I understand that there is an inherent and pervasive bias in pure-text communication which makes statements intended to be *good-humoured* sound *sophomoric*, makes statements which were intended to be *friendly* sound *smarmy*, makes statements which were intended to be *enthusiastic* sound *brash*, makes statements intended to be *helpful* sound *condescending*, makes statements which were intended to be *precise and accurate* sound *brusque and pedantic*, makes statements which were intended to be *positive* sound *neutral*, and makes statements which were intended to be *neutral* seem downright *hostile*.

Comment: What good does it do to leave a very general comment like, *"Please read How to ask and provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example"*? Why not just downvote, vote to close, and let the system leave the comment for you? Unless you have some very specific advice for the asker, I can't see a compelling reason to (A) waste your time, (B) risk setting off someone's ire that they'll aim at you personally, or (C) cluttering up the comment field.

Comment: @Cody because the question being put on hold can take a long time, while that comment gives the OP something to read and correct their post before it's closed. You don't post such a generic comment if the question is beyond salvaging or if you don't have the time to engage in helping the OP. When they become annoyed at you, remove the comment and run away.

Comment: // , It also helps if lurkers without an account, unfamiliar with the SO model, stumble across a down-voted post that matches their search results. I have done this, and the comments helped me ready my mind quite a bit for my first few questions on here.

Answer (score 7):

This will sound like a sad "me, me" story, but it is intended to answer your question and add something useful to the discussion.

A few months ago I was on the receiving end of what I perceived to be the famous Stack Overflow Attitude. It turned me off posting for a long time, but didn't stop me reading. The poster schooled me by returning a quick google result for what I needed, and I was hurt because I honestly thought I had just tried the same search and come up empty-handed.

The funny part is, now I am a bit better at researching, and I'll see bad questions on forums and facepalm pretty hard. It's tempting not to want to help at all.

I think sometimes the message returned is "You didn't try," when the more appropriate message could be, "You need to practice trying more."

Asking a question can make you apprehensive--you see you got a reply (oh boy!) but then you read it, and it's like you got a hammer for Christmas. Well.. they should be grateful!

I think this community is interesting if some people choose to be polite and some don't. Hostility, however, is unnecessary. Maybe there should be a link you can slap on a "closed" banner that tries to explain what it's like to read a bad question. That it's like being asked to teach somebody how to walk. You don't teach people how to walk, you teach them how to bike, maybe. How to fly a plane. They learn to walk on their own.

Answer (score 5):

> Should I be nice to new users?

You *can*, but you don't *have to*. This site is about Q&A, that is, information exchange, not pleasantries exchange. Note 2 points:

- Questions that are of the structure

  > Hey everyone, how are you doing?
  >   --Question--
  >   Thanks a lot!

  Should be edited to retain only the `--Question--` part (see "Making a good impression" [here](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)).
- Questions are marked as protected exactly in order to block comments in the form of "thanks".

So, here are 2 instances in which the site guides you towards not being nice (but not being not-nice either!). There is nothing wrong with any of this, it's just sticking to the target.

Up to here "nice" was in the context of what we are used to. Now we have a slightly different context in https://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice, which states:

> 1. Rudeness and belittling language are not okay.
> 2. Be welcoming, be patient, and assume good intentions.
> 3. Don't be a jerk.

And there is nothing wrong with these either. Notice that being nice in this site is mostly not doing not-nice things. As long as you are not actively a jerk, rude etc. then you are (almost) nice by this site's standards.

The conclusion is that **not saying "please" does not make you not-nice**. Asking you to remove "please" is a bit excessive, but not wrong per se. Use pleasantries only when needed, they often clutter the already cramped comments section.

Note that there is nothing here about the quality of the question (including downvotes), it's completely unrelated.

Comment: If the word "please" clutters the comments section, then an entire new comment telling someone not to use the word "please" in comments _certainly_ does. Other than that, I agree that it's mainly important to just avoid being not-nice.

Comment: @Don'tPanic It's not that a single word clutters it, but if every comment was part of a polite conversation with "please", "thanks" and so on then it does. Notice that the OP uses it twice in the same comment. Also, I do agree (and I thought my point was clear) that comments about comments are clutter for the most part. When I said it's not wrong per se I meant that the content is not wrong, not that posting it was not wrong.

Answer (score 4):

You should always be at least somewhat polite to strangers, but you're here out of your own free time helping others, and people who ask questions should at least have the proper understanding of what they are actually receiving out of you helping them.

If you detect any disrespect toward the site's rules and guidelines then it's OK to be strict, or even better, just ignore them. If they violate the rules flag the post and move on. There are others to help here who apparently deserve it more.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, be nice to them. I find that a comment requesting that the OP improve their question by letting them know what they need to add, and directing them to a relevant help page if appropriate, lets other people know that there is still hope of a good question. Maybe add a bit of editing, if necessary, to make the question as it is at that time more presentable and encourage the OP by showing that we are paying attention.

If they take no notice or action in a reasonable amount of time, i.e. they are not nice back, *then* downvote and vote to close.

Answer (score 1):

My two cents:

You should be nice to everybody. It maybe a matter of choice, but one must choose being nice over being mean any day.

As far as removing salutations and clutter from the post is concerned, it is welcome to spend some time to take the initiative to remove it. But using words like 'please' should be fine in comments when making suggestions or requesting clarifications.

Answer (score -2):

No, you are right.
Some points why I think so:

1. I've read often that you shouldn't use Hi, Hello, Cheers and so on and shouldn't end with thanks or something alike. I can grasp that, because it pollutes the question and you can't move your mouse over the question and see directly what its all about. This doesn't apply to comments in my opinion.
2. It may be true that this is a Q&A platform and as user1803551 stated correctly

> This site is about Q&A, that is, information exchange, not
>   pleasantries exchange

I would reply that, hospitals should help to cure your illness and give you advice but I guess you would be rather upset if the doctor would say to you:

> Mr/Ms XY you have Cancer/AIDS/Lupus go to room 6 ... Next patient please

btw. its never lupus ;).

3. Just downvoting is not an option, because the person will not know what his/her fault was. Its like screaming at your children without telling them their misdoing (I am not an expert but i've heard that its wrong).
4. Avoiding being not nice is like avoiding to make code messy. The code **may not be** messy but it still **can** be not good.
5. One thing one might often forget is that behind the question is a user with an actual problem. The problem might not fit into stackoverflow or doesn't meet the standard but you are not "unnice" to a question but to a person.

During time in the university my professors always stated how important it is to not only point out whats wrong but begin with something which is good.
Maybe the question was rubbish but the intent was to write "clean code".
This may not apply to all questions but if you want to improve the quality of the question, the user and in the end, of SO, you can read the question think about the intent and give them a hint on what is wrong in the comments.

If SO was an office full of developers, I think we wouldn't reply to a person who asks a question which is somewhat stupid with:

> What ?

or

> Ask your question different so that I can understand you

But rather reply

> Sorry your question is not clear to me could you please give me an
>   example.

One thing we should also keep in mind is that, culture is different. What to some might seem normal can be harsh to someone else. I've heard a rumor about japanese tourists in Paris, who get a "cultural shock" because things that are normal in France seem so offensive to Japanese people.

Coming from a German background here a quote by Otto von Bismarck:
*“Be polite; write diplomatically; even in a declaration of war one observes the rules of politeness.”*

Comment: Adding fluff to text in the hopes of not offending the person at the other end of the conversation isn't very productive. Pleasantries are welcome in face-to-face communication, but unnecessary in this particular Q&A format and many other formats on the web (forums, mailing lists, ...).

Comment: What do you mean by isn't very productive ? Just stating it is unnecessary in Q&A doesn't make it so, could you (please) say why ?

Comment: I'm merely talking about the "fluffing" of text in order to make it appear more pleasing, if that's its only purpose. _"Please show some example input and output"_ versus _"I'm sorry, but I'm having a hard time understanding your question. Could you pretty please show some example input and output so I can understand it better?"_. The latter is unnecessary if it's done for the sole purpose of pleasing the OP, in the hope they do not get offended by a short comment. Be to the point.

Comment: If pleasing someone was the whole purpose of being polite I guess most of us would have stopped doing it a long time ago furthermore is pleasing something different than not offending but I get your point.So then, can we agree that it should be: As precise as possible and as polite as necessary ?

Comment: Yup, that's about it.

Answer (score -5):

To clarify my point, since the source material (which I still can't find) offers some cloudiness to my example:

If you value bringing up novice/naive users as returning and savvy questioners, and this is part of your interest in participating in the community, then I absolutely recommend kindness as something that is worth it. Especially for new developers, having the sophistication of judgment to understand what constitutes a complete/reproducible question (yes, even with FAQ answers) for other coders is a challenge. In those cases, kindness can help someone who might otherwise get scared away or shut down to engage and improve.

As I said in a comment... my example was from a post of over a year ago when I had no experience yet in the workforce as a dev. So I'm not really in a place to attempt to justify my post or impressions at the time -- I can only communicate what they were.

OP:

> Yes, please. And that doesn't mean only using "please" in a sentence... it also means offering clear and actionable feedback.
>
> I'm an active reader, voter and commenter on SO but I have only ever posted one question (since deleted, it seems, so unfortunately we'll both have to rely on my recollections). It was my first question ever, and I did my best to provide as much information as I thought was useful. The first and only comment I got (along with a downvote) was something hostile about how I hadn't provided enough information -- but the comment didn't deign to give me any hint as to what the poster thought was missing. I guess they just thought I needed to know that I sucked at constructing my question, and that was it. No one else weighed in on the question and I ended up figuring it out myself.
>
> That was over a year ago, and I still haven't written another question. Surely not the only reason I haven't, but it definitely discouraged me from cultivating a habit of posting on SO.
>
> So I guess, if you as a commenter value having new users get better at writing questions rather than just being discouraged from asking questions, the answer to "should I be nice" is always yes -- in the sense that it's a kindness to write comments with a goal of helping the user to write better questions, not just tell them they're wrong.

Comment: By way of constructive feedback, I've just looked at the question, and the comment you're referring to asked you to add a minimal, complete, verifiable example, and linked to https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. That's pretty self-explanatory. Your question *did not* provide such an example. Instead you described a sporadic problem that you yourself couldn't reproduce. You provided some code snippets that were neither complete or self-contained, that could not run because they referred to variables and data sources that weren't included in the question, and a link to your github repo.

Comment: The first thing anybody downloading your github repo would do is try to produce the shortest example that reproduced your issue, by paring down code until the problem is identified and isolated. **You** are expected to do that first part of the debugging process before asking a question, and include the resulting example in your question.

Comment: Far be it from me to attempt to justify my actions or impressions as a fresh developer over a year ago (and SO still shows nothing in my 'questions' part of my profile from my view, so color me impressed/embarrassed that you found it) -- but your explanation is indeed helpful.

Comment: I should say that your question was definitely better than most. It showed effort, and you tried to provide the code you thought we would need to answer your question, it was well worded and showed the steps you'd taken to try and fix your code. The problem is that the type of question you were posting not well suited to this site, and it's the kind of question we see constantly. What you needed was a second set of eyes to sit down with your codebase and help you debug it. That kind of interactive debugging is out-of-scope for Stack Overflow, it's not a service we can provide.

Comment: meagar can see your deleted questions in your profile because he is a moderator. They should be visible to you via this search: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A4318362+deleted%3A1

Answer (score -8):

Indeed it's not a sin to be nicer. I think being nicer not only to new users but all the users gives a sense and feeling of your high professionalism. Otherwise new users feel reluctant to continue using the site on getting unfriendly gestures from other users.
Being a user of this site for almost a year and a half, I have seen many people with different attitudes; some even strike off "thank you", "please help", "help appreciated". Some user edits if I give the details that I am new to Stack Overflow or to any other topic. They consider it an offense. Anyway, being nicer does not cost anything and does not violate the rules and regulations of the site.

Comment: [Should "hi", "thanks", taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2950)

Comment: There are lots of balances we all try to keep here. Between people using the site as the site rules ask them to and using it other ways. Between cluttering "please's" or "thank you's" and simple civility. Between enforcing (and taking a chance of offending) and "letting it go" (and site its purpose). Between overzealous and wise enforcement. Fundamentally, we're mostly strangers to one another here; civility and professionalism are most appropriate. All the world's religions teach (in various forms): Treat others as you want to be treated. They're right.

Comment: There’s a difference between Q&As addressing the topic and comments addressing the user. Comments are ephemeral artifacts anyway, you can stuff them with polite phrases as you wish, after the addressed issue has been resolved they should/will be removed anyway, sometimes even earlier.