# Top Network Posts showing wrong score?

Tags: support, bug

I just noticed that under my Top Network Posts section my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37643296/6214222) to the question "[How can I make sense of the else clause of Python loops?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37642573/6214222)" shows a total score of 20:

[image]

whereas the actual [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37643296/6214222) only has a score of 19 (19 up/0 down).

I'm guessing that someone must have at some point upvoted and then unupvoted the answer and that the system only stores the highest score an answer has ever been at. Is this true? Because it sure is confusing.

I'm not sure if this is on purpose or a bug. If it's on purpose I don't get the point of this feature.

Comment: [Cross-site duplicate](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/256398/post-score-in-the-top-network-posts-borked-somewhere)

Comment: Perhaps it is including "anonymous voting", which are upvotes from users that are not registered.

Comment: @TravisJ Is that actually a thing?

Comment: @Keiwan - It is actually tracked, so yes. Is that the reason for this display issue? Unsure.

Comment: @TravisJ No, you cannot vote if you are not registered. You can try with incognito tab to verify. To upvote from another stackexchange community (i.e. register to another one but not SO), the page requires you to join to the community

Comment: @smttsp - Yes, you can vote if you are not registered. It even loads a modal saying explicitly, "*Thanks for the feedback!*". This vote may not be reflected in the score of the post officially, but that does not mean that data is not retained behind the scenes. You can try with an incognito tab to verity. To upvote, simply click the upvote arrow, and watch the modal appear. The message will be there along with an invitation to join the community.

Comment: @TravisJ, I got your best answer: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/328271/1746852 which has 248+, 1-. In an incognito tab, I upvoted and received "Thanks for the feedback, sign up or log in" alert.I'm checking the votes again, still the same. I go to your profile, that is also the same. I'm not sure how an unregistered user can upvote.

Comment: The vote isn't actually reflected on posts that I have seen, even on accident.  Their internal database tracks these votes though for other reasons, such as traffic from search engines, user signup rates, etc. The suggestion above was that, *perhaps* that vote is being used on accident in the count displayed, or perhaps it is cached, and then invalidated later on. I am unsure, it was just a lightweight guess at somewhere to look. Clearly you can see the ability to use the upvote tool though as an unregistered user, it just has a different outcome than if you are a registered user.