# How to encourage others to be welcoming to newbies?

Tags: discussion, new-users

We all know that new users often ask dumb questions without reading. The answers to [Should I be nice to new users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/328269/should-i-be-nice-to-new-users) provide plenty of good reasons why we, as a community, should encourage new comers and guide them to the protocols for asking good questions. But we also need to acknowledge that it takes time to learn how to get the information you need.

My question is, what's the appropriate way to respond to a short blunt comment that is correct but really doesn't attempt to help them improve the question and could easily be read as 'you're not welcome'?

An example might OP asking a poorly worded question about how to correct a piece of code and a comment comes back 'learn to unit test and use a debugger'. There's nothing particularly rude about the comment but it's hardly welcoming.

Should we just ignore the comment and post our own more encouraging one (in other words, lead by example)? Should we also point the other commenter to information on how to encourage new users?

Comment: Flag it as "Rude or Offensive"

Comment: @TylerH sorry I should reword the example. I wasn't really meaning the comment was bluntly rude, just very unhelpful to a new user. I'll rephrase to make that clearer.

Comment: upvote said comments of course.

Comment: Using debuggers, performing unit tests, and debugging skills in general are all essential to programming. Suggesting that the user learn those things is very good advice in my opinion. Why would you say anything? The only thing that would make a comment like that more helpful would be a link to some helpful debugging information.

Comment: *Should we just ignore the comment and post our own more encouraging one* - I have seen a good, constructive comment stop a dog pile in action so sometimes it can stop things from getting worse. People are willing to just up vote an existing comment rather than post another saying something similar.

Comment: Post a comment _Welcome to SO, read our [tour] before posting to understand how to ask good questions_ and move on.

Comment: maybe ask Stack Exchange management to [ban yet another "impolite expression](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/281787/165773 "like they did a while ago")? They seem to believe that this way works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the job of moderators to handle situations of moderation. OK, that's a little syllogistic... Telling users to behave/be nice is something best left to moderators, because of their ability to actually enforce the "Be Nice" policy. Comments on Stack Overflow are transient and intended for request clarification, basically, not for telling another commentator to be more helpful.

If someone posts a comment that is rude or insulting, flag it with the prescribed reason of "Rude or Offensive". If the commentator is someone who 'should know better', then they probably are astute enough to notice when their comment disappears. Likewise if they just comment with something like "this is so basic/you should know this already/go away", flag it as "Not Constructive".

If you feel so inclined, you can *also* respond with a comment that provides constructive criticism, like "please include an MCVE" or "Check out the help center for more info on crafting your question", etc. Hopefully an astute user will notice this comment and perhaps have a change of heart about their own comment and delete or edit it. Don't directly engage rude behavior, because that's not what comments are for, and it's not the best way to handle the rude comment, anyway (loop back to my first paragraph).

If the comment is mildly helpful but phrased in such a way that it might be construed as not constructive or too vague or slightly rude, you can expand on what the initial comment was trying to get across, perhaps in a more polite way.

Comment: Ok that makes sense. Use of 'not constructive' flag seems like the way to go for the type of comments I have in mind. thanks.

Comment: @sprinter A helpful comment that is simply blunt or brief, instead of filling the comment with lots of fluff that doesn't add any useful information, isn't "not constructive".  It doesn't merit any type of flag at all.

Comment: Ok I think I'll delete this. With 5 downvotes I'm clearly being told it's a dumb question. Thanks for your ideas in any case.

Comment: @sprinter You can't delete a question with an accepted answer.

Comment: "Please include MCVE" is not what most authors of such questions consider "be nice". I can't see any way to express "you did not even try" so it *can't* be considered rude or offensive by someone. I'm not sure if this recommendation is good suggestion at all... (mine would be downvote and move on... but there is another group that would consider it "not nice")

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov If "you didn't try" doesn't work then use "you didn't follow the rules" instead. I tend to just copy/paste the close reasons but some people use shortened versions. Either way, you're not telling the OP anything that the system won't when their question gets closed so it's unlikely to get removed for being rude or nonconstructive.

Comment: @DavidPostill yep I decided to accept the answer and take my medicine. To be honest I have a lot more to say on this based on conversations with bright young developers in my company who tell me they wouldn't dream of using SO. But clearly I can see I'm out of step with the rest of the community on this one.

Comment: @sprinter The problem with asking questions is... it is really hard to ask good questions, really easy to ask bad questions, and really easy to ask a question instead of searching for an answer first. Most good questions concerning mature popular technologies have been asked and answered hundreds if not thousands of times already. On average, the asker puts far less effort into researching their problems and formulating their questions than is expected of them. I haven't asked a question in a long while, because I can usually answer it myself given enough time and effort.

Comment: The main reason that anyone will encounter flack when asking questions, is that they have formulated it in such a way that they are the only person who will be helped by it, no future users will be able to gain anything useful from it.

Comment: @TinyGiant I agree with you. The majority of new users are unlikely to be willing to put the effort into learning how to ask questions. The motivation for my question was to see how, as a group, we can encourage the small subset of newbies who are willing to learn and will contribute well in the longer term.

Comment: @sprinter It's not a dumb question; it's a valid concern considering working together constructively is how we advance as a species. If the comment doesn't offer any constructive commentary, keep flagging away as "not constructive", regardless of how much some may want to castrate that option. If it does offer constructive commentary but in a rude manner, feel free to flag it as Rude or Offensive, but beware that it's clearly a matter of tolerance here; much of the meta community is OK with being rude if it makes them appear/feel elite, and likewise a mod handling the flag may not agree.

Comment: @TylerH thanks for that comment. I try hard in my business to encourage young developers to use SO but all but the thickest skinned avoid it which is a shame as I've found it so useful over the years. I'd love to see us be more welcoming to newcomers but I realise I'm pushing against the tide.