# Why was this question put on-hold as "asking for off-site resources"?

Tags: discussion, support

One day ago, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40494241/5211833) question ([<10k screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LlPAp.png)) was put on hold because it was "asking for off-site resources".

I see nowhere in the question where the OP is asking for off-site resources. At the bottom of his question, he asks:

> Why are they being used in this example?

This is his question; He is asking about why something was implemented in a certain way in a program. His question has nothing to do with trying to find an off-site resource. Furthermore, I don't see anywhere in his question where he mentions trying to find an off-site resource.

It seems that a much more appropriate on-hold reason would have been "very low quality" for lack of research, or maybe "a duplicate" for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/730764/try-except-in-python-how-do-you-properly-ignore-exceptions?rq=1). But not because the question was "asking for off-site resources".

Maybe I'm mistaken in my conclusion, but is there a reason that five users put this question on-hold for "asking for off-site resources"?

---

**Note:** I am not "whining" because the question at hand was closed, so please don't make that assumption.

Comment: the reasoning they likely used to choose that close reason is the question is answered in the documentation. I don't agree with that reasoning, but i also don't see the question as worthy of being reopened, so.... ohwell.

Comment: It's a question trivially answered by a simple Google search. I appreciate the effort you invested to answer the question well, but it feels like pearls before swine -  there's good documentation out there that could answer the question easily. That it was closed with an incorrect close reason seems secondary in comparison. The downvote you received on your answer may be connected to the question's trivialness, too, rather than any quality issues with the answer itself

Comment: @KevinB What? That really doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @leaf in other words, the question was closed using a close reason for something it wasn't meant for. but... it's a terrible question so i don't care. at least now it will be deleted. well, not anymore since the answer was updated. woo. /s

Comment: @Pekka웃 Your right, and I was planning on removing my answer in the next couple of hours when I have some spare time. But just to make things clear me asking this question is not related to my answer. I'm not "whining".

Comment: @Kevin puts it very succinctly. That's the short and long of it

Comment: heh, i butchered my own comment and now i can't fix it.

Comment: There is no close reason that approximates "This question isn't good enough to belong here".  There used to be, but the company that owns this web site lowered their goals to be competitive with Yahoo Answers without telling us.  Well, no need, everybody can tell.  So SO users pick whatever is available in the close dialog.  "Off-site resource" is certainly not inappropriate for this particular dog of a question, there are plenty to choose from.

Comment: I care the close reason, it aids the asker how to improve the question, also warns other visitors what's the problem of the question (While I agree most askers like that wouldn't look back and edit what they dropped actually, it doesn't mean you can't do your best own job that picking a right close reason)

Comment: I was one of the close voters too. I'm sorry for choosing the wrong reason. I found that page in the 10k tools page as it was heavily downvoted. I agree that "too broad" would have been a better reason. Andras has explained this clearly.

Comment: @BhargavRao Its cool. I get it. Sometimes drastic measures are taken to remove crap from SO as fast as possible.

Comment: I'm curious: would Very Low Quality stick as a close reason for a question like this? Probably one of the few that doesn't actually apply. Lack of research is a trigger to downvote, not to flag VLQ.

Comment: @Gimby Frankly, I find VLQ to be the most appropriate close reason. The OP clearly show a lack of research by not using google.

Comment: @Gimby VLQ isn't a close reason.  It's just a flag to put the question in the Triage queue so that someone else can pick an *actual* close reason.  It's really only ever a useful flag for someone who doesn't know what any of the actual close reasons mean, so if you've taken the time to read through them, there is never any reason to use VLQ.  Just choose an applicable close reason yourself rather than asking someone else to do so for you (mostly because that someone else might choose to not flag it for closure at all).

Comment: @Servy very nice, that puts things in perspective.

Comment: I don't think "too broad" is appropriate, as there is only one answer for the OP.  It's very short, one or two paragraphs.  I do think the close reason is acceptable because 1) the answer is a link to the official documentation and 2) no other close reason approximates this.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I am one of the close voters. I agree that the choice of close reason is suboptimal, but as others have already noted in comments, the question is so egregiously off-topic that I didn't bother writing a custom close reason.

There *is* rationale to the close reason I chose, though. Read the first paragraph of the question:

> I've seen "try:" and "except ValueError:" once in a program and I don't know what are they and what are they doing in the code? I would like to understand what it is and its uses in programming to see if I could implement it to some of my own code.

The asker confused Stack Overflow with a tutorial service (that happens a lot). The time they took writing up that question should have been spent googling exceptions, or even better: reading a tutorial. I understood that question as a request for a tutorial, since that is exactly what the asker needs to read.

One might also say that the question is too broad, but that could be equally challenged by saying that a 101 could be given to the asker in a few paragraphs. The best course of action would probably have been a custom close reason, but frankly I always find it important to close such *blatantly* off-topic questions as soon as possible (and by the above reasoning the tutorial recommendation reason was a good enough fit for me). Too bad that the question attracted 4 answers until closure, we should have been quicker.

Comment: It's a shame people answer such garbage questions for those few upvotes, which will be revoked when the community deletes the question anyway. [Please stop being a care bear](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252740/5211833) and flag/close vote that immediately.

Comment: @Adriaan I pretty sure that your comment is partially directed towards me, so sorry up front. But I didn't answer that question to gain a few up-votes. I was pretty sure nobody would visit the question and upvote anyway. I answered the question because I had some spare time and figured I could give the guy a decent starting point. But, as I said before, I do apologize that my answer may have caused a hindrance in deleting the question, and will stop being such as care bear in the future :P

Comment: I can't find any words that the asker is finding tutorials directly, so just think we should not direct the story that it is asking for tutorials. And if the question cannot be answered without a tutorial, that sounds like too broad

Comment: @amuse:  The answer concisely acknowledges that this was the wrong close reason.