# Why was this question downvoted?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, downvotes, downvote-reason

I have asked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41188908/4164298) question and was downvoted. Can someone point out issues with this question, so that I can improve?

Edit: I have read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252677/4164298), but want to know which reason [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252740/4164298) justifies the downvote to my question.

Comment: Yes. I want to know what's wrong with my question. I have read that before @πάνταῥεῖ

Comment: LOL, I wanted to correct the grammar issue in the title, but "Why was my question downvoted?" was already taken...

Comment: thanks for letting my reply and multiply my meta rep by 0. It's my first answer on meta :)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre thanks (and +1) for writing a detailed answer, which IMHO is really helpful for the OP. Duplicates aren't bad *per sé*.

Comment: My pleasure. It felt very good to answer on the meta site and get upvotes. I cannot wait for my 0 acceptance points now :)

Comment: As it stands, you'll get at least two badges out of it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I had a quick look and:

1. your question is unclear. There isn't a real question formulated.
2. The "I've got no output from CRON" is very close to the "why this code isn't working".
3. You could have used other means to try to know more (for instance a log on disk to monitor your script result): `ssh` + `sudo` + `crontab` add a lot of complexity and may deter people from attempting anything (but downvotes or close)
4. The image in the end with the password enter is irrelevant and doesn't help understanding your problem, and after your edit, the source code of the page is even more confusing: the problem is not about entering IP address
5. "let me know if you need more details": you're admitting that the question is bad.

All those reasons above make people downvote your question: it's unclear, and shows no research effort.

(and posting here with a link to your question is a brave thing to do, it may draw more downvotes on your question. I think it's called the "meta effect": you're experiencing it now, with more downvotes all of a sudden)

How to improve it:

- you could edit it to remove the useless parts (the picture, anything not vital to the question, the start of the script is pointless, all the echo, the awk stuff could be summarized to the result they achieve)
- provide a minimal example, so people can reproduce easily (tricky with all this ssh and crontab stuff: you have to research more or people won't be able to reproduce)
- end your question by the real question. Don't put it in the middle.

Now is a good time to edit it. Your question is discussed in meta, so people will check it. And maybe they'll counter the downvotes if they think they're unfair. That is, if you edit your question of course.

Comment: 1. I don't understand!
2. Read my question again. I have mentioned clearly ONLY `crontab` is NOT working (I tried with `cd` and `ls` command and they are working).
3. I tried already and when ONLY one command is not working, it is an issue with the usage of that command and those who are expertise in that can help. NO help yet, not even a single comment.
4. May be, I agree. Thought that might give clarity what I was trying.
5. You can't just simply interpret what I meant ! I ain't expert, when people who know about particular domain troubleshoot an issue, they might need more details!

Comment: I don't mind downvotes, but if someone can be help to my original question, that is appreciated.

Comment: go over the question checklist: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist

Comment: I have edited my post to be more accurate. Please don't shoot the messenger. _I_ did not downvote, I'm just explaining why you got downvoted. And when you say "only 1 command isn't working" it's the most complex command I ever witnessed: sshpass, ssh, sudo, crontab, password that may need escaping from the shell but that you don't provide... so no wonder why `ls` works and that doesn't!

Comment: I have edited now. Please check. Also I didn't understand `sshpass, ssh, sudo, crontab, password that may need escaping from the shell but that you don't provide... so no wonder why ls works and that doesn't`. Do you mind explaining and helping me out?

Comment: I'll try to help directly on SO site.

Comment: I think I better ask this here.  Is it a good practice to ask a question like `Why my question is not well reached?` in meta to get more views(I understand that might invite more downvotes also)?

Comment: @prado well yes if you really want help - that's what meta is for. If you don't ask you may not do better on the next question, receive more downvotes and ultimately might end up worse in a question ban. But then do ask about ways to improve the question, don't ask "why is this downvoted".