# Can the site come out with an objective criterion of asking questions and down voting

Tags: discussion, support

Asking my question again, keeping the following points in the scope of discussion:

1. What is the criterion for determining whether a question is fit for asking? Can an algorithm be designed to warn users in advance?
2. What is the criterion for down voting and how it is applied?
3. What is the targeted audience of this site and to whom does it cater to?
4. Should people below a certain well defined criterion be allowed to ask questions?

Comment: 1. Read the help centre. 2 ditto + the tooltip on the down vote button. 3 Read the help centre. 4. Sure, otherwise how would folks get started here?

Comment: to point out [this is the help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) that @RobertLongson is talking about but you also have the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as possible duplicate of [The Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help).

Comment: 2: "this question does not show any research effort" reason may apply to this question. It would be good idea to show that you've already read information in help center and search this site for reasons for downvote for example.

Comment: see [When is it justifiable to downvote a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252677/when-is-it-justifiable-to-downvote-a-question)

Comment: Relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43221220/what-is-the-best-way-available-to-add-multiple-social-sites-such-as-linkedin-and

Answer (score 9):

To attempt to answers your questions, although repeating asking questions like this probably won't get you far:

1. Look at the [Help Centre](https://stackoverflow.com/help). Specifically [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and what's [On Topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
2. Anyone ([> 125 rep](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down)) can downvote for any reason. They do not have to provide a reason. Even if they do, you may not agree with it and that's ok. Downvotes *should* be used for:

   > whenever you encounter an egregiously sloppy, no-effort-expended post,
   >   or an answer that is clearly and perhaps dangerously incorrect.
   >   https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down

   but there is nothing preventing downvotes for any reason. If your question is good, one or two downvotes shouldn't matter.
3. Developers and software enthusiasts, I guess? Look at the [2016 Developer Survey Results](https://stackoverflow.com/insights/survey/2016) for a breakdown of who comes here.
4. If you ask too many low quality questions as determined by the community, you may receive a question ban or cooldown. The exact operation of this is not disclosed.

Comment: Asked for a proper question on how to encorporate scientific computations of a well respected community in the app but got voted down without proper explanation. What do stack overflow esteemed members expect of its users - to write a scientific library of its own then why not to start from the basics and assembly language and designing your own compilers. Moderators please explain. Its unbecoming of the sites' high priests attitudes towards newbies and anyone who asks a question which people are unable to answer.

Comment: This attitude has brought lot of organizations down and stack overflow is not an exception.

Comment: I...have no idea what you're trying to say.  SO expects it's members to ask well researched, specific questions as defined in the help centre. If you asked for help about a particular library, given you had already attempted something, you would probably get a better response.

Comment: Sir the question is how to incorporate GNU Multi precision framework in an iOS app and got voted down without proper explanation. I am asking well defined and well researched question but trying to know how to incorporate it into an iOS framework. If I would have known then would not have asked. Whats pains me is the snobbish and high handed attitudes towards any newbie. If thats case then site should make it clear that newbies are not allowed.

Comment: Bringing discrediting questions via down votes without proper mechanism is unfair. For me it doesn't matter but for lot of other people (especially in software industry) stack overflow profiles and down vote matter for their career advancement and then making it so casual does not do any justice. Moderators should understand this. Also not allowing any fair discussion and just down voting is an unnecessarily bullying up and harassment of people with whose views one does not agree and this is not what a proper and fair discussion is about.

Comment: The whole idea of a question and answer forum is a place where people can ask questions and if some one finds it suitable he answers or doesn't like question gives reasoning before down voting . What may be easy for one will be difficult for others.

Comment: i have been barred from posting answers just because I don't agree with some views or have some difficult questions. Its just an example of my way or highway and this attitude will not take one far.

Comment: Again put on hold for being too broad. Anything which seems unpleasant gets blocked or barred one way or another. May be Microsoft's 1990's impact on the site. But then the same set of people should look at current day Microsoft and try to learn some lessons.

Comment: @NikhilPandey, please drop the rhetorical question subterfuge. You're not asking about general guidelines. You're asking about a particular question of yours. Simply providing a link to the question in the meta post and ask for clarification. This will get you better results. Alternatively, you can create another rant in affirmative. Then the correct title is "SO stinks and newbies are abused".

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, just asked a question with the same title https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/346655/so-stinks-and-newbies-are-abused

Comment: I am just asking that shouldn't down voting or anything negative should be properly handled and reviewed and there should be an objective criterion for that. The site focuses on questions which are as objective as possible then shouldn't this be applied here as well.. And what I am seeing the trend that anything which is unpleasant is just barraged with negative reviews and voting even in meta , where there should be open and honest discussion.

Comment: @NikhilPandey you're confusing "unpleasant" (which your question is not) with "not showing any research effort" (which does apply to this question). Reading the help centre, and therefore not asking various questions which are answered there, realising (from the help centre) not to ask multiple questions, showing that you'd read other questions and their answers prior to asking by referencing them would all have changed things considerably for you here.