# Ideal approach to asking questions and interacting with answerers

Tags: discussion

I recently asked a detailed and well-structured [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45123836/output-file-written-to-by-pool-of-processes-is-cut-off-at-arbitrary-locations), and quickly after that, a user posted a helpful comment:

> are you flushing the output objects?

I responded:

> No, I'm not sure what that is. I have one output file object that all processes are writing to. What does flushing the output object mean?

The second sentence where I mention that I have one output file is to make sure he's aware of that, since he said "objects". He then replied with this:

> Show your code, then we'll talk.

I researched and figured out what flushing the object means, and it turned out that what he hinted at was in fact the problem, and I was able to fix it. I then responded thus:

> I'm not sure why you didn't proceed when I had answered your question, but that turned out to be it! I added output.flush() then os.fsync(output.fileno()), and the problem disappeared. If you would like to put this in an answer, please do. Thank you very much!

Later, I found that a user downvoted<sup>1</sup> my question (that was my first upvote!), and upvoted the user's "show your code" comment, which suggested that I'm missing something, since more than one person disagreed with me.

Based on your evaluation of my question and the comments, did I need to include more code? My assessment is that I included all the relevant code. The code I omitted was code I described: processing the input, and writing to the output file. What did the commenting user mean when he said "show your code, then we'll talk"? Of course, the user might just have been wrong, but I'm asking this assuming he is right and I'm missing something about the way questions are asked on SO.

I want to understand this specific situation so that I can 1) post better questions in terms of, for example, the code I include, and 2) better understand what users (especially senior ones) mean when they hint at certain things.

But beyond understanding this specific situation, my general motivation for asking this is to better understand the preferred approach for asking questions and interacting with answerers on Stack Overflow. Was my last response to the user in the comments an agreeable one, for example? I'm really interested in becoming a more active and influential part of the Stack Overflow community, and I do appreciate the stringent, well-thought-out rules and the attentive and critical community, but in some cases I don't get it. I appreciate any input, especially from people who have been part of this community for a long time.

<sup>1</sup>: I went over [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252677/when-is-it-justifiable-to-downvote-a-question?noredirect=1&lq=1) but didn't find something applicable to my question.

Comment: First of all the commenter ask to show your code. Now I'm not an subject matter expert on Python but it looks you included some code unless you have left out (too) much of that first snippet. In that context [mcve] is relevant. You didn't make an edit to your post so it looks like you didn't respond to the request of the commenter. If no further code is needed maybe explain that in a comment but at best you show what happens after `pool = multiprocessing.Pool(..)`.

Comment: Question and comments look OK-ish to me although having such a elaborate question for a missing `flush` call might fall into the category of *not useful*. Keep in mind users are not here 24/7. It might take time for them to respond if you just catched them at the end of their day (in a weekend).

Comment: I surelly downvoted too if I was the guy you are speaking of. It's easy: Is this question helping people? - I think not. Why? Problem is not obvious, text may be too present, too dense, but the main point is you ran in a kind of [X-Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Is that makes you a gad guy? Nah - But it does not deserve upvote anyway. (Up|Down)votes are done to make goods questions with good answers more visible. Lot of better questions / answers exists for your issue, so you didn't get upvoted. That's all.

Comment: "output truncated" is very common problem for all languages/frameworks. Post does not *demonstrate* any effort to find an answer - so would deserve downvote unless Python is rare/new language that no one used for file output yet (which is hard to believe is the case). Also as noted earlier post missing https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve (but that is *not necessary* reason to downvote, but to close).