# Questions Downvoted - Kindly Asking for Willing Review

Tags: discussion, specific-question, downvotes

Here is the Question:

[Rust: Specialization Tree (vs Linear Inheritance)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45125084/rust-specialization-tree-vs-linear-inheritance)

The way I see it: It's perfect for Stack Overflow because

- Programming Question
- Technical Methodology / General Case
- Real world Example / Extremely Relevant
- Fully Presented / Logical
- Exhausted Searching / Helpful for others

I don't feel the downvoting is justified, and I would like to have my question reviewed to find out what's wrong. I would just like an honest review. As programmers, I'd like to rule out any contradictory reasons.

Some proof links:

- https://aturon.github.io/blog/2015/09/18/reuse/#ending-1-the-trait-based-approach
- https://internals.rust-lang.org/t/pre-rfc-inheritance/4888
- http://smallcultfollowing.com/babysteps/blog/2015/10/08/virtual-structs-part-4-extended-enums-and-thin-traits/#antithesis-thin-traits

Comment: You are worrying about a single downvote, seriously?

Comment: > I am constantly downvoted here and other websites.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When is it justifiable to downvote a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252677/when-is-it-justifiable-to-downvote-a-question)

Comment: I'm actually asking for a review here.

Comment: When questions are downvoted, they do not get as much attention, but at any rate if there's no reason to downvote one, then that is an issue, and I cannot fix that myself. Also, ditto when it happens often.

Comment: @HTDE Well, I'm by no means a rust expert, but that error message you're getting is pretty straight and clear, no?

Comment: I don't understand some of the comments here - certainly "what might be wrong with my questions" is an on-topic question for meta, is it not?

Comment: Unless maybe I never use the account for that reason, especially a new account, that never gets used.

Comment: I think that asking for review of your question is on-topic for meta, but regardless of whether it is on- or off-topic, you will want to beware of the [Meta Effect](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/235225/what-is-the-meta-effect) where asking a question on meta about a stackoverflow question brings additional attention to the question, possibly positive attention and possibly negative attention.

Answer (score 16):

I can't speak for the downvoter, but your question appears to be a stream-of-consciousness thing more than a focused question. You describe some feature in Rust, that you think *should* work with the current version of the language but does not. That's fine, if a little verbose (but nothing I couldn't follow along with — my questions and answers are often loaded with exposition that no one has objected to so far). You then provide a code example, along with an error message (that, fortunately, you understand). That's fine too.

But then you end off with an *assortment* of questions:

> Am I missing something? Another way to keep the type specific? Is there anything I can do in the meantime? Any special workarounds? Anybody know why (technically) the compiler doesn't now?

It's OK to ask both why something doesn't work a certain way *and* how to work around it in the meantime, but I count no fewer than *five* question marks in this paragraph alone, and they aren't all technically asking five different questions either.

So perhaps your question was downvoted because while your train of thought is easy to follow, it's not exactly presented very well. Granted, this might sound like a nitpick considering it's just one paragraph and the rest of your question seems fine, but I think the paragraph does create an overall impression of the tone and writing style of the question, and I think that does sway voters a certain direction more than they would otherwise have.

Again, I can't speak for whomever actually downvoted your question, but if you're looking for pointers on how you can improve your question, I'd suggest making your question(s) a little clearer. Maybe something like:

> My questions are twofold:
>
> 1. Why is this not possible with the current version of the compiler?
> 2. How can I implement type-specific constraints in the meantime?