# Is Stack Overflow Meta the place for discussing and correcting problems with questions?

Tags: discussion, questions, meta

I was told here in the meta that it is not, and the correction for my question I received was that Stack Overflow is not a place to ask for help from programmers with programming questions.

*[Questions Downvoted - Kindly Asking for Willing Review](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/352320/questions-downvoted-kindly-asking-for-willing-review)*

Comment: Where were you told that? I can't see it in any of the comments or the answer

Comment: @Clive: "I'm afraid this isn't the right place for a review. – user0042" No idea what on earth user0042 means by that...

Comment: @Boltclock right, I actually meant the _the correction for my question I received was that Stack Overflow is not a place to ask for help from programmers with programming questions._ bit, I wasn't very clear

Comment: Meta is the absolutely correct place for a review, provided both sides are open to discussion

Comment: He probably meant that Meta is not a place to get *downvotes* reviewed. The only time votes are invalidated is when they were cast fraudulently, and that's something you need to flag a moderator to investigate (assuming you have some reasonable suspicion that they were). If your question had been *closed*, then that would have been a reasonable thing to get reviewed/discuss on Meta. Or, if you were just open-mindedly looking for input on how to improve a question. But, as it stands, you were just looking to rant about it having been downvoted. We can't do anything about that.

Comment: that's just it, we don't need to think about it. A huge, huge majority of people who frequent this site know how to use it, and agree that it's being done correctly. You can try to pass that off as those people "refusing to confront issues", but really, you've just got it wrong. Happens more than you might think.

Answer (score 23):

Yes, it is.

But that doesn't mean that any question posted on meta is received the same.

Your meta question contained the often seen exaggeration of drama with a sentence like:

> I am constantly downvoted here and other websites.

Looking at your [profile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LpRVq.png) (before you invoked the [meta effect](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251487/getting-to-know-stack-overflows-voting-culture) on your question) there is no evidence you were *constantly downvoted*. When users visit your reputation history they might conclude *hey, that doesn't seem right*. And that possibly influence how they judge you and your question.

Next thing is that you bring up *other sites* even with links. What on earth do you want to discuss with us about those links? We are not policing the policy of other sites, nor are we willing to become your personal coach. Your question seemed to invite us to review all your contributions around the internet.

The meta crowd is happy to help out with giving advice on how to improve a post but that does require it starts with an honest, narrow scoped presentation of the problem to be discussed.  The meta regulars see a daily flood of complaints about unjustified down votes which in most cases turns out that all those (single) down votes were indeed justified.

The best approach is to be humble and assume you did indeed overlooked something and from that starting point most of us are happy to have a fruitful conversation. Without it, expect direct, harsh sometimes rude comments. The latter ones can be flagged for moderator attention.

Comment: @HTDE That's enough comments. No where did rene call you a liar, and yes it's up to you to take feedback *you have asked for* constructively. If you can't reply in a constructive and civil way - just don't. Thanks.

Comment: @JonClements maybe the first revision wasn't up to par ...

Comment: @HTDE no need for you to apologise, just be more careful how you ask questions in the future. 'other accounts', and links to Q&A other sites, are irrelevant to SO and are essentially just noise.  Nobody is assuming that you are lying, and 'schoolyard bully' accusations like "Are you calling me a liar?" will not get you far on SO, nor will appeals to experience, (they may backfire).