# My question received a down vote but I need some help to understand the reason

Tags: support, specific-question

I made [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45821682/how-can-i-redirect-an-entire-site-in-codeigniter/45824038?noredirect=1#), and I received comments and answers, then I accepted an answer because it solved my problem. I think this is what SO is for, also I made a *good question*. Then looking at my question and it's at -1, and in the comments, and in one answer tells  me:

> Including index.php in routes is wrong. Please check the docs.

Maybe I am programming in the wrong way, I am still a little new in CodeIgniter, but I do not think that that is a *bad question*. Please help, what can I do? Is it correct the down vote? I´ve had some down voting on questions, and sometimes I understand and some times I don´t understand, but in this case, I am worried.

Comment: Any user with > 125 rep can down vote a question and that is considered to be correct. See also: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252677/when-is-it-justifiable-to-downvote-a-question

Comment: You searched the web and found answers but you didn't explain what you found and why those answers were not suitable.

Comment: You've received just *one* downvote before you posted this... You may need to develop a thicker skin.

Comment: The whole idea behind SO is that it's _moderated_ and _controlled_ by its users if it's a good question, you may get some downvotes but the upvotes should outweigh that.

Comment: You can use the checklist: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist to see if your question addressed all points thoroughly.

Comment: @yivi there is no rule AFAIK that you're only allowed to ask a meta question after 3 down votes, which the OP now qualifies for due to the meta effect.  Grow a thicker skin might be the outcome of all this but this meta question doesn't look like the regular rants we see on this topic although it is a bit under researched.

Comment: @rene, never said there was rule. But a meta post for one DV seems excessive, IMO. The OP is relatively newish, but not new and not a stranger to voting in SO. Still, nothing wrong in asking about it I guess.

Comment: I understand some down votes, but I just said that the people understand my question, and they answer it. Why they down vote after is marked like acceptes?

Comment: People downvote based on whether they think the question is likely to help *future* visitors, not just based on whether or not you got the answer you needed right now.

Comment: @Mary point is, we want the content to be useful for future visitors that have the same problem you're facing. For that to work the questions need to be clear and understandable for everyone, not for just you and the lucky poster that got it right.

Comment: @BilltheLizard I'm okay with you writing an answer that was similar to my draft. If you start leaving almost similar comments as mine then it becomes annoying ... stop doing that....

Comment: @rene Did you think we were playing *Slowest* Gun in the West today? ;)

Comment: @BilltheLizard well, at least I could try to win that game ... ;)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There are two red flags that I see in your question. The first is minor.

> I am searching in all the web an find some answers but don´t work for me, or at least, I do not know how to use it.

You can probably just remove that. It doesn't really serve any purpose to tell us that you searched if you aren't going to tell us specifically what you found.

The second is a little bit more of a hot-button for people.

> But this doesn´t work.

This one is a bigger problem because a helpful editor can't just remove it. You have to replace it with something more informative. You should explain *how* things aren't working. Does it give you the wrong output? No output at all? Take too long to execute? Spit out an error message? If so, what did it say? We really prefer to have specifics here in order to help you.

It looks like someone was able to figure out what you needed already, and that's great, but I'd still take the time to edit the question into better shape (particularly since it's getting renewed attention due to linking to it here on Meta). And please remember to give as much information as possible on future questions.

Comment: I change my question, some people help´s me, and I add some other things, I hope this works, becouse my question get another down vote

Comment: @Mary what you're seeing now is what we call the "meta effect". Meta has  a lot of activity from people who care deeply about the standards on the site. You basically shined a massive spotlight on your question, so the extra attention means more votes. Since the question is iffy, that means more downvotes. It can also go the other way and give you more upvotes if a good question is linked. (do note that everytime someone tries to "use" the meta effect to their advantage, it backfires)

Comment: @Patrice what happen if I said that the other answer solve my question?? my reputation goes down?

Comment: @Mary not sure how that related to the meta effect I explained... Your rep is going down because you are getting more downvotes, and you are getting downvotes because you linked your question here.

Comment: @Mary, still, the net change has been positive so far. You've received the same amount of downvotes as upvotes, and upvotes have a much greater effect on your reputation (although not necessarily on other things).

Comment: @yivi what can I do, delete my question in meta or in SO?, it´s still been down voting

Comment: @Mary well the best would be to improve your question so it becomes worthy of upvotes. In any case, deleting any of the questions won't be possible, as they have upvoted answers. Considering Bill here (and Brian on your Stack question) spent time answering you, it would be kind of rude to delete their effort, no?

Comment: @Patrice you have right, but I change all that all of you are tell me, and other people edit my question too, and still is been down voting, and I do not know what more I can change.