# My question was ill-received, even though I tried to show my research and include all relevant details

Tags: support, specific-question, quality-improvement

I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46946639/cannot-gain-focus-on-edittext-programmatically-in-android-even-after-trying-pre).

Although the question was asked before on Stack Overflow, I had looked at multiple answers and tried them before asking (and mentioned them in my question). I think my question was clear, and I added as much details as possible without bloating the question and so I might've gotten a bit angry about the downvotes.

It was also marked as duplicate against a question which was clearly not a duplicate.

So, **I'd really like to know how I can further improve my question to counter the downvotes?**

I did read the question about [when it is justifiable to downvote](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252677/when-is-it-justifiable-to-downvote-a-question), but I consider this post to be well-researched, and I had shown what all I had done.

Comment: Ah well. Now at least one guy edited my post and capitalized the start of my sentences. I'll do that from next time on :/

Comment: @ColonD: I do see you claim to have read the proposed duplicate. Have you considered *putting that fact in your question* and addressing *how* the duplicate did not apply or work for you?

Comment: @ColonD: it is important to *share your research*, make it clear and explicit that you read that other post. We can't read your mind, just as much as we can't read the minds of those that voted.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I did do it on my actual question on Stack Overflow

Comment: Ok. I understand. I did put all the methods I tried in my question, but it would have been better just to link the previous questions

Comment: I agree that the title of my post initially did sound like a bad question. that is why I added the "even after looking at other SO answers" part. even though it sounds like a stupid, that certain feature wasn't implemented in a clear or intuitive way, causing many people to ask such questions.

Comment: I've cleaned up the comments to focus on this specific question; this is not the place to re-hash age-old discussions on when to comment with voting.

Answer (score 5):

Your question does seem to show your research but this sentence is not going to cut it:

> I have tried the following solutions mentioned elsewhere in Stack Overflow but none of them seems to work

You should have added links to the posts you tried those solutions from. So you could have said something like:

*from [Force EditText to lose focus when: some keyboard keys are pressed and when user clicks on something else in the activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40325325/force-edittext-to-lose-focus-when-some-keyboard-keys-are-pressed-and-when-user) I tried [code block] but that gave me [what ever it did]*

and that basically for each possible solution you tried and dismissed.

Doing it that way achieves two objectives:

- it narrows down the scope of your problem
- it helps users who want to answer to verify if a possible solution was already tried.

Linking to the other questions with non helping answers also helps to check if you correctly assessed your actual issue. By not sharing those links the visitors had to redo your research without knowing if what they will find was actually what you tried.

I'm not an Android dev but isn't it important to share on which version of the OS you have this issue? Ignore this if the problem is version independent.

One final remark:

> so I might have gotten a bit angry about the downvotes.

Never loose your temper, no matter how bad received a post will be. Down votes are for the post, not for you. Just feel sorry for your post and work with feedback you get to improve it. Leaving a comment like: *hey @user, thanks for finding that dupe, I did find that one and the accepted answer looked hopeful but didn't work because... I fail to see what is differnt in my case though* or similar wording will get a much better reception then *No, not a dupe, read my question!*

Comment: Thanks for the feedback :) . but the two questions are not duplicate but opposite, and I did point that out

Comment: Sure, it is still your task to edit your question why those suggested duplicates *appear* to be related but how they can't work in your specific context. A duplicate doesn't become not a duplicate because you say so. That only happens because there are verifiable facts that prove the answers in the dupe can't be applied in your case. Those facts need to be supplied by you.

Comment: ok. but I did not feel the need to elaborate as my question was about *getting* focus while the marked duplicate was about *removing* focus. hence there was nothing more I could point out ( and i even pointed out why I couldn't use the way the poster did in the code in his question)

Comment: That is the whole problem, right? You don;'t feel the need because the root cause seems clear to you. Casual visitors don't find this so obvious, hard to believe, think they have seen this before, etc. For tricky behavior it might take a careful explanation and MCVE to show/present the issue.

Comment: I do understand what you're saying, but in this specific instance, there is no way of elaborating any further -  this was the comment I wrote: " 
I read that, but it's about losing focus, not gaining it. Even if he explains how he got focus in the first place, he does it in xml, and not programatically.".

Comment: Note that another key advantage of showing why another answer doesn't work for you is that sometimes you simply won't have implemented that solution correctly, or not properly adjusted it for your situation.  Without seeing that mistake, others are just as likely to repeat that original solution (if it really is the correct solution) and won't be able to see how you improperly used it and so won't be able to correct that problem.