# Stack Overflow questions downvoted because of "Hello" and "Thanks"?

Tags: feature-request, help-center

I am quite sick of my questions in Stack Overflow being downvoted because of the leading "Hello" and the "Thanks" at the end.

I always try to write constructive and comprehensive questions with images and examples. Every time I discover an answer I add it to the list, keeping the question updated.

Shouldn't a question be considered only for its content and quality instead of stupid frippery like these?

I don't think that a simple "Thanks" or "Hello" could hurt people or ruin the question, don't you think?

Comment: Why would you think they're being downvoted because of that?

Comment: On what basis do you feel that questions are being downvoted for saying "hello" or "thanks"?

Comment: so... if you think your questions are downvoted because of that.... remove the hello and thanks? I also don't think it hurts, or that it warrants downvotes. If you think it's why you're downvoted, I'm confused as to why you include it...

Comment: Because it happens a lot of time that my questions (last one is this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47833311/phpunit-code-coverage-false-positives) get 1 downvote after few minutes without reason or comment and they get edited without "Hello" and "Thanks", just as this one.

Comment: correlation, causation, something something......

Comment: Especially as a cursory search would have shown that "hello" and "thanks" are **noise** and shouldn't be included anyway.

Comment: @StockBreak So you don't actually have any reason whatsoever to think that that is why your questions are downvoted, you're just assuming that that's why your questions are downvoted without any evidence at all.  Good to know.

Comment: @Patrice you are right, but why shouldn't I greet or say thanks to future people helping me?

Comment: @StockBreak It's considered noise, that's irrelevant for the contents of your question. I'd edit such out, but would certainly not downvote a question if that is the only problem.

Comment: @StockBreak because it's in the rules and guidance of the site? In any case, you don't write for the people answering you. You write for all the other people who will Google their problem, see your question, and get their answer from it. Do these people a favor, focus on the actual problem you/they have. The fluff is.... just that. fluff. Again I don't think many would downvote just for that. So I wouldn't take the easy route and think this is the reason for the DVs.

Comment: @StockBreak its just accepted on SO that we remove this question fluff and get to the point, there are many meta/blog post on the subject. The short answer is you should not included "hello", "thanks", etc. in your questions/answers. I wouldn't say it warrants a downvote, if I see this I would just edit to remove.

Comment: And to talk about the question you linked. I frankly don't know symfony or phpunit, so I may be wrong... but it feels like an incomplete question. Too often I play with a project and see something weird, thinking "but this class is only getters/setters, it can't be problematic?!" and then break my head for a bit before I actually look in the class and realize "oh F, I was wrong". I would say including the actual content, instead of a generic "this is what it does" would be better (at least)

Comment: You do not seem to have that many downvoted questions anyway... Are you using only this last question as evidence of this alleged behavior?

Comment: The posted example question is too ambiguous from my perspective and likely others as well so that is most likely the reason for the down votes.  Code coverage is a necessary topic, but becomes a judgement call when it comes to deciding whether or not to cover "everything".  Try to ask more pointed questions that have direct answers, not fuzzy answers.  If you want to talk about coding concepts you can take it to https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/ .  I appreciate it can be  difficult to decide which is which sometimes.  That is also a judgement call.

Comment: @Jeremy I didn't know about that site, it seems exactly the right place for my question which is about a "concept" more than a practical example. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: see also: [When is it justifiable to downvote a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252677/839601)

Comment: @Jeremy mentioned question is a poor fit over there - it would be quickly voted down and closed, see [Where does my tool question go?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7253/where-does-my-tool-question-go) Recommended reading: **[What goes on Software Engineering (previously known as Programmers)? A guide for Stack Overflow](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7182/31260)**

Comment: From your last 10 questions only 1 has a net negative score at this moment...

Comment: @gnat I agree the question as stated would be a poor fit since it is posed as a specific question about a general topic.  It is the general topic of unit testing and code coverage that should be acceptable.

Comment: 'El tiempo te dara la razon'. Most of the comments here are mocking your post and not getting to the point with saying 'it's not because of the hello that your posts are downvoted'. Now SO automatically cuts the 'hello'. Time has shown the truth. Sorry about that

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> I am quite sick of my questions in StackOverflow being downvoted because of the leading "Hello" and the "Thanks" at the end.

That's probably not what's happening. Both downvoting and editing out greetings are relatively common activities on Stack Overflow. It's quite probable that these two had nothing to do with each other.

> I always try to write constructive and comprehensive questions with images and examples. Every time I discover an answer I add it to the list, keeping the question updated.

That's great! Keep it up.

> Shouldn't a question be considered only for its content and quality instead of stupid frippery like these?

Yes, absolutely. Most probably are.

> I don't think that a simple "Thanks" or "Hello" could hurt people or ruin the question, don't you think?

No, they don't ruin a question, and they aren't really worth a downvote, but they don't really *add* anything either. As such, they're considered unnecessary by many active users of the site. There's even a script that will remove a lot of common greetings, but a lot of less common ones get through and people edit them out manually. It's nothing personal, we just prefer if people get to the point of their question here and leave out greetings, signatures, and taglines.

Comment: I think you are right, they don't add anything to the answer and I will probably not add them to my answers/questions anymore. I still think that my questions will be a little more impersonal and I am sad because I lost 15 (still counting) hard earned reputation points, maybe I deserved it...

Comment: @StockBreak You seem to be still assuming you were downvoted because of those comments... it's very unlikely that was the case.

Comment: @yivi I am referring to the points I lost because of *this* question, not the one on StackOverflow. The other one was probably too vague and more suitable for softwareengineering.stackexchange.com

Comment: @StockBreak Votes on meta do not affect your reputation. Do not fret about it.

Comment: I think so because I had more than 1110 points before this question. Are you sure?

Comment: @StockBreak Yes, I'm sure. Votes on meta do not affect your reputation. Check your "reputation" tab in your main profile to see where it went.