# How can I know what I did wrong in my question?

Tags: discussion, questions, downvotes

Occasionally I ask a question and get downvotes which don't provide any information on what exactly I did wrong.

Everyone makes mistakes and I really would like to improve.

Is there a way for me to know what was my mistake so I will not repeat it?

Assuming I did a mistake, what can I do to correct it and get an actual answer to my question? I sense there's a snowball effect that once I got downvoted, future viewers will automatically assume that the question is wrong and downvote it without even reading it.

Comment: Are you able to see the pending Close Votes on your latest question?

Comment: Do you not find the help/tour information useful for diagnosing your question problems?  What is it missing?  How would you impove it?

Comment: You are convinced none of the reasons in *This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful* applies?

Comment: @Stijn How can I do it without pressing 'close' myself?

Comment: Not sure, that's why I asked :) Try pressing 'close' yourself, you should see a '3' next to the off-topic reason, select it and you should see the full close reason.

Comment: @rene Someone did comment 'search in google' which I commented back that it's what I've been doing for the last few hours. So that brings us to my second question.

Comment: This is the *down vote guidance* for voters: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252677/when-is-it-justifiable-to-downvote-a-question

Comment: @EladWeiss did you include *I searched for [search term] and found x ,y and z, none of those apply because [reasons]* in your question?

Comment: @rene mmm no. Perhaps that's it...

Comment: "I couldn't find what I liked on Google" does not automatically qualify the question for SO.  Shopping questions are not on topic.

Comment: @Hans Passant Is this off topic?
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49531163/does-qt-have-something-like-a-pager-widget. I really do want to learn...

Comment: also: use the checklist https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist and apply to your post what is missing.

Comment: @rene That's excellent I'll keep that in mind.

Comment: @rene I reviewed the list, but I still don't understand why my question is off topic. I'm not asking for a library recommendation, I'm asking if a specific, well known, tagged library has a way of doing something. What's the difference between that and questions like "how to do ... in ..."?

Comment: No, you ask for a ready made solution. Something that comes off-the-shelve or something that is build for you to order. If it had clear requirements you could ask it on SoftwareRecommemdations but in its current form it will not fly there either.

Comment: What you could have done is attempting to implement a pager widget your self, and then ask a question when you're stuck, saying something like *I think I'm reinventing the wheel*. Answers might fix your issue or offer an out-of-the-box widget that does what you want.

Comment: Thanks in Advance is noise and should be edited out. That leaves nothing more of your question then "something like this", not counting the title. That feels like an extremely lazy question and is a bit disrespectful to anyone who you invite to answer it, let alone that future visitors gain nothing with that question. It is not the kind of content we would want here. having 10,000's of these type of posts would scare anyone off including the users with the knowledge and that are the ones you seem to need ...

Comment: @rene Finally I understand. That actually makes sense which is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @rene In general if I look up a way of doing something, and can't find it - I should not ask here on SO. Does that sum it?

Comment: @rene BTW I'm a little afraid my comments sound sarcastic. I want to clarify that they are absolutely not.

Comment: That is about right, you should try it, and then share where you're stuck. That is a much safer approach. In theory *How can I do X* is on-topic but when phrased like that by today's standards it will not fly. That only worked the first two months after the site was launched in 2008.

Comment: It depends on the scale and scope of the "something" you are asking about. But generally speaking, if you are attempting to do something and asking about it; you are expected to show your efforts and explain what's blocking you from carrying on.

Comment: @EladWeiss my comments are sarcastic/blunt. I can handle your tone of voice, no worries.

Comment: Shopping questions fly on reddit, quora or in chat. Questions that detail 1) what you need to do 2) the code you wrote to try and accomplish it in minimal form 3) why it didn't work for you, including inputs and outputs and/or detailed error messages, *these* questions fly on SO.

Comment: @Elad I want to take a second to thank you. It's rarea meta question asked this way ends up positively like that. Normally OPs fight every inch of the way against the feedback. We all make mistakes and it's ok. You learned from it and aren't Q-banned from it. Imo, you'll be fine :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I presume you're talking about [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49531163/1079354), right?

Where to begin...

- The question is asking if a library has a specific feature - in this case, a paging widget.
- The answer is regrettably boolean; it either does or it doesn't.  It likely *does*, though.
- A quick Google search turns up some information about how to do pagination in PyQt.

A couple of things pop to mind to see where you'd want to ask this question.

- The search results don't have any visuals to go with them.  You're just staring at code.
- It's tough to see without actually implementing something if you get what you're looking for.  (This isn't meant to be a dig at you.)

So, what happened when you asked the question here?  In a nutshell, **we're not equipped to handle these sorts of yes/no questions, and rightfully so.**  It isn't useful to say "yes" or "no" to the question and call it good, since what you're *likely* asking is, "How do I actually implement it?"  In premise, that would make your question too broad since we're not set up to write all of that code for you.

What we're *really* good at is, if you have written code and that code is giving you trouble, if you provide that code, we can help you figure out what's going sideways with it.  Giving us *something* to start with is better than giving us *nothing*.

Comment: Thanks. Few comments: (1) You are wrong about #3. I did enough google research to know that's not what I needed. (2) I didn't at all want to know how to implement, since I can do it myself. I even mentioned it in the original question. I just wanted to know if such a feature already exists so I can save a few hours. rene has explained to me that this is not what SO is for and I accept it.

Comment: @EladWeiss Are you claiming that Makoto did not find some information about how to do pagination in PyQt? Regardless, a yes/no question that does not ask how to implement it might not be too broad, but still translates to a request for an off-site resource (since no one is willing to take "yes" or "no" for an answer).

Comment: @E_net4 1. I also found pagination info in PyQt. It's not at all what I asked. 2. I understand and accept.

Comment: @E_net4 Yes it was a little counterintuitive for me to understand why my question is off topic but I understand now (after some effort :))

Comment: @E_net4 my favorite reference on these matters is [Question closed because yes/no answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/183183/165773)