# Why was this question down voted?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, downvotes

I don't get why [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54307095/5148062) question was down voted?

Note that after the down vote I edited the question and guessed I should try and remove my code attempt at the solution (after reading [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252740/5148062)), but I'm still left with a down vote?

Edit: As discussed in the comments below, I've rolled back the removal of my  code attempt. It is visible once again...

Comment: Only the downvoter could tell you why they voted as they did. Voting is anonymous, and we could only speculate why would anyone vote one or another.

Comment: The edit actually made the question worse. Now it's missing any attempt to solve to problem, nor does it explain what it is you are struggling with. I don't know what in the linked meta question gave you the impression that removing the attempt is a good idea since the answer there says: Downvote if the question is "asking us to do ... anything, with no attempt to do so oneself".

Comment: The only thing I see mentioning code in your link talks about poorly-formatted code blocks. It doesn't say all code is bad. If you have a wall of code with missing indents, extra line breaks, etc, put it through a beautifier (most IDEs try to do this automatically and also have an option to manually trigger a full-file operation).

Comment: @BDL One would think so, but I gave it a shot anyway after reading the link above in particular the part where Denis say "Feel like puking in the face of the OP's wall of hideous spaghetti code?"

Comment: @Rhdr: True, but 15 lines are not a wall of hideous spaghetti code. This is more targeted at 1000LOC with no formatting at all code blocks.

Comment: Hmm? Is your answer based solely on the answers on another question? Might be a duplicate then?

Comment: I was looking for a translation for c++ to pyqt

Comment: Anyway I have rolled back the last edit, the code is visible once again...

Comment: Posting this question here is likely going to draw more downvotes from the added attention.

Comment: If there is nothing wrong with the question why vote on it at all? By all means if there is something wrong down it but at least let the op know why he is being down voted

Comment: Likely there is something wrong with the question, but the voters just don't want to justify themselves, which is perfectly reasonable; votes are anonymous by design.  The insistence that not telling you why the question was downvoted means nothing is wrong only reinforces why we have it that way.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You haven't stated what your problem is in sufficient detail.  You say you have some code you want to translate, but then you only say, "The loop & QLatin1Char is giving me trouble."  Well.  What trouble?  Why can't you translate it?  Is it not working, is it giving you errors, do you not know how to write a basic loop, or is it the body of the loop giving you trouble?  There's just so much detail missing in what isn't working, and why you can't fix the problem.

Also I don't see any mention of what research you've done in how to do what you're trying to do in PyQt5.  I'm not familiar with the topic, but this doesn't sound like something so esoteric that there wouldn't be any information out there already on how to solve the problem you're trying to solve.  What information did you find on the topic, and why could you not use the information presented there to solve this problem?

Comment: @Rhdr I don't see any evidence of research *in the question*, which is what really matters.  Saying what line of code you're having problems with doesn't address the fact that you haven't stated *what the problem is*.  Just saying, "there's some problem that I'm refusing to tell you anything about on this line of code" is not a good question.  That you want to post an answer doesn't change the fact that *the question still needs to be a good question*.  If you want to help others with the same problem then you need to *state what that problem is, clearly*.

Comment: @Rhdr A question that just states, "here's some code, there's a problem in there somewhere" and an answer that states, "here's some code that fixes the problem" with *literally nothing else about it* isn't helpful.  How is anyone with the same problem going to find that question if the question never even states what the problem is.  If someone with the same problem does find the question, how will they know that it's actually about the same problem?