# Downvoting copy/paste answers

Tags: discussion, downvotes

I frequently see answers to questions which are primarily copied and pasted from documentation. While there are no problems with plagiarism if the answers clearly state that they have reproduced the documentation, it still seems lazy.

Is it then reasonable to downvote those answers? 
Is it also reasonable to downvote the question if the answer could so easily have been found in documentation?

Comment: Extremely related, if not a dupe: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252677/when-is-it-justifiable-to-downvote-a-question

Comment: that's more to do with questions. My question is primarily concerned with answers.

Comment: No, it is not reasonable to downvote to punish.

Comment: I believe it is simple enough: answer seems useful (for me personally, for future visitors,  etc), vote up! Doesn't seem useful (not informative, misleading, very poor, waste of space in any sense): vote down!

Comment: `so easily have been found in documentation` --> not always easy to find the correct documentation and then to search inside that documentation (ex: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53577522/8620333 I spend a lot search for that part and I didn't find it and the answer is mostly a copy/past from the documentation)

Comment: @Gimby Who said anything about punishment?

Comment: To me, the main downvote guideline is offered by the tooltip "This answer is not useful". Selected part from documentation offered to a question is, in general, something that could definitely be useful. Sometime you don't see the obvious, and someone pointing at it can save you lots of time wandering on the wrong paths. Of course,if it "seems lazy", or if it were clearly not *that* helpful to me, I wouldn't upvote either.

Answer (score 4):

**Answers** to questions that are mostly copy-paste from documentations should in general not be downvoted if they completely answer the question.

There are a few exception though were a downvote might be warranted:

- The answer does not fully address the question. When a question, for example, asks about using language feature X in a specific piece of code, then just pasting the documentation page there is not enough. The answer has to address (and fully answer) the specific question.
- The question is close worthy and should have never been answered. Note, that asking for something that is answered in the docs is not per-se a close reason.
- The same answer can already be found on SO. In this case, the question is a duplicate and should not be answered. If it is not a duplicate, then the answer has to address the differences.

**Questions** that ask for something that can be answered by looking in the documentation are already discussed in [another meta.SO question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252677/when-is-it-justifiable-to-downvote-a-question).

Comment: +1. Conversely, I tend to **upvote** precisely selected quotations from documentation that completely answer a question. Sometimes the relevant/important bit in the docs is either misplaced or not emphasized.

Comment: "The question is close worthy and should have never been answered" - downvoting answers because of question is very controversial topic... I'd not add it to list of "were a downvote might be warranted" (at least without some sort of clarification).

Answer (score 1):

As with voting on any post, the question is always, "Is this post useful."  While lots of other people feel that just reproducing readily available information is useful, I certainly don't, and I cast my votes accordingly.

We expect people asking people asking questions here to be doing their research, which is *going* to include looking up the documentation for the topics related to their question.  This means that there's really only two reasons to be quoting the documentation in an answer, either it's not obvious why the topic you're quoting is related to the question (and so you wouldn't expect people to have looked their before asking), or it's not obvious why the quote answers the question asked.  Both cases would involve additional explanation.  In the first case, you'd need to explain why the topic you're quoting is actually relevant to the situation, because it's non-obvious, in the second, you'd need to explain why the quoted information actually answers the question (or you may need to explain both).  If these explanations aren't an important part of the answer then it's a pretty strong sign that the entire answer is not in fact a useful addition, and also that the question was simply poorly researched, as it's answered in entirety by readily accessible information, making it not a useful question.

> While there's no problems with plagiarism if the answers clearly state that they have reproduced the docs

This is false.  Plagiarism can take multiple forms.  *One* of those forms is using another's content without indicating the original author(s).  Another form is reproducing the works of others without adding your own original contributions.  Answers citing others' information are expected to use that information to *augment* their own original content.  If they don't, it's plagiarism.  Flag accordingly.

By the way SO once created an entire section of the site that existed for the primary purpose of plagiarizing the documentation for various topics.  It was called "Documentation".  It ended up needing to be shut down because it was not only not useful, but actively harmful.  It turns out that asking questions about information *not* already covered in a language's documentation is helpful, but just regurgitating it isn't.

Comment: I don't think it's at all unreasonable to expect answerers to do more than just dump something they found elsewhere.  At least try to put a modicum of effort into explaining how it works for that specific issue.

Comment: @fbueckert For lots of questions no other explanation is necessary because *the documentation is clear and explains the issue well*.  Of course, there's no value in just repeating it, because people searching for solutions to that problem will find the documentation, but so many people just incorrectly assume that documentation can never explain a problem well.

Comment: I hear you; the .NET documentation does a pretty good job of explaining itself when I run into an issue, so I don't even need to search SO for that issue.  I  think it's reasonable to expect users to spend time looking at that prior to asking their question.

Comment: Stating "it could have easily be found" is always simple when you already know what you are looking for. But even if it is simple to Google: if the question isn't a duplicate, then there is no reason with which it could be closed. If there is no reason to close it, then it can be answered. If the answer completely answers the question, then I see no reason to downvote.

Comment: @BDL And others think that answers should *actually be useful* in order to be upvoted, rather than upvoting answers just because "the question doesn't merit closure".  Of course I can't *stop*  you from upvoting posts that aren't useful (or that are plagiarism), in violation of the site's guidelines.  All I can do is hope that you'll change your behavior and starting following the rules and voting on post's usefulness, and hope you choose to do so.

Comment: @Servy: I did not say anything about upvotes. I think we disagree on the useful part. I see such questions as useful because they act as additional signpost to the documentation, quite similar how (well written) duplicates also act as signposts.

Comment: @BDL If it's not clear how the question at hand would relate to the solution in the documentation, and there's no readily accessible information out there already linking that problem to the documentation, then that would be covered by the first case of my second paragraph.  That would be a situation where you couldn't expect reasonable research to find the solution, and so an answer that *explains why the topic with the solution is in fact related to this problem* and then includes that solution, can be helpful. That's not very common, but it can happen.  And it would never be *just* a quote.

Comment: @Servy: I don't agree that there are only two reasons for quoting. Documentation is often huge and the person who asks may simply failed to found the right part. At the same time such documentation part may be completely obvious for the person who was asking after he/she reads it and it may directly answer the posted question in a most straightforward way. In such case only the quotation may be enough, no additional explanation needed. Of course such cases are quite rare.

Comment: @godfryd I specifically mentioned in my answer that if the answer is in a section that isn't clearly related to the topic at hand, it would be appropriate to explain why that section is in fact related, and then quote the relevant portion.  Saying that my answer doesn't cover the cases and then listing one of the two cases I covered doesn't really prove your point.

Comment: @Servy maybe I wasn't clear enough: the case that I described is not covered by any of the cases you listed. The case that I described is when the quoted documentation fragment is directly, clearly and without doubt related to the question (so is the docs section it's in). In fact it directly answers the question without any comment needed. You are still missing the point that someone might do the research and search for the answer in the documentation and yet he may fail to find the answer. Documentation may be very big, search engines are not perfect, humans are also not perfect.

Comment: @godfryd Either the solution was in a topic clearly related to the issue, and it's reasonable to expect them to have found it, or it's *not* a topic that's clearly related to it, and you'd need to explain why it's related to the issue.  If they knew that the topic being asked about would be describing the behavior of what they're asking about it's *not* reasonable to assume they wouldn't have looked through it.  If it really is so clearly the place that you would expect to find that information, to the extent that no explanation is necessary *they should have had no problem finding it*.

Comment: @Servy Thats exactly where you are wrong. Even when the solution was in a topic clearly related to the issue it is *not* reasonable to expect that someone *must* find the right documentation section, even when he/she spend quite some time searching for an answer in the docs. Some documentations are really huge and like I said search engines are not perfect. Yet, when someone provides the right fragment it can be really obvious for the person who asked that: a) this is clearly the answer to the question 2) it is in documentation section clearly related and where it should have been searched

Comment: @godfryd Care to provide an example of an answer so obviously related to the topic no possible explanation is useful and where it's unreasonable for the author of the question to have found it on their own?

Comment: @Servy any such example would be artificial, but ok. Lets assume that someone is a scikit-learn newbie and he wants to run _any_ regression model training in parallel, on multiple cores. He searched the docs but missed the answer. Then someone gives the answer by pasting the part of RandomForestRegressor _n_jobs_ parameter - this is easy to miss, the docs page on RandomForestRegressor is quite big. Googling for "scikit learn parallel execution" also won't direct you to this. This is just an artificial example but much more plausible cases _do_ happen.

Comment: @godfryd Using that exact search term you stated provides lots of information on how to use that tool to run code in parallel.  I've never heard of it before you mentioned it, but what makes you think that none of the information presented when searching on that topic would help someone use that tool to run a model in parallel?  There appears to be lots of information on the topic?  Is it really all wrong?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187588/discussion-between-godfryd-and-servy).

Comment: @godfryd If you think that the information found when searching on that topic is not useful, then a good question would *be explaining what they found when searching on that topic, and why it wasn't helpful to them*, and an answer wouldn't be just quoting the documentation, but explaining what you did, in that the solutions they're looking at are lower level tools that aren't needed in most situations, and describing the higher level tools, and how to use them to solve the problem that they have, that are more suitable for the situation.  Just quoting the documentation would be a bad answer.

Answer (score 0):

What matters is the usefulness of the answer. You seem to be primarily concerned about laziness ("it still seems lazy") but there's nothing wrong in being lazy. In fact if a useful answer can be produced using lower amount of work I think it's only better.

As a side note: in my opinion there's a lot of laziness in the technology in general - instead of doing something by yourself manually you build a machine that will do this work for you.

That being said, in most cases just providing a link to the documentation is not the most helpful or useful answer and providing a more detailed explanation is preferable. But still in my opinion downvoting such answer is an exaggeration. Just upvote other, better answers. (or provide one by yourself!)