# Is downvoting someone for asking a very complicated question okay to do?

Tags: discussion, questions, specific-question, downvotes

I believe I just got downvoted because I asked a [very complicated question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57466834/1364007).

I am aware of opinion-based downvotes, broad question downvotes, but does a very hard question also call for a downvote?

Seems counterintuitive as what we do everyday is solve very complicated issues.

I did not deliberately make the question complicated, the problem to be solved is pretty complicated. This is why I asked for help after having tried various approaches.

Comment: downvotes are for questions that are low quality, poorly reserached, unclear, or not useful. it has nothing to do with opinions, broadness, or difficulty/complexity.

Comment: The question linked above could definitely do with some trimming, though I'm not sure it warrants a downvote *in my opinion*; but downvoting is not black-and-white. Note that "minimal" is one of the adjectives to aim for when asking a question, and it could be argued that there's a whole lot of unnecessary code in there.

Comment: @TylerRoper, thank you. I added as much information as a way to show what has been done thus far, hence someone mentioned "poorly researched", so I am showing this is a question that has been worked on rigorously.

Comment: From that wall of text, it's going to be hard to see it as a minimal representation of the issue at hand.  That's pretty downvotable, if you ask me.  I count no less than six code blocks.  You don't know why someone downvoted; that's by design.  Someone *commented* they thought it was complicated, but you don't know if they downvoted or not, so that's a red herring.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When is it justifiable to downvote a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252677/when-is-it-justifiable-to-downvote-a-question)

Comment: How is this question not a 'normal' null object reference mega-dupe?

Comment: It is not a very complicated question, it is instead a hard problem to have. Something gets upgraded, things go boom and all of a sudden all eyes are on you and you're forced to dig into code which you absolutely did not want to touch and are in immediate risk of going over any and all time estimates. Unfortunately - it is a highly likely thing to happen when you upgrade Javascript frameworks. There is no easy fix except dive in deep and understand the code that is causing problems. That is not the type of question which works on Stack Overflow, "explain my code".

Comment: I can hardly imagine this question can help anybody in future except the OP himself. Please don't misunderstand me, I wholeheartedly understand the frustration when dealing with platform specific exceptions when you have to dig into everywhere inside some library that you didn't wrote like finding a needle in ocean, however it's just not a good question to ask on SO, since it's basically like "I got this code and it doesn't work and I have no idea what's wrong, please help me find out what's wrong". This kind of questions have little help on future visitor since it's too localized.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Right, so, here's my initial impression of this question:

I read your error message. The first thing *I* want to see is the code where the error happened. Line 217 of RootNavigation.js. A quick scan through your question... and i have no idea where in your question that line of code is. I don't think you actually provided it. Maybe it's not your code, but something from node_modules, however, even in that case, knowing what in your code caused that to occur should be #1 in your question, with a stack trace showing how you know it's that line in your code.

If you can't pinpoint where the problem is occurring... all future work on the error is just a guessing game.

Comment: Thanks Kevin, I recently just added `RootNavigation.js` so it is in there. I will clean up the question then. I guess I was supposed to interpret, complicated as the question needs to be cleaned up. Hard to gauge whether the person is referring to the question or the problem to be solved, it was not made clear. Hence my asking of the question here. It came off as, I can't figure out a solution so I will downvote you.

Comment: Re: initial impressions, using a screenshot for the error message text doesn't help much either.

Comment: the screenshot though in this case does provide a bit of context, it says that the code was compiled in dev mode.

Comment: @Daniel "It came off as, I can't figure out a solution so I will downvote you" - I wouldn't assume that the commenter was the same as the downvoter.

Comment: @Daniel  and now the post has received a further six downvotes... The lesson is "never complain on meta about a single downvote or two" Instead ask how to improve or fix a post. Note also the -22 score. Tough crowd here.

Comment: @Mari-LouA, so are you suggesting that now I am getting downvotes on a question I improved regardless of the improvement, just because I asked a question on meta?

Comment: @Daniel this is my personal experience, and one I have observed repeatedly. The most veteran users on SO are burnt out, probably have seen hundreds of questions from users "complaining" about downvotes,  the fact you suggest that the DV(s) are due to your question being very complicated is implying that someone downvoted because they were either too stupid to understand or too lazy to post an answer.

Comment: @Mari-LouA, that's unfortunate. I was definitely not suggesting someone was lazy or stupid but rather may have been penalizing me because of the complexity of a question, but I was mistaken. Hopefully the machine gunning due to burnout will be resolved since I do trust SO is good at catching sockpuppets and hopefully misuse of downvotes as well. I pray people who do machine gun downvotes due to burnout see the bigger picture. It lowers the quality of SO and deters future participation thereby further deterioration of a good platform.

Comment: @npostavs it was definitely not the case of "I can't figure out a solution so I will downvote you". For more info a fuller explanation/answer is on the way.

Comment: @RichardLeMesurier, I understand that I misunderstood and I thank you again for reaching out to me.

Answer (score 12):

As one of the first downvoters (although I don't think I was the first), but also as the person who initially commented to the OP (@Daniel) about this being a complicated question, I'll offer my point of view (unfortunately I have since deleted my initial comment, as the OP had addressed it - can mods get that back I wonder, it might be helpful on this thread).

Firstly I didn't mean *the problem was complicated*. In fact, it may turn out to be very simple at the end of the day. I meant *the actual post was complicated, difficult to read, hard to parse and make sense of.* The type of post that a lot of "veteran users" are likely to look at, and move on.

When I first saw this, it looked like the classic "wall of text" type of question. I read through it and my first impression was that a lot of things were going on, and if one could cut away at all the distractions, the root cause of the problem may be easier to spot. ([as suggested by comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388563/is-downvoting-someone-for-asking-a-very-complicated-question-okay-to-do#comment722129_388563))

This is my experience in coding and tracking down "weird" bugs.

My intent for commenting was to try help OP improve (from my perspective) his chance of getting quality help. Did I use the right words, in hindsight it is obvious I did not.

---

As for the downvote, it was given because, in my view, it matched enough of the usual reasons, listed nicely in:

- [When is it justifiable to downvote a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252677/when-is-it-justifiable-to-downvote-a-question)

Primarily, when I first read it, I struggled to get useful info out of it nice and simply.