# What to do when a correct answer is strategically downvoted?

Tags: discussion, tactical-downvoting

It was a little while ago now, and I can't find the example.

But what do you recommend when you answer someone's best practice question (a question that didn't have any votes or much attention whatsoever), and you log on a day later and someone else has down-voted it and commented that it was wrong, and then provides their own answer which is clearly not the best approach and the person who asked accepted the answer?

I am not trying to put tickets on myself and just say I am right and they are wrong, but sometimes you can clearly see a poor answer and pick it out, yet the person (a new user) who asked the question believed it's the correct thing.

Is there anything suggested to do? Just leave the person who asked the question to live their lives with the wrong answer (I know it's not life or death), or should you report an answer? I guess it's a bit late once it's already been accepted. It seems a lot of new users lodge one question, get it answered and then bail never to return.

EDIT: Just for those questioning the validity of any "best practice" answer. May I be more specific in saying it was a security "best practice". Having unprofessional answers accepted in the line of security is most likely harmful to the asker's product.

Comment: "best practice question"... there's an alternative: don't answer those. This is a (usually) subjective area, what's clearly wrong to you might very well be clearly right for someone else, with no real practical/technical argument to decide either way.

Comment: Yes I understand this, the question was not really subjective as it was talking security matters, like how should I store this password in the db. If it was a general best practice question I guess there is no real answer, only opinions.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6460/if-you-just-witnessed-tactical-downvoting-is-it-a-reportable-offense

Comment: I don't see this as "strategical downvoting" - it's a disagreement. I view "strategic(al) downvoting" as downvoting answers that you have no objection to, just to make your own answer look better.

Comment: Right - what the OP describes has nothing to do with "strategic" downvoting.  OP regarding the annoying situation when you know you're right, just firmly downvote all the incorrect answers, and explain clearly, maybe at length, why they are quite wrong.  It's pretty common on the computer-code SO sites that an accepted answer is plain wrong.  You just have to say so, and have other experts say so, in the comments.

Comment: I already raised the question about strategical downvoting here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/207733 .

Comment: While both really similar,my question is more focused on the fact the answer provided was wrong and mislead the question asker to think it was correct and accept it

Comment: Really nothing we can do about that. If the op thinks it's correct and marks it as accepted, it's his right to do so. "Best <insert anything ehre>" questions are usually too opinionated anyway.

Comment: I've allready had this case, and after a few comments the O.P. understood why the seeming good answer was not that good. Most annoying answers are when OP has not the least interest in answer's quality : he takes first thing that work never to come back to the site until his next issue...

Answer (score 26):

If it's wrong, downvote it.

Ideally, with a comment that it's incorrect -- the why being detailed in your own answer.

Comment: Even though I agree, the "Ideally, with a comment" part seems not to be the current position: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252314/519216

Comment: @Lamak: interesting. I think I'd still include one, to trigger a discussion on the merits of the two competing answers for follow-up visitors to understand the disagreement.

Comment: @Lamak I took that to mean that it's fine to downvote and comment but simply don't reference the vote in the comment. E.g. Instead of "-1 some explanation" just put the explanation. Of course in practice the answerer could easily guess it was you anyway by examining the timings though.

Answer (score 15):

The OP has the final say on which answer is accepted, period.  With a "best practices" type question, there is a certain amount of discretion.  In the end, the OP may simply disagree with you.  Or, as sometimes happens, the OP may have poorly stated the problem, and the other answer really is best for the real problem.

You seem to be making an assumption that the other author downvoted you.  That is not a reasonable assumption.  Possible, but answers get downvoted for many reasons.

If you feel strongly about this, I would suggest doing the following:

- Add a new section to your answer, explaining your reasoning on why your approach is better.
- Comment on the accepted answer, briefly noting that you disagree with this and reference your answer.

On very rare occasions, I have left a comment asking OP's about accepted answers particularly when my answer bad been unaccepted and then unaccepted.  In all cases, the comment starts with something like "As the author of the question, you have absolute discretion in accepting an answer.  I'm curious why . . .".  Two responses stick out in my memory:

1. I didn't realize that I cannot accept multiple answers.
2. The accepted answer is a friend of mine.

We do wish that Stack Overflow had a perfect community, with everyone fully knowledgeable about the rules and applying them with a high degree of integrity.  Alas, that is not the case.  For a real world, open site, the checks and balances seem to do a very, very good job of minimizing such absurdities.

Comment: I've come across the issue where the OP thought they could accept multiple answers too. And they didn't actually realise ticking a second answer would untick the first. I think maybe this comes from other forums such as MSDN which do appear to allow multiple selected answers to a question.

Answer (score 8):

If you believe that the new answer is wrong, downvote it.

That is all.

Comment: @Michale Petrotta - A much better approach would be to leave a comment explaining why you believe the new answer is wrong.  Otherwise, how will the person know why they got downvoted? By the way, I didn't downvote this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Best practices rarely are, so saying something is correct "because it's best practice" is quite likely not going to be the best way to do something, just the most dogmatic way.

So sit back, take a deep breath, and look at the other answer pragmatically rather than with a "darn, he downvoted me just to get his own answer on top", as you would likely have done the same were you him.

Comment: You are here implying that the OP of this meta question would go as low as someone else supposedly did on one of the questions the OP here answered. I don't see any reason why you should be implying such a thing here.

Comment: @skiwi as he clearly doesn't comprehend the limits of his own greatness, thinking every downvote is a personal insult just to get someone else's post higher than his own...