# How to deal with downvoter?

Tags: discussion, downvotes

I answered one of the question in SO . Another user also answered after me. That's normal as everyone has right to do.

But suddenly my answer got `downvote`. That answer was the up to the mark and there was no explanation of why `downvoted`. As usual i deleted the answer in thought of that may be my answer was not so good enough.

But what i saw that after deleted my answer my point was back but another posted answer users point also increased to 1 . I do another time just for sure and i was correct. That user `downvoted` me just to keep his post to the top as he answered after me .

My question is how to deal with them ?

This is happening so often that i have asked it here.

Comment: "That user downvoted me just to keep his post to the top as he answered after me." Or maybe they thought there was something wrong with your answer. Unless your mind-reading abilities are much better than mine, you can't know why they downvoted.

Comment: @resueman you may be missed the point `But what i saw that after deleted my answer my point was back but another posted answer users point also increased to 1 . I do another time just for sure and i was correct. `

Comment: @AnikIslamAbhi I'm not arguing that he's very likely the downvoter. But you cannot know *why* he downvoted unless he decides to comment.

Comment: @resueman there was another poster in that answer he also get downvoted i pointed downvoter in that post's comment . that downvoted may be noticed and removed downvote from that after removed downvote from that answer his point also got increased by 1

Comment: Alternative duplicate about "strategic downvote" - http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253209/what-to-do-when-a-correct-answer-is-strategically-downvoted

Comment: *As usual i deleted the answer in thought of that may be my answer was not so good enough.* - You always delete after just one down vote? You are being very harsh on yourself.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's only a couple of things you can do:

- Make sure your answer is correct and sufficiently answers the question.  Many people will downvote an answer because it's not a sufficient answer (like code-only answers) or because it's incorrect.
- If someone comments, take their feedback into account.  They're at least telling you that you're wrong in some way; it's worth a listen.
- Don't let it bother you.  Answers get downvoted for the silliest reasons sometimes, and if you're certain that your answer is correct, there's no reason to let it get to you.

Comment: I also wanted to point out this issue `But what i saw that after deleted my answer my point was back but another posted answer users point also increased to 1 . I do another time just for sure and i was correct. That user downvoted me just to keep his post to the top as he answered after me .`

Comment: [Perhaps they're the Slowest Cheater in the East](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22368/175248).  Don't let that bug you too much.