# Is the system handling unreasonable downvoting?

Tags: discussion, downvotes, abuse, tactical-downvoting

I've come across a couple of questions in which someone instantly downvotes other people that post an answer in hopes of being selected as the answer. This kind of behaviour is not tolerable on a site like SO, where sharing information and giving feedback is absolutely necessary.

It's happening significantly more often than about a year back, that's why I'm curious if there is any form of protection against unreasonable downvoting apart from the measly -2 points per downvote.

Has the community changed so much that people really come down to actions like these to get points?

Comment: I've occasionally seen something like this happen.  Is it that widespread?  How can you be sure that is what is happening?

Comment: At least I am not in the firing line for this one.  I hardly ever downvote answers, (they have to be totally wrong - it does happen, but not often:).

Comment: Your post is full of conclusions based on pure speculation. You don't know the reasons for other people's votes, up or down. You don't know that one person is downvoting everybody else, and even if they were, you don't know their motives. I have *personally* done this, downvoted all other answers to a question that I've answered, when all other answers were FGITW carbon-copies of a well known anti-pattern.

Comment: @TimPost yes that's precisely what I meant.

Comment: Downvotes don't really inhibit the sharing of information or feedback. Downvotes *are* feedback.

Comment: @meagar I'm just asking if it's taken care of and the behaviour discouraged, or if the users can freely lower the quality of the community.

Comment: @4castle downvotes would be feedback, if the person abusing it was downvoting because of quality of the answer. Sadly I've come across multiple instances of people downvoting to increase the exposure of their own answer. Just to make others look more bad, just as Tim said.

Comment: No, it is not taken care of as it is impossible to determine if a vote is tactical or not not.

Comment: @Dropout That's another completely false conclusion, it's starting to feel like you're not asking this question in good faith. "It's taken care of" and "the users can freely lower the quality of the community." are not related, one does not follow from the other.

Comment: Best I can find as a related post: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272224/downvoting-all-other-answers-to-have-your-favorite-one-rise-up, doesn't mention if the system is handling these kind of events. Also related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253209/what-to-do-when-a-correct-answer-is-strategically-downvoted

Comment: @Dropout Increasing the exposure of your own answer can be good if the other answers are all incorrect. The people who post answers are usually the most qualified to vote on the other answers.

Comment: @Dropout So how did you know that those votes weren't based on the quality of the answer, and that they were cast entirely to increase the exposure of the voter's answer with that voter believing that the other answers were in fact useful answers?

Comment: @meagar So blindly downvoting 5 other users just so you can get more exposure on your own answer is somehow OK behaviour? I'm completely in shock right now.

Comment: @rene thanks, going to check them out

Comment: @Dropout No, obviously that's not "ok", but you're still speculating on the motives for somebody else's votes.  A user who downvotes all other answers because they believe the other answers are wrong or not useful is not "freely lowering the quality of the community", they're **raising** the quality of the community.

Comment: @Servy one example is instant downvote on page long answer. Instant as in < 3 seconds.

Comment: @meagar but it's trivial to determine if someone is abusing the system or if he's expressing an objective opinion from his behavior patterns. Please don't get philosophical.

Comment: if an answer can't be tweeted it deserves down votes ...

Comment: @Dropout I've seen answers where I could tell from the first sentence that the answer was wrong.  You need to read the entire answer to figure out if it's doing everything right, you only need to find the first problematic statement to know that the answer is problematic.

Comment: @rene you're kidding right?

Comment: Are you .......?

Comment: @rene I can't tweet your comment, how do I downvote it? :-)

Comment: @Dropout If it's trivial to determine if someone is actually voting based on the post's quality or not, then how do we in fact do that?  How can you reliably tell whether someone is voting based on other answers' quality or not?

Comment: @Dropout This is not philosophy, this is a hole that undermines your entire argument. It's anything *but* trivial to understand why somebody downvotes something, if it were trivial to somehow reject bad-faith votes, we wouldn't be having this conversation.

Comment: @Dropout don't you see the risk of turning down ANY downvote you give on a post with one of your answers? There can be very valid reasons to downvote when I give an answer as well. How do you plan on measuring which scenario is which? You can't just invalidate ALL of them, you'll invalidate a lot of very well-reasoned downvotes....

Comment: ' instant downvote on page long answer. Instant as in < 3 seconds' I can see that can happen on rare occasions.  I have, (very rarely), downvoted every answer to a question.  To do that, the question has to be terribad and, fairly obviously, I don't post any answer of my own.  If you were to post your pagefull of answer just as I was scattergunning downvotes, you might be misled into thinking my downvote on your answer came from one of the other answerers.  Such a scenario would be unfortunate and rare, but it could happen:(

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tactical-downvoting

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's really hard to track this because you'd have to teach an automated routine to understand *intent*. And in order to do that effectively, you'd have to do a lot more analysis of long-term behavioral patterns of users, which .. isn't something I think we're comfortable doing any more than we currently do (hint: we don't track pages you view in a manner that anyone could say is convenient for us to look up).

What we *do* track are suspicious votes where the intent is *obvious*, you're targeting a specific person (with up or down votes, the result is equally bad). We do need to put more work into that, including some just-in-time help letting folks know that they seem to be really focused on one or several users based on recent voting patterns.

But *unreasonable*? That's .. I mean sit and think about how you'd determine that and what that code would start to look like as you considered even a few edge cases there and you'll pretty quickly arrive at something sort of close to the current expression on my face:

[image: Me]

I think we *can* come to a place where people are a little more aware of how they're influencing other people's feelings, in fact we [were just talking about that](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/365811/can-we-do-more-than-just-delete-rude-comments).

But votes are *always* going to have quite a bit of subjectivity surrounding them, and you'll always notice more (or less) of stuff as platforms like Stack Overflow scale. Have things been a *bit* more 'prickly' as of late? I'd agree with yes, but I think that's only a part of the phenomenon overall.

As [S.L. Barth points out](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/365822/50049) we *do* investigate patterns where it looks like votes are being used to game the system in a manner where *good* information ends up looking bad, but there's no really good way of automating that. Every tag has at least one question with a bunch of highly upvoted answers that would be considered downright *dangerous* these days. It really does start to look like spaghetti when you think about it. And there are some people that just hate *everything*.

We can and should occasionally check to be sure we're handling the human parts of the equation as well as we can, but sometimes there's just no automating (or in some instances, even explaining) it.

Comment: You could run an Internal SEDE query where you look for a ratio per user of (down) votes on competing answers. Would be interesting to see   what the impact of the problem is. My gut say it is small but some stats can confirm / dismiss that. That doesn't need a long research, just wake-up Shog9 and put him to work ;)

Comment: Thanks for the insight. I know you guys are doing your best, but I'd hate to see this community worsen just because of stuff like this. I've always seen SO as a place where the best help each other. Seeing instant "tactical" downvoting just makes me feel dissapointed, because I don't remember such behaviour a bit back when I was far more active. I was just curious if SO tries to discourage such behaviour.

Comment: @rene Even if you did, that doesn't mean you can assert that the votes aren't based on the quality of those posts.  Lots of people go out of their way to post answers to questions *because* there are lots of bad answers posted to those questions.  Those people are being *helpful* by both providing said answers and said feedback on the other answers.

Comment: @rene We're playing with that, the problem is being able to assert that the competing answers are in fact undeserving of down votes. What you end up with is a pretty good list of places where a grown up should go looking, as much as we'd love to figure out some more magic to put into it.

Comment: ... wait. wait, just a second. You're not a chimpanzee?!!!!

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier Huh? Oh the picture. Yeah, that's my human; I keep giving him injections in the top of his head to keep him quiet and just snapped a picture of it on a whim.

Comment: The raw numbers will do. I don't expect you'll ever be able to get that right by any system/machine learning, nor do I expect you to implement such system because I agree with @Servy's analysis/statement.

Comment: @rene That's something kinda like a "Gamesmanship" anti-badge -- sounds like a reasonable heuristic. Taking into account the overall score of the downvotes answers might help with removing noise from the genuine bad ones.

Comment: Some food for thought, people may be writing an answer precisely because all the other answes to a question are terrible. It follows they'd also make use of their vote then. A scenario that might happen...

Answer (score 0):

What you describe is called "tactical downvoting".

It's when someone downvotes competing answers, for the purpose of making their own answer more visible, and more likely to get upvotes and an accept.

Downvoting an answer (anywhere) will cost you 1 point of reputation. This was specifically done to discourage tactical downvoting.

If you see this happen often, *and* can reasonably assume that it's the same user, then you can use a custom moderator flag and ask the moderators to investigate. Moderators can't see votes, but they can escalate to the Community Team. In other words, it has to be escalated to the highest levels before something can be done.

This is why you really should have a **reasonable suspicion** that it's the same user, engaging in a **pattern** of tactical downvoting. We can't see who voted, so the best you can have is a suspicion. Try not to waste the time of the SO staff unless your suspicions have a solid basis.

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly what I'm talking about. So basically it's up to the moderators to investigate. That's quite surprising. But better than nothing I guess.

Comment: A moderator has no means to evaluate such a flag.  Votes are anonymous to moderators, so there will be nothing for them to do in response to such a flag.  A moderator can see if a user has a pattern of votes *on another user*, which says nothing about this situation

Comment: @Servy I see. I've updated the answer. Makes it even more important that this should only be flagged if there is a reasonable suspicion that the same user is engaging in a pattern of tactical downvoting.

Comment: @S.L.Barth There is nothing for anyone to do in response to a flag.  No one has any means by which to determine that a person was actually voting on something other than the content of the answer.